# What should I do if I don't get an answer?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, unanswered-questions

What should I do if I don't get enough answers when I post a question? For example: [Return value from PYQt slot of QwebView to main window widget (PYQt python)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36787709)

I asked this question 2 days ago and did not get a response.

I have tried editing the question 4 times with edits in title, body and code. But still no responses.

What extra steps should I take, if any?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a bounty and wait till someone answers.

Answer to your question is here: [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers)

> Suggestion(if you have less than required rep) : Go back to your
>   original question and request one of the commentator to raise a
>   bounty. They would if they feel the question is valid/makes sense.

Comment: thanks for the answer but what if i don't have enough reputation to set the bounty?

Comment: Get enough reputation. Or if your question is good enough ask someone to set it for you.

Comment: getting reputation is not in my hands, i can only try to get and if i raise some question then obviously its good for me....and if its good or not for other person it depends on him only.

Comment: Go back to your original question and request one of the commentator to raise a bounty. They would if they feel the question is valid/makes sense.

Comment: @rickyrana suggestion added.

Comment: Note that a bounty will attract plagiarisers (in 2023, often [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) (or similar) plagiarisers). They don't have ***any*** interest in the usefulness or accuracy of the answer. They are ***only*** interested in the bounty.