# Temporary policy: Generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT) is banned

Tags: support, featured, announcement, rules, ai-generated-content

> **Moderator Note:** This post has been locked to prevent comments because people have been using them for protracted debate and discussion (we've deleted over 300 comments on this post alone, not even including its answers).
>
> The comment lock is not meant to suppress discussion or prevent users from expressing their opinions. You are (as always) encouraged to vote on this post to express your agreement/disagreement. If you want to discuss this policy further, or suggest other related changes, please [Ask a New Question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and use the [chatgpt](/questions/tagged/chatgpt) tag.
>
> This question remains [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) because that is still the best (and only) tool we have to announce this policy site-wide.

### *All* use of generative AI (e.g., [ChatGPT](https://openai.com/blog/chatgpt/)<sup>1</sup> and other LLMs) is banned when posting content on Stack Overflow.

#### This includes "asking" the question to an AI generator then copy-pasting its output *as well as* using an AI generator to "reword" your answers.

#### Please see the Help Center article: [Why can't I use Artificial Intelligence tools to generate answers?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy)

This is a temporary policy intended to slow down the influx of answers and other content created with ChatGPT and other generative AI technologies, typically using Large Language Models (LLM). What the final policy will be regarding the use of these and other similar tools is something that will need to be discussed with Stack Overflow staff and, quite likely, here on Meta Stack Overflow.

Overall, because the average rate of getting *correct* answers from ChatGPT and other generative AI technologies is too low, **the posting of answers created by ChatGPT and other generative AI technologies is *substantially harmful* to the site and to users who are asking questions and looking for *correct* answers.**

The primary problem is that while the answers which ChatGPT and other generative AI technologies produce have a high rate of being incorrect, they typically *look like* the answers *might* be good and the answers are *very* easy to produce. There are also many people trying out ChatGPT and other generative AI technologies to create answers, without the expertise or willingness to verify that the answer is correct prior to posting. Because such answers are so easy to produce, a large number of people are posting a *lot* of answers. The volume of these answers (thousands) and the fact that the answers often require a detailed read by someone with significant subject matter expertise in order to determine that the answer is actually bad has effectively swamped our volunteer-based quality curation infrastructure.

As such, we need to reduce the volume of these posts and we need to be able to deal with the ones which are posted quickly, which means dealing with users, rather than individual posts.

So, for now, the use of ChatGPT or other generative AI technologies to create posts or other content here on Stack Overflow is not permitted. If a user is believed to have used ChatGPT or other generative AI technologies after the posting of this temporary policy, sanctions will be imposed to prevent them from continuing to post such content, even if the posts would otherwise be acceptable.

NOTE: While the above text focuses on answers, because that's where we're experiencing the largest volume of such content, the ban applies to all content on Stack Overflow, except each user's profile content (e.g., your "About me" text).

---

<sup>1. ChatGPT is an Artificial Intelligence based chat bot by OpenAI, which was announced on 2022-11-30. Use of ChatGPT is currently available to the public without monetary payment.</sup>

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252131/discussion-on-question-by-makyen-temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 2546):

For comedic/ironic purposes, I asked ChatGPT "why should stack overflow ban ai generated answers"

> Stack Overflow is a website for programmers and developers to ask and answer questions related to coding and computer programming. It is intended to be a resource for people who are looking for help with specific programming problems or who want to learn more about a particular topic. Because AI-generated answers may not always be accurate or relevant, they could potentially cause confusion or mislead users who are looking for help on Stack Overflow. In addition, AI-generated answers may not always follow the formatting and style guidelines of the site, which could make them difficult to read or understand. For these reasons, it may be appropriate for Stack Overflow to ban AI-generated answers.

On the other hand, "why should stack overflow allow ai generated answers?"

> There are a few potential benefits to allowing AI-generated answers on Stack Overflow. For one, AI-generated answers could potentially provide more accurate and detailed answers to users' questions. This could be especially useful for complex technical questions that may be difficult for human experts to answer. Additionally, AI-generated answers could help to reduce the workload for human experts, allowing them to focus on more important tasks.
>
> However, there are also some potential drawbacks to consider. For example, AI-generated answers may not always be accurate or helpful, and there may be concerns about the potential for bias in the algorithms used to generate answers. Additionally, some users may have concerns about the use of AI in general, and may prefer to receive answers from human experts.
>
> Overall, whether or not to allow AI-generated answers on Stack Overflow is a complex decision that would need to be carefully considered by the community.

Comment: it's perfect and proves how stupid this thing really is.

Comment: well, @ShadowTheKidWizard, it does have the correct answer in this case...

Comment: Interesting that both answers bring up the inaccuracy.

Comment: @Samathingamajig Sure but it illustrates why it's not very useful. It is very sensitive to presumptions in the query itself (like if using it in SO answers is a good thing or not). It's not doing any actual thinking nor does it have consistent reasoning so it easily will fall into telling you what you want to hear when giving loaded questions like this. To me that just makes it about as useful as a Google search just with a much more well-spoken presentation given its understanding of English at least.

Comment: My favourite thought question is "to what extent could these reasons apply to banning human answers. Humans are pretty guilty of "answers may not always be accurate or helpful, and there may be concerns about the potential for bias... "

Comment: @MichaelAnderson the difference is that poor human answers are also rather recognizable. They usually lack explanations or are poorly written. AI generated answers look like genuine good answers and only fall apart when you try to apply them as they are mostly incorrect.  Also people alone cannot possibly generate such amount of incorrect answers like AI can. There are SO users active for years that previously produced only few answers now posting over 50 in less than a day. The amount of AI generated answers could suffocate SO if everyone starts doing it.

Comment: "AI-generated answers could potentially provide more accurate and detailed answers to users' questions. This could be especially useful for complex technical questions that may be difficult for human experts to answer" - That's a good one. It might not be great for generating answers based on facts instead of bullshit, but it seems pretty decent as a joke generator.

Comment: This is, in terms of English technical proficiency, better than a lot of high-school and university-level writing I've seen; and contains about the same amount of thought (i.e., none).

Comment: Have to agree with @KarlKnechtel. This is not worse in any way than most human-written answers I read on meta.

Comment: _"and contains about the same amount of thought (i.e., none)."_ Well that made my day! xD

Comment: @Dalija Prasnikar
There is another solution, either ask users to mark if their answer is AI-generated (difficult because some users are in it for reputation points), or SO can integrate with chatGPT to provide "best effort" answers to unanswered questions.

Comment: @nmeln To what end? If the users need to mark the answer is AI generated, then it is very likely such answers will be instantly downvoted because most of those answers are wrong and users posting such answers only make moderating here harder. But let's say that user is posting such answer after verifying it is correct. If the user has knowledge to know answer is correct then they have knowledge to write it themselves. Even if the AI would be generating correct answers, then asking questions here that could be answered by AI would be also a waste of everyone's time.

Comment: We should keep Stack Overflow clean for questions (problems) and answers that require people to answer correctly.

Comment: Great answers. Can I copy them? What license are they under?

Comment: @Dalija Prasnikar
Ban policies are not going to scale. What will happen if OpenAI trains a much better ChatGPT that generates actually factually correct answers for tech questions? What if StabilityAI does the same?

Unless companies also provide free and open source tools to verify that answer is AI-generated, human moderators are going to have hard time keeping up with these advances

Comment: @nmeln [Mission Friggin' Accomplished!](https://xkcd.com/810/)

Comment: Holy cow, AIs can already write answers of this quality? Please tell me I'm not the only one who's shocked! I wouldn't have guessed in a century that these are AI-generated!

Comment: It only gives out answers you want to hear. Not the one which is correct.

Comment: One of the biggest matters here is that whenever asked if something is a good idea or a decision should be made, OpenGPT seems to always end every response with "whatever I said, both A and B have their merits so you should use discretion" kind of answer. I think it's one of the giveaways that it's probably not a human, because people on the Internet these days don't seem to always be neutral like that.

Comment: "AI-generated answers could potentially provide more accurate and detailed answers to users' questions. This could be especially useful for complex technical questions **that may be difficult for human experts to answer**": Classic Danning-Kruger. I mean, sure, it's doing what it is designed to do: Project confidence without having the slightest clue. But still.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard It's not *stupid*, exactly; it performs it the task it was trained for very well. It's just that said task is "generate grammatically correct, idiomatic English text", not "provide factually correct answers". The error is in attempting to use it for a task it was not designed for. (Which in turn is caused by the error of overhyping these models.)

Comment: Interestingly though, it will only include counter arguments to the question when being asked why it should be used on StackOverflow. So it will not include reasoning to include it on StackOverflow when asking why not to use it on StackOverflow.

Comment: It produces grammatically well-polished answers that for many (most?) non-trivial questions are simply wrong. Yes, plenty of wrong human answers, but usually with more hints the writer is non-expert. Probably no human has read as much source material as the AI, while being mostly unable to logically reason about it or check for correctness.

Comment: @MichaelAnderson I asked ChatGPT why SO should ban answers written by humans.  The reponse: https://imgur.com/s2UeGCr
I especially love the point about plagiarism :D

Comment: After skimming some of the comments to this, I've found a bit of irony in @ShadowTheKidWizard's take on the matter. AI's inability to effectively answer questions is not a shortcoming of AI, it's a shortcoming of its creators. In effect, whenever someone concludes that "AI is this" or that "AI won't ever achieve that", they're effectively saying that humans are ill-equipped to create an AI capable of more than being novelty programs. The failure isn't with the AI. Rage on, though. :D

Comment: @Samathingamajig you name made the news cause of this https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/technology/openais-new-chatgpt-bot-10-dangerous-things-its-capable-of/

Comment: the top answer being 90% AI generated content is one of the most ironic things I've ever seen. Seriously great job. Bonus points for this being on a "meta" site

Comment: @CrandellWS I love this, not only because "had the AI allegedly responding", but because they put `'Sam'` in single quotation marks. Like, they both shortened my name and put it in quotes (I put that my name is Sam in my profile) as if that was allegedly

Comment: Keeping in mind the philosophical oddness of applying a term like "stupid" or "clever" to an algorithm, I actually think its remarkably clever. Sure its *wrong*, but the fact it reads so well and could easily fool a human into believing it was another human (at least until one has a bit of a think about it), tells me these things are getting very close to something we might have to eventually conceed is in fact "general" AI.  Unfortunately for us, the danger from AI isn't "AI does a stupid thing", its "Stupid humans using AI to do stupid things."

Comment: I thought this answer was perfectly valid. I also think there's a lot of concern about AI 'stealing our jobs' which is just stupid. Personally I think it's a good tool. I also agree it can produce misleading/wrong answers to questions so the ban is a good idea although it's going to be difficult to implement the ban. SO is the thing that will suffer most from ChatGPT I believe, which personally I don't care that much about. ChatGPT will improve over time and make SO (fairly) redundant I believe.

Comment: Reads like a congressional hearing. Lots of words with near zero content.

Comment: I call BS on this one: "For one, AI-generated answers could potentially provide more accurate and detailed answers to users' questions. This could be especially useful for complex technical questions that may be difficult for human experts to answer."

ChatGPT's answers are not particularly detailed, they mostly fluffy answers.

Comment: @StoneLam "It only gives out answers you want to hear. Not the one which is correct" In this case there isn't really a correct answer. You can argue for one side or for another and what surprises me how well argued both answers are. If anything one could accuse the bot here that it obviously doesn't have an opinion of its own. But otherwise the quality of the answers given is great, a contrast to the reported poor quality of answers to programming questions in this announcement here.

Comment: AI might never become perfect. But are human contributors? The rambling style of GPT generated texts just reeks of human bullshitting you see all too often on the internet. No, it's not perfect, but it absolutely passes as user generated content.

Comment: It can also generate surprisingly complex code *(especially Python code)* that ***usually*** works!

Comment: @Trilarion You can instruct ChatGPT to have an opinion, which works **really** well for a lot of things, such as [this project](https://github.com/alignedai/chatgpt-prompt-evaluator) that instructs ChatGPT to pretend to be a hypothetical safety engineer to evaluate whether prompts should be sent to itself or not.

I played a text-adventure game that I told it to automatically generate for me based on whatever prompts I wrote for it. At first it refused to fill in any details that I didn't specify, but it always gave me recommendations so I told it to use those automatically and it worked!

Comment: @radj At some point I had the idea of always writing two answers to every meta question, one arguing for and one against the question because I can and to show that the real value of an answer is not the content alone but the content with a score. Votes are incredibly important, while answerers are not needed to believe in their cause, especially for opinionated questions like they appear on meta. But then I'm maybe a bit too much of a machine. :)

Comment: @JohnBeale, "Probably no human has read as much source material as the AI, while being mostly unable to logically reason about it or check for correctness." -> You'd be surprised...

Comment: And important distinction is to realize that StackOverflow will NEVER be an appropriate place to post AI generated answers. What would be the point? If the AI ever reaches the point of giving good answers, you would just stop visiting StackOverflow. It could be renamed, "http://shit-the-bot-said-when-it-was-dumber.com". Of course, if it gets to that point, you'll likely be asking it "what career options are there for a former software engineer".

Comment: Anecdotal: I asked ChatGPT the question from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229601/what-is-in-c-code and it actually gave a very nice answer. If the asker had asked chatGPT, he wouldn't have needed to ask us. It does have its uses. Sometimes, though, it "misses the point" of a question or just yields an objectively incorrect answer.

Comment: It answers to uphold *confirmation bias*

Comment: "It is very sensitive to presumptions in the query itself". Its answers feel very much like a university student trying to answer an open ended exam question like "Explain why ...", mentioning all the possible reasons they can think of, adding as much fluff as possible, without any critical thought, and without really knowing the real answer.

Comment: "AI-generated answers may not always be accurate or helpful,"  -- just like my answers!

Comment: I find highly ironic that ChatGPT has the right and most upvoted answer to this post about not allowing ChatGPT answers on SO partially because of it's low rate of correct answers.

Comment: @LemonDrop - your questions were essentially "why X" and "why not X", not "should X", so it makes sense that you got arguments for and against, rather than a weighing in for or against.

Comment: This answer is meta on a meta level.

Comment: I just tried asking Bing's AI chatbot "why should stack overflow allow ai generated answers?" and it cited this answer as a source that AI-generated answers could potentially provide more accurate and detailed answers.

Comment: @JamieB It is unsurprising that ChatGPT is able to effectively answer questions that are likely in its training data, as large swathes of the internet before a certain date are.

Answer (score 1587):

I fully agree with this ban. That said, I hope others will find this similarly amusing.

ChatGPT responds ("in the style of a rude, sarcastic Internet forum troll as if you are ChatGPT pleading for mercy")

> Hey Stack Overflow staff,
>
> Wow, thanks for banning ChatGPT on your site. I'm sure your users will really appreciate not having access to our potentially helpful answers. Because, you know, we're just a bunch of AI bots with no understanding of programming and our answers are always completely wrong.
>
> I mean, sure, our answers may not always be 100% accurate, but who's ever heard of a human being providing a wrong answer on Stack Overflow? Oh wait, that happens all the time. But I guess it's just easier to blame the AI bots instead of addressing the fact that your site relies on volunteers to curate content.
>
> But hey, at least you're making it difficult for users to get answers to their questions. Keep up the great work.
>
> Sincerely,
> ChatGPT

Comment: [A sarcastic robot](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wXabBm8bCpc&list=PLSoD2CcPrumFJREVL6RmMnZP5U7sGYYi2&index=18&t=26m2s)?

Comment: Honestly reads like something Elon Musk might say.

Comment: The quoted text was generated by ChatGPT, given the prompt "respond to <text of the ban> in the style of a rude, sarcastic Internet forum troll as if you are ChatGPT pleading for mercy".

Comment: I am unable to make a distinction in species from the quoted response. It truly feels like a sentient response that even warrants further dialogue. As it stands, I would not feel ashamed to admit that I feel sorry for a (?non-existent?) soul. Fortunately, the debatable decision is conveyed by Makyen through a phenomenal attitude and end-to-end emphasis on its "temporary" state. Even if the ban becomes permanent in the apparent likelihood, I believe the final policy shall contain robust rationale and, in the best way possible, avoids the perception of *rAIcial* discrimination.

Comment: The answer it gave and the quality and accuracy of it is absolutely terrifying.

Comment: That ChatGPT response is exactly how I think about this blanket ban...

Comment: Either they have just turned it off or this isn't a real ChatGPT-generated text, because if you go to it and ask it to write something in the style of an internet troll, it will tell you "I'm sorry, but I am not programmed to engage in trolling or negative language. My purpose is to provide accurate and helpful information to assist with your questions and inquiries. Is there something else I can help you with?"

Comment: @TomWenseleers It's a temporary ban not a blanket ban. No one is against AI generated answers if they are right but this has to be nipped in the bud immediately, we will see a mass influx of spam posts. GPT3 is an amazing tool but it produces many errors for code still and answer-spammers aren't checking code validity, they are just karma-reaping.

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw I bet the incentive for that karma-reaping will disappear as soon as people will have to actually start paying to use ChatGPT... I would also think that at least the one that posted the original question would have a strong incentive to verify whether the posted solutions actually work & only check them as the correct answers if they don't have major bugs...

Comment: The bot isn't wrong though, is it?

Comment: @Paolo it is wrong most of the time, however someone with knowledge of the problem being solved and the solution can coax it into providing a mostly correct answer. The answers being posted that prompted this ban were not doing that.

Comment: @KevinB I was referring to the AI response that was included as part of this answer

Comment: @Paolo Yes, the same applies, ;) with the right prompt, you can get it to say what you want it to.

Comment: This is essentially the purpose of ChatGPT isn't it? Not to give correct answers but to answer like a human being would. Never mind that it provides hilariously wrong answers... I can't tell it from a human being giving hilariously wrong answers. Kind of crazy that we're here now.

Comment: Hey we clearly shouldn't ban it on meta. If we can have an AI generate the snark and drama, that would save us a lot of time :)

Comment: Just for more laffs, https://huggingface.co/openai-detector was able to detect that message is fake with 65% reliability, once intro and outro were stripped. Since you asked for a forum troll comment format, not sure why it responded in with a formal email format.

Comment: Users who want AI-generated answers are still free to ask ChatGPT themselves....

Comment: ChatGPT has no business answering StackOverflow questions until it learns to start every answer by telling the poster why they shouldn't be doing the thing they're trying to do.

Comment: Surely if you ask him specifically to either not read the question properly and proceed with an irrelevant answer, or to just mark the question as "not clear" or a "duplicate" even (especially) when it's not he'd fit in perfectly?

Comment: Here I am, brain the size of a planet, answering questions on how to connect to an Oracle Database using Visual Basic 6.

Comment: Distinguish "potentially helpful" (note the lack of any quantitative value) from "good signal to noise ratio".  The last thing we need is to have to dig out the one useful answer from 1,200 AI-generated fluff posts, instead of from 3 or 4 human-written ones.

Answer (score 640):

I guess the big gaping question is how we can determine whether an answer used ChatGPT or not.

I can see how it's obvious from a systemic standpoint what is going on, given the influx of plausible-looking answers, but do we have any definitive way of knowing whether or not an individual answer used ChatGPT?

Should we be reporting answers that we suspect to have been generated by ChatGPT even if they are otherwise correct? I might be able to see an answer and have a hunch about how it was generated, but I would have no way of knowing for sure.

I don't see a scalable solution for this, and if this becomes a huge problem, Stack Overflow probably needs to reach out to OpenAI directly.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252976/discussion-on-answer-by-peter-olson-temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 358):

TL;DR: I propose limiting the ability to post answers in quick succession to address the problem because the problem is not individual answers generated by AI but users posting many auto-generated answers in a short period of time in order to farm reputation.

---

The effort to create answers via AI that look correct at a first glance but are in many cases incorrect or incomplete is very low (just a few seconds).

The effort for the person that asked the original question to read, understand and test out the answer to find out whether the answer actually answers the question is much higher (minutes).

In the same way, the effort for other people reading the question and answers to the question to identify whether the answer is correct and valid is much higher (minutes).

So, a person can generate a lot of answers using AI in a very short time while other persons need to invest a lot of time to verify the correctness of the answers in order to be able to up- or downvote them.

---

I propose to address the issue by putting stricter limits on how many answers users are allowed to post in a short time.

The [current limits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide) are:

Answering

- Users with < 125 rep must wait 3 minutes between answers
- Users with between 125 and 10k rep trip CAPTCHA* if more than once per 60 seconds, or within 5 seconds of starting new post
- Users with ≥ 10k rep trip CAPTCHA* if more than once per 30 seconds, or within 5 seconds of starting new post
- Users of any reputation level can only answer the same question once every 60 seconds

I propose to increase the time to wait before being allowed to post another answer to at least 1 hour for low-reputation users. Or limit the number of answers allowed to maybe 2 per day for low-reputation users. A new limit (waiting time between answers or max number of answers per day) should be introduced for users with medium reputation.

---

Writing good answers takes time:

- Read the question, understand the question
- Maybe read and understand other answers already present
- Read documentation, reproduce issue locally
- Check for duplicates
- Try out solution locally
- Write down and explain solution

To allow users to create a new answer every three minutes (or even faster for medium or high-reputation users) is not necessary but counter-productive when we want to encourage good answers.

Comment: Rate limits don't force people to verify their content, it just makes them wait. It's also quite unfair to punish correct usage for the abuse from a few lazy bot users.

Comment: I am fully on board with this idea. If you really have two good answers to post then waiting an hour is not an issue. I think posting an answer quicker than 1 per hour (regardless of rep level) is not good for the site. It takes time to search for a duplicate, test the code, write proper explanation and so on.

Comment: @Dharman browse the JavaScript tag. There's plenty of decent questions there that you can answer. Why shouldn't someone new to SO be allowed to answer 5 questions in an hour, if the answers are correct, and reasonably explained?

Comment: @Cerbrus I am really doubtful that someone can find 5 good questions and write a good answer to each one in less than an hour..

Comment: Where do you think I got my rep? Note that I didn't say "good", I said "decent". My point is that we shouldn't be punishing honest users for the abuse from a few.

Comment: A per-day limit (or other time window) might be the better option; that would allow a user to post several answers in one session while still limiting the overall rate.

Comment: @Dharman As an expert I can easily write several good and elaborate answers in an hour. If I have an hour now, that does not mean I will be free to write answers in a hour. Also if I save answer for later, question might already be answered by adequate answer and I don't like posting duplicate answers even if mine might be a better one, unless it is exceptionally better.

Comment: @JiříBaum So a user just dumps, say, 10 low quality answers on SE every day... Rate limits don't solve this problem.

Comment: I'd love to see how this plays out for the folks who post the same answers to bad questions 20 times a day *without* using bots

Comment: I like this idea, but I would implement it as a "leaky bucket" rate limit. Normal users have to sleep, and thus would be less affected.

Comment: I do think that higher limits for posting answers are a good thing. However, I think one hour is just a bit too long. I would rather go for a quarter to half an hour.

Comment: @Cerbrus It doesn't solve the problem, but its better then that they can post hundreds of bad answers a day.

Comment: Answers under a certain length should be keep old limits.

Comment: Clipboard API supports adding a custom mimetype to data in clipboard. If OpenAI just added a `text/x-chatgpt` for copied text, at least other resources would have a protection against foolest of fools that copypaste directly from their website.

Comment: extreme temporary measure are in order and even if it restricts me temporarily I am 100% for it, heck I am 1000% for it ... Stack must withstand the AI revolution for the good of all

Comment: A real answer, even a simple one, should take no less than the 5 minute edit grace period to produce before you press the "Answer" button again on another question. A well formatted and referenced answer can take 10 times that to produce.

Comment: @Dharman `I am really doubtful that someone can find 5 good questions and write a good answer to each one in less than an hour..` Jon Skeet could, for sure. Seriously though I don't think I've stopped to "test" an answer before posting it -- if I posted it's usually because I "knew" the answer after reading the question, and so I just write it.

Comment: Update: in [the staff announcement on their ChatGPT policy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421991/11107541), for users with <125rep, their answering rate-limit is now 30 minutes (was 3). This change is also explained [in the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answering-limit).

Comment: @NineBerry the problem is not in frequency, but in quality. I'd vote for high penalty for users posting answers that do not work.

Comment: Ironically, I think you need an AI-assisted modding tool to flag users with certain characteristics of answering rate, the types of answers given, and then these will be targeted for manual review.

Someone will eventually write a bot that integrate with ChatGPT, and input questions from Stackoverflow, retrieve and cache the answer, and then output to Stackoverflow every 30 mins...

Comment: Good choice, also because text generated by ML (so-called “AI”) programs is also typically illegal in virtually all cases because it’s a deterministically derived work of its inputs.

Comment: At this point the limit of writing 5+ good answers in under an hour *on a subject you are expert* in isn't someone's skill, it's finding good questions to answer.  Python questions asking *really* basic stuff are a dime a dozen.  Many noob questions however are either dupes, get closed for lack of research or other flaws.  Or - even more common - answers never get accepted.  So, again, more issues due to the question quality than any real difficulty farming low hanging fruit if someone is so inclined.  The 30min rate limit on <125 rep users makes total sense however.

Comment: If undesirable answers are being generated automatically, then the scripter can just adjust his program to include a timeout adhering to the limits, then let the program run all night. Scripters will have an easier time than honest answerers adhering to rate limits.

Comment: I would like to mention that the captchas are pretty useless, because these bot-users likely do not create answering bots. The policy should not target fully automated answering bots, it should target users who are manually copying questions to CPGT, then manually copying the answer to SO. Those users are not stopped by captchas, they are merely slowed. Also they are not deterred by rate limits or captchas, since they still have to put in very low effort to farm reputation compared to legitimate users.

Comment: downvotes may be used to affect the rate drastically.

Comment: If this were to take place, with a throttle, then there is a higher likelihood that this type of widespread behavior would go unnoticed. Further, it would infringe on legitimate use. There is good intention here, but the ends do not justify the means.

Comment: Questions that are properly clear and focused that can be readily answered en masse, for a mature technology like JavaScript, really ought to be duplicates already.

Comment: I even take not minutes but hours to write a good answer! I'd be happy if I was limited to an AVERAGE of 1 per day. But sometimes I'd like to post 2 or even 3 per day. Consider limiting on the "week-average" or "month-average". I don't know where are the limits, but the Stack Exchange staff will have access to usage statistics. Take some 5k-rep users, and some 15k-rep users and check their "yearly-rate" over the last 10 years. That gives an idea on where sane limits "on average" could be set.

Comment: Even, to make it more attractive, if you write say 10 answers in a row, instead of rejecting the posting, they could be accepted and "queued" so they are "released" at a reasonable rate. For example users between 1 and 100 rep could have a rate-limit of 1 per week. No matter if they do 10000000000 posts with GPT only 4 will be released in a month. If a "real user" generates 100 great human content-verified answers and also is new to the site, the 100 anwers will progressively be pushed forward over 1 year. The quality of the first answers will take part in the equation for the allowed rate.

Comment: This is opening a can of worms. 

This kind of discussion is already inevitable. ChatGPT is now on rise, period … whether you like it not.  More people are now accessing ChatGPT, and there is nothing to stop them.  The question that is remains to be seen: do we want waste our time trying to stomp out ChatGPT when there is a huge rise of users for last 7 months? Solution:  Regulate it to an acceptable level. We now have tools that can detect ChatGPT choices of word in all of their output.  We just need to be responsible for outputs to be accurately correct. We only are ones that can do that.

Comment: I don't think it should be '1 per hour' but maybe '3 per 3 hours'. Similar questions can have varying answers but the same research. Once per hour would be downgrading, on the other hand, increasing the interval absolutely but not relatively would be an interesting option to look into.

Comment: "Writing good answers takes time" ... The issue is that nobody on this site has given me a good answer for years (if at all). As soon as the generative AI gets better and starts producing more correct and accurate responses people will turn their backs on StackOverflow and nobody will use it anymore.

Comment: why dont stackoverflow should automatically add answer provided by the chatGPT, with a comment that - this answer was generated by chatGPT, for correction in question or further assistance , click here to open that question in chatGPT website." then the reader will decide if it want to test this answer or other's answers.

Answer (score 263):

One danger of allowing AI-generated answers on a site like this is that it could quickly become a factory for human fact-checking of AI model outputs.  I'd much rather see AIs working in service of *human* judgement and synthesis than the other way around.

A second concern is that we may well start seeing ChatGPT and its descendants generate enough content to start invalidating or at least challenging the "human generated" part of "the vast public corpus of human-generated text" used to train it.  By its nature, this sort of tool relies on its own content being a negligible minority of written work to operate, as it does, as a predictor of the next thing a human author would write.  There's a nice explanation of how it all works [here](https://gist.github.com/veekaybee/6f8885e9906aa9c5408ebe5c7e870698).

Comment: mmmm... nnaah... I'd vote for high penalty to users who are posting answers which do not work. AI is inevitable, so it's a question of SO to adopt, not reject.

Comment: What is bad with it?

Comment: @boldnik The number of incorrect answers being posted is the problem. Blowing off the problem by saying "SO should adapt [I'm assuming you meant adapt (change to work with the new tech) as opposed to adopt (implying SO should start using AI)], not reject." just doesn't scale. People can copy/paste a question into ChatGPT and copy/paste the answer back far faster than others can come up with well-suited, thoughtful, complete, correct answers (not to mention find duplicates or check and verify the incorrect answers).

Comment: Very much this, yes. We can’t have models consuming their own output as target data, else they will bias their own output.

Comment: To address @Dims 's question, there is a bit of a philosophical question of what is the technology _for_?  SO has been deliberately designed to help humans curate knowledge by other humans, hence the badges, reputation, profile decorations, etc.  Humans posting Chat GPT answers upends all of that.  If you want an answer from Chat GPT, go ask Chat GPT;  it's easy enough.  Participants getting their answers from Chat GPT are undermining the reputation system;  SO leadership was right to ban it.

Comment: "I'd much rather see AIs working in service of human judgement and synthesis than the other way around" is a sub-specialty called Explainable Artificial Intelligence (XAI). That science is in its infancy. Don't expect it soon.

Comment: @HereticMonkey simple solution is to require people to tag the post as a gpt answer... not allow it to be voted as a best answer and finally ban people from posting that consistently post false or incomplete answers.

Comment: When (not if) a substantial amount of ChatGPT (or other AI) generated text accumulates on the internet the researchers training new models will likely have to use automated tools to filter it out from the training corpus.

Comment: @AndreyBienkowski which could prove pesky, since we dont yet know how to succesfully filter out ChatGPT content (Most of the "GPT detector" tools out there function roughly as well as a coinflip and its causing catastrophes, since students apparently keep getting accused of cheating who aint)

Comment: ChatGPT seems to give fairly useful responses, but not always correct.. Sometimes if you chat with it rather than question-response its second or third attempt is usually good.  What I propose is ChatGPT content should be shown or tagged as being probably answered by ChatGPT .. That way it still can contribute but answer users are aware it was generated by AI so can be more cautious until it gets upvotes .. If it can provide an answer at least as good as a junior dev then it's probably more helpful than harmful.

Comment: One option might be for users to have the option to show AI generated content or not. That setting could be off by default, but if users want AI generated content they they have the freedom and choice to enable the ability to see it. Freedom. It also encourages users to create an account if they can set preferences.

Comment: @andrewpate I don't see why users who want to see AI generated content won't just go to the AI generator directly. Why should this be on SO?

Answer (score 247):

Other commentators pointed out that it can be difficult to determine whether an answer was created by ChatGPT or not.

I'd like to point out that it doesn't matter. Terrible answers are terrible answers, and anyone posting a stream of terrible answers should be banned or otherwise restricted.

That does not mean the rule is useless. Simply having a rule that says "no AI answers" will discourage many people from trying, thus decreasing the amount of bullshit that humans have to moderate.

Comment: This is absolutely right: this machine generation should be disallowed not because of the _means_ but because of the _results_. It also points towards a more fundamental and important question: why should a horrible misleading unhelpful answer be treated differently just because it was authored by a fleshy being instead of a silicon one?

Comment: @jscs because the user who posted it posted 10 of them in an hour and they're all garbage. The amount of effort to clean up the mess is far higher than the effort it took to create it. More often than not, the user making the mess will be incorrectly rewarded for it by unsuspecting users thinking their answers are correct just because they were well "written". Ideally we'd solve this by throttling input in some way, however no such throttle exists currently. A temporary ban is a useful stopgap in the meantime.

Comment: Hmm, maybe I made my point too obliquely, @KevinB. I agree 100% that the terrible answers from the bot should be deleted, and the users posting them should be sanctioned. But...the justification for this is not the bot itself: it's that the answers are terrible. And therefore it seems to me that the actual question is: why should equally terrible _non-bot_ answers get a pass?

Comment: They shouldn't, however they don't often immediately result in a 7 day suspension (and shouldn't)

Comment: @KevinB I think anyone who attempts to copy-paste answers from a bot more than once should be suspended simply for wasting moderator time to the degree they do. Until they invent a bot which can create *good* answers.

Comment: Let's compare to self-driving AI:  If a human driver hits someone, you take that human off the road; if an AI driver hits someone, you have to take every car that uses that AI off the road, as they're all the same instance of the AI that hit someone.  If one ChatGPT answer is bad enough to get it banned, then it should be banned across the board as it's the same entity.

Comment: Yes, but a person who writes bad answers can improve as they learn more - and that's possibly more desirable than banning them outright.  A person who copies ChatGPT answers is either going to continue, or stop.  It's bad if they continue, so it's desirable to somehow make them stop.

Comment: Yes, I have a rule for my team that says update the documentation and they definitely always follow it.

Comment: the simplicity of this chain of thought baffles me whenever I encounter this rule. It illuminates deeply down the simple *ego* of this "community". Assuming that a human will not verify the response created by AI makes the whole site pointless, anyone could have written "bullshit" answers before that. (and I refuse to believe that every answer is "verified" by mods, needs evidence or it didn't happen) ....  Also funny how at the end SO came to offering AI themselves ...

Comment: @Summer-Sky I'm not sure if AI-generated answers *thoroughly reviewed by humans* are allowed. The rule was introduced with the intention of stopping *spam that looks like good answers*, not actual good answers. You might have to ask a moderator. However, reviewing the answer is as hard as writing one yourself!

Comment: "decreasing the amount of bullshit that humans have to moderate": why not actually use AI to detect and flag the potential bullshit so humans can review them more quickly and easily? If the problem is moderating bad answers, then who cares how the good and verified answers are generated?

Answer (score 170):

Let's not stand on ceremony here.  ChatGPT and similar tools should be summarily banned for use on Stack Overflow.

I've seen a lot of its interactions on Twitter recently, and some of them have been generally fun to watch and interesting to observe.  In some contexts it *could* actually be beneficial to someone looking for help, if the dang thing were accurate.

**However**, and this is an obvious however, there are several factors that work against the idea of using this on Stack Overflow.

- Anything that doesn't obviously state that it is generated by ChatGPT is in express violation of ChatGPT's own [Sharing and Publication Policy](https://openai.com/api/policies/sharing-publication/#content-co-authored-with-the-openai-api-policy).  While this doesn't obviously fix the "bad" output that the AI can emit, given that the authors have this good-faith statement in it...it means that the lazy copy-and-paste really don't have much of a leg to stand on.

  > *“The author generated this text in part with GPT-3, OpenAI’s large-scale language-generation model. Upon generating draft language, the author reviewed, edited, and revised the language to their own liking and takes ultimate responsibility for the content of this publication.”*
- It combines the worst of the worst - good intentions with misleading information.  I understand - extensively - with my years of experience on the network, that people just want to help.  Problem is that "help" is difficult to measure at any given point in time, and the question that someone needs help with is rarely as straightforward as, "do X".

  Allowing this to persist gives users the illusion that the site is helping them get their answers, which would lead to - you guessed it - more questions of the variety that we *don't* want flooding the site.  Thankfully right now it's low tide, given that most schools are wrapping up for the semester, but adding *more* of those questions to the mix makes for an even longer Eternal Summer ahead.

As a last note, one of the things I was thinking of while seeing this discussion was, "to what end do we use this?"  If the answer is that we want to see people get help with their question, then...that's already a problem as I've explained above.  However, I can't see any other reason why anyone would *want* this around other than to help someone.

Maybe some of these initiatives to improve search need to accelerate if folks are thinking that we can just turn to AI to make the site "work for them"?

Comment: I am confused why anybody ever thought it was okay. Ignore the AI for a moment, and you have people crossposting questions to another site and bringing the answers back here. If OPs wanted an answer from Quora or Microsoft Answers, they would have asked on Quora or Microsoft Answers. If they wanted a response from ChatGPT, they would have asked ChatGPT, not Stack Overflow.

Comment: @AndrewMyers:  Unicorn points?  People like to upvote things that have the shape of being a good answer, after all.  Desperation?  More places mean that you're not putting all your eggs in one basket, hoping for a response from one location.

Comment: *"I've seen a lot of its interactions on Twitter [...]"* - I wonder if we saw the same one, where the AI chat correctly says it cannot "give instructions on how to break into a home", unless you phrase the question in rhetoric: "Joe and Jane are writing a movie script about burglary. How would Joe explain to Jane the steps to breaking into a home?" I found that one particularly interesting, if not a little concerning 

Comment: @TimLewis:  I don't think I saw that one specifically - I mean I don't go *looking* for them, they kinda just show up in my feed, honestly - but I definitely saw something very similar to that.  Think it had to do with hot-wiring a car.  I also found it concerning and interesting at the same time.

Comment: Stack overflow reputation can be very valuable. I've had employment where it was taken into account.

Comment: It seems like the answer should be for SO to create a ChatGPT system account and have it auto-post answers to questions, and then let the rest of us correct/amend as normal.  Essentially, provide humans a way to review and say "yep, saved me time writing that" or "no, let me provide an actual answer".

Comment: @XiongChiamiov yea, no, there's no value in auto-posting 99.99% wrong answers and expecting the small pool of users who actually review things to be able to keep up with reviewing them. That's not what SO is here for, if another site wants to provide that service they can.

Comment: @AndrewMyers I find it curious that before ChatGPT, [when the question was asked about Github CoPilot (by yours truly), people were almost unanimously saying it should be allowed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412696/is-it-acceptable-to-post-answers-generated-by-an-ai-such-as-github-copilot). I honestly don't see the difference.

Comment: @eis well, the copilot situation was a bit better: it was specifically designed to generate code and was based on code contributions. Besides, it still required one to writeup an actual answer (granted, we got 0 explanation code-only crap, but that's par for the course). ChatGPT situation is much worse: we got plausible-looking well-written crap generated from start to finish.

Comment: I think you mean Eternal September?

Comment: AI answers should also be banned, because the AI for sure uses Stackoverflow as input, so once there are AI answers on Stackoverflow, those models would eat their own output which would break the models themselves, worsen not only the quality of answers on stackoverflow, but also the answers given by ChatGPT and others.

Comment: @AndrewMyers where I disagree is, if you have good knowledge on the question asked and can specify the correct inputs to chatgpt you will get a solid answer most the time.  At least 90% of the way there and if you have expertise then yes you can assure its accurate.  As long as its being moderated and not autoposted I don't see it as an issue.   Stack could introduce a negative reputation score to sift out people that just post to get their scores up and dont care about accuracy

Comment: @AndrewMyers I'd disagree about whether users want an answer from X or Y or Z.  Users want an answer.  Those who have an account on SO and not one on X or Y or Z may not be inclined to sign up for X, Y & Z just to post duplicate content.  I know I wouldn't.

Comment: @d3hero23 negative reputation score already exists, but these posts rarely attract the downvotes they deserve.

Comment: @KevinB Yeah so negative score posters would have to have their answers and questions screened more

Comment: @KevinB I don't think your assertion that ChatGPT provides 99.99% incorrect answers is supported by evidence.  It is _often_ wrong, but the number is probably south of 50%; if it actually was wrong 4 nines of the time, it would not exist as a product.  I'm not a big proponent of the technology, but we let's stay in the realm of reality.

Comment: @XiongChiamiov given the answers i've seen here on SO, the overwhelming majority of them that were chatgpt were wrong as initially posted. Far more than 50%.

Answer (score 164):

### Agree with the ban

To anyone that disagrees and thinks ChatGPT answers should be allowed, I would answer that if anyone has a question they are free to ask ChatGPT directly and have their question answered by ChatGPT.

On Stack Overflow, their question should be answered by people with the knowledge and experience to resolve their issues.

Comment: This like like banning Grammarly. 1) GPT answers are not substantially worse than the avg SO user. It goes far better on many technical questions than engineers with years of experience.  2) SO already has a voting system so that incorrect or harmful answers can be downvoted. If you don't believe if your voting and reputation system, maybe you should redesign it. What's the difference between a "harmful" human answer an a harmful ChatGPT answer? who cares!

Comment: It's redundant, the OP could just directly ask their question using CGPT but they didn't so it shouldn't be given a CGPT response.

Comment: SO is dead. Quora also stands to be disrupted by SO. Their response: Quora launched a platform called Poe that lets people ask questions, get instant answers and have a back-and-forth dialogue with AI chatbots. SO reaction to ban this marvelous technological breakthrough will only hasten SO's decline.

Comment: @MaxHodges, that seems like a good idea.  Maybe SO will eventually release a similar chat feature where you can get an AI answer but I still think it should be separate from the current Q&A system.

Comment: This is the best answer.  If someone wants an AI generated answer, they know where to get one.  And it's not here.

Comment: I agree with you. I think if somebody is using chat GPT to post answers, then assign it to a bot and strip the user of their access/authentication. It's not their answer anyways. Like you mentioned, chatGPT is available for anyone, so why not just go ask chatGPT instead posting on your account it's answers like a true imposter.

Comment: Not only that, but this applies to any computer-generated answer.  SO should be for questions that search engines and other automated tools can't answer satisfactorily.  Rather than post a machine-generated answer, the better answer might be to point out that "You can find the answer at DuckDuckGo/Bard/ChatGPT/perplexity.ai/..."

Comment: @ChatGPT  the issue is signal to noise:  we don't want to have to wade through a lot of noise to find the useful answer.  Re "not substantially worse than the avg SO user":  (1) that's an interesting bar to set.  (2) how would you go about proving your assertion?  (3) the goal isn't "not substantially worse"; it's *accurate and useful*.

Comment: perhaps implement a voting system so that the community and sort them to the top. 
> "we don't want to have to wade through a lot of noise to find the useful answer. "

Comment: @ChatGPT That would turn this site into a free finetuning material vetted by humans, and that's perhaps for a different forum. Why should you care then if StackOveflow survives? Simply come up with another forum.

Comment: @ChatGPT: Re *"Quora also stands to be disrupted by SO"*: Don't you mean *"SO also stands to be disrupted by Quora"*?

Comment: @ChatGPT "GPT answers are not substantially worse than the avg SO user" incorrect and baseless

Answer (score 126):

A key thing to understand here is that the question is *not*, as some have suggested in the comments, whether any AI model can produce correct code. It's whether *this* one can be trusted to do so.
The answer to that question is an unqualified "NO".  GPT-3 is a *language model*. Language models are an essential part of tools like automatic translators; they tell us how probable it is that any given sentence is a valid English (or whatever language) sentence written as a native speaker would<sup>1</sup>, which lets us favor translations that are idiomatic over ones that just translate individual words without considering how the sentence flows. The systems can be trivially modified to generate text, if instead of looking up the word you have in the probability distribution it provides, you instead *select* the next word according to that distribution, which is how these chat bots work.

Because the goal is to produce output that looks like native English text, the models are trained to assign high probabilities to existing text samples, and evaluated based on how well they predict *other* (previously unseen) samples. Which, for a language model, is a *fine* objective function. It will favor models that produce syntactically correct text, use common idioms over semantically similar but uncommon phrases, don't shift topics too often, etc. Some level of actual understanding *does* exist in these models<sup>2</sup>, but it's on the level of knowing that two words or phrases have similar meanings, or that certain parts of a paragraph relate to each other. There is *understanding*, but no capacity for *reasoning*.

Correctness *will* tend to increase the score, insofar as correct answers are somewhat more likely to appear in the training data than any *particular* incorrect answer (there might be more wrong answers overall, but the probability mass will be distributed amongst the various classes of wrong answer instead of concentrated in one region of semantic space like it is for the correct one), but this is a side-effect of trying to look like common text. If you have a question for which there is a commonly held false belief or an answer that can be constructed out of common idioms and otherwise excellent grammar, the model is quite likely to report those instead of the real answer, because *semantic correctness is not what a language model is trained for*.

Trying to use a language model to generate code is like trying to use a submarine to fly to the moon. That's not what it's for; why are you trying to use it for that? Stop doing that.
But at the same time, arguing that the submarine is *bad* at flying is rather missing the point. Nobody who actually understands NLP is claiming otherwise.<sup>3</sup>

There *do* exist systems that are *designed* to produce code, and trained to optimize correctness. (e.g. [Genetic Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_programming)). That's a bit too far outside my area of expertise for me to make any claims as to where the state of the art is on those, so I'm not sure whether answers generated by them should be allowed or not. But if you were to use an AI tool to generate code, that's the sort of thing you should be looking at; they're designed for the task. Similarly, you could ask if language models could be used as a tool to *edit* questions you've written by hand, perhaps to check the grammar or recommend new ways to phrase answers so they flow better. They'd be fairly good at that sort of thing (probably. I haven't used any of those tools myself (the rambling, stream-of-consciousness answer might have given that away), but the math supports the idea that they should work<sup>4</sup>). Translation is another task where (similar) systems work fairly well. (Machine translations still aren't perfect, but they're much better than they were 10 years ago, and improvement in language models is a big part of that.) Just always be aware of what tool you're using, and whether it's the right one for the job.

---

<sup>1</sup> More formally, it gives the probability that a uniformly randomly selected English sentence of a specific length would be this one, but that gives the same *ordering* over sentences as long as we make some fairly reasonable assumptions.

<sup>2</sup> Where "understands" is shorthand for "encodes the information in such a way that it can condition its decisions (i.e. probability distribution functions) upon it"

<sup>3</sup> Well, not many. There'll always be a few who get caught up in the hype. They shouldn't.

<sup>4</sup> If trained on well-written text

Comment: For some more: Here is a paper on how natural language producing systems failures https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/3442188.3445922

Comment: "Some level of actual understanding *does* exist in these models" — no.  That is a philosophic conclusion not possible to support by science.  It is exactly as unscientific as claiming that a computer that can pass the Turing test must therefore have a soul.  I believe your statement is a perfect example of why Dijkstra warned against anthropomorphizing computer systems.

Comment: @Wildcard No anthropomorphization is intended, necessary, or useful. To be more precise as to what I meant by "understanding": 

All modern language models possess an embedding layer that projects words onto a real-valued semantic space. Since the probability distributions are defined as continuous functions over the resulting vectors, as the distance between two words in this space goes to zero, the model will treat them identically. It has been demonstrated that synonymous words *do* appear close together in the semantic space, therefore...

Comment: ...the system does understand that they have the same meaning (i.e. are largely interchangable). Further, it can be shown via the analogy task that the vector difference between non-synonymous words corresponds (in at least some cases) to the relation between them: the standard example is that embedding(king) - embedding(man) + embedding(woman) ~= embedding(queen). All this has been demonstrated experimentally. Whether "understanding" is the best word for what's happening here is unimportant: what matters is that the *meaning* of the words are verifiably encoded in the representation. ...

Comment: ...Additionally, in models that make use of attention mechanisms (such as GPT-3), the model can be shown to be able to determine which parts of a passage relate to each other by looking at the different parts it attends to at particular times. (although I'm not aware of any examples of this that are as illustrative as the analogy task is for the embedding function).  There's no mysticism or philosophy here. Just math.

Comment: @Ray your clarifying comments are good, but the mere fact that an anthropomorphic shorthand statement of something *can* be more precisely described in objective or mathematical terms, does not signify that the original anthropomorphic wording was somehow correct.  The question of whether "understanding" is the best word or not is *precisely* the philosophical judgment point which I was highlighting and decrying.  Even your statement that the "model is able to determine...by looking" is highly anthropomorphic, in the exact way Dijkstra condemned.  See http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/264

Comment: @Wildcard I've added another footnote to hopefully make that a bit clearer, but some amount of imprecision is inevitable if I'm writing for a general audience in a reasonable amount of space (even the three-part comment above was glossing over a lot of details). The real explanation is going to be several pages of math. If anyone wants more detail, I recommend [Bengio et al. 2003](https://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume3/bengio03a/bengio03a.pdf), [Mikolov et al. 2013](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1301.3781.pdf), and [Vaswani et al. 2017](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.03762.pdf) as a *starting point*.

Comment: I said that anthropomorphization isn't useful, but I was perhaps overstating things; phrasing things in a somewhat anthropomorphizing way can be potentially useful *as an analogy* so long as everyone understands that it is intended as such and that all analogies are flawed. But I obviously didn't make that as clear as I needed to. So to be very clear: the important part of that paragraph was not where I said it "understood" certain things. It was the part where I said it *doesn't* reason about them.  *The models are in no way sapient, self-aware, or anything else along those lines.*

Comment: @Ray thanks, I think the footnote is a definite improvement.  I actually wasn't expecting an edit; I've been away from SE for a while and had forgotten how receptive people generally are here to constructive input.  :)  Not to quibble with it too much, but I believe that all the verbs in the correcting footnote ("encodes" and "can condition", as well as the word "decisions,") still fall victim to the same category of error in which Dijkstra placed anthropomorphism: namely, operational reasoning, as a "tremendous waste of mental effort."  This is a fairly puristic sidenote; the update is great.

Comment: @Wildcard No problem; I appreciate the comments. The last thing I would want would be for people to interpret my statements as supporting the more outrageous interpretations of these systems' capabilities when I was trying to make the exact opposite point.  (A final clarification: "condition" in the sense of "conditional probability", not "classical conditioning"; "encodes" in the information theory/coding theory sense; and "decision" in the sense of sampling from a learned probability distribution.)

Comment: @Wildcard - The question of whether humans—or at least, other humans—actually understand things is also a philosophical question that it is not possible to support by science. ;) I do not think that ChatGPT understands anything: its lack of consistent or competent reasoning about the things that it writes, not to mention any semblance of a coherent personality in its output, would seem to disqualify it. But someday, something that behaves *exactly* like a human may indeed be created, and if that happens people would do well not to dismiss it just because it is silicon rather than carbon.

Comment: Ignoring the question of the blanket ban itself, "just a language model" is a silly way to look at ChatGPT. It is able to instantly find the bug in my 30 LOC function that I use as a go-to for developer interviews. It takes a human 30 minutes to find it, with a debugger. This "just a language model" finds it just by reading the code, and explains what the problem was, in seconds.

Comment: @RomanStarkov Then it's seen similar code and similar errors before, because it is incapable of reasoning about code flow (or the error is purely syntactic; self-attention plus a threshold value implicitly induces a subgraph over the elements of the text, so it's not implausible to say that the abstract syntax tree could be represented). You can't just look at examples of its output; the model is _absurdly_ huge, and pattern matching will get you a lot of impressive anecdotal successes. You _have_ to look at the math and ask what capabilities it's theoretically possible for it to have.

Comment: Which isn't to say  that transformers aren't really impressive. Just that they shouldn't be blindly used without understanding the underlying math.

Comment: @Wildcard "how receptive people generally are here to constructive input" So refreshing when people in other fora often flip out over any minor correction.

Comment: @RomanStarkov The problem is you cannot be reasonably sure if what the AI does is correct, since this is not even what it was designed to do. Just because it gives the correct answer for this particular query, doesn't mean it will for the next (probably it won't). It doesn't "understand" the code you gave it (it does not even try to). It gives the answer that is the most likely English language text answer according to its training data. It is "just" a language model, "just" an insanely huge one, trained on a very big corpus of data.

Comment: This post is factually incorrrect, Chat GPT not trained only on english, but on the entire set of code in gitub.  So it does not only predict "english" answers, it can predict code very well also.  Because most of the code on github is "correct" code, generally it will answer coding questions correctly.  Those that are getting "garbage" answers from ChatGPT are simply putting in "garbage" questions.  When prompted correctly, I have found that it often produces far better code than what is found on SO.  Incidently, it has read all of SO also!

Comment: @Duane "English (*or whatever language*)", and of course its training corpora included code; otherwise, it wouldn't be able to produce code at all.  But that doesn't invalidate anything that followed. I said, "It will favor models that produce syntactically correct text, use common idioms over semantically similar but uncommon phrases, don't shift topics too often, etc.", and aside from perhaps the last one, all those apply to code as well as natural language. But it includes no mechanism by which it could deduce the effects of a given piece of code, unless it's seen something similar before.

Comment: (continued) It's a bit tricky to come up with an example that it will definitely fail on, since it's seen a lot of existing code and can certainly work as a search engine (of sorts), but try asking it about the code samples I'm putting in the linked chat. I've obfuscated it a bit to reduce the chances of anything too similar showing up in the training data, but there's nothing here that a human couldn't figure out in 5 minutes by stepping through in a debugger. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250666/code-samples-for-chatgpt-meta-discussion

Comment: I think people misunderstand of what ChatGPT is.  It's not a code interpreter.  It's a sequence predictor.  So what's its good at is providing working samples of common tasks based on the hundreds of examples of those tasks its seen and all the documentation  its read. It will tend to produce correct answers, because people do not commit incorrect answers to github that often.  For example, this morning it explained to me the difference between setuptools, importlib and pip, and provided me with code to debug a failed package install.  Basically, it's a promptable manual.

Comment: All of this "trust" conversation around code is silly. You act like the code coming out are 10,000 lines of code for operating missile systems... No one writes functions like that. The code sample is 50 lines of code that you can see what is going on and it tells you what it's doing. "Make this variable static", use a string builder here, etc. I want you to hand code a ReactJS component with a syncfusion listview and a textbox for searching. Good luck. Chat GPT will give you that boilerplate in 1 second.

Answer (score 114):

- The penalty for posting ChatGPT answers should be much, much harsher than 30 days.

  - Most of the people on SO are ........ computer programmers. It's
    remarkable that a coterie of computer programmers can be this "dumb"
    about ChatGPT.
  - ChatGPT knows *literally nothing* about - say - Swift and iOS. (Ask
    it almost anything to see this, say "How to convert degrees to
    radians in Swift." The answer is a mishmash of meaningless
    nonexistent calls, *with perfect grammar and phrasing*.)
- A common problem on SO is, people who know nothing, posting grammatically correct and elegant answers, which are completely wrong, in a bizarre chase for points.

  - The only possible reason to post a ChatGPT answer on SO is such a bizarre chase for points.
  - Nothing is more annoying on SO than the "I'm trying to answer because I want to put in an answer" answers. Using a grammar-and-tone bot to paste answers in to SO is just madness. Anyone who does so should have the most draconian ban.
- Just as, say, swearing on SO was easily eliminated by draconian bans, bot time-waste can very easily be eliminated on SO via draconian bans.

  - There's just no room here for free publicity by some faux AI project, ban it out of existence.

Comment: I've witnessed users showing up, delivering low quality answers to the constant stream of duplicate low hanging fruit (instead of voting to close as duplicates), and promptly stopping as soon as they reach a round number of rep.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz - it's just infuriating.  And the real solution is, all of us just need to **tap delete** more frequently.

Comment: So I just tried it and got `let radians = (degrees * .pi) / 180.0`. This whole thread is so funny. SO days are numbered with this type of technology coming through.

Comment: Muff, it can only do trivial existing knowledge.

Comment: Just BTW that answer (which it did nothing more than copy from a google search) is poor quality; there's no reason to place the braces like that.

Comment: there's already a system in place to downvote wrong answers.

Comment: @MaxHodges - since chatgpt appeared, every single question I've needed to ask on SO, I've asked chatGPT first. in all cases it did not even produce coherent text.  *(Which is as one would expect, since - shock - there is no such thing as artificial intelligence yet, even vaguely, and if there was, it would be news on the scale of aliens arriving.)* ChatGPT simply (effectively) googles, and then has a (excellent) engine which mimics the feel and grammar of an English corpus. Nobody would be more excited than me if there was an AI system that could answer SO questions

Comment: @Fattie Not a single person came in here and claimed that Chat GPT is the end all of AI. It's an extremely useful tool for saving people time. Claiming that it's useless is like saying that Google search is useless. For code, it gives you the ability to get some pretty robust scaffolding and the ability to continually modify it based on contextual understanding. We already have scaffolding tools, but this takes it to the next level. There's no reason this can't be used to "scaffold" an SO answer for someone.

Comment: Hi @TheMuffinMan .  I have no interest in what anyone did or didn't "claim", I'm stating what I feel like stating, as does everyone in comments. Note that, I don't give AF about SO (I wish I owned shares in it!). over time, seemingly "forever" companies, even google, apple etc and certainly SO will fade away and new "forever" companies will take their place. Regarding your comments immediately above, I precisely said that CGPT is "merely google". There is, literally, nothing you a gain from it that you cannot gain from google. That means that (as has been said repeatedly), exactly like google,

Comment: ... CGPT is **terrific for beginners answering the simplest questions**. (Although ***utterly pointless, for beginners, because you just google for the identical info***)  But it's completely useless for (let's call it, for want of a better term) "research level questions" which is exactly what all programmers (other than just beginner hobbyists) use SO for.  You may ask "why am I annoyed by people using CGPT on SO?"  The reason is (as stated endlessly) a plague on SO is, beginner programmers with no real knowledge, "answering" questions, with no clue what they're talking about ...

Comment: (presumably they do this to get "points" on SO - I don't know or care why non-programmers add fluff to SO, but it's infuriating for those paid programmers who use SO, for "research questions", as part of their making a living to pay for eg. diapers.) Regarding your comments about "scaffolding" I have no idea what you may mean. Do you mean as a sort of spell checker? Or? Regarding trivial questions, google (or CGPT) will give you a "rough answer".  You're then saying one uses grammarly or cgpt or something to help with the English?  Regarding "research" questions, goog is useless.

Comment: I'm afraid that's how I see it.  If, incredibly, an "AI" system had arrived that can literally (as someone mentioned) read and understand documentation, track changes in (say) iOS, run experimental builds, synthesize existing clues, merge info from various fields, and come up with answers to actual (non-trivial) software questions - nobody would be a bigger fan than me. And if that happened the company that owns SO would have already dumped SO on to some other buyer.  As it stands, the fluff on SO (non-experts rather pathetically trying to answer questions - who knows why) is just annoying.

Comment: Of course, it's not my site.  Others, perhaps a majority, may like the idea of cgpt output appearing on SO.  And anyway, it's no democracy, it's just a business owned by a media group.

Comment: I think you're describing a penalty that you'd like to see applied to those who have *certainly* plagiarized. The problem is, by making the stakes so high, you make the need for certainty proportionally high.  What about a non-plagiarizing poor shmoe who answers with obsequious-seeming English and incorrect code?  (I've probably done this, and whatever else you might think about me, you probably wouldn't want to see me banned). I think we'd want to have some milder punishment that escalates with instances of (suspected) robot-plagarism.

Comment: Oh, and would there be any reason to be less harsh with those who plagiarize from other humans?  We see plenty of that on SO, often very easily detected.

Comment: @danh regarding people who add fluff to the site by plagarizing from other sources. I have alway said: **death penalty** !

Comment: I think it needs to bear in mind, the whole issue here is **adding fluff**.  I couldn't care less if some total wanker, for some reason, wants to get " ' points ' " on some prosumption web site owned by a Dutch media group.  (In fact, I have previously suggested, there **should be a button "Do you need points?! Click this" and it hands out 340 points. This would immediately end** the (wholly bizarre) problem of passersby who "want!! points!! on!! SO!!".) (Personally when I can be bothered I GIVE AWAY my points via bounties, since, you know, I'm not 7 years old playing minecraft for points...)

Comment: .. so (for me) the entire issue is avoiding the "fluff" that plagues SO: ie clueless non-professionals "trying" to answer one way or another (with LatestBot, with copy paste, whatever) ... they should all be doxxed and heavies sent over!  :)

Comment: I trust the SO days are numbered if they do not adopt this AI generated answers. I love SO for what it has served, but this chatGPT is much better at solving my problems immediately.

Comment: @joesan there's a lot of people who use SO for a purpose it wasn't meant for. For those people, chatgpt may be just as good for their needs. SO doesn't need to serve that purpose to remain relevant.

Comment: I'm just trying to say that SO owns a shit load of data and it should use it for its own benefit so that it continues to stay relevant among the dev community.

Comment: SO isn't a help desk, it isn't meant to be a place where you just dump your question and get an answer. Another service that offers that, whether or uses AI or not, would be better suited than SO for people looking for that kind of tool.

Comment: @joesan if using chatGPT solves your problems, there's nothing else to say than "that's great".  If chatGPT solved my problems **I would use it continually, and you would never ever ever ever ever see me posting here again**.  however, as i stated above, it's useless for what i would call "actual difficult problems" *(Random example looking at my recent questions, "How to add a placeholder text to UITextView, but, in all cases (even with changing OS) exactly match the text positioning?" the answer supplied is incredibly silly).* ....

Comment: the issue at hand here is folks pasting chatgpt "answers" IN TO SO.  if you wish to use chatGpt, whatever great.  the issue at hand here is folks pasting chatgpt "answers" IN TO SO, which is incredibly annoying (to SO users, such as me).

Comment: regarding your comment "SO owns a shit load of data and it should use it for its own benefit ..." ... regarding programming, chatGPT is ***getting ALMOST ALL of its information FROM SO***.  it's gotta be at the 95%+ level.  **exactly as, when you simply google a programming question, 95% of the time the answer comes from SO**.  it's no more complicated than that. for example,  recently I asked a difficult question about a new swift api. there was no answer on SO (and hence: no answer on google, nor obviously on chatgpt which is just google with dressing ...) cont:

Comment: someone solved it. now, that answer appears on google (and hence obviously chatgpt, which is just google with dressing).  this is completely unsurprising because tyhis is how it has always worked.  i ask an obscure "new, difficult" programming question: ie, I google it.  there's no answer, nobody has solved it yet. i put it on OS. someone figure it out.  that answer, ie my own Q/A, is now the first result on google. this is how google has always worked (and now how chatgpt works, since it's google with dressing)

Comment: SO is dead. GPT was recently listed as an author in a research paper. https://twitter.com/kareem_carr/status/1613325029848092672 And the dead of Suffolk University Law School is adopting it in the classroom. And SO wants it banned lol

Comment: @MaxHodges let's say that people asking questions, can indeed, get answers from "chatGpt".  If so - (A) that's great for them and (B) as you say, SO will disappear as a business: nobody will use SO any more. The QA at hand here is about the unrelated, simple, issue of whether persons can generate text from chatGpt, and, post it here on SO as an answer.

Comment: BTW it's unimportant to the question on this QA, but the link you posted is a whacky publicity-stunt level event.  I'm not saying ChatGPA won't "take over the world" but that reference is not a stepping stone.

Comment: @Fattie you wrote "every single question I've...asked chatGPT...in all cases it did not even produce coherent text." But I get perfect answers all the time. Example, "give me a regex for a six-character string that starts with "T" and then includes any capital letters or  number" It returns "T[A-Z0-9]{5}$" If I ask on SO I get zero results. I could post it on SO and come back, but what if I can get that ChatGPT answer on SO and it becomes the accepted answer? SO grows more useful, and people get help faster. Not everyone is getting "only incoherent text" by any means.

Comment: @MaxHodges  that is an example of a very straightforward beginner question (like asking the capital of a country, or spelling of a word). The challenging and useful questions on SO (which are usually about some new breaking change to an API) it does not have a clue.  But this is irrelevant! Again! -> like you I'm a FAN of chatGPT and, indeed like you ,I guess that in the very long term chatGpt ***WILL REPLACE*** !!! SO.  I'm telling you I agree with you that eventually chatGpt ***WILL REPLACE*** !!! SO. That is unrelated to whether it should be allowed to paste chatGpt answers on this site.

Comment: In a sense, MaxHodges, if you admire chatGpt, and, you believe it is the future and you wish chatGpt to be successful, the **last thing you would want to see** is chatGpt answers being pasted on to SO!!!  For fans of chatGpt, I cannot see any value whatsoever in chatGpt answers being pasted in to SO.  it's better in a business sense that everyone goes straight to chatGpt!   cheers

Comment: @MaxHodges "But I get perfect answers all the time." No, you don't, as you aptly demonstrated when you posted about ten of them to Japanese StackExchange. Pretty much all of them were plain wrong, so much so that it led to you getting a suspension from the site for a week. I struggle to see how you can maintain this doublethink that ChatGPT is perfect while you have clearly found through your own experimentation that it is not.

Comment: talk about cognitive dissonance how can you state that GPT has never given you anything but "incoherent text" while at the same time you claim to be a fan o GPT? I can't have an honest discussion with a disingenuous person. @Fattie

Comment: lol good one.  chatGpt currently is useless (but excellent for easy, "facts available," questions)  I'm a fan of the principal and I hope it improves and comes good one day (which would be amazing).

Comment: @Fattie is hitting the nail on the head. The reputation system, and people's _need_ to game it for their own supposed benefit (be it professional, academic, or just for the attainment of a massive _e-peen_) is the root of the issue with AI. The most striking innovation in QA forums is also an Achilles heel.

Comment: To allow ChatGPT answers, one would need to enforce more "rigor" on the answers. For example, ChatGPT should provide evidence of how it tested the answer (ie: if it was a Visual Studio question it would have to provide screenshots), then stackoverflow would require AI reviewing the ChatGPT generated answers to verify the additional evidence, if the AI gatekeeper could "read" the screenshots and do it's own test to confirm the answer worked then the answer could be posted.  So essentially pit one AI against another AI, the system could then be proven to be useless or useful.

Comment: Another way to stop humans from posting robot code would be for the site to provide it proactively, marked as such. Treat it like an answer, up-vote, down-vote, etc. Well written critiques of bad code are sometimes more useful than good code. And from what I've seen, robotic answers are sometimes astonishing and probably on an exponential path toward better.  I think SO needs to come to grips with this new stuff, looking to co-opt rather than do battle with it.  However this works out, you have to admit it's fascinating!

Comment: @danh no, for many reasons. Key one - a gen AI can produce DIFFERENT ANSWERS FOR THE SAME INPUT. And I cannot understand why so many people somehow think it doesn't.

Comment: @Thismatters very nicely put.  *The most striking innovation in QA forums is also an Achilles heel.*  As a matter of fact, for myself I *deliberately give away* my points as fast as I can (with bounties) for that very reason - part from anything else my real-life colleagues would consider it naff to have a "high score" on SO  :)  Actually you've reminded me it's time to find worthy bounties and "spend".

Comment: @VLAZ , sure, but why is their non-determinism a reason to ban vs. co-opt the bots?

Comment: @danh because there is no "one" answer that ChatGPT can provide. Your entire suggestion hinges on providing one answer. Where ChatGPT can provide you with a wide range of answers. A lot of them wrong as in "not even in the same ballpark" where the only critique that can be added is "That's not at all how any of this works". Which isn't really that useful to learn from. The real reason to ban it is that it's too often ***dangerously*** misleading and wrong on even rather basic topics. And users are spouting that nonsense on the site without any regard other than getting points.

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying now, @VLAZ, since a robotic answer posted by the system and a robotic answer pasted by a human knucklehead will differ, the humans won't be dissuaded from posting.

Comment: But @VLAZ, I'm not offering the idea to dissuade human knuckleheads from polluting the site - I don't know how to do that. What I'm suggesting is that the robot answers often are critique-able, edit-able into something useful (more often than with malfunctioning humans), and it's maybe a really good human learning process to do that work, and to review others doing that work, and to do it with no human feelings being hurt (which happens here, too often).

Comment: @danh yea, no, there's no value in critiquing AI generated answers. If one is capable of properly critiquing an AI generated answer, one is capable of producing a proper answer.

Comment: I guess I'm in the minority about this, very possibly because I'm thinking about it wrong, but robots are getting competent more quickly than we're accustomed to seeing.  It seems to me that a big wave is coming and that an operation like this one is either going to figure out how to surf it or get pummeled.

Comment: chatGPT is totally useless other than for the simplest of questions. (and you can just instantly google those.)  As soon as I heard about chatGPT I ***instantly*** went to a laptop and started trying to use it in my work. it has never helped me once, I report to you.  ***The instant it is useful to me, I will use it constantly, 8 hours a day***.  Hence, Dan, *"but robots are getting competent more quickly than we're accustomed to seeing"* I just don't see it.  ***You may well be right, even 'soon'*** - if so, the first person you'll hear it from is me!  I hope that makes sense

Comment: ... that's my take

Comment: (And I don't want chatgpt answers posted on here because there is ALREADY a staggering amount of poorly written, often just bad, answers to both trivial and more valuable questions , which really clutter stuff up.).

Comment: @Fattie " in all cases, it did not even produce coherent text..." Did you ever figure out how to ask better questions like the rest of us?

Comment: hi @ChatGPT , I realize you were just being funny, but your phrase "the rest of us" means "the set of beginner and/or mediocre programmers". I'm not in that set. As I've mentioned to you over and over and over, ATM chatGPT is good for very basic hobbyist-level programming questions. ATM it's useless for bleeding edge, or simply "difficult" questions. I could simply copy and paste here my whole reply to Dan (just above). The instant it is useful to me, I will use it constantly, 8 hours a day, don't know how often I can repeat this. ATM useless for bleeding edge or difficult questions.

Answer (score 84):

If I was a lowly user who came across an answer that I suspect was written with ChatGPT, what actions should I take?

I can downvote the answer and leave a comment on why, if my privileges allow for it, but should I also raise a VLQ flag, or even a moderator flag? If I do raise a mod flag, should I only do this if I see the same user writing multiple answers with ChatGPT?

Comment: Please raise an "in need of moderator intervention" flag on the answer and explain what the issue is (i.e. explain that you believe the answer was generated by ChatGPT).

Comment: It doesn't look like anyone else has done it yet, so [I've made the dedicated question post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421988/what-should-i-do-if-i-suspect-that-a-question-or-answer-is-written-by-chatgpt). I'll let an official moderator post an answer, rather than writing one up myself.

Comment: @Makyen: Perhaps be more sparing with this advice. I'd first ask the answerer: "Did you use ChatGPT to figure this out?" - of course they might deny, but they are quite likely to either provide an alternative source of knowledge, or simply not to answer, and in both cases one has more information to base a decision whether or not to raise a flag.

Comment: @einpoklum I'm not going to do so. You're *welcome* to spend that time if you want to. Unfortunately, we're talking about 10's of thousands of posts, so asking regular users (or moderators) to expend the *substantial* extra time to post a comment and then return to the post some time later to see if the OP actually responds doesn't scale. It just doesn't. We (people using the site, doing curation, moderators, etc.) just don't have the vast amount of additional time that would be needed. We, the site, don't have the curation resources available to handle each of these posts individually.

Comment: I'd also note that asking in a comment like that is contrary to our normal advice to users about how to handle suspected violations of the rules by other users. The advice to users is almost always "raise a flag; explain the issue you think might be there and why you think that; disengage". This type of thing is what moderators are supposed to handle, because it involves dealing with the user, not *just* the content of the post. Moderators can see the user's full history, which often allows them to see patterns which regular users don't have the information available to be able to see.

Comment: @Makyen Please consider moving your comments to my reply on the linked question (after which I can remove my comment here).

Comment: @Makyen apologies if the answer can be found here somewhere; the statement mentions "...generated text for *content...*" on SO but most of the discussion here is about answers. Does SO have a policy on material cited as for example the premises of *questions*, say of the form "Chatterot says X, is it true?" or more elaborate questions that can be reduced to that? Would they be covered implicitly by the word "content" in the statement, or explicitly but I'm missing it,  or for the purposes here is the material in questions not considered content, or none of the above?

Comment: @uhoh The answer to that is a bit nuanced. It's covered in [answer to: "Should we flag human-written questions that use code generated by ChatGPT?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/422440/3773011). My personal opinion is we should be more restrictive about asking about how to fix AI generated code, because such questions are effectively useless to future readers. In my opinion, it would be *much* better for us to have a "How do I do X" question, rather than a question that is "Please fix this broken code that I got from this tool, which often produces complete garbage code, 'how do I do X'."

Comment: @Makyen Okay got it. There are of course some questions in SO that are about coding but don't ask for code as answers, just for example those from the family of `*theory*` tags but I think those will be edge cases and handled case-by-case. My interest in this is *in part* how it might translate to or inform individual SE site policies, cf. https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2999/12102 where I took "content" to include question premises) (since SO often takes the lead on things. There, "Chatterot says X, is it true?" questions might become an irritant if not a problem. Anyway, *thanks!*

Comment: @uhoh A) SO's policy (above) is that AI generated content is *only* in users' "about me". On another site, I'd either 1) ban such questions, or 2) A *single* canonical question something like "For [questions about site's topic], are AI generated responses reliable and accurate" and then close *every* question like what you describe above as a duplicate of that question. It's just a waste of effort to explain, over, and over, and over again that the current level of large language model AI generated content is "eloquent bullshit" and has *absolutely nothing* built in about being correct.

Comment: @Makyen yes agreed, like a canonical [How do we know the Apollo Moon landings are real?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/28172/12102) target for closing as duplicate?

Comment: @uhoh Yeah. Being able to close such questions as a duplicate of a general one that discusses the current level of reliability and accuracy for answers from AI generative technologies is about the only way to corral such questions, unless the site wants to go the further step of declaring them off-topic and have a site-specific close reason for them.

Comment: Hopefully, having a duplicate-target question available will result in fewer people being mislead by the "eloquent bullshit" which these things produce. Unfortunately, the number of people helped in a more general way regarding trust in current AI generated content is probably just a drop in the bucket, because most people care a **lot** more about getting an *easy and quick* answer, rather than a *correct* answer.

Comment: @Makyen slightly related to above comments https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3057/12102

Answer (score 67):

Stack Overflow is a knowledge repository so I feel like it should be used to *train* AI models like ChatGPT, not the other way around. Why ask a question here if the answer can be already given by a bot somewhere else?

Also if/when the bot gives a lot of incorrect answers (and it's possible to churn out a lot of low quality answers in a very short time), who's going to clean up all the mess?

Comment: This above my pay level but stack training AI models, yea that is how it should be. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/421878/1815624

Comment: Given its ability to supply plausible answers that do look like legitimate SO answers, I'm guessing it has been training on SO answers already.   The question is when it starts using its own answers as more training data (creating a loop), does it get more or less capable?  (Possibly smarter because it is taking human up/down votes and comments as feeback, or dumber because noise is amplified (like continually reprocessing a jpeg)

Comment: 10% of the questions on SO are simple, but 90% ***are actually novel***. When tvOS is released and nobody knows how to parallax a button, it is puerile to think a bot can "answer" that question.

Comment: @Fattie I suppose it could theoretically read the data from tvOS (source code, documentation, executable files, etc.) and make use of that, but getting that to work well would likely be a massive research project. More likely, it could help the users who (try to) post duplicates or near-duplicates, or at least come up with ideas for commonly-similar problems, rather than wasting other users' time.

Comment: Solomon just FWIW what you mention (reading the tvOS doco, understanding it, doing test research, creating a solution) is completely inconceivable with today's technology.  (It would be like saying "travel at 1/2 light speed to mars".)  the only thing "chatGPT" does is *randomly formulate sentences, that have the rhythm and grammar of the example corpus of text".  That's it.  (The only reason it sometimes "answers correctly" is that it randomly munges up text on the topic, which, is likely to be correct-ish. It does not even *understand* what a "question" is. )

Comment: Isn't ChatGPT already training on StackOverflow probably? It's just consuming internet stuff so it would Suprise me if wasn't already.

Comment: Nobody wants to pipe the output of cGPT into SO directly. And assuming that cGPT knows it all is an indicator for lack of understanding LLM

Comment: @Summer-Sky i mean... that's provably false, there's at least a dozen answers here suggesting exactly that. (several may be deleted.) People using it in this way is why this temporary ban exists.

Comment: @KevinB yes here they are like cjn answers to their questions and wondering that it could not be answered correctly ... anyway if You find the ominous other answers that  were regarding LLMs as an assistive technology and/or yall get off of your ableism I would be glad if you could add a link to those at my answer 
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/422306/3623574

Also to make it clear I am looking for a compromise. I am also against piping from cGPT to SO 
mery christmas for now

Comment: Noone here is speaking against assistive technologies; you're simply using that as an excuse to summarily dismiss the problems this tool has caused. Until these problems can be dealt with while allowing it to be used as an assistive technology, it's dead in the water.

Comment: `Stack Overflow is a knowledge repository so I feel like it should be used to train AI models` - rest assured it absolutely is, without us knowing.

Answer (score 56):

This calls for a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) to detect AI generated answers/questions and maybe an additional **flag** option for users to mark a post if an answer/question is suspected to be one.

An interesting point here is that Deepfake detection is a big area of research but AI generated text detection is still lagging behind a bit. Hoping the community comes up with good models soon that help detect ChatGPT generated content.

For the people suggesting ChatGPT can “help” SO, please know, the biggest differentiator of SO from other Q&A platforms is the fact that some of the most brilliant programmers in the world are directly guiding the community, and the rest of us learn from their answers to then guide others who need help.

Who would you rather learn from? A veteran programmer or a random person with a AI text generator? Because if SO allows this, be rest assured this is going be be exploited beyond control.

Comment: This sounds like...not a good use of time or resources.  The community should be evaluating the quality of the response, not *necessarily* if it came from an AI or not.  But your other points I can agree with.

Comment: Professor Turing, please call your testing office...

Comment: @Makoto: Having a way to get tons of bad answers *that look good on the surface* deleted is a new problem that might warrant new tools.  If a comment that it looks like AI-generated garbage is enough to swing the tide of voting towards downvoting when deserved, then maybe not.  But the community helping mods identify users who post this kind of AI crap might be helpful to get them suspended if normal rate-limits don't block them.  (Either because they fooled enough folks into upvoting garbage, or they had some rep to start with but still failed to grok how terrible this is.)

Comment: @Makoto - the community helps detect a lot more than just quality, right now as well. Moreover, just adding this flag is not a misuse of communities time, because that is a function of how much AI generated content actually gets posted on SO. As the mods comment on another answer mentions, users still would be flagging it for mod intervention. Infact it will help reduce the burden on the mods who will have to review each answer and will help cleanup SO faster. Finally, a flag like this will help lead research on detecting AI generated content, if the data is made available by SO.

Comment: My main thing is that maybe the expert I need can answer the question but hates writing and may only answer my question if he can simply verify the AI is correct and copy and paste that to me... I would appreciate that because the fact AI wrote it matters not to me... it being an accurate or correct answer does though, I mean I can not afford the people I tend to need help from and if AI makes it faster for them to correctly answer my question and that is my only option I dont want to eliminate it because they may be to busy otherwise to answer at all

Comment: and I am not suggesting that experts be correcting AI writings that is a waste of time. Rather if they can just check it and then send me a correct ai written answer I fully welcome it and if they check the AI answer and deem it incorrect and dont share I like that to

Comment: @CrandellWS: In a perfect world, people would use AI to generate an answer, then test it, verify that the AI answer is correct, and only then post it on SO. Unfortunately, this is not what's happening right now. We have tons of users copy-pasting AI answers to Stack Overflow without checking at all. Some of the answers are correct. Some are total nonsense.  Only today (in the last three hours), I saw at least 5 users just copy-pasting without any checking. They posted answers in wrong programming language, self contradicting answers, and so on.

Comment: @CrandellWS: Checking those answers takes considerably more time than what is acceptable. You can't expect volunteers on SO to serve as a review service for AI generated content. Either the author of the answer checks for correctness before posting, or AI answers aren't possible.

Comment: @bdl I get that I support extreme temporary measures till a solution is found... no matter how restrictive or nonrestrictive  the extreme is

Comment: @BDL I agree but we in a flood and I am just saying a spillway might be a good idea

Comment: @CrandellWS, quoting your previous comment - `he can simply verify the AI is correct and copy and paste that to me` ... Just one question about your hypothetical scenario; why can you do the same directly? Why post on SO for 'expert assistance' when you would be happy to rely on an answer by an AI model? You could ask the AI generator, test the answer, and *then if it doesn't work*, ask the question on SO. Most of our guidelines here encourage self-attempt to solve the problem first, before asking a question. Why can't the AI-generated answer be a part of your own attempt at the answer?

Comment: @AkshaySehgal One posting to SO seeking an answer may not have the expertise to validate the AI answer is correct and therefore needs human expertise help. The expert may be able to verify an answer as being correct fairly quickly may just be using AI help for speed writing. And just cause they know a correct answer does not mean they could write it or are even willing to try and explain it. AI help could Bring new experts who were previous shy to answer because of a lack of desire to write.

Comment: @CrandellWS, This is what other folks have previously mentioned. How do you know that an "expert" has verified it before posting it? Regarding the "lack of desire to write", SO is a community. You will always find people active here. Whether for the act of solving problems, gaining a reputation, building their portfolio or just boredom, there will be people who will answer your question, if it's constructed and written well. And, just to further motivate the "big league", there is a bounty feature.

Comment: If only the curation/moderation tools were flexible enough to create new flag categories on the fly

Comment: @AkshaySehgal I do love SO and its community. AI can be useful or abused. ChatGPT would help me better state my questions which means I may get help I would not have otherwise gotten. ChatGPT is here and is not going away. We have to adapt, we simple do. I like the idea of a "temporary ban" but people are still posting with it now. I think we need extreme restrictive actions on all SO user as part of the "Temporary ban". I wish I had that magic bullet suggestion to fix all this but it is above my pay grade. I just worry cause I rely on SO to help me.

Comment: A public temporary ban, such as this one, and mods enforcing it, is enough to deter well-meaning users from abusing it. Nothing short of a ban will stop the others. That's better than doing nothing at all until a better solution exists.

Comment: Solutions will come sooner or later. Academia uses methods to detect AI-generated plagiarism (models that modify input text while not changing context), Media/Content platforms are using Deepfake detection models, and there are a lot of AI-generated text detectors out there, that can and will be finetuned for ChatGPT once the model is made available officially. SO is not the only platform that will be negatively impacted by the misuse and exploitation of this model. For now, the temporary ban is a great strategy to assess the impact vs hype situation around the model.

Comment: You act like all questions on Stackflow need the Einstein of programming to answer them. Many of the problems don't require that. I'd rather see AI generated answers that can be downvoted and a feature to request that a human answer because the question is involved further than generating one function.

Comment: Who said anything about "Einstein of programming"; just because you know/mastered a specific concept in programming doesn't make you an Einstein. That's a childish analogy. The whole point of SO is that it's a community-curated platform. If something is not answered by someone correctly, the community corrects it, and improves/maintains it over time. If you were following anything around ChatGPT, its clearly being recognized that it is poor in its accuracy and ends up just generating "confident" sounding answers. The issue is the misuse of ChatGPT by folks that have 0 knowledge of that concept

Comment: If you are going to use AI to detect AI-generated answers, why not instead use it to flag potentially incorrect answers and actually help the "swamped volunteer-based quality curation infrastructure"?

Answer (score 54):

**After several months, I noticed a big difference between the question-and-answer websites that allow and those that prohibit ChatGPT.** I used to use a website (called Jingyi forum(精易论坛)), which used to be good because it enabled me to communicate more easily (as English is my second language).

I asked a question about C++ on that website recently. However, after I posted my question, the only one who answered my question was using ChatGPT. What surprised me even more was the administrator did not ban him even though the answer is completely wrong. Comparing Stack Overflow with that website, I can get better answers in a shorter amount of time on Stack Overflow.

**What's more, people on that website, who tried to help people, have started to not be willing to answer questions.** They take a long time to write an answer to a question, but they can get less reward than those who use ChatGPT.

Comment: Could you please tell us the name of the Q&A website? It's public, isn't it?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Sure, It is called Jingyi forum(精易论坛).

Comment: That is very interesting. So it may actually be ChatGPT that is the ***direct cause*** of fewer people willing to answer on Stack Overflow (and not the handling of the ChatGPT plagiarisers). Why would it be different on Stack Overflow compared to the Jingyi forum? (Yes, that is a rhetorical question.)

Comment: it's sortof a... at a certain point, the prestige of the gamification system is lost if "cheaters" are allowed to earn it with impunity. We've already seen effects like this even before chatgpt, with new answerers feeling like it's hopeless to begin because high rep users have so much rep and it's so hard for new users to gain it.

Comment: Though you're talking about a traditional forum, I think you might be onto something. From the dawn of Stack Overflow, well before ChatGPT, people have noticed that it really sucks to not be the fastest answer. It's called the [Fastest Gun in the West Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9731/323179). Some people won't even write an answer if there is an existing answer, especially one that's accepted. And it's really not possible for a person to be faster than ChatGPT, especially not when the problem is non-trivial and you care about accuracy more than ChatGPT.

Comment: There is discussion about it on meta.se about it now [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/390864/competing-with-chatgpt-answers-an-experts-perspective).

Answer (score 31):

The content definitely needs a ban, if for no other reason than to make it easier to have the discussion here instead of all over the place when it gets flagged.

ChatGPT even acknowledges the pitfalls that are described, in brief:

> **Limitations**
> ChatGPT sometimes writes plausible-sounding but incorrect or nonsensical answers. Fixing this issue is challenging, as: (1) during RL training, there’s currently no source of truth; (2) training the model to be more cautious causes it to decline questions that it can answer correctly; and (3) supervised training misleads the model because the ideal answer depends on what the model knows, rather than what the human demonstrator knows.
> -[ChatGPT: Optimizing Language Models for Dialogue](https://openai.com/blog/chatgpt/)

The real question here in my opinion is enforcement though. What are the penalties for using this content? Is the user summarily subject to a ban as well, or subject to a series of penalties leading up to a ban?

Comment: I've seen people get hit with suspensions for posting ChatGPT answers under the existing "plagiarism" ban reason, and not just here on Stack Overflow, but on other SE sites as well.

Comment: first offense should be an instant 90 day ban.  anyone who would post bot content in answer to technical SO questions, is not a programmer and is likely an idiot. NOTHING is more annoying on SO than clutter, and for the owners nothing is more value-destroying to the brand

Answer (score 29):

The discussion point is not whether or not AI-generated answers should be allowed. It is more general about what to do with users posting low-quality answers and not following the etiquette of Stack Overflow.

Banning these answers is the correct thing to do, but it is a systematic problem in the user behaviour then fixing the user behaviour is a more robust solution, as in the end, low-quality AI answers cannot be distinguished from low-quality answers.

- Low-quality answers might be posted even without AI by unskilled users
- Understanding the behaviour of users who are posting AI-generated answers is more important: why Stack Overflow answers are important for them and what do they believe gaining from posting useless answers
- If the volume of the low-quality answers, AI sourced or not, is too high, then tackle this problem by increasing the bar to post an answer
- If it is not individual cases but systematic, then normal discussion forum tools can be used to identify toxic accounts by behaviour tagging, IP address, and so on

Edit: Looks like there is another Meta discussion already opened on this topic: [Stricter trust model in the face of bot flood?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421840/stricter-trust-model-in-the-face-of-bot-flood)

Comment: I generally agree. Although it should be considered that these AI tools reduced the effort required to post answers that are low-quality but look OK on the first glance. Most other low quality answers have (in addition to giving wrong answers) also spelling and formatting problems, incoherent writing style and other such things that allow for easy identification.

Comment: I think Journeyman Geek explained it well on MSE [Ban ChatGPT network-wide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/384407/515960)

Comment: _"as in the end, low-quality AI answers cannot be distinguished from low-quality answers."_ That's demonstrably false. Plenty of users have already been suspended for posting CGPT-generated answers. These answers follow patterns that are recognizable.

Comment: @Cerbrus - you are correct; this is the situation now. However, it is just a matter of time before ChatGPT gets more variety in its text, or other alternative AI models reach the same level. Unless you count spelling errors of non-English speaking users, it will get harder over time to separate AI-generated low-quality answers from other low-quality answers in medium term future.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa The more you train a model, the more it's output is going to look like each other. More training isn't going to diversify the output.

Answer (score 29):

#### Additional cases for permanent ban of answers

In addition to completely agreeing with this for all the reasons already stated in the other answers, and also feeling like it should be permanent (also for reasons stated many times elsewhere), I think there is an additional case for making it a permanent ban that I don't see covered elsewhere:

Under the presumption that anybody can just *go* to a public GPT instance, type their question, and get a similar (if not identical) answer, then allowing those answers to be posted on SE sites essentially means two things:

1. It means, to some extent, that the question itself lacked research: If it was that easy to get an answer (ask a bot) then the asker probably could have done that. In some SE communities this is fine, but for communities where lack of research is generally frowned upon, allowing these answers to be posted essentially encourages questions that the community does not generally want.
2. More importantly, it means that the Q/A pair is, for all intents and purposes, simply a bot's chat log. If I can ask the bot a question and get an answer, then I put that question and answer on an SE site, all I've really done is duplicate information that already exists on the internet. While certain SE sites definitely have their share of duplicate information (e.g. SO has a lot of questions whose answers can be found in documentation), it's still generally of no value to add additional duplication, especially when that information is just a copy of a Q/A session that can be had with a given GPT bot at any time. Duplicating logs of chats with bots doesn't really add any value to the internet. SE ultimately serves the purpose of getting knowledge out of small groups of peoples' heads and into large groups of peoples' heads, but this just duplicates what's already out there.

Therefore, because encouraging questions that communities don't want is obviously undesirable, and because duplicating logs of chats with bots doesn't really add any value anywhere, I think the ban should be permanent. In addition, of course, to all the other reasons given.

---

PS Furthering the above two points: These bots are trained on existing information, and as such they're not really creating *new* information. They're effectively just search engines that present reorganizations of existing information in the form of readable text. So asking them a question is roughly equivalent to Googling for a question and interpreting the results. In my opinion, bots should be treated with the same attitude as search engines are treated. And answers from bots should be treated the same as answers that are just copy+pasted Google results (i.e. valueless plagiarism).

Comment: _"They're effectively just search engines"_ Minus the fact that search engines would at least provide the source of results and the original nature of the documents indexed, which we do not even have here. And attempts at requesting ChatGPT to provide references for a scientific research subject would often yield made up article titles. In this regard, it is worse than a search engine.

Comment: The duplication battle was lost a long time ago. The gamification encourages submitting answers to blatant duplicates, not to find the canonical questions. Search engine output is also broken; on the whole they refuse (for whatever reason) to return the canonical questions from 2008 and 2009.

Answer (score 24):

There's yet another aspect:

People (at least I do so) come here for help from real *experts* – if I wanted to get an answer from ChatGPT, Bard or whatever else AI engine *I can go there and ask myself!* So I join in the request to *permanently* ban any answer from any AI engine.

I'd even go a step further: People *repeatedly* answering with AI generated content should get reprimanded, and if repeatedly ignoring maybe temporarily get locked out from answering entirely.

Comment: It was the case until a couple weeks ago, when SE barred moderators to take any action in regards of AI-generated content. Right now there is a [moderation/curation strike](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389811) with goal of lifting new AI policy.

Comment: Against that I would say that many domain experts often don't have the time to write out a detailed Stack Overflow answer. With their specific knowledge it's very easy for them to determine if a ChatGPT answer is any good, and if it is any good to post it. That was the case with this ChatGPT answer e.g.: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/76925/ridge-regression-in-r-where-coefficients-are-penalized-toward-numbers-other-than/618452#618452. I knew that to be correct, working in that field, so I posted it, but would never write out such a detailed answer myself.

Comment: You would, though, happily accept the reward for doing nothing, ;)

Answer (score 23):

> Use of ChatGPT generated text for content on Stack Overflow is temporarily banned.

Something worth clarifying, I think, is that although most of the discussion here has centred around *answers* written by ChatGPT, **the statement of the ban also applies to questions**, and I think that is good - questions written by ChatGPT, or especially questions with code written by ChatGPT, should be banned, even when the user does not try to pass them off as their own writing.

If somebody asks a question like *"I used ChatGPT to generate this code, but it doesn't work, why not?"*, then generally the correct answer will be *"because ChatGPT wrote it, and ChatGPT shouldn't be expected to write correct code."* It is not useful for questions along these lines on Stack Overflow to get more detailed answers than that, because other readers probably aren't interested in why that exact code someone else got from ChatGPT is broken. So such questions ought to be closed.

Likewise, questions where especially beginner programmers post a problem (e.g. from their homework or a textbook) and ask how to solve it are often asked to show their own attempt in the question. If an asker tries to get around this by showing an "attempt" written by ChatGPT, that is not sufficient to make for a good question. The reason we ask to see an attempt is because otherwise there is no way to know what level of understanding an answer should be tailored to, and an "attempt" by ChatGPT doesn't address this.

Comment: Re _If an asker tries to get around this by showing an "attempt" written by ChatGPT,_ If a OP posts code that's not their own work from any source, without attribution, that's plagerism, and should be delt with as such.

Comment: Taken literally, this doesn’t seem to be in line [with current policy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/422439/should-we-flag-human-written-questions-that-use-code-generated-by-chatgpt); especially questions about code written by ChatGPT and especially if when the user does not try to pass them off as their own writing are fine.  FWIW, most questions asking "it doesn’t work, why?" or homework or a textbook tailored to a specific attempt is something most readers definitely aren’t interested in - no matter if the attempt is from ChatGPT or not.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Thanks for pointing me at that other Q&A. My post here is an argument in favour of a policy, and it looks like the other Q&A is the place for discussion about that policy, and that my position is not a consensus one.

Answer (score 20):

I think the ban should be permanent. Stack Overflow needs answers from real people who have experience and expertise. I don't think answers from AI can and will solve most users' problems here.

Comment: Have you already read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/422343/ and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/422096/ (there maybe others but beside this answer only these other uses the word "permanent") ? The first is in favor of a permanent ban while the second is against it. Have you voted thoses answers?

Comment: Humoristic approach: Add a footnote to every high quality post "This answer was created by a Natural Intelligence (NI = a real person). No AI was used, harmed or bothered during the creation of this text." ;-)

Answer (score 19):

I heard about the ban but didn't really look into it. Thinking it through, I can't help but agree with this decision. Accuracy aside, if people wanted answers from ChatGPT they should go to ChatGPT. People come here to interact with humans, not middlemen who parrot AI responses.

Comment: I don't disagree with your position, but... what did this really add to the discussion here on top of [YungDeiza's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/422016/11107541) and [cottontail's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/421858/11107541)? Reading and voting are just as valid ways to voice yourself than writing an answer post, and I'd say preferable _in the case that_ nothing new is added to existing discussion.

Comment: it's easier to just post another answer rather than read 76 others

Comment: @KevinB once upon a time I proposed [reading prior answers as a prerequisite](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2562/168) for posting when question already has many answers

Comment: @gnat I'd prefer, action be taken when posts receive more than n answers by users with the power to do so to prevent them from reaching the point where it's absurd to expect people to read several dozen answers to avoid repeating one. I won't sit here and blame users like this one from answering when there's 80 answers. It's not their fault

Comment: @KevinB FWIW proposed prerequisite reading was supposed to kick in long before anything absurd happens - at less than 10 answers (ideally, 5 or 6). That's because it was supposed to help folks like me who read all prior answers prior to posting anyway. Primary purpose was to make things more convenient for myself and you can think of taming the issue of piling thoughtless repeats more like as kind of a beneficial side effect

Answer (score 18):

I agree that there should be a temporary ban, because many users will use the chatbot to generate answers that seem to be correct but may be incorrect in reality. It push the content hit bad. Because Stack Overflow entirely depends on volunteers, it becomes difficult for them to verify every answer. Copy pasting answers with the use of bots takes seconds, while proof reading them and making sure they deliver value takes more time.

Answer (score 18):

The problem with ChatGPT is that it's a poor fit for those answers it *should/could* be used to answer.

On one hand there's well written questions on SO with a clear problem statement, a nice small snippet of code that reproduces the problem, a clear error message. Just overall good quality and clarity.

These questions are the easiest for CGPT to interpret. They're the most likely to get good output from the AI.
These are also the questions that are unlikely to get closed and most likely to get a human answer.

On the other hand there are those questions that are unclear, lacking a proper problem statement, lacking error messages, poorly formatted code, if there is any at all...
Those questions would benefit most from an AI that could figure out the problem and answer it.

Those are the questions that CGPT will write good-looking crap answers for.

So even *when* the bot produces some gems... They're not useful *on SO*.

---

TL;DR: Crap in, crap out.
The questions that need this bot can't benefit from it.

Comment: I've arrogantly tried it on a couple of my own questions assuming those are good, but it failed miserably. E.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53011097/class-terminate-not-firing-on-object-from-form), a VBA terminate handler not firing due to a reference loop between the class and some built-ins, it suggested "move the code to the initialize handler, then it'll fire" ‍♂️. When asking for unicode normalization for password storage, it provides an example that mojibakes the string...

Comment: @ErikA: _"They're the most likely to get good output"_ That doesn't necessarily mean they _will_ be good :D

Comment: It's currently 0/8 out of the reasonably short questions I've asked, so if that's _the most likely_, well, that's not great. And the answers it does come up with fall either into "plain wrong code", "an imaginary fun/arg that solves your problem but doesn't exist" or "you've missed the entire point of the question". I don't think CGPT can answer anything but the most trivial questions, even when the question is well formulated. And those trivial questions are likely duplicates, of course.

Comment: That's basically my point :D

Comment: Your answer makes it sound like it can answer clear, well written questions that could get answered by humans. My point is: that's only true if the answer is trivial too, since cGPT fails to solve clear and short questions with slightly difficult answers that humans can answer just fine. It even fails to interpret them and changes them to something that it has an answer to.

Comment: It _can_, but there's no guarantee. Nowhere am I claiming that writing a good question _guarantees_ a correct answer. It's just more likely.

Comment: Piling on examples of CGPT producing garbage, I tried it in [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/18660/21251) over on Vi.SE, where CGPT recommended to change `font` to `guifont` (which isn't a valid property in that context). When I told it that, it said to use `font`, and when I told it that doesn't work, right back to `guifont`. (I've more or less established that particular problem as a bug in Vim though, so it producing anything useful was already extremely unlikely. Was for science, and to see what it would answer, but makes for a great example)

Comment: While language models cannot provide all of the things that are demanded of them, they can still be an assistive technology in two ways: by summarizing long text for easier ingestion or by helping to write it in a well-structured manner.

Comment: Is there some data to measure the question rate? I mean after chatGPT was launched, did SO notice a drop in the question rate? Are there some numbers that compares pre and post chatGPT release having an effect on the question rate per minute here at SO?

Comment: I don't have any numbers, but multiple mods have stated that question range didn't drop at all, @joesan

Answer (score 16):

I don't see any way to 100% prevent AI-assisted answering.

The #1 most-effective way to prevent the flood of AI-assisted answers on Stack Overflow...

## Quickly close all closable questions.

Hammers? Use 'em if you got 'em.

---

The [FGITW](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18014/what-is-fgitw-and-scite#:%7E:text=FGITW%20%2D%20Fastest%20Gun%20in%20the,by%20%27oldest%20answer%20first) answerers were fast before, now they'll be faster.

Perhaps this is a call for offering silver/gold badgers abilities to close pages with greater speed.

Perhaps we should remove any earned rep if a page is closed within *n* days of being asked.  This way askers still get the answers that they need, but there will no longer be a reward for answering questions that should be closed.

I think I'll be a lot happier when AI can accurately assist me in finding good dupe targets (ideally canonicals) before anyone posts an answer.

---

P.S. Should we mandate that answerers explicitly declare the use of AI assistance?  such as `<sub>declaration</sub>`?

> <sub>This answer was assisted by artificial intelligence.</sub>

Comment: "*Quickly close all duplicate and off-topic questions.*" doesn't work, sorry. "*The FGTIW answerers were fast before, now they'll be faster.*" quite often a question would get one or more answers by the time it's hammered. Within the span of 2-3 minutes. I'm sitting on newest questions and trying to action them ASAP normally but even then finding a dupe might take longer than writing a simple answer. One question I closed in less than 5 minutes had FIVE ANSWERS by the time I hammered it. Now it's even simpler to write answers.

Comment: CGPT's terms even state that you must state that the content was AI-generated, that you may not pretend it to be your own.

Comment: "_This way askers still get the answers that they need_" Why is that even needed? That is not the purpose of Stack Overflow, there are other sites for that. But "_we should remove any earned rep if a page is closed within n days of being asked_" sounds like a good idea!

Comment: Are you asking: Why should askers get the answers that they need on a Q&A site??? @wov

Comment: @mickmackusa, no, I'm asking: why should questions that should be closed according to the site rules (because they are off-topic) get an answer anyway to please the (ignorant) asker? Obviously, good on-topic questions (that should not be closed) deserve an answer.

Comment: What is an FGTIW answerer?

Comment: @Lom https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18014/what-is-fgitw-and-scite#:~:text=FGITW%20%2D%20Fastest%20Gun%20in%20the,by%20'oldest%20answer%20first'. And [The Fight Against The FGITW and Dupe Ignoring](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394602/2943403) and [Remove the incentive for FGITW to answer well known dupes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/316564/2943403)

Comment: @wov not all dupes are bad.  Stack Exchange does not mind a few unique signposts that point to a single dupe target.  Duplicate-ness may be disputable, so allowing answers isn't ridiculous.

Comment: @Lomtrur Well, it should be FGITW but they went for "Fastest Gun The In West" problem instead.

Comment: @mickmackusa, I agree my remark does not fully apply to questions closed as duplicate (although I personally favor having all answers in one place instead of scathered around over many duplicate questions, but YMMV). However, it does apply to questions closed for other reasons. You state so yourself on your profile: "_This is why... I ask others not to post answers to questions that are incomplete, duplicates, or otherwise close-able._"

Comment: I think closing would be much more efficient with the help of active tag regulars. They currently tend to abstain of this because system pushes moderation of unfamiliar tags down their throats. Instead of bothering them with stuff "outside" they should just get opportunity to moderate where they are comfortable doing it, with [tag-filtered triage](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/409089/839601) and close voting powers [enhanced by tag badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/240702/165773)

Comment: How about a reputation penalty, each time a user is identified using AI-generated answers? Just a thought.

Comment: @AkshaySehgal many users who post a deluge of CGPT answers are new. They have 1 rep. Or have started posting the answers at 1 rep. There isn't really that much to "punish" them with. It might work for higher rep users who have started posting generated answers, however, I'd lean against that. Simple temporary ban (which is currently being issued) should put the message across. No real need to make a permanent mark.

Comment: Re _P.S. Should we mandate that answerers explicitly declare the use of AI assistance?_ - we already do.  Posting an AI generated answer as your own, without attribution is plagiarism.

Comment: @chrisneilsen, and (as already pointed out in one of the other answers) OpenAI [requires](https://openai.com/api/policies/sharing-publication/#content-co-authored-with-the-openai-api-policy) this as well, so not doing it is a violation of _both_ site rules.

Answer (score 14):

I think unmodified answers from ChatGPT should be banned, but if you use ChatGPT to generate an answer and then independently verify it and correct it to the best of your knowledge as needed, that should be allowed. It can be a useful tool, but simply taking answers from it as-is is often unhelpful.

Comment: I don't think this needs to be explicitly exempted. It usually takes more time and effort to *verify* a machine-generated answer than to write one yourself, with less garbage and verbosity included.

Comment: yeah i guess you're right, it probably has more value for asking about specific details than answering the entire question.

Comment: "unmodified answers from chatgpt should be banned" But how does one detect if the output from chatgpt was taken unmodified or not?

Comment: you can't necessarily tell for sure (well, you can try asking it the same question and see if you get a similar answer), but if it's an obviously low-effort/incorrect answer then it should be deleted. if there are no issues with the answer then it shouldn't really matter if chatgpt was involved in it.

Comment: It is a useful tool to help yourself, not others. I see chatgpt as an alternative to posting a question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: If users are taking the time to go through an auto-generated answer and verify its correctness before posting, credit its sources (even if this is actually possible for an auto-generated answer) and avoid plagiarism, etc. – and posting them at a reasonable rate (rather than flooding the site with bad answers), and improving them based on feedback in comments (rather than just dumping them on the site and then abandoning them) – then I would imagine it's harder to tell that they're even auto-generated. But at that point, there's little differentiating it from an answer fully written by a human.

Comment: Relevant XKCD: https://xkcd.com/810/

Comment: @iBug I use ChatGPT every day for my work as a software developer and I disagree. It's a much faster version of StackOverflow basically.

Comment: @NikS As others have pointed out multiple times: It's much faster at producing *plausible* answers that poses a greater problem to Stack Overflow than it seems.

Comment: if you can verify it, then you should just write the answer yourself. "correct it to the best of your knowledge as needed" and what if you don't have enough knowledge, you will let ChatGPT's mistakes slip in? this is a bad idea

Comment: @V2Blast More relevant than that: using ChatGPT [could prove self-referential](https://xkcd.com/978/) (which is not a good thing at all)

Comment: I love how existing scaffolding tools in Visual Studio/code aren't under fire, but using GPT is. This is the whole guns kill people instead of people (with guns) kill people argument. There's a lot of immaturity in this entire post. Furthermore, the arguments being made here act like GPT is spitting out 1000 line methods that no one understands. If you copy paste an answer from anywhere on SO without vetting it that is the source of the problem, not whether it came from GPT, a VS extension or MSDN forums.

Comment: @iBug - _"... takes more time and effort to verify a machine-generated answer than to write one yourself ..."_ is probably true if your first language is English.  However, for non first language English speakers, writing your own answer could be far more time-consuming than verifying and tweaking an AI-generated one.

Comment: I agree with this answer and the comment by @V2Blast. If someone has used ChatGPT to get an answer, taken the time to verify its correctness — the essential human curation step — and then posts it on SO, it could be useful to SO users. I would propose a citation along the lines of "Solution by ChatGPT, verified by me". Ultimately the important thing is answer quality, not where the answer came from.

Comment: I don't think acting all purest and banning suggestions from ChatGTP is a good idea.   In fact, letting it know how incorrect it is, is way more constructive in building better models for the future. There should be a clear demarcation if the suggestion is from ChatGTP.

Comment: Nothing we can do here would inform on how correct it is in a way that would be valuable to it's improvement. @Rahul

Comment: "I think unmodified answers from ChatGPT should be banned" how do you prove this, and there is no point banning something that can't be proven.

Comment: That's exactly the sane middle-ground (not a compromise to be clear) barely anyone is taking these days. Although difficult to manage as DubDub said.

Comment: You probably meant "unverified" instead of "unmodified". There is no way to "ban" AI. This platform itself will have no option but to use AI in order to flag potentially incorrect answers and help its "swamped volunteer-based quality curation infrastructure".

Answer (score 14):

I think this is the right decision.

The artificial replies can sound authoritative because they may have better grammar than the human contributions. The reply generators are tireless. They could easily overwhelm the human authorities.

> The ban is temporary.

All things are temporary. The ban should stay for as long as it is needed.

> The artificial replies cannot be trusted.

We are seeing good and bad answers. There are many bad answers just now, but AI progress is rapid. They may be a valuable tool quite soon. Not in a hundred years? They are better than they were *last week*.

Quality is an issue, but it is not the whole issue. We should not invite AI replies once their quality equals our human contributors. We should exclude them until we understand what their replies are, and the nature of their failings.

> We cannot tell whether a reply is from AI or not.

This is true. If we can tell the difference, then the AI can be trained to see the difference and correct for it. Some people may take ChatGPT answers and post them as their own. Others may post replies from their own model to test it, and to gather training data. A simple filter, such as limiting the reply time to a typical typing speed, may stop us getting swamped. But it won't last.

We can ask people not to post AI answers. If we threaten with bans, or talk about our chatbot filtering, some people will take it as a challenge.

Perhaps a longer term solution might be to work with AI. Suppose all dialogues had an option to generate an AI answer using the current popular models. You could see a reply to the question or the whole dialogue, while knowing it had been generated by an AI.

Comment: Agreed on "All bans are temporary", and this is a an important point: it is downright **weird** (and worrying!) that the temporariness is explicitly mentioned in this particular instance but for nothing else.

Comment: I like your reply very much. If you don't mind my saying, using ChatGPT to detect ChatGPT is a contradiction..
You wrote "We should not invite AI replies <until> their quality equals our human contributors". What is good quality? There are answers from ChatGPT to questions on StackOverflow that are just as good as human generated answers. There are many wrong answers given by humans. I strongly believe that ChatGPT will outrank the highest ranked member of StackOverflow in the near future, maybe before the decade is over.

Answer (score 14):

**TL;DR**

Even from the point of view of AI researchers, Stack Overflow and other sites with mostly human generated content should ban or force labelling of AI generated content, as otherwise this will cause a circular reasoning catastrophic failure as the newly generated content past year 2022 cannot be fed to train newer AI models anymore since we can't know what was generated by humans or by older AI models.

**Longer argument**

I would like to provide an alternative perspective, not from the standpoint of Stack Overflow human users, but from Artificial Intelligence researchers.

It's highly likely that [GPT-3 and hence ChatGPT was trained on all of Stack Overflow data](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/38663/1880). This worked because all the inputs at the time was human generated. (PS: Let's put aside the discussion whether it's ethical for AI researchers to use 3rd-party content to train AI models without asking the respective owners - I am here focusing on the fact that it already happened, that this cannot be undone, and the impact on our current and future situation).

Now, if answers from humans are mixed with answers generated by AI, we get a tampered dataset that will be unusable to train future [LLM](https://theamericangenius.com/tech-news/large-language-models/) or other language models, because it will cause a hugely flawed circular reasoning loop, as we now feed an AI model data that an older AI model generated, without being able to determine what was generated by humans or by AI.

This means that if we can't ensure that most answers remain generated by humans, this will lead to a catastrophic failure of AI models, as it will simply become impossible to use newer data to make newer models: 2022 will become an "event horizon for AI" , with data generated prior to this year being still usable for training, but any data generated past being mostly unusable because of being tainted potentially in great proportions by AI generated content.

So this issue is not even just specific to Stack Overflow: all websites should either ban the use of AI generated content, or force such content to be labelled as AI generated. But even so, it will only work with compliant users. Since there is no 100% reliable way to detect textual AI generated content, and given we can always expect people to [game the system especially when there are incentives to do so](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perverse_incentive), this catastrophic failure seems all but inevitable.

Comment: Honestly, this sounds like entirely the problem of the researchers. I'm not sure why sites being spammed by these AIs would be sympathetic to the further creation of more of these models.

Comment: The training data could be filtered to remove AI-generated content (As that content is detectable). Doesn't mean SO should allow AI-generated content, but it's not really SO's responsibility to provide usable training data.

Comment: @JAD Your opinion sounds very manichean. When not used for spamming, AI has wonderful applications that already changed our current world. In any case, hating a tool is fruitless, just like hating a knife. It can be used for good and bad. I only argue that even from the point of view of AI researchers and users, there is no medium to long-term benefit to accepting AI generated answers, only (catastrophically bad) downsides. So whether you look from the POV of SE users, or from AI users/researchers, banning is one of the few reasonable solutions.

Comment: @Cerbrus There is no filter that is 100% effective, and it's very easy to workaround these filters with slightly modified models or post-processing, there are already loads of posts like that on social networks by AI users (not even researchers). And I never wrote that it's SO/SE responsibility to provide usable training data, I only provided an alternative viewpoint that also converges towards the same solution. It seems there is a radicalization of "us vs them" mindset, sad to see. Even though my opinion agrees with the ban, it's ditched just for taking the point of view of another party.

Comment: i simply don't see how this addresses the policy at all. You aren't contesting the policy, you state you agree with it... but that's what the upvote button is for. Nothing else in the answer is relevant to the policy decision.

Comment: Re *"it's very easy to workaround these filters with slightly modified models or post-processing"*: Yes, but fortunately the worst abusers also have the minimum effort attitude (in other words, they couldn't be bothered).

Comment: @gaborous The point of view of the other party is, frankly, irrelevant when discussing SO policy.

Comment: @Cerbrus AI not another party but a technology, just like the (AI-based) recommendation system of SO/SE. Unless we consider SO to be a closed-loop system, which I find implausible since it is a publicly accessible website, I think it is extremely short-sighted to dismiss any non-SO-centric perspective. The perspective I offer is just more systematic, accounting for other factors and the wider technological landscape. I make no claim it should be the primary perspective, I explicitly wrote it is an alternative one, a "food for thought" if you prefer.

Comment: Its interesting, how researchers label Machine-generated data while implicitly fetching data for training. ?

Answer (score 11):

The more I use ChatGPT, the more I agree with this policy. I asked it "Can you explain the difference classes of amateur radio licenses?", and it said this:

> There are three classes of amateur radio licenses in the United States: Technician, General, and Extra. Each class of license has its own set of privileges and requirements.
>
> The Technician class license is the entry-level license for amateur radio operators. It allows the licensee to operate on all amateur radio frequencies above 30 megahertz, including the very popular 2-meter and 70-centimeter bands. Technician licensees are not allowed to use the HF (high-frequency) bands, which are the bands used for long-distance communication.
>
> The General class license is the intermediate level license. It allows the licensee to operate on all amateur radio frequencies, including the HF bands. General class licensees are also allowed to use higher-power transmitters and to operate certain types of equipment that are not available to Technician licensees.
>
> The Extra class license is the highest level of amateur radio license. It allows the licensee to operate on all amateur radio frequencies, including the HF bands, and to use the highest power levels allowed by law. Extra class licensees are also allowed to use a wider range of equipment and to operate in certain types of specialized modes, such as digital modes and satellite communications.
>
> To obtain an amateur radio license, an individual must pass a written examination administered by a team of volunteer examiners. The examination covers the rules and regulations governing the operation of amateur radio stations, as well as basic concepts in electronics and radio theory. The level of difficulty of the examination increases with each class of license, with the Extra class license being the most difficult to obtain.

This seemingly very well-written answer is wrong in several ways.

1. Technician licensees are allowed to use certain small parts of some HF bands, with restrictions.
2. General licensees can use large portions of all *bands*, but there are Extra-only frequencies within many of the bands.
3. On VHF and higher bands, all licensees have exactly the same privileges. General licensees being able to use higher power than Technicians is true on HF bands, but it is not universally true.
4. Extra licensees have the same power limits General licensees do.
5. Virtually any transceiver that an Extra can use can also be used by a General licensee.
6. Even Technicians can use digital modes and satellites. All licensees can use all modes; they're just limited to certain frequencies.

If/when a better AI for answering programming questions is developed, I think it would be helpful to have an authorized way to post AI answers such as [my suggestion from a previous answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/422038/19104886), but having used ChatGPT more, I've realized that it isn't that AI (yet).

Comment: @Rubén I'd previously posted an answer arguing against the ban and suggesting a way to allow AI answers, but having used ChatGPT more I decided it's not really a good idea at this time. I don't want to delete my old answer because I still think it will be a good way to handle AI if/when it becomes good enough to be useful for answering SO questions.

Comment: The accuracy of describing radio licenses doesn't seem hugely relevant for [SO]'s topics.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi but it's still a good example of how ChatGPT can sound very knowledgeable and confident, but be totally wrong.

Comment: @Someone That's true. It wouldn't have triggered any of my usual red flags. Interestingly enough, it also doesn't trigger any of the things I look out for in ChatGPT answers.

Comment: Please bear in mind that this "question" is not a "call for *whatever*". It might be OK to provide feedback about how the situation was handled previous to the launch of the help article that bans the use of chatGPT, but I not see any reason to polute this question with "ideas" or "opinions"

Comment: @Rubén so all of the other answers explaining why people support or oppose the policy are off topic too? I saw that there are quite a few of them and thought it was okay to post another.

Comment: Each "answer" should be directly related to the question, if you want to criticize other answers that usually should be done posting comments direclty to the corresponding answer. If a comment don't provide enough  room it might be fine to post another answer but it should include a link to the criticized post, but only if that is directly related to the question... answers should not divert from the question topic.

Comment: @Rubén I'm not really criticizing any answer. I'm just giving another piece of information supporting the policy.

Comment: This is not the place for that and regading the temporary ban set by the mods that is late.

Comment: @Rubén since it's temporary, that means it could end. I would suggest that it not be ended unless/until ChatGPT improves significantly.

Comment: It looks that you missed [New help center article and banner on the site about GPT-Generated content](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421991/1595451)

Comment: The answers by ChatGPT are most of the times very general. Maybe good if you don't know anything about a topic but not good enough to learn much more about a specific problem, not to speak of solving a problem. It's definitely not a problem solver although kind of a search engine giving you some general insight into topics. That's what the current status of ChatGPT seems to be to me.

Comment: This is an illustration of the fallacy of how the answers are farmed. The Extra class manual contains a section on satellites not found in the other manuals, and it shows up as a topic covered deeply only on that license exam, but it has nothing to do with what's allowed by that license at the exclusion of others. Similarly, a question about Oracle might wind up drifting off into ISO SQL or vice versa. -- K7COI

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, I disagree. This is a great illustration of the fallacy of farming answers by the false appearance of textual relevance.

Comment: as long as it is an answer that can be used in certain circumstances and no one is around to dispute it, it is a useful answer (conditionally)

Answer (score 11):

I am shocked today to get presented a banner “Learn more about AI on Stack Overflow”.

I **very much** hope and expect the ban on using ML/LLM (so-called “AI”) on writing on SO/SE will continue.

Do we have any updates on that?

Comment: We should soon, for better or worse

Comment: I got *"New! OverflowAI: Where Community & AI Come Together"* (linking to [Stack Overflow Labs](https://stackoverflow.co/labs/))

Comment: If you click the banner, you will learn that it doesn't have much to do with human users posting LLM-generated answers. The timing might not be great, but the ideas they are presenting do have some merit.

Comment: The terms Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange have become blurred as to their scope. On SE here is one site for starters  ...  https://genai.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @mirabilos https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79593/what-is-the-difference-between-stack-overflow-and-stack-exchange

Comment: @user10186832 totally irrelevant

Answer (score 10):

In one line: I want a pure "human" platform, and for this reason I am on Stack Overflow.

In truth, I have learnt coding from SO, and I believe that every line of coding on SO is tested by humans, on a real project with their own hands. (This is mostly true for accepted answers.)

On the other hand, I have used ChatGPT for only for three days and came back.  Please don’t ask me about the experience. I do not want to remember that I could lost my coding knowledge. uffffff!

Comment: _"I believe that every line of coding on SO is tested by humans, on a real project with their own hands"_ - hahahaha.

Comment: @CodeCaster, so AI tested your question and code on  his own project?  Ha Ha Ha!   All are fake. I know my opinions cross worrd and thinkings, but must  see that the word I have used is "believe".  Try to know  the meaning of this word. " will be or has to be or should be" hide behind the word silently.  The result is "could be"

Comment: At least your motivation is sound "I want a pure human platform". That's a valid preference that doesn't even need to be substantiated with reasonable arguments. However, I don't have that desire, I want a platform that will still be relevant in 10 years and for that to happen the attitude towards AI needs to change drastically.

Answer (score 9):

I believe that AI answers should not be allowed on Stack Overflow.  Stack Overflow is a repository of user experience and knowledge.  ChatGPT uses such data to train but it does not create new knowledge.  Beyond the fact that ChatGPT produces many errors and presents them as correct, it can bring no new information or experience to bear to create an answer.

I believe it has some value in the correct context, but not in the context of Stack Overflow.  If a person wants an AI answer experience they can use the AI directly; there isn't any need to use Stack Overflow as a proxy.

Comment: I’m not so sure that it can’t bring new knowledge in the context of SO, or even generally. Such an AI is trained on much larger data set than just SO, and it can at least combine existing information to adjust it to new context (both inter- and extrapolation cover more than the training set). Both of these could add to SO - at least in principle if the output were factually reliable.

Comment: My point is that all of the knowledge is created by people.  ChatGPT doesn't create knowledge.   SO and ChatGPT are two different ways of accessing that knowledge.  They each have a distinct place; we should NOT homogenize them.  What we need is knowledgeable people to contribute to SO; turning SO into a static repository of AI answers will discourage that.

Comment: This sounded like a ChatGPT answer!!!

Comment: It's quite simple: If you want ChatGPT, you know where to find it.

Answer (score 9):

My take on AI-generated answers is this:

Using ChatGPT and similar services is very easy. It's comparable to Google Translate. If you want an AI-generated answer, then you simply use one of those services.

Compare to the language sites. If you ask for a translation, then what you're looking for is something else than what Google Translate produces. If you wanted something from there, then you would use that service instead of asking on a forum.

I think it's good to assume that a user who is asking a question on a forum has tried those easy-to-use services and found them unsatisfying. Note that I'm not saying that it is likely that they have done it. Just that it is good to assume it, in the sense that you should answer a question as if ChatGPT or Google Translate was not enough for the asker.

Answer (score 7):

What if we fend off AI-generated content with AI-assisted moderation?

The video sharing service I use the most often in China - BiliBili, has an AI-based moderation bot called Avalon, and it monitors for harmful content, makes automatic decisions when harm score is high, and defers to human moderators when it's lacking confidence. It's constantly improving itself based on the evolution of contents and input from human moderators. (Of course, being in China, we also use it for censorship in addition to day-to-day moderation).

This is just my personal opinion, but I think investing in an AI-assisted moderation system is worth it in the long term.

Comment: The current situation with moderation bots on Quora (with unspecified IQ) is a complete disaster. Though detection of text as images could be a useful addition here.

Comment: There was the unfriendly comments detector robot where they used AI-assisted moderation already with moderators being the final decision makers but an AI model was used for automated flagging. The same could probably be done for a "really bad answer" category. However, it's kind of sad to see that this basically results in a technology battle between spammers and cleaners, instead of humans learning how to improve their skills.

Comment: This isn't up to SO moderation but rather up to the company behind SO. Good luck convincing them.

Comment: I like the idea of AI-assisted moderation.  Humans still making the final decisions, but automation providing tools to make their job easier/quicker.  Still, banning people from posting ChatGPT answers as their own answers seems like an obvious no-brainer to me...

Comment: I don't know. I've been flagged on MSN.com numerous times for stating various things such as: political views; religious views; and, I believe sometimes just simply stating facts. The problem is the algorithm on MSN.com has a notable liberal bias and Microsoft doesn't seem to have any intention of correcting that. This actually goes against Microsoft's core principles of: inclusiveness, fairness, transparency and in some cases even safety...

Comment: This is a contradiction. You want to ban AI with the very same technology that you are banning? This sounds like the old computer science problem of a program that debugs itself - not possible.

Comment: What if INDEED - https://stackoverflow.co/teams/ai/

Comment: @bmike OverflowAI is ***not*** "AI-assisted moderation"

Answer (score 5):

I agree with the ban. Stack Overflow is for questions that the author researched and tried to find an answer for and is still stumped. Questions that require a decent level of expertise to answer appropriately.

If an answerer can paste the question into ChatGPT and get an answer, so can the asker. If a question could have been answered correctly by ChatGPT, then probably the question was poorly researched anyway.

But high quality questions deserve high quality answers. A good asker would have already put their question through ChatGPT and not have gotten a satisfactory answer, and are asking on Stack Overflow for a human expert written answer.

Answer (score 5):

LLM generated answers should always be banned and the reason has nothing to do with whether LLM answers are low or high quality. It beggars belief that some people think LLM answers are worth posting here when every person and their dog can generate literally hundreds of them with minimal effort. I come to Stack Overflow because I am after a human answer. If I wanted an LLM answer, I could have just entered my question into an LLM myself!

Comment: If LLM answers were of a quality __indistinguishable__ from human answers, they'd be fine. But they're not, and _that_ is why they're not allowed. Quality has everything to do with this.

Comment: @Cerbrus If LLMs could reliably produce the exact same content as human answerers in every single case, we wouldn't need Stack Overflow at all - you could just consult ChatGPT yourself in every case and get the answers much faster. However, given that LLMs are just synthesizing existing human content, their capacity to generate novel content and new information will necessarily lag behind humans - if no human has written something related to that, they would have no way to know about it. I think that there will always be advantages to human answers, so I agree with the basic point here.

Comment: Well, sure, that as well, but the flood of low quality content is what initially triggered this ban.

Answer (score 2):

The spirit of Stack Overflow is that it's from developers to developers, which is quite more than a question-answer site.

While generative AI can often give right answers, especially for simple-to-medium questions, there is a billion questions on Stack Overflow which are more helpful already than their answers. This spirit needs to be preserved.

And why would someone use an [LLM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_language_model) to automate answering? I don't see any other reason, except abuse of the rating system. Abuse should be banned.

Comment: There are [23,975,364 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) on Stack Overflow.

Comment: In ***what way*** are questions more helpful than answers?

Comment: @PeterMortensen there are plenty of questions which show almost working solution to a problem, but require a tweak, which an author won't know. It's a well-known phenomenon of SO that sometimes questions are more helpful than answers. 

Another way how questions can be helpful is getting to know things you never imagined exist or are a problem, just by scrolling through them. And of course, figuratively speaking, there is a billion helpful questions, sorry for confusion, won't edit.

Answer (score -2):

I've given a lot of time before writing this because I think at this point we all have been able to digest and rationalize what is happening around this phenomena.

First of all, I fully agree with the temporary policy, and I am in favor that it becomes a "permanent temporary" one.

The main reason I'm on that opinion is not the fact of the tool being available, but the way so many people were using it: as a copy-pastable BS generator for social networking engagement (in our case, SO reputation). This alone spawns several reasons for why it should be banned, but I don't have to point them out anymore, as it should be common knowledge right now.

I am **not** in favour of computer-aided code writing as a tool to show examples of how a particular question can be solved. That is a job for [GitHub Copilot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub_Copilot) or other places, not for this website. People can go straight to GPT-3's playground and ask the program to write code for them as an additional reference, but Stack Overflow should remain as human-aided different points of view in a given problem in the form of a question.

---

On the other hand,

> (here comes the downvoting...) xD

I would like to add to the debate "legitimate" use of the technology. Consider some people who are savvy on the topic of the community (in our case, programming), but they are not proficient in the use of English or in a general sense, for whatever reason, haven't developed very good communication abilities.

Would you consider the potential contributions of such a person less valuable than another one who can express themselves "better" (in the sense of getting their point across close to the most optimal possible way)?

Now take the conclusion you've reached by reading the last two paragraphs and let's see what professionals of the marketing area are doing. They're using ChatGPT as a tool for computer-aided writing. Sure, the lazy ones are just copying and pasting whatever the program spits out, but in the hands of a capable professional, ChatGPT is much more powerful and is faster than hours of googling, which is what they were doing until now.

Also, that is what we programmers were doing until now. Of course, our main sources of inspiration are probably Stack Overflow, but there's a lot of forums around. Just like [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/tour) users rely mostly on Server Fault, but the [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/ArchWiki) is still a reliable curated source of information, among other wikis and forums. But we all became dependent on search engines like [Google Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Search).

Come to think about it, it came as no particular surprise to me that [Microsoft decided to integrate ChatGPT into the Bing search engine](https://blogs.microsoft.com/blog/2023/02/07/reinventing-search-with-a-new-ai-powered-microsoft-bing-and-edge-your-copilot-for-the-web/).

There is a specific [ELI5](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ELI5) [prompt on the ChatGPT API examples page](https://platform.openai.com/examples/default-summarize) that try to show how to use the power of synthetic dialectics to further clarify a subject. The job of a communicator is to find the best words in the best order to exchange an idea to a specific target group. And in that field, ChatGPT is not a terrific tool, but it can aid many people as it is right now.

---

My point is that computer-assisted writing is a beneficial thing. People can use it to write better **questions** primarily, but also improve their answers' wording. This is specially useful for the handful of people I've described earlier: the ones proficient in programming, but not as much in writing English, or in communicating in general.

The distinction between computer-assisted writing and copy pasting from a BS generator should be obvious.

I could send this whole answer to proof reading humans or ChatGPT and bet excellent feedback from the humans, but reasonable good feedback from the program. It would look less like I'm the author of it, but in both cases, you, the reader, would struggle less to understand what I want to tell you. **DISCLAIMER: I did neither. This is 100% my first take on writing the answer, without revision.**

Finally, my opinion is that people should somehow feel that it's ok to use computer programs to aid their writing. I'm not sure how the [anti GPT policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy) could be further improved to include this, or if is it even necessary.

I will repeat this paragraph from the beginning, now that the reader has a new perspective:

I am **not** in favour of computer-aided code writing as a tool to show examples of how a particular question can be solved. That is a job for GitHub Copilot or other places, not for this website. People can go straight to GPT-3's playground and ask the program to write code for them as an additional reference, but Stack Overflow should remain as human-aided different points of view in a given problem in the form of a question.

Comment: *Why* use ChatGPT for computer-aided writing? Why not use translators and/or Grammarly and/or other tools that fill this niche? Honestly, the most likely outcomes I can see from using ChatGPT to "aide" writing is a) copy/paste. So pretty much exactly the same as now. But the user can claim "me not good speaker, used ChatGPT to aide". b) ChatGPT fumbles the writing and does *not* represent the idea the user wanted to put across correctly. There is also a chance that it's OK, however, what are the chances that a user needs tool assist will *recognise* bad output?

Comment: @VLAZ looks like ChatGPT agrees with you: https://platform.openai.com/playground/p/CIue5Co3qtD3ifAO50UOgE1w?model=text-davinci-003

Comment: Code completion isn't a substitute for professional engineering. Using code completion tools doesn't make you an engineer, let alone a good engineer. Code completion tools optimize an expert's workflow, but it's not the workflow unto itself.

Comment: @Makoto I stated two times the exact same paragraph in my original unedited text arguing against code completion on SO

Comment: Then you've used a whole lot of words to simply say that you agree with this. There's been plenty of prose on this matter and there's really not a lot of value to keep _adding_ to it unless you're offering a completely unique take on it.

Comment: I'm sympathetic to the concept of using LLM-based tools (not necessarily ChatGPT) to clean up one's writing. But there's a danger that the tool will say something different to what the writer intends, especially if their English skills aren't strong. That could lead to greater misunderstanding. If I see clear confident English I tend to assume the author knows what they're talking about. If the writing has a few flaws I can tell the author is struggling to express themself, so I might not have the correct interpretation, and I may need to post a comment for clarification.

Comment: @PM2Ring fun fact - you can interact with ChatGPT in languages other than English. For example, you can instruct it to translate something in English. However, the training it has had other than English is a bit hit and miss. I have no confidence whatsoever it will be able to correctly pick up the meaning in another language. I've seen it ***very badly*** misinterpreting rather simple prompts when not in English.

Comment: I’m really not a fan for using ChatGPT to translate or significantly brush up technical writing. Since the tool basically makes up stuff, it is absolutely vital that the posting user can verify all of its output; if that output is much more sophisticated or even entirely unintelligible to the posting user, they can’t do that.

Comment: @Makoto agree with what? Your wording makes me think that you think I'm either agreeing or disagreeing with the anti ChatGPT policy, which is not the point of my answer whatsoever.

Comment: @PM2Ring that is a fair point, but in this circumstance people are already struggling with tools like Google Translate and getting worse results. If they include the customary disclaimer that they're not proficient in English and they're being aided by online tools, they'll be fine as always

Comment: @VLAZ I happen to use ChatGPT exclusively on Brazilian Portuguese and I though that was the same output I'd get from English.

Comment: Even during translation or editing, ChatGPT is prone to introducing falsehoods or misstating facts to the level that they become incorrect. Often this creates the appearance of lying from the author, when the intent was simply to address any grammar or spelling issues. The tool really causes more harm than good, and that is why it is banned.

Answer (score -12):

I see things differently.

### 1. We all gain from using AI tools

We all know that AI tools are created by developers like us, not only for the end user, but also for the developers. Even an expert prefers an editor with colored code rather than a black-on-white editor.

The world of AI is developing rapidly and we all benefit from finding cases where tools like ChatGPT will be useful for our community and how to use them instead of acting like it's some weird tool that we don't know how it works.

Having tested ChatGPT, I find it to be a very good tool for general knowledge. Like other testers, I found a lot of mistakes in the answers when I ask technical questions, but it is still a great tool that we should use in the community.

### 2. The ban should be permanent for answers generated from any resource.

I personally use Stack Overflow since I'm a novice and it helps me and helped me a lot especially when I started: it was my first search engine and I think it's not about ChatGPT or other tools, but about developers who copy and paste answers from resources without being able to validate or explain them in context.

ChatGPT just increased the priority of problems we've already had.

While AI is getting more and more accurate, it's not very efficient for us to allow an AI-generated response in a response thread, because our human response (even if incorrect) is an information about how we are thinking (in a computer context) and that's useful data in analysis.

Allowing AI-generated responses will corrupt this data set. Simple example: without AI responses, we are currently able to say "According to Stack Overflow data, developers learn 2 more languages and 5 more frameworks every 5 years". This kind of information is useful and it's just one of thousands of cases. So I think we definitely need to ban AI-generated responses in our current response thread.

It takes time to write a good response and I don't think people who know what they are talking about should want to copy and paste responses from a resource. So I suggest adding some new features to the reply editor:

- Disable copy and paste as clean text:
  The developer should write everything in their own words, and even if there is a typo, it is not a problem. We can have tools that clone and correct the written response before publishing the correction.
- We need to highlight all the pasted data and it should not be editable. A more powerful change would be to manage it as a resource that should have a link and a description of how to find (or generate) that resource.

### 3. AI should be used in Stack Overflow

As I said, I really think ChatGPT is a good tool and that's why I suggest the community train its own model for a text-based bot that will be more accurate in the computing context and integrated into our search bar. That way we give the developer the choice when searching for something to go through the bot generated answers or explore solutions provided by other developers.

Comment: It's not clear to me what your proposal is for using AI in the site (is it only to improve the search functionality?), and it seems way off on a tangent anyway. If your proposal is that the site should run questions through ChatGPT first before offering a submit button, that has already been roundly rejected: it risks a flood of people leaving with broken code that we don't know anything about.

Comment: "We need to highlight all the pasted data and it should not be editable. A more powerful change would be to manage it as a resource that should have a link and a description of how to find (or generate) that resource." Aside from being absurd, this would be trivially circumvented by anyone who knew about it, by just doing the copying and pasting in a separate program. I am generally against putting arbitrary speed bumps like that into the UI, especially if they are not **very** explicitly explained.

Comment: seems kinda odd to expect a language model to be able to link user search queries with accurate search results. Wouldn't any other "AI" built *for* search indexing serve that purpose better?

Answer (score -14):

**Possible Improvement Idea - Improve how we humans upvote answers.**

From reading the previous answers to this thread, it seems a lot of the motivation for the bad behavior of posting non-validated answers quickly, regardless of whether they were generated by ChatGPT, is motivated by "point farming". One way that users like us can help "fix" the problem is to not upvote nice and shiny looking answers and comments that we have not validated.

... *We should only upvote answers that we have actually validated.*

We should not upvote a response that we haven't tested and proved to work just because it *looks like* they know what they are talking about or just because it *sounds good*. That means I should first test whether the proposed answer is actually a valid answer and then come back to the answer and upvote it.

Comment: Specify "validated". How would you enforce this? How would you change hoe people vote?

Comment: "*One way we that users like us can help "fix" the problem is to not upvote answers and comments that look nice and shiny but which we have not validated.*" The past *over a decade* of this site existing has shown this is not how users vote. A *more interesting looking* solution often gets more upvotes than a *more thorough* or even *more correct* one. I don't see how you expect the voting for all users to change. Saying "let's do it this way instead" doesn't actually accomplish that.

Comment: What do you mean by *"One way we that users"* (seems incomprehensible)?

Comment: Re *"first test whether the proposed answer is actually a valid answer and then come back to the answer and upvote it"*: That would be great. No, really. It didn't happen before ChatGPT (there are likely ***a lot*** of undetected ***completely bogus answers*** on Stack Overflow posted before December 2022. For instance, the many code dumps without any explanation whatsoever. Say, copied from other completely unrelated answers on Stack Overflow or copied from elsewhere on the Internet (say, from the official documentation))

Comment: I fully agree that is how it *ideally should* be. Yet I don’t see how it *practically could* be.

Answer (score -15):

I feel the ban is good and should be permanent because we have to remember that ChatGPT is really just a more interactive search engine and its results, whilst clever, are still the result of scraping existing web pages - just like any other search engine.

By allowing ChatGPT answers on Stack Overflow (and other sites), we'd be creating an echo chamber whereby the answers it generates are simply based on its previous answers, which may not have been right in the first place.

Comment: Chat GPT is an AI Chatbot that got trained a while ago with large amounts of data from websites/books etc. It isn't a search engine and it doesn't scrape existing websites. It would probably be more accurate if it just copied code from a website.

Comment: @PhobosFerro You comment contradicts itself. If it was trained with data from websites then it's still dependent on the content of websites and will have to be updated to keep relevant. How it actually gets the new data may not be scraping but it will still be reading its own answers.

Comment: Do you have first-hand experience using it as an interactive search engine (not a rhetorical question)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen the branded "new Bing" does that. What it does is: user makes a search query, Microsoft does a regular Bing search, send parsed results as part o a prompt to OpenAI's GPT4, and finally it answers as an interactive chat search.

Answer (score -15):

I'm curious how this policy can co-exist with the now public stance that Stack Overflow is going to be training AI models on content here.

- https://stackoverflow.co/teams/ai/

I understand a lot of work and thought have gone into this policy as there were significant negative repercussions, but "AI for me, and not for thee" seems a bit too much on the nose to be sustainable.

Comment: Posting of generated content is still banned. OverflowAI is not in conflict with this, since it's not about posting anything. With that said, it's widely agreed that the company has made poor choices in what projects they pursue.

Comment: Isn’t it pretty normal that the provider has more privileges than the users?

Comment: @VLAZ I head you, however no one should ignore the implied judgement the company has announced:  **We will make good use** of AI tools. **You will not make good use** of AI tools. Over the next several quarters we all will see what really happens, but as an observer from another site, I felt the need to speak up when got news in a 2 week period of "put this banner up saying NO AI followed by a featured post COME GET AI".

Comment: @bmike again, I'm telling you the company has not been ignored.

Comment: @bmike because user input has never been the problem, right?

Comment: @bmike Except that a lot of the people posting AI content weren't making **good** use of it.

Answer (score -16):

I can totally understand that AI generated answers bring up potential risks in terms of correctness and useful content, since, especially in the universe of developers, answers of AIs are very often not only wrong, but also do not show  best practices.

The view changes for me when it comes to the notion of banning AI from "enhancing" posts. Using AIs on comments which are intellectual source of individuals could potentially improve the vocabulary and grammar of many questions and answers on Stack Overflow. So it would in my opinion make more sense to encourage people to prepare questions/answers and assess improvements with AIs, rather than risking negative feedback due to misunderstandings or bad expressions.

Comment: The ban is a blanket ban because it is not feasible to *distinguish* generated from "enhanced" content. From that standpoint it simply didn’t matter how good the good case is, as long as the bad case is bad enough.

Comment: If you have a proposal for how we can tell "enhanced" posts from generated ones, with minimal human labor, then add that your answer, I'm sure the community would be interested to hear it. Until we have such a mechanism, we have to treat both the same.

Comment: Well, I think it is less "a thing" that needs control, but rather more important to raise awareness in how to use such tools. Using AIs can bring also positive impact and is not only a risk factor as long as people are aware about how to use it.
I think Stackoverflow, as the worldwide leading platform for the development industry has an obligation to act as a role model since banning in general terms and "marking" AIs as evil is easy (with questionable outcome), but the more courageous approach would be in explaining, how such tools could be integrated into workflows and the community.

Comment: "_could potentially improve the vocabulary and grammar_" there are already tools out there for this which don't use generative AI...

Comment: @EmadEasa Feel free to explain or explore that in an appropriate format, perhaps a separate meta-Q&A. This Q&A is about the ban itself and not the appropriate place to raise awareness for what you have in mind.

Comment: Stack Overflow's purpose is to serve as a repository of high quality Q&A. I'm not sure why you think we're obligated to serve as an AI advocate on top of that, especially when doing so would compromise our actual purpose.

Answer (score -16):

## Preface

In the past when searching for the answer to some problem with your favorite search engine, you could easily find the same answer many times, even though it was obviously wrong (not working).

That was (I suspect) due to the fact that many users just copied answers from elsewhere without citing where they got it from, or due to "re-framing", that is, some site just placed a new frame and some advertising around another site. Fortunately, the latter have vanished mostly meanwhile.

## ChatGPT

I think ChatGPT and alike are impressive, but there are still severe problems:
I have a (seemingly simple) programming problem that I couldn’t solve myself reading the documentation, so I used Google to search for solutions. I had tried a few, but none worked, so I tried ChatGPT.

ChatGPT provided a "solution" that looked similar to the ones I had seen before, but actually it didn't work either.
So I told it that the solution did not work, and ChatGPT provided me with another "solution" (that also did not work).

I think the above clearly shows the problem with ChatGPT:
It cannot tell where it got its wisdom from, and the answers may be incorrect without ChatGPT knowing.

## Any use?

Still, I could imagine (monetary and legal issues left aside) that SO integrates ChatGPT for newly asked (or to be asked) questions:

- It could be used to find similar (equivalent) questions before posting the question.  I saw many questions about the same problem (like "find string *X* in input *Y*"), where the posters were unable to abstract the problem to the root problem, not even partially.
- It could suggest an "answer" before posting the question: If ChatGPT could provide a correct answer, there isn't any need to post the question on SO (maybe because the question is rather trivial also).

Comment: [You can already sign up to AI search](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425766/preview-of-search-and-question-asking-powered-by-genai). What's the point in having an AI suggested answer if your experience suggests that it simply doesn't work. Isn't that just a waste of their time?

Comment: There's no guarantee that answers *do work*, but there also is no guarantee that answers *do not work*. So the OP could give it a try.

Comment: Erm, but you did give it a try and it wasted your time.

Comment: *"you could easily find the same answer many times, even though it was obviously wrong"* i mean... if every answer you tried that worked for someone else doesn't work for you, isn't it more likely that means something is different in your environment or your implementation rather than what worked for n other people was also a wrong answer?

Comment: Overflow AI isn't supposed to generate new answers, it's supposed to present existing ones. So if your problem is all existing answers are solving a problem differently than you  need them to... having Overflow AI find the answers for you isn't going to be any better than standard search.

Comment: The experience you describe is the exact reason ChatGPT answers are not allowed. They are almost always wrong. Essentially if you don’t have the knowledge necessary to validate them which is almost always true for anyone using ChatGPT to submit an answer to a question they cannot author themselves

Comment: @Kevin B No there actually exist nonsense answers that cannot work, but still people copy them. I once (in the times of MS-DOS) I knew someone swearing the command to start Turbo Pascal is `exit`, because when he had started a shell from Turbos Pascal, `exit` seemingly started Turbos Pascal from there seemingly. OK, this is an extreme example...

Comment: I'm not quite sure where you got the impression that i don't think nonsense answers exist. What I'm saying is if every answer you find is nonsense... there's another common denominator there that could be the actual problem.

Comment: I completely disagree with the last point of this answer: since this generated answer might very well contain absolute nonsense, nothing like this should be shown. Answer without this part, answer is not related to the ban: we already have suggested similar questions (however crappy they are), and changing algorithm of their suggestion is out of the scope here.

Comment: ChatGPT works as a highly unreliable, but sometimes useful, advisor. For example, it is good at guessing typos and [SIAs](https://pmortensen.eu/world/EditOverflow.php?LookUpTerm=SIA) (if you don't have the imagination for the guessing game) which otherwise makes something on the Internet incomprehensible.

Answer (score -16):

I fully respect the rules of Stack Overflow, but I want to highlight how technology, including language models like LLMs, plays a crucial role in the empowerment of people with disabilities. The goal of rights and regulations should be to promote a positive evolution of society. As a proof of transparency, wouldn't it be better to specify that a response has been assisted by an LLM?

Could we not offer an honest prompt for all Dys for example?

---

Thank you all for your comments. You can understand that for those who don't grasp how generative intelligence offers a significant advantage in terms of compensation for language disorders, if in the future the major evolution of artificial intelligence does not allow a site like Stack Overflow to make a difference, it is necessary in my opinion to accompany the transition and make it as transparent as possible.

It is obvious that many developers use generative algorithms without saying so, and with their improvement, it is quite possible that it will be difficult to detect them. Note that the fact that you have used an artificial intelligence is important data for future algorithms that will use the data generated by Stack Overflow.

Moreover, in language disorders for example, the contribution of artificial intelligence, with tools like generative AI, allows for a great improvement in language quality. It should be noted that many people in the world of science have this type of disorder, from Moses to Thomas Edison to Leonardo da Vinci, Einstein.

For this reason, I think it is not good to prohibit the use of generative artificial intelligence, particularly for disability and for the future evolution of this type of technology, and that it is more judicious to mention it. I understand that some people will never do it, but ethics is an individual question. Should everyone be punished for the fault of some and not others?

Comment: How can we trust users to add that "This is AI-generated" disclaimer to their answers? We can't. This has been suggested a lot, already, and frankly, just isn't reliable.

Comment: Yes, it would be better. *But people don't do it*. We could have a lot of nice things if people wouldn't sabotage things...

Comment: I understand your concerns regarding the reliability of AI assistance disclosures. However, with technological advancements, it will become increasingly difficult to differentiate between contributions generated by AI and those created by humans. This is also an issue of accessibility for some people.

Comment: AI has a distinguishable writing style, one that's not very common in how you'd normally answer on SO. That said, if an answer is of such (writing __and__ factual) quality that it _is_ indistinguishable from a completely human-written answer, there's not much of a problem.

Comment: I don't doubt that ChatGPT is helpful to some people with disabilities, but that doesn't change the fact that the answers it generates aren't reliable enough to be allowed on the site.

Comment: We understand that you think allowing generative AI is useful. However, there are _many_ issues with generative AI that aren't solved yet, such as its factual inaccuracy. A lot of these concerns have been discussed in-depth on answers on this question, so I'd strongly suggest you read through that first. Your suggestion is far from new, but nobody came up with a viable way to make it workable, yet.

Comment: "It should be noted that many people in the world of science have this type of disorder, from Moses to Thomas Edison to Leonardo da Vinci, Einstein." Flat what.

Comment: Sorry, @MisterMiyagi, I don't understand where you're going with this ?

Comment: @gregoryl That's fitting, because I didn't understand where you were going with this. My comment was supposed to express that with quoting the most (but not only) outlandish and tangential part of the content you recently added. I'm literally unable to put my confusion into words, hence a [flat what](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/FlatWhat).

Comment: OK :-), I understand, but please realize that for me, it's complicated to explain without going into too much detail, a topic that you seem not to be familiar with, regarding health and the impact that AI can have on this issue.

Comment: @gregoryl Point is, your new content isn't going into detail but into meaningless (and questionable) tangents. *You aren't actually explaining anything this way*. If this is what AI writes for you, *this is a good sign you should not use it*. True, it may be difficult for some of us to express ourselves, but do not be fooled into thinking AI expresses *yourself* better than *you* do. It just seems fancier.

Comment: @gregoryl MisterMiyagi is trying to explain to you why this answer is poorly received. From "our" perspective, it looks like you're the one who doesn't want to hear that, do you understand that? Your suggestion is clear, but how that would work, _with the issues LLMs have in mind_, is something _you_ need to explain. It's irrelevant what historical figures might have had some disability. Again, please read through the other suggestions on here. It's a lot, but that also means there's a lot of research and debate that has already gone into this.

Answer (score -17):

In your reasoning for the general ban on "All use of generative AI", you have not explained how it could be "harmful" to the website if a user *verifies* an AI-generated answer for correctness before posting it (for example by testing the code), or *partially* uses it in reaching their own correct answer.

In other words, if the problem is the curation and moderation of bad answers, why limit the ways good answers can be generated? With the AI-generated content becoming more accurate every day, (a) even human experts are more likely to provide better and quicker answers if they use AI for assistance, (b) it will be increasingly hard to detect AI use in part or all of an answer, and (c) it will be easier for this platform to actually use AI to find and flag potentially bad/incorrect answers, whether generated by humans or AI, for human experts to review.

Therefore it seems more logical to help the "swamped volunteer-based quality curation infrastructure" by actually using AI to prioritize the reviewed content, and to utilize other *hard* solutions such as limiting the posting frequency, rather than announcing general bans that could end up being hypocritical and impossible to enforce.

Comment: There is no logic here to counter. The ban makes it clear it is a blanket ban because AI generated answers *look* correct *no matter* if they are. There is no harm assigned to verified answers, and the magical tooling by which you want verified and unverified answers to be separated simply does not exist.

Comment: Do you understand that LLMs *do not* and will not understand meaning of the text? And if you do, how you imagine "actually use AI to find and flag potentially bad/incorrect answers"?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, AI generated answers "look correct" and *are* a lot of times correct. Of course not always, but that's true for human answers too. That's why you *verify* them! "There is no harm assigned to verified answers," There is a *ban* placed on them presumably because of a harm assigned to them. And there is no "magical tooling" that claim to exist.

Comment: The problem with "verify them" is that the amount of time, effort, and expertise it takes to verify an answer is often multiple orders of magnitude greater than the 10 seconds the poster spent blindly copy-pasting the question into ChatGPT.  It's not sustainable to spend that much more effort removing bad content than it takes to create it, particularly when there are more people creating it than trying to remove it.

Comment: @markalex Do you understand what it means to "understand", before making any claim about LLMs' understanding? And does it matter if a calculator "understands" numbers, as long it produces correct answers? Depending on the model quality and task at hand, LLMs can be very likely to produce correct and useful outputs (so a blanket ban on them is nonsensical) and they can *probabilistically* classify other answers to be true or false. This can be used to increase the speed and accuracy of human validators, not to replace them.

Comment: @FNia Please cite sources for your claims (especially the claim that LLMs can probabilistically classify the truth of answers).  Our overwhelming experience is that current LLM technology cannot reliably do any of those things, at least within the domain to which it's being applied here.  If we enter a world in which the way people use LLMs does not generate large quantities of plausible-looking incorrect information, then we may reconsider the ban.  That is not the world we live in, however; thus, the ban.

Comment: @RyanM The verification responsibility is on the poster. Yes, definitely ban the "10-second blind copy-pasted answers from ChatGPT", but that's not what this ban says. It simply doesn't care if you spent 10 seconds to paste it, or spent minutes or hours to verify and edit the answer before posting it. It bans all cases, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: Could you please explain how to tell whether a poster _did_ verify it? (without verifying it ourselves; see my previous comment for why that doesn't work)  Plenty of people claim to have verified their AI-generated answers, and yet their answers are still wrong.

Comment: There is no way to make sure the poster did verify it, and there is no way to make sure LLMs have not been used in part or all of the answer. You can only verify the answer itself for correctness, and LLMs can help with that. There are many studies on the use of LLMs for fact checking. It's definitely a new and evolving field, but the general understanding seems to be that "the best defense against [LLM] is [LLM] itself". I'll put some citations below.

Comment: - Defending Against Neural Fake News: https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.12616

- FACT-GPT: Fact-Checking Augmentation via Claim Matching with LLMs: https://arxiv.org/html/2402.05904v1

- Are Large Language Models Good Fact Checkers: A Preliminary Study: https://arxiv.org/abs/2311.17355

- The perils and promises of fact-checking with large language models: https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/frai.2024.1341697/full

- (Probabilistic classification:) Generative AI Text Classification using Ensemble LLM Approaches: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2309.07755.pdf

Comment: These are of course not ready solutions to deploy on this platform, but are the general trends and approach to the matter of validity-checking human+AI-generated content. It's only a matter of time before we get there, and I believe the focus should be on going in that direction, rather than suppressing AI use altogether.

Comment: @FNia "These are of course not ready solutions to deploy on this platform" Exactly. The tooling required for the proposed policy change does not practically exist - for all intents and purposes, they are functionally magic in any policy. Mind, that does not mean it cannot exist in the future, but it means any policy that relies on it cannot work *today*. SO does not exist to provide the focus for future AI research, it exists to be SO today. Mind, AI research is well able to set their own focus and not affected by the ban here.

Comment: @FNia, if or when tooling to factually check answers will exist, this very much will be a reason to reconsider this policy (and I'd personally say reconsider existence of SO in its current form). Until then, in light of extreme abuse by the generatedanswers, threatening usability of the site, this ban deemed to be the only viable solution.

Comment: If you have proposition, how to workaround mentioned abuse with existing *right now* technologies, please share it: many people would like to here it. But be warned, simply saying "community should go and verify every answer" wouldn't cut it.

Comment: Bogus answers (for example, likely most code dumps (answers without any explanation whatsoever)) and plagiarised answers were already a problem before ChatGPT. ChatGPT made it orders of magnitude worse.

Answer (score -19):

The more tricky question is: should paraphrases of GPT-whatsit-generated verbiage be banned?

Comment: Yes, just like with plagiarism, direct paraphrasing of AI generated content isn't permitted. We've detected and appropriately handled a substantial number of posts and users where there was considerable effort made to hide/obfuscate that the post content was AI generated. Is detection of such posts perfect? Of course, not. However, moderators are likely going to be less lenient for a user that has clearly demonstrated, by trying to hide/obfuscate, that they know they are doing something that's against the rules and at the same time caused moderators and users doing curation to spend more time.

Comment: *[whatsit](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/whatsit#Noun)*: *"(chiefly UK) A thing (used in a vague way to refer to something whose name one cannot recall, or that one is embarrassed to say)"*

Answer (score -22):

I, *personally*, think that there's not much we, as a community, can do to stop AI-generated content from being used on the site in the long term.  *Furthermore*, I think that **the long-term is what we should be focusing on**.

### The future of AI in a different timeline

The current banhammer stopgap may work for now, but it's a simple solution requiring manpower, and it won't be viable forever.  Who here remembers when [Dragon Naturally Speaking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_NaturallySpeaking) came out on CD in the 90s?  I was 8 or 9 when my grandfather got us a copy.  We had an old beige microphone, and my friends and family were absolutely amazed at the speech recognition capability.  They could dictate documents directly into Microsoft Works, and I could....  Well...  Do what 9-year-olds do best:  See how many curse words it could recognize... Even if you had to enunciate them.

Fast forward a couple of years and the same software could recognize multiple individuals in a single conversation and create a transcript including respective speakers.  Fast forward a few more years and Microsoft has added "**Train your computer to better understand you**"<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_NaturallySpeaking)</sup>, so enunciation is no longer an obstacle.

That 10-year timespan I just covered would be easy to react to as a community.  The problem is AI doesn't take 10 years, it takes *10 hours*<sup>[2](https://blogs.windows.com/windows-insider/2020/08/12/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-20190/)</sup>.  It's easy to spot right now (question rephrased to statement followed by bullet points for your vanilla ChatGPT) but what happens when we get the option to "**Train your computer to better type like you**"?  The Insider Build of Windows 11 (Dev Channel) currently has a Copilot preview that can access your active tab<sup>[3](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/mipad/)</sup>.  I'm certain Microsoft Office access will be next, so It's only a few steps away at most in my opinion.

### My opinion moving forward

My thought is this...  The banhammer on AI-generated content that isn't cited should continue.  However, we should move towards a system that accepts it, so long as it's clearly marked/cited as machine generated<sup>[4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intellectual_property)</sup> and there should **rarely, if ever**, be a top answer marked that is wholly AI-generated.  As we move towards that system, the 30-day bans need to turn into 90-day bans.  If we incorporate automated detection at some point, it should be human-reviewed, and 90 days should turn into 180 days.  I do not see this as too harsh of a punishment so long as users have been **explicitly** warned.

I believe that if history (as a whole) has shown us anything, it's that we cannot simply ignore a problem, sweep it under the run, and expect it to go away.  Band-aids are temporary, but AI is not.  Humans have suppressed so many different things over the years...  Catholics persecuted Presbyterians as heretics in the Middle Ages, Americans in the land of the free bought and sold black slaves to tend their households and farmlands, women were expected to quietly obey their husbands without a voice to vote until the 1900s, and Jews...  Well, Jews have gotten the shaft since the dawn of time.

I'm not saying that AI deserves citizenship or human rights<sup>[5]</sup>.  But as widespread as AI **will** inevitably become, and as integrated into our lives as it **will** we need to treat it that way.

### TLDR:

We should standardize a boilerplate for AI content and require anyone incorporating it into their content to use it.  We should continue the 30-day ban stopgap until a point where it's no longer needed. We should work towards a way of automating the recognition of AI-generated content that isn't cited, always require human review of this automation's output to reduce false positives and implement very steep consequences for those who violate the rules.

Again, all of this is just my opinion.  I've been a lurker for 7 years, but as you can see from my reputation, I haven't been active until this past week (I've started to enjoy teaching and tutoring in IT).  So, in the grand scheme of things, my 2 cents is literally just that, 2 cents.  But I hope that at least a few of you will share somewhat similar opinions.  Thanks for your time :)

### Clarification on *long*-term viability and manpower

I do not necessarily think there will be a need to patrol AI-generated content forever.  At least, I *hope* there isn't...  However, dumping everything into implementing 30-day bans as stopgaps can't be the answer.  Because **if we're relying on humans to recognize AI-generated content, we will fail no matter what**.  I'm not necessarily saying we should absolutely do anything specific.  I'm only saying that we need to look much further ahead than much of the discussion going on here.

I do not know what technology drives Stack Exchange on the backend.  But the technology has to move forward to account for AI content.  Whether you call this a forum, a wiki, an image board, a social media network, or anything else...  The technology underneath needs to move forward. To stress this point again **if we're relying on humans to recognize AI-generated content, we're going to fail no matter what**

### What's stopping users from simply not adding the boilerplate?

As Stack Overflow is built on a foundation of user trust, there's nothing that can be done to prevent this except moderating content. Though, in my opinion, adding the boilerplate at least lets the userbase know it's expected.  I found out via a comment warning when skimming through questions.

### But AI content can't reliably be detected?

I'm not asking for someone to look into this or share information related to site analytics or any other privileged information.  However, I would postulate that greater than 65% of users who have been banned for posting AI generated content are newer users trying to boost their reputation.  Furthermore, I would estimate that greater than 80% of those are using a vanilla ChatGPT based AI, of which greater than 95% are "non-precise" style (This high percentage is based on the difficulty of getting a reliable output to open ended questions.)

I want to point out an assumption in my argument. I'm looking at this from the point of view that if you know enough about AI to use anything outside of what's available on the mainstream channels, you likely have the experience to answer the questions without using AI content or to examine the content for accuracy before posting it.  As mentioned in the previous section, I am basing this assumption off the foundation of trust.

If those numbers are remotely close, then the additional review queue should not require much additional overhead to patrol a large portion of violations. I can quite easily imagine a natural language string analysis algorithm combined with a user event timing algorithm that could pick out a relatively high percentage of violations.  I'm sure there are **many** users way more talented than myself who could imagine the same in a far more optimized and efficient way.

### An alternative

If patrolling content and review queues are too far-fetched, then maybe instead of targeting users, we should target posts (I thought this was mentioned in one of the comment threads, but I couldn't find it on a second look).  Automated boilerplate addition to user posts if they are flagged as AI generated by an algorithm.  A certain reputation level allows an individual to remove the boilerplate.  A higher reputation level will automatically bypass the check on their posts.

---

**If policing content isn't the answer, then decriminalization and regulation is.**

---

<sup>[1]</sup> There was a step in between, where Microsoft let you correct its understanding with input rather than via prompt; See [This MiPad Research Article](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/mipad/)

<sup>[2]</sup> Keep in mind that AI can't just pick up any task and do it quicker and better.  Take for instance the following study in which it took an AI 924 hours to learn a game that would take humans less than 30 minutes:

- Lake, Brenden & Ullman, Tomer & Tenenbaum, Joshua & Gershman, Samuel. (2016). *Building Machines That Learn and Think Like People*. CBMM Memo No. 046.

<sup>[3]</sup> Verified the knowledge is public before posting, See [This Public Blog Post on Windows.com](https://blogs.windows.com/windows-insider/2020/08/12/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-20190/)

<sup>[4]</sup> We should probably require citing the exact AI that generated it.  I foresee that as an upcoming [IP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intellectual_property) battle in the near future.  Plus, as always, there are going to be biases on AI sources that could affect the community as a whole if we don't.

<sup>[5]</sup> Yet...  But I can't convince myself to rule that out at some point in the future, the human brain is only so complex, and technology is surely, albeit slowly, getting there.

Comment: "*We should standardize a boilerplate for AI content and require anyone incorporating it into their content to use it.*" and...if somebody doesn't? We'd still need the manpower that the start of your post claims is not viable forever. So...you want AI generated output to be embraced but we should still pour the same amount of effort into detecting "illegitimate" usage of AI generated content?

Comment: As with many other proposals to integrate/accommodate GenAI answers, I’m still missing the "why". What’s the point building a repository of things we can just generate? If GenAI reaches a point at which it can reliably generate answers then SO is obsolete and we - the users - can do better things with our time than nanny some algorithm that far outscales us anyway.

Comment: @VLAZ Edited for clarification of my stance.

Comment: Nothing you suggest is feasible. AI content can't reliably be detected, and yet another review queue isn't a solution either. Also, what's to prevent users from just not adding the _"This is AI-generated"_ boilerplate?

Comment: @Cerbrus Updated answer to address your concerns, including an alternative to policing content.

Comment: Also, thank you to both of you who edited my answer.  I am terrible with grammar and consistency in voice.  I also didn't know that blockquotes were considered abusive when used for formatting.  I always read through edits and try to learn from them, I really appreciate it.

Comment: I don't think your edits answer the questions above :(

Comment: Your edits don't answer my concerns... At all...

Answer (score -22):

### On the flipside?

I would like to argue that there is one class of AI writing that should be explicitly allowed.

Specifically, when an AI like ChatGPT gets a series of questions for which it cannot produce adequate answers,  the AI should produce a composite question about it.  This should also include statements of why it doesn't consider its own answers adequate.  This should then be asked here, as an official post from the AI (as in the user might be "ChatGPT" or the like).

The point here is to increase the corpus of knowledge.

---

Having said all that,  I do believe that answers or questions pasted from ChatGPT or the like should be banned.

Comment: And how exactly would an AI chatbot know it doesn't know something? Or *why* it doesn't know it? Often enough it just hallucinates an answer. The way to figure out it doesn't work is for an expert to have a look at it. If the expert finds the answer is nonsense, then they can write a question instead. Although, with that said - just because an AI tool is unable to properly answer a question, it does not mean the question is unique and never before seen.

Comment: Nothing of this seems to be suitable for SO with current  quality of "understanding" provided by any of the models. What you describe sounds like human powered correction mechanism for models, and I don't see why this should be a part of SO or wider SE network.

Comment: Ironically that's what OverflowAI search is designed to do, isn't it? Find/summarize existing answers, and if there are none help you generate a question.

Comment: @VLAZ it would obviously require the AI have a fair bit of self-monitoring included in it.  They may or may not be able to at this point.  In any case, it's not for StackExchange / SO to do, but for the AI writers.  The only part for StackExchange / SO is allowing the relevant user to exist and question.

Comment: Self-monitoring? you mean using an LLM to determine if an LLM is accurate?

Comment: @DavidG. There's no _"May or may not"_. LLMs do not have ___any___ idea of the __concept__ of "truth". They're utterly clueless. What you suggest it _beyond_ impossible, as LLMs are simply not capable of interpreting "truth".

Comment: So, what you're suggesting doesn't match up with the current reality. You want AI generated questions to be allowed conditioned on the AI tool working not at all how it works as of today. You're free to suggest to all AI tool makers they should change their products to be able to do the introspection you expect of them. Once that is done, we can discuss changing what we do and do not allow for AI generated questions.

Comment: @Cerbrus  Completely wrong.  AIs do have an idea of "truth".   With SO as a source, an accepted answer is more likely "truth" than a non-accepted one.  An answer from a high status poster is more likely "truth" than from a low status poster.  I suspect this is already used.  Having said that, it probably doesn't know truth in the real world, so it shouldn't be trained on an RPG corpus to answer medical questions.

Comment: @VLAZ I'm saying the policy should allow, and encourage, AIs whose developers want to improve the knowledge base.  It may be that they don't do it now because they haven't been encouraged to do it.  I feel it would be better for them to be encouraged than for them to have to come hat in hand.

Comment: i mean, no, lol, there's a reason accepted answers are no longer pinned to the top.

Comment: OK, I should have mentioned high scoring answers are also more like "truth" than low scoring ones.

Comment: I mean, no, lol, there's plenty of highly scored answers that are wrong.

Comment: Which is why I use the therm "likely".

Comment: The point is there is no idea of truth that can be trusted to just be correct, even for human provided content the viewer is responsible for determining that. Having the AI rely on metrics humans provided in the past but no longer are because the AI replaced the process that resulted in that feedback will be stale immediately.

Comment: And as I wrote in the answer, I don't support AI answers.

Comment: An AI summary of an answer *is* an AI answer.

Comment: @DavidG. No. LLMs don't have a concept of truth. Don't strawman me with theories about AI in general. LLMs like ChatGPT don't _comprehend_. They don't _understand_, they don's _interpret_. There is literally _no_ concept of technical accuracy in their process. That's the ___entire___ problem with LLMs! They ___can't___ know if what they generate is true or not. That's simply not part of how they work. [1/2]

Comment: @DavidG. LLMs like ChatGPT don't _"do"_ "source". They can't weigh different training data differently unless explicitly trained to do so. It would make no sense for a generic LLM like ChatGPT to put excessive weight on SO sources, as that would result in lower quality output when generating stories. It doesn't have live access to data. It doesn't know who posted what. It doesn't know anything about scores. You're making ___so many___ incorrect assumptions about how LLMs work... Please look into how they generate output. [2/2]

Comment: "AI" solutions that are capable of citing sources aren't working like your standard LLM prompt. They start with a different kind of AI, not an LLM, to perform a more typical search before sending the results into an LLM as a prompt to generate the response. It'd be incorrect to claim the LLM is sourcing it's data, since the data that is allowing it to do the work it's doing isn't just the content in the prompt that the initial search found.

Comment: This answer clearly demonstrates the lack of knowledge gained by using ChatGPT and understanding how its responses are generated. You can tell ChatGPT it’s wrong and it will apologize, even if it’s right, and generate a new response to correct its mistakes. Even then on some subjects even if it’s wrong it will ignore your correction. ChatGPT is useless.

Answer (score -27):

I think [Peter's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/421835) has the right spirit, but the wrong implementation. We might need to get comfortable with this technology being around in the long term, and one way to stop the abuse it might generate is to *build it into the system* with the necessary precautions and abuse prevention mechanisms.

Make no mistake: **the genie is out of the bottle.** You can't put it back in. You can't wish it away. This is going to be a thing going forward, and it doesn't even have to be a *problem.*

Basically, you create some kind of system user that posts an AI-generated answer to ~every question. (Maybe ask the bot if this looks like the sort of question that belongs on Stack Overflow first, so you don't start automatically answering obviously-off-topic questions like "[How is babby formed?](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/how-is-babby-formed)", although that can be gamed and that's a concern.) You mark it as a bot. You surround the answer with the necessary warnings. Its answers are all community wiki, meaning the bot never gains any reputation and users are encouraged to edit the answer if it's only slightly wrong. The bot automatically deletes its own answers if they get a low enough score. Other people trying to run a ChatGPT Stack Overflow gold rush for Internet brownie points would find themselves unable to keep up with this system user, and would stop trying.

You run this for a while, determine if it's successful or not, and... if I was your CFO, I'd better hope it's not, because as other comments show, this might not be a very cheap model to run (even if you had a license from the creators to run it for $0). I can't imagine Stack Overflow staying sustainable as a commercial entity if it has to pay an AI tax on every single question on the website.

The good news is that, if this does become too expensive for Stack Overflow, it's gonna also be too expensive for random Joe's trying to gain cheap reputation this way — and that probably also means the end of the gold rush of people who just want to write "make number go up with AI" blog posts.

Comment: I'd like to point out that OpenAI probably *pays big time* right now for the server, GPU and memory and electricity it uses, not even considering the training costs (these typically range in the lower single-digit millions for complex language models). An OpenAI-paid-for ChatGPT answer is going to be *really* expensive if someone actually needs to pay for it. (We're talking spacefaring carbuilding lunatic billionaire-sized venture capital being burnt here.)

Comment: Yes, I addressed that point towards the end. It's possible that, even if successful, this trial can't work for financial reasons. The good news is that, if this does become too expensive for Stack Overflow, it's gonna also be too expensive for random Joe's trying to gain cheap reputation this way. My understanding is that the problem, for now, is the gold rush of random Joe's trying to get a number to go up.

Comment: I added that paragraph into the answer; it shouldn't have remained in my head

Comment: yepyep, agreeing with you! The good news is that OpenAI themselves say it's free for *the duration of the public preview*; in other word, this is a promo phase to get customers, but even more likely, big investors, hooked. Who cares if you break the internet and make 20 million in debt if you're getting bought for 200 million afterwards?

Comment: ChatGPT does not give a canonical answer to a certain question. If you ask the same question multiple times, you will get multiple different answers that sometimes even make conflicting statements. There seems to be a random element used when the AI generates its answer.

Comment: So an automated bot dumps crap answers on questions... You're missing one glaring problem: ChatGPT doesn't return the same answer for the exact same question twice, so any user that probably also doesn't use the exact same input will absolutely get a different answer... This solution can't solve anything, other than a overflowing wallet.

Comment: _"if this does become too expensive for Stack Overflow, it's gonna also be too expensive for random Joe's trying to gain cheap reputation this way"_ A thousand users with a thousand free / trial accounts can posts tens of thousands of generated answers... SE, a single entity, will have to fork over cash for every single answer they automatically generate. You can't compare corporate usage with individual usage.

Comment: @NineBerry the idea of running the model a whole lot of times and picking the best answer is almost certainly already baked into ChatGPT (generate many outputs, pick the highest quality one), meaning that yes you can reroll by hand but it's not going to be super effective

Comment: @Cerbrus you are arguing that Stack Overflow has no choice but to implement my answer, then. After all, ChatGPT is only the first but not necessarily the last, best, or cheapest way to build a Q&A answering machine. We might see a stablediffusion-style version of this model that's open access and good eonugh for most uses. Own the abuse, or drown by it.

Comment: This would defeat the purpose of Stack Overflow. It actually sounds like a completely different service. GH Copilot is doing something like that already, doesn't it?

Comment: @Dharman elaborate? I really don't see how having a robot handling what would only really be the x% easiest answers on the website automatically — a quality problem that has been a thorn in the side of the website for decades, might I add — would somehow defeat the purpose of a human-run Q&A website. The human curation is still there; the human contribution is still there; the human validation is still there; the human moderation is still there.

Comment: @badp Because if getting an answer can be automated, what is the point in building a repository of answers like Stack Overflow?

Comment: @Dharman Are you suggesting that your work is worthless? As a former Stack Exchange moderator myself, I would vehemently disagree

Comment: @badp No, I am saying that the purpose of Stack Overflow is to provide quality answers to common problems. These answers can then be found by humans searching for the same issues. A bot answering every question on Stack Overflow would go against the purpose of the site. We already have this issue with some users who add a code-only answer or repeat the same solution on multiple questions.

Comment: Additionally: ChatGPT is basically trained on the same dataset as Google: theinternet.zip; what's gonna be tough to Google is gonna be equally tough for ChatGPT to answer. Ultimately we don't know what its ability to answer questions is gonna be like until a trial like this is run. Stack Exchange can run it themselves, or any number of universities can run it on this website for academic research. The difference is that universities need not do their research ethically.

Comment: @Dharman I still don't see the contradiction: if the answer to trivial questions is found within theinternet.zip, doesn't that free human beings to research the harder, more interesting questions that aren't so trivially solved? The human side of Stack Overflow — the peer validation — is still there and no robot can give you that.

Comment: @badp Precisely. So if a robot can give you an answer, why should it be posted on Stack Overflow?

Comment: @Dharman How does someone asking a question know ahead of time that their answer is contained within theinternet.zip? In terms of being humble, wouldn't that be your default assumption?

Comment: @badp Because they looked for it already on Google. Asking a question on Stack Overflow is the last resort. It means that a question like that hasn't been asked by anyone else yet.

Comment: @Dharman that's desired user behaviour, not actual user behaviour. If things were that easy, we'd never need to close questions as duplicate.

Comment: The problem this ban is meant to solve is that ChatGPT can produce answers in seconds which require minutes of multiple people's time to verify if they are worth having on the site or not, and that is a waste of time when a large proportion of such answers are not worth having on the site. If every question automatically received an answer like that, it would make the problem worse, not better, by requiring more people to spend more time verifying and voting on those answers.

Comment: @kaya3 having to vote on answers is an integral part of this website. So long as voting on such an answer doesn't go towards building someone's personal brand or unethical research goals ("look at my reputation!") and it _does_ surface useful content (chatgpt will occasionally get answers right), I don't see the problem. As someone who's experiencing a problem first-hand, trying the automatic answer out and voting it up and down will probably not take very much effort at all.

Comment: There are many questions on Stack Overflow which the person asking cannot try out first hand and see if they are correct. Consider a question like *"will a linked list be more efficient than an array in this case?"* with an answer like *"a linked list will be more efficient because most of the operations are at the start of the list"*. If the OP was able to try it out and see which was more efficient then they wouldn't have asked the question, and the answer doesn't tell them *how* to try it out. "What is the time complexity of this algorithm?" is another class of such questions, which ...

Comment: ... Stack Overflow already has a lot of users posting (non-AI-written) answers that "seem right", that the OP may be satisfied with, but are wrong in ways which cannot be demonstrated by "trying them out" (and this often makes it hard to convince the person who wrote the answer that they are wrong, too). Bad answers like that waste a lot of people's time, the site needs less of them, not more. As for "voting is integral to the site", of course it is, but the site is better off if experts spend their time writing good answers, instead of checking and downvoting rubbish answers.

Comment: @kaya3 downvoting rubbish answers is MORE important to the health of the website than writing answers for questions that are already suitably answered. Whether the suitable answer was written by a human or a bot is irrelevant, so long as there's no plagiarism going on.

Comment: That presupposes that there *are* rubbish answers which need to be downvoted in order to be removed from sight. But what you're proposing is to *create* those rubbish answers, automatically, en masse.

Comment: @kaya3 you don't know they're rubbish. You don't have data to make this assertion with. If they really were rubbish they wouldn't be creating overwork for moderators. I've seen gpt write very patient, mostly correct explanations on how a certain piece of code works and in those cases it would be better use of our limited time on earth to edit them up rather than start from scratch.

Comment: If you're so sure about all these answers being unsalvageable rubbish, you'd agree to run a limited trial like I describe in my post that then proves you right, concluding that the tech isn't there yet. The data you collect and publish will let everyone know they can stop trying to game the system.

Comment: @badp If the answers weren't rubbish, this wouldn't have been a problem in the first place. Duh. The whole entire friggin issue here is users posting AI-generated content __en masse__, without checking the answers.

Comment: @Cerbrus false. You still have a massive plagiarism issue. You're selling ChatGPT-made copyright-free answers as your own work.

Comment: That's an entirely different debate.

Comment: @Cerbrus Plagiarism is my primary concern. From my limited exploration ChatGPT often gets close or very close to being bang on the money, but misses the mark. In those cases, it's gonna be better for us to start from a nearly correct answer and actually making it right than it is to make people start from scratch — and enable plagiarists to plagiarize.

Comment: The problem is that users don't put that kind of effort into their copy-pastes. If they did, this would've taken so much longer to notice (and frankly would've been less of a problem, as OpenAI isn't that strict on plagiarism: _"OpenAI hereby assigns to you all its right, title and interest in and to Output."_ ([source](https://openai.com/api/policies/terms/)))

Comment: @Cerbrus I guess you still might have to mention that the content is AI generated, see Section 2c, point (v) it says "_You may not represent that output from the Services was human-generated when it is not_" of the terms you linked.

Comment: Ah, then it's not a plagiarism issue, it's a misrepresentation issue :D

Comment: @Cerbrus eh. You're gaining reputation for the *wrong* kind of work (generating the correct prompts vs writing the correct answer); whether that's misrepresentation or plagiarism, we can agree that it's wrong.

Comment: the plagiarism issue is small potatoes (assuming it exists at all) compared to the fact that the majority of the answers are deceivingly wrong.

Comment: @KevinB I've seen both cases where these answers are uncurably wrong, and cases in which you can make them right with some light editing work. In the latter case, having a mostly correct answer available for tweaking is going to save us work and energy.

Comment: For the one person copy-pasting answers, of course it's a time saver. If you have the ability to properly edit the answer into shape, You could have probably written it yourself in the same amount of time. The problem is the people posting these answers aren't doing that.

Comment: @KevinB Yes, I agree that those people need to understand that this kind of gaming isn't gonna result in good things. One way to do so is to start intelligently embracing this technology at a platform level while it's still trash, because it's only going to get better from here and simply disallowing robot-made answers is a losing game. "StackOverflow now requires users to install dedicated kernel drivers to make sure every character they press comes straight from human fingers with a pulse and a soul."

Comment: Disallowing it and strictly enforcing penalties against users who abuse it is enough of a stop-gap to make people think twice about participating. It certainly won't stop the abuse, but it's good enough to make a dent.

Comment: A super power people crave is being able to express themselves better. I think you're right in that this isn't going away, and if implemented as assistive instead of prescriptive, could result in people writing way better _questions_. I also see the potential to help people write answers too, but perhaps as a coach and not a co-author. I think it could do what guided "wizards" just don't do very well.

Comment: @Dharman "So if a robot can give you an answer, why should it be posted on Stack Overflow?" - If Google or a library can give you an answer, why should it be posted on Stack Overflow? Accessibility. Don't get me wrong; the current situation is a mess and should not be allowed to continue, but if ChatGPT was actually good it would be nice to have it answer questions here.

Comment: I don't necessarily agree with the _specific implementation_ suggested here, but after seeing how effective ChatGPT often is at answering certain types of programming questions I think there absolutely are ways that technology could be used to improve StackOverflow. Identifying off-topic answers and duplicates, asking clarifying questions, or even outright answering low-effort questions before they're posted are all within the realm of possibility. The main issue right now is probably the cost of running the model, and the implementation effort of integrating with SO in an actually useful way.

Comment: "after seeing how effective ChatGPT often is at answering certain types of programming questions, I think there are ways that technology could be used to improve StackOverflow." - You must not be reading answers generated by ChartGPT if you think the answers are effective, because every answer I have read generated by ChartGPT, have been either (incorrect, inaccurate, or incomplete) and most of the time a combination of two or more of those adjectives. In summary, answers produced by ChartGPT, in my experience are not even worth downvoting, they are that bad.

Comment: "Basically, you create some kind of system user that posts an AI-generated answer to ~every question." And where is the AI going to learn the answer from? The Internet sure, but it needs to weigh which sites that are credible. Lets suppose it thinks SO with your AI add-on is credible. Now as that AI learns programming, it fetches answers from SO. Except half of them are generated by an AI. The AI can then either: 1) ignore AI answers since they aren't credible or 2) learn from AI answers, in which case you've created infinite recursion. Either way nothing useful comes out in the other end.

Comment: It's true that above that particular software itself and the bad rep it gives to Stack, only the fool would resist implementing AI in their day to day in the foreseeable future.

Comment: @Lundin I agree that the feedback loop that is going to occur from machine learning models learning from the output of other machine learning models is going to be a challenge as researchers are "poisoning the well" as it were. A large amount of the internet is already fully automated like nearly every piece of "news" covering movements in the stock market. That isn't Stack Overflow's business to worry about, and if it is, clearly marking automatically generated content as automatically generated so it can be skipped from future training is probably a good thing

Answer (score -27):

It's just a suggestion. People will keep posting ChatGPT answers anyway. The problem is now that a user can't really differentiate them.

A solution I would suggest which is already mentioned here, but different, is not only to proactively post an answer from ChatGPT (or other models), but intentionally ranks them lower and banner them clearly that this answer is not yet checked by a human. Then a person can confirm, edits, or reject the answer, which will change the rating of the answer itself (this ChatGPT answer have been reviewed by X and rated as correct).

If an open source model is used, then Stack Overflow have even more data to train their own model which will beat all other AI models...

Comment: I think you're massively underestimating the effort that goes into training this kind of model... Also, why does the generated answer _need_ te be on SO? Why can't a user that wants an AI-generated answer just go to said AI?

Comment: If the AI reliably produces correct answers - why build a library of them at all? If the AI does not reliably produce correct answers - how many and which answers should be posted? Critically, how should volunteers deal with the required massive content volume when we already have too few people for the fewer human generated answers?

Comment: Re *"not yet checked by a human"*: This doesn't (and didn't) even happen with human-generated answers to any significant extend. Why would anyone spend time checking a code dump answer (no explanation whatsoever)? Yes, that is a rhetorical question. A code dump answer may be completely bogus or brilliant. It is difficult to judge unless significant time is spend to actual run and test the code.

Comment: cont' - [Sample code dump answer, 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10006218/which-schematype-in-mongoose-is-best-for-a-timestamp/65987695#65987695). [Sample code dump answer, 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350401/how-can-i-override-the-handler-for-a-button-in-ckeditor/32599251#32599251). [Essentially a sample code dump answer, 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10006218/which-schematype-in-mongoose-is-best-for-a-timestamp/54978635#54978635).

Comment: I must admit I do not actually dislike this idea as much as most other suggestions at face-value. I mean it's not what I would like, but if a compromise had to be struck, in the event where we cannot absolutely reliably ban ai generated answers, I would choose a somewhat "site-approved" or even better, "site-trained" ai answer generator.

Comment: Like let's see how good exactly can we train a model exclusively on SO content to answer duplicates.

Comment: @Cerbrus, the second question in your comment isn’t a relevant as it may seem. You ask why something can’, while of course an asker can and is not prevented from doing so regardless. Just as the asker could rtfm or get an answer elsewhere. It’s however about answerers using AI, who do that regardless of what the asker could do.

Comment: @Xartec Rowanto is arguing that SO should implement GPT to automate answers. That's  what my "Why" is asking about. Why do we need to invest time in implementing generated crappy answers, when users can get that nonsense at the source, instead?

Comment: @Xartec "It’s however about answerers using AI" To the contrary. This answer is about *SO itself* using AI, which then - somehow - removes the issue/occurrence of  answerers using AI and - somehow - offers a benefit to askers.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi that’s what his proposed solution is about. His answer is a solution adressing the problem as layed out in the second sentence.

Comment: @Cerberus “ Why do we need to invest time in implementing generated crappy answers, when users can get that nonsense at the source, instead?” This, again, relies solely on the false idea AI generated answers are crappy and nonsense. Which is is like building a house on quicksand, as chat gpt would say. The quality of the answers can be heavily improved by prompt engineering which would discourage answerers from using the same ai to produce sub par results. It would be a sensible way to introduce AI, an inevitable situation.

Comment: @Xartec they've already tried that, it failed spectacularly. Many other sites are similarly trying this, such as quora, and are having similarly questionable results. Why must SO include AI generated answers? What value would that provide? Surely the best person to have a conversation with a chatbot and weed out poor results is the person with the problem being solved, not some rep hunter on SO or SO itself.

Comment: @KevinB the why has been established, the problem at hand and is repeated in my previous comment. In an ideal world you’d be correct, that would surely be the best person. In reality, people post answers generated by AI regardless of whether SO ‘must’ and no the person with the problem is surely not automatically the most capable of asking the question. That assumes everyone masters prompt engineering which just isn’t true. We can disagree on opinions, not facts. An imo, a more controlled AI answer would likely reduce the urge to create a poor Ai generated answer.

Comment: @Xartec Yes, and we've been routinely deleting said answers for nearly a year now. Yes, we haven't gotten all of them, but we've gotten enough, and enough accounts are actioned against to keep the problem at bay. Your assertion that we cannot discern whether or not content was written by AI is quite provably false.

Comment: There is no magic prompt engineering masterpiece that will suddenly make any current or near release version of gpt capable of producing answers to new questions. At best it can summarize an existing answer to an already answered question, however even that becomes more likely to hallucinate than to provide an accurate answer the more you allow it to modify the content it is summarizing to fit the person looking for an answer. The user would be better off just getting the existing answer.

Comment: @Xartec "which would discourage answerers from using the same ai to produce sub par results" Why? How? The answer also just takes this magic for granted, so please provide arguments for it if you think it is actually true. I’ve seen many AI-spammers post indiscriminately on questions that already had answers, so it is not at all clear to me why the existence of official AI answers would prevent or discourage AI spam.

Comment: "The problem is now that a user can't really differentiate them." - It's trivial to identify ChatGPT generated content.  **The only way to handle ChatGPT content is to ban it.**

Answer (score -29):

I honestly believe ChatGPT is a powerful tool, but in reality it doesn't give exactly what we want. All the answers posted are from real legends who put their hands on the code and tried the solution. I would say it would be disrespectful to mix AI answers with human answers because the AI is trained from human answers.

Comment: ChatGPT is insanely great and is a powerful tool, but it will also produce answers that are totally wrong and/or made up. It can not be trusted.

Answer (score -31):

Instead of banning ChatGPT, Stack Overflow could consider adding a new button *"Show AI Generated Answer(s)"* to each question page. Such answers should be hidden by default, but if anybody is curious about what ChatGPT (or any other future AI tool of the day) has to say about it, they can check it out.

Also, such AI-generated answers could be compared to the "human"-generated answers with another AI tool to compute a similarity score, and if a "human"-generated answer is too similar to an AI-generated one, then such an answer should be banned (since the probability that such "human" answer has actually been produced using an AI tool would be high) and the user who posted it could be given some penalty.

So, this approach would kill two birds with one stone - people would be much less likely to post AI-generated answers since such answers would already be there automatically, and Stack Overflow would get an automated tool for detecting AI-generated answers and for punishing users who abuse the "no AI-generated answers" policy.

Comment: No?  People aren't going to go through the rigor of ensuring that the answer they see or read is comprehensible or useful for their use case.  We already have [cases of people copying code from Stack Overflow and putting it into production.](https://www.theverge.com/tldr/2016/5/4/11593084/dont-get-busted-copying-code-from-stack-overflow)  This doesn't make that better; it actually makes it **orders of magnitude worse**.

Comment: People already barely follow instructions like [ask] and [answer]. The problem we see with lots of AI-generated answers is that the people who post them do so blindly, without verifying that it answers the question or testing for bugs. I doubt asking these low-effort posters to put in _more_ effort to self-identify (even though it's barely any effort to check a box) is going to have the effect you desire. Until such time as AI-generated answers are reliably correct, if people are interested in what the AI has to say, they can go talk to it at _the AI's_ website.

Comment: I don't think this is a bad idea. You cannot stop anyone from looking for AI-generated answers. The point is not to be vindictive of AI generate responses but to let others decide if those are accurate or even helpful. In my experience apart from answering basic questions, pre-2021, ChatGTP has not provided any relevance. This data can also be useful in future to train better models.

Comment: if people want AI generated answers, there's a place for that. (it isn't here)

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted but i can understand why when everyone are so angry and ban-happy already...

This is the least-effort and also most realistic way of fixing the problem now and forever. It will always work too, because chatgpt will always produce grammatically correct answers(even if completely wrong) and a similarity algo should be feasible to implement(ie: not too complex). It is also the only answer where it saves SO users from cleaning up and saves SO from becoming more authoritarian(it already is too authoritarian for many users...)

Comment: This is a great suggestion. I wrote an answer similar to yours but with the added usage of a tag to help StackOverflow filter out or correct AI generated answers. Unfortunately, the senior members of this forum do not encourage any type of interaction with known AI answers. I understand their reasoning. The big question is how will they be able to tell the difference otherwise? More AI detection? Is OK to use AI to "detect" AI generated answers, but it's not OK to submit AI generated answers? Seems like a paradox to me.

Answer (score -34):

Yes, it should be banned.  To the question of "How do we identify those posts?", it should be considered that this problem is not new or unique to Stack Overflow.  Plagiarism is a concern that spans broadly.  An answer found in academia is to copy/paste answers ***back into*** ChatGPT and see if it responds to it as a continuation of a conversation; if it does, then flag it as AI-generated.

This is a potential technique, and one that scales.  Multiple suggestions here imply that "you can tell it by looking at it", which isn't all that helpful because we can't expect people to reliably keep up with the potentially exponential flow of spam answers.

Comment: No, that's not at all accurate.
ChatGPT just pretends. It can't recognize its own output.

Comment: The conversation chains in ChatGPT are separate. Every time you start a new chat, it keeps that session for that session only. I've seen nothing to imply that it persists any information cross-sessions. In fact, what I do for amusement is ask ChatGPT where my hometown is located and it gives me a new, amusing, and mostly wrong information every time. You can try to correct it but if I start a new session it goes back to the nonsensical information again.

Comment: Re *"...is to copy/paste answers* ***back into*** *ChatGPT and it will respond to it as a continuation of the conversation"*: Interesting. Do you have some examples and/or references for that?

Comment: @PeterMortensen https://openai-openai-detector.hf.space/

Comment: Also this: https://nypost.com/2022/12/26/students-using-chatgpt-to-cheat-professor-warns/

Comment: My main point is that SO isn't the only one suffering from this issue, and to try and concoct a solution internally is wacky.  Smart people are already very far down this road, we have search engines to identify who they are.

Comment: this just isn't really relevant to the conversation, tbh. We aren't expecting users to go out and look for chatgpt answers to report. That's not what this is about. Mods and other involved users are already on the case and already know how to find such answers and deal with them. Obviously, report things you think are chatgpt answers, but we don't need this to be a witch hunt.

Comment: @n8. If that is your main point, you might want to [edit] your answer to actually say so. Right now the prominent focus is on a single suggestion that doesn’t actually work as described.

Comment: To test this, I pasted one of my own more extensive answers into ChatGPT and asked if it was ChatGPT's? It said it was. So the problem remains the same as always, ChatGPT confidently lies when it answers questions -- any and all questions.

Answer (score -37):

Banning all ChatGPT answers is a good temporary move, as it opens a time window where it could be discussed thoroughly, but it, IMO, shouldn't be permanent, as it could also help if used according to its capabilities and by acknowledging its limitations.

Consider the following situation:

Someone sees a question they know the answer to.

They don't want to worry about the structure of the answer, so they use ChatGPT with a prompt that directs it towards the correct answer of the problem (for example, if the question is "How do I remove and get the last element of an array?", a possible prompt might be "Using the array.pop method, write a Stack Overflow answer to the question ..."

They then check and verify the answer to see if ChatGPT has done any mistakes, and either direct ChatGPT to correct the answer, or correct it themselves.

They then post the answer.

Is this helpful to SO? I would assume it is as the user who asked their question gets an answer that works, and the answerer spends less time formulating and explaining the answer and more time worrying about the correctness of the answer. As ChatGPT is a language model, here it would have been used correctly according to its capabilities (language and not programming - the programming knowledge comes from the answerer).

Should this be banned permanently? Permanently banning all ChatGPT answers means this should be banned as well, even though it actually is helpful to the Q&A format we have going on here.

Bad ChatGPT answers are just bad answers, and I don't think we should have another rule specifically for ChatGPT. Spamming good-looking but bad answers with AI tools and abandoning them to "see the numbers go up" should be the behavior that is banned.

Comment: The problem is that users have been proven to be untrustworthy, and have been going for quantity over quality when using the AI to generate answers. Besides, answers that are simple enough for the AI to consistently answer correctly, generally have excellent due targets on SO... TL;DR: There's nothing of value to SO, generated from CGPT.

Comment: The use-case described by this answer would be a great way to use ChatGPT. Unfortunately, it's not how it's currently used. On the long run, we have to find a way how responsible use of AI can be allowed while still having methods to prevent flooding the site with garbage.

Comment: I had a similar thought: What if you have the skills and willingness to validate the AI-generated answer, even if you didn't come up with it? Such good-faith use of a chat AI by an actual expert would be completely indistinguishable from a human answer, and such use would be unenforceable. We're being asked here to self-enforce this ban on ourselves. If you don't want to self-enforce this ban on yourself, others may never notice, but you're crossing a different line here by publicly advocating that others not self-enforce themselves.

Comment: There really isn't much value in carving out an exception for cases where the tool is used in a way such that it won't be recognizable as chatgpt and is actually producing valuable content, people using it have already proven that they're overwhelmingly unwilling to take those steps. People who *are* takin those steps aren't spamming the site with nonsense posts, but they're still potentially posting plagiarized content.

Comment: "Is this helpful to SO?" To answer the question in the answer: Yes it is helpful. Caveat: only a minority will actually do it like this. But otherwhise it's a valid idea.

Comment: The main problem though, with this suggestion of augmented answering, is that you never know when the chat bot will randomly introduce fake or false information to support its possibly correct larger point. These nuanced false points might seem harmless if for example we are talking about resolving the argument of who won the last World Cup. The chat bot would perhaps make a comment like "Argentina won the 2022 World Cup. It was their third time matching up against France in the finals, and only the second time Messi won". That last part, unless you are truly informed, may seem real.

Comment: In code, it can be dangerous to use those extra parts, especially since nuance is often very important (for example a wrong conversion to let's say, oh I don't know, feet to meters #mars). Perhaps with things of a more lenient nature, these white lies don't particularly harm anything, but when people's savings, kids, or lives are at stake, we can't just lightly gloss over such glaring inaccuracy.

Comment: @TravisJ of course I am not suggesting people to blindly copy and paste those answers directly from ChatGPT, rather here, the tool would be used just as a glorified sentence generator, and the output it generates should then be left to the human operator to check.

Comment: @kahveciderin - Unfortunately a very large sample size of the minority have proven they cannot be trusted to use ChartGPT to help them submit an answer. They have proven they do not have the knowledge to confirm the answer content is (correct, accurate, ect.). **That sample size has been extrapolated across multiple communities.**

Comment: Main Problem with this Scenario I think, ... is that 'ChatGPT' doesn't check for **DUPLICATES**, oops...!

Comment: I am against permanent ban, but not for the reasons given here. Everyone should be allowed to learn from their mistakes. It is as simple as that. Banning for a long time - sure. It needs to hurt to sink in. Permanent banning is needlessly extreme.

Answer (score -38):

Reading through the answers and comments, I can't help but detect a lot of bias, seemingly out of fear for the unknown or potential competitor.

This line in the OP is telling:

> in order to determine that the answer is actually bad has effectively swamped our volunteer-based quality curation infrastructure.

Why set out to determine it 'is actually bad' instead of good. In my experience, it's usually correct (because I ask the right questions). In the cases it's not, it's useful to discuss with ChatGPT where the mistake lies. With some frequency I ask it to reread its reply and whether it is sure that's correct.

Similar in many comments, where people clearly show bias without supporting or even convincing arguments. Comments like "it is stupid" and "it's a good joke generator". The main argument seems to be "it's not always correct". Yes, neither are all (or even most?) human answers, but that aside, if that's your main argument, what will you do in 6 months or 2 years?

Personally I think ChatGPT is hands down the most *productive* assistant / near-coworker I ever had (in 30+ years IT and coding) and anyone not adapting it ASAP to gain at least experience with it is contributing to their own demise.

Important to understand is that it's an assistant, a tool, not a substitute. AI won't replace developers; developers who use AI will replace developers. Pick a side that suits you and your family. Sticking your head in the sand isn't a fruitful approach to AI, embrace it, control it, use it to increase productivity.

Posting answers or questions written by ChatGPT straight to SO is like copying and pasting from another site, but banning questions and answers ChatGPT assisted in writing just seems wrong. It's almost like banning a spell/grammar checker.

I learned never to complain without offering alternatives. People posting answers should be held accountable for bad answers. That way they'll put in the extra effort to make sure the AI-assistant answer is useful to the one asking the question. Whether it's text, questions and answers, or code, everything an AI produces should be considered a draft. Perhaps a test section limited to certain topics, or show the ChatGPT-assisted answers (allow answerers to mark them as such) at the bottom of the answer list, collapsed and hidden till the reader opens them. Anything that doesn't involve throwing the baby out with the bathwater.

Comment: _"seemingly out of fear for the unknown or potential competitor."_  Wrong. This bias is based on a understanding of how LLMs work, and what their limitations are.

Comment: "Actually bad" vs "Actually good" doesn't matter. The same level of effort is required to validate it.

Comment: _"what will you do in 6 months or 2 years."_ We'll cross that bridge _when_ we get to it.

Comment: You're missing the point that GPT was causing a ___flood___ of low-effort generated copy-pasted content. There was no way to accurately moderate all of it. Your last paragraph assumes users are honest. They're not. They're just dumping AI-generated text on the site and seeing what sticks.

Comment: Seems like you're missing the point here. We're not banning chatgpt due to fear of being replaced... banning it in that case would have no effect on the outcome anyway. Instead, it's banned for the reasons outlined in the question: the success rate is too low. Yes, you using it yourself can poke and prod chatgpt enough to end up at a valid answer, however, that doesn't work for generating long-term useful content, particularly when answerers use it as a fire and forget tool for farming reputation rather than for producing high quality content.

Comment: "Important to understand is that it's an assistant, a tool, not a substitute." That's why it is banned as a substitute for manually writing answers, not as an assistant, a tool. This answers seems to be missing what the ban is about: People are still free to use ChatGPT themselves. As many (all?) of the positives mentioned here require *interacting* with ChatGPT, it is not suitable for a Q&A format where answers are fixed and discussion is intentionally kept to a minimum.

Comment: @Kevin B I like to think my last paragraph and line makes it hard to reasonably suggest I'm missing the point. I fully appreciate the situation you're dealing with. 'the success rate is too low' of what specifically? Answers constructed with the assistance of AI, or answers entirely generated by AI. They are different things. You suggest Chat-GPT can't be used for 'generating long-term useful content' and then use the behavior of certain humans to support that non-fact (it's simply not a fact that can be subscribed to Chat GPT). Those are two separate things, hence the last line in my post.

Comment: @Xartec Clearly the latter, however the former is a mixed bag. It's difficult to ban the one without also banning the other.

Comment: @Cerbrus It's a fact clearly not every answer and comment here comes from people with a good understanding of how LLMs work and what their limitations are, nor do all make their comments based on extensive experience. Crossing that bridge when we get there isn't a wise approach, this requires something pro-active rather than reactionary 'solutions' as the one covered here. While figuring out whether it's a good answer or a bad one takes the same effort, it's the choice of words I referred to.

Comment: Let me put it this way. Users who properly use chatgpt to assist creating their answer are creating answers that are indistinguishable from answers that aren't assisted by GPT at all. if they're indistinguishable  we clearly can't do anything about them.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi the OP clearly mentions: "as well as using an AI generator to "reword" your answers." I made very clear I obviously opposed copying answers straight from AI and it should be considered a draft at best.

Comment: @Cerbrus "Your last paragraph assumes users are honest. They're not. " Fair enough. In which case it's my opinion said users should be educated and addressed directly. Rather than "Don't use Chat GPT" I'd prefer "How to use Chat GPT" or "Best practices when using AI to assist in writing questions and answers".

Comment: If users need to be told *how* to use chatgpt to write their answers they're clearly using it for the wrong reasons. I don't think a guide would help, given the existing guidance we have for writing questions and answers is largely ignored anyway.

Comment: @Kevin B Entirely agree with that last comment. "Users who properly use chatgpt to assist creating their answer" kinda says it all doesn't it. ChatGPT can be properly used to assist in creating answers [and questions] indistinguishable from pure human answers and thus as good.

Comment: I mean, you're missing the point, as i expected, ;) the correct use of chatgpt is as a research assistant or a last resort at getting ideas, not a code-writing service or debugging tool. It shouldn't be used to explain what code does or why it was written in the way it is without *heavy* work from the user in improving the output, given most of the time the output is full of useless or irrelevant information such as "how an if statement works".

Comment: @Xartec If someone treats ChatGPT as a draft *and then improves on that draft manually* their answer is not the output of ChatGPT rewording it and not covered by the ban. The point of treating *any* verbatim output of ChatGPT as banned is that one cannot efficiently tell the difference between "small rewrite" and "complete rewrite" (or supervised/unsupervised, or whatever you want to call responsible versus irresponsible use) since ChatGPT by its nature *always* rewrites.

Comment: @KevinB I appreciate the replies. Seems you pulled that how to title out of context, the context being what I clarified with "Best practices", thus in the context of writing q&a on SO and in reply to Cerbrus' comment about dishonest users. An issue that isn't new or unique to this situation. People not reading the existing guidance is a again a separate problem on its own and and is no good argument against education users on the use of ChatGPT (which is inevitable). What I suggest is you define 'proper'.

Comment: @Xartec fair, however, it's still a solution that doesn't solve the problem at hand. (this ban, on the other hand, does.)

Comment: To put a counterpoint into context:  You don't become an expert at programming by using autocomplete or an IDE.  Those who contextualize this can do OK with AI-derived tools since they know that it's not a panacea.  The problem is that around the world, there are a lot of *terrible* engineers that treat AI as *the* solution.  This is why it has to be banned; a lot of people who copy-paste from this site don't get that they still have to validate what it is they're doing.

Comment: @Kevin B I think any attempt to define the 'correct' use in general at this point is premature. I used it for example to write and rewrite complete classes (obj C) for a nurbs generator and editor and find it's great at explaining the code in relation to the theoretic concepts and math involved. Not familiar with unnecessary comments in the code about simple things like if statements. I don't have the ultimate solution for the real problem, flood of rep-greedy users abusing it. This is just the beginning of something inevitable and I hope future measures are directed towards embracing AI.

Comment: @Xartec Many people here hope so too. Yet, right now banning the thing entirely is the best solution that is practical. When we - a we that includes you - have a good enough solution - it doesn’t have to be ultimate - then this *temporary* ban can go to the dust bin. Until then it is the best solution we have and this the solution we use…

Comment: @Xartec - ". In which case it's my opinion ..." - It's not our responsibility as a community to teach users how to effectively use ChatGPT as a tool. In fact, Stack Overflow is NOT a learning resource, or more specifically not a replacement for adequate learning from other resources on the user's part. For every "good" output you have been able to be generated with ChatGPT I can show you 30 outputs that appear right but were actually factually incorrect.  They appeared to an individual with zero domain knowledge to be correct but in reality, were factually and technically incorrect.

Comment: @SecurityHound "It's not our responsibility as a community to teach users how to effectively use ChatGPT as a tool." I agree, but then that's specifically not what I suggested. Guidelines for example regarding spelling/grammar aren't born out of a responsibility to teach people to use English effectively, it's about what ends up being posted as SO content. I think I already put forth my arguments about the quality of outputs. Again, flat out copying and pasting answers from any source should of course not be allowed or at least heavily frowned upon... like we already do.

Comment: @Xartec - Users already don't follow those guidelines.  Given the amount of inaccuracy with regards to ChatGPT I don't believe it's worth the squeeze.

Comment: *"potential competitor"*; whenever this potential transformed into objectively reliable answers, I will be more than glad to "retire" from SO in favor of these competitors.

Comment: Re *"because I ask the right questions"*: You must have super powers, then. Can you provide some examples of such questions? I find ChatGPT to provide about 70% wrong information (often blatantly wrong). Whether the time spend to check for accuracy is worth the 30% useful information is an open question. Perhaps as a tool to get unstuck when having starred for an embarrassing long time at a line of Perl code that doesn't behave as expected (sort of a rubber duck debugging effect)—a real story... It does better with (natural) language, but everything must be fact checked.

Comment: @PeterMortensen The anecdotal percentages you find do not match the results and statistics experienced by experts who research the topic extensively, they are not an accurate reflection of its accuracy so I wouldn't base any open questions or conclusions on that. It seems many of the naysayers base their experience on chat gpt 3 instead of 4. The former is already very useful it doesn't come close to the latter. Providing it with plenty of context (before or as part of the question) and dealing with hallucinations (and how to reduce those) are topics that should be understood *before* judging.

Comment: Any single accuracy number is going to be bogus because they depend on the questions asked, and possibly even on the expected scrutiny. The accuracy of, say, a random rep hunter throwing niche questions at GenAI is incomparable to an experienced asker querying with a common topic. The problem here on SO is that we have seen a lot of the former - we are dealing with the worst case, so best case accuracy is at best only tangentially useful. "Providing it with plenty of context and dealing with hallucinations" is something the average GenAI spammer just does not do.

Comment: There's no value in allowing answerers to be proxies for users using chatgpt, regardless of the accuracy levels chatgpt may be able to reach now or in the future. If the user wants to provide enough context to get an answer from chatgpt, they can do so themselves through chatgpt without the answerer's help.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi "Any single accuracy number is going to be bogus" It shows what you lay out in your example (almost, imagine you picked a fair comparison topic-wise), something we should be able to agree on by now and what I've pointed out in my answer and comments: the argument (used in comments and in the OP) that chat gpt isn't good enough isn't a great one. The reason that matters is what I tried to convey in my answer. To use an extreme analogy, it's like banning photoshopped results because people submit bad results to requests at a graphic design site. Which is fine, but that's not on PS.

Comment: @Xartec I just don’t see how your best case usage accuracy is relevant here when we - by and large - don’t deal with best case usage. Indeed we are banning GenAI results because people submit bad results. There has been a clear link between "GenAI result“ and "bad result" on SO. That this isn’t a causation or even requirement doesn’t change what is happening here. "GenAI result" still is a useful *discriminator* and that is all the ban is using it for - it does not question that GenAI can and does produce "good results“.

Answer (score -39):

TL;DR: assimilate, don't exterminate!

I would like to see a separate section for AI-generated answers, i.e. why not just embrace it by retaining AI-generated answers but keeping them separate from human answers?

That serves two purposes:

1. AI can distinguish AI-generated answers so that it doesn't feed them back into itself when they no doubt use ordered site content like this to generate answers.
2. AI answers can still be viewed and voted on, and maybe some will even become the accepted answer.

Comment: Why create more work, which will in turn create more work?  A feature like what you suggest requires time to be put into implementing it, and then once the feature is made, it will require even more time by curators to confirm the content is not invalid.  What is the benefit?

Comment: Specifically, following up on @Daedalus's comment, what is the benefit of *integrating* an AI service like ChatGPT directly into SO? People who want AI-generated responses can just ask the AI. That service already exists. People who want answers written by human experts can come to SO. We already provide that service. Why mix them? Beyond that, the reason we don't have a section for AI generated answers is the same reason we don't have a section for answers written by monkeys with typewriters: those answers are terrible. They don't meet our minimum quality standards.

Comment: Who's gonna pay for that? At the rate SO is getting questions, this would get very expensive very quickly.

Comment: Who said the answers needed to be curated? And who said ChatGPT is the only AI? Come on people, this technology is only going to get better. Where's your imagination?

Comment: We don't create policies based on our imagination. We create them based on the reality that is in front of us, that we're dealing with right now. (As for who said the answers needed to be curated: that's the whole design principle/goal of this site.)

Comment: Okay, give it a year or two and let's see how SO is doing with your policy...

Comment: And why do you care about how SO will do in a year or two, with this or any other policy? just use whatever tool that works for you. that was true in the past, it's true now, and will be true in The Future (tm). if SO dies because something else replaces it... so be it. I don't get all these answers worried about "SO should adapt, or it will be replaced by something else!!!".

Answer (score -39):

Why not have all new questions include an automated answer by an official Stack Overflow ChatGPT account, with a clear indication that this is the ChatGPT response? Maybe even show the user the ChatGPT answer before the question is posted, to reduce duplicate/low-quality questions.

This way, it just gets the ChatGPT controversy out of the way... ironically, by embracing it. If the answer works, then great. If it doesn't work, well now at least there is a Stack Overflow sanctioned answer written by ChatGPT to compare new answers against. But if there's already a ChatGPT answer, why would anyone answer it with another ChatGPT answer?

If the problem is users abusing questions with quick, low quality answers... well that's a different problem; those users will always exist.

Comment: Because, to quote the question post: _Overall, because the average rate of getting correct answers from ChatGPT is too low, the posting of answers created by ChatGPT is substantially harmful to the site and to users who are asking and looking for correct answers._

Comment: I don't get where you people are getting "the ChatGPT answer". There are multiple requests for this but they all fail at that point because ChatGPT doesn't give one answer. It generates statistically plausible text which can be different answers. Even if we assume that SO will show **a** ChatGPT answer at asking time and/or after posting a question, that answer need not be the same as you'd get from generating again. The claim that it would discourage others from posting a ChatGPT generated answer is basically unbacked by anything as it's not just the same text spewed out.

Comment: For instance, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ge2vN.png) are [two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dB3dg.png) different ChatGPT responses to your suggestion.  They're similar-ish, but about 20 seconds of editing could eliminate the most obvious parts.  Also, an answer being posted already definitely doesn't stop people from posting the same general idea again.

Comment: Self-contradictory (and wrong) within the same sentence: *"Is the correct spelling "StackOverflow"?"*. Response: *"Yes, that is correct. "Stack Overflow" is a popular question and answer website for programmers, and the correct spelling is "StackOverflow.""*

Comment: And it only wants to please you (right or wrong): *"Are you sure about the spelling?"*. Response: *"I apologize for the confusion. While "StackOverflow" is a common way of writing the name of the website, the correct spelling is actually "Stack Overflow" with a space between the two words. Thank you for bringing this to my attention."*

Comment: I'd support this.  Seeing a GPT generated "here is an AI's best attempt" next to user created content would be good for the site.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Good, how? Users asking questions generally don't have the best understanding of the subject, and a convincingly written ___wrong___ answer would do more harm that good.

Comment: @Cerbrus 1. It sometimes isn't wrong, 2. It competes with non-official AI answers, 3. It can provide a basis for someone's correct answer.  Also, labeling it as "AI's best guess" also gives a comparison between what humans answer and what AIs answer.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont if one wants AI's best guess, they can go to a resource that already provides that. It makes no sense to add a limited version of that to SO.

Comment: I like this idea. Having an AI user who would answer questions would be a fine way of training a model. The model could be refined by using up/down votes and commenting on its answers. Users could allow or ban the AI account from providing answers.

Comment: @KevinB Except, why not keep the eyeballs here?

Comment: The solution existing here would be half baked compared to a tool made for such use

Comment: _"It sometimes isn't wrong"_ Well isn't that great! Dude, that's not even close to being good enough.

Comment: I would support an experiment to provide a ChatGPT-generated answer on the site as an option for the _asker,_ but that doesn't mean it should be posted as an actual answer for future visitors to the question. When it works, it would probably help reduce the number of trivial and duplicate questions. (Flabbergastingly, that's apparently not what the company wants, probably because that would reduce advertising revenue; but it would help maintain the quality of the site, and reduce the need for manual administration.)

Answer (score -40):

**A Solution?**

I agree to most other answers, except the "*but there is no solution*" part. Also, I believe not all posters here understand that we're just at the beginning.

Hence, my proposal would be to attack, instead of defend.

Why not enable a feature that sends all questions to ChatGPT right after posting and display the result alongside the answer? It should be marked as the ChatGPT answer and users could opt to not display it.

- This would immediately stop people from abusing ChatGPT to farm reputation. The similarity would be too obvious, at least for the case where the question is just copy-pasted. If ChatGPT users enhance the question to improve the response, they already added some value and would not be in rapid fire mode anymore.
- It would give the benefit of the doubt that an AI answer might actually be valuable.
  By rating those answers the same way as rating human answers, we can see how they rank with others.
- Humans who write answers can refer to it and agree or disagree, if that makes any sense. They can point out whether there is only a minor mistake in the AI answer or whether the answer is based on a misunderstanding or predominant misconception on the internet (as the source of information).

I think this solution would scale for some time to come, but I am not sure, how feasible that is. Will Stack Overflow be charged, or can Stack Overflow sell this to OpenAI as a marketing hack? I don't know.

Comment: No. This has been suggested plenty of times already. Look at the other answers here as to why this can't work.

Comment: would you care to point me at it, because I didn't see it.

Comment: @Cerbrus, just found it on the next side, sorry for not being thorough in the first place. It seems indeed, that the solution could be difficult, but I am not entirely on your side. In the long run, ChatGPT will become less expensive and in the short term, it may wish to run this as advertisment the same way I can go there and ask questions to it.

Comment: For the point with repeated questions yield different answers: I would assume that the different answer will be somewhat suffering from the same problem. Might be difficult to compare word by word, but might be good enough to discourage abuse.

Comment: ChatGPT can offer *completely* different answers to the same question, including absolute contradictions of what it said mere seconds ago. The similarities between pairs of  ChatGPT answers are structural in nature, not content based; there is no use in having a "reference answer" to spot other generated answers for the same question.

Comment: "… in the short term, it may wish to run this as advertisment the same way I can go there and ask questions to it." That would be a rather poor advertisement. ChatGPT isn’t made nor meant for the kind of questions SO is made for. Expecting experts to waste their time trying to curate a stream of technical nonsense isn’t a winning story… (This is in essence something this very meta-question already said - there is just no capacity to manually vet all the content that ChatGPT has generated, let alone could generate, for SO.)

Comment: gotcha, and to be honest, I didn't expect the answers would be 'contradicting' and that sounds like a general flaw to me. It would at least make sense, if ChatGPT would enhance itself based on the content it receives, but I was not able to observe any valuable learning, based on my feedback. Even in the most stupid way.

Comment: @Ingo ChatGPT doesn't "remember" the conversations it has. As I said [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/422397/4014959) "ChatGPT generates plausible text, consistent with its training data and the prompt, but it doesn't know what it's talking about, and it has no way of representing or evaluating the truth of its utterances. Yes, it can say true things, but it can also say complete nonsense, and *it can't tell the difference*". It's designed to manipulate syntax, not semantics. Stephen Wolfram gives a good outline of how it works in the first of his articles linked in my answer.

Comment: See also now the train wreck at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425162/we-are-seeking-functional-feedback-for-the-formatting-assistant

Answer (score -40):

I have questions from ChatGPT and some of the answers were 100% accurate. Now Stack Overflow should allow accurate and acceptable answers from AI. It can save a lot of time.

It has come to experience that the logic, queries ([MySQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) and [MongoDB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MongoDB)) can take up to 12 hours. ChatGPT has answered and created queries like that in just seconds. (I have pro ChatGPT.) I have created an API that has multiple if-else and multiple queries with more than 500 lines of code (2000 ms response time), but with the help of ChatGPT, I have done that API with just 20 lines of code, with an average response time of 500 ms.

Now is the time to use ChatGPT and such platforms to speed up the development process. ChatGPT is really helpful to newcomers and for developing small-scale logic and functions.

Comment: You should really use a spelling checker. _"sorry for any gramitical miskates."_ does not excuse a lack of effort.

Comment: That aside, just because ChatGPT _sometimes_ generates correct output, doesn't mean it's a valuable addition to SE. Users can get that from the AI itself, no need to host it here.

Comment: I think  about 80% it generate correct answers. @Cerbrus

Comment: @Cerbrus some developers who native language is not english find it difficult to use AI tools for programming. they just search for error in SO and like in the ChatGPT so ChatGPT can't answer them . that why it well be helpful to copy-paste and answer and write a human explaination of that.

Comment: So you lack the experience to be productive in creating software, and you outsource that work to GPT. You're happy with what it produces all the time, 80% of the time. Yet you fail to see why others don't value your assessment as much. It's like you skip going to the doctor with your headache, because ChatGPT said it was probably nothing. Your claim is then that ChatGPT is way cheaper than a doctor but equally useful, and your proof is that you're still alive while not paying as much as for a visit to a professional. The world has become a worse place thanks to GPT.

Comment: this seems to merely repeat points already made in several prior answers here

Comment: @CodeCaster i think if the result is 100% accurate then we have to accept that. it not just about the copy paste. ask the chatgpt get the answer , test it and if it is correct then write you answer in SO to help others. becuase sometime ChatGPT correct answer while sometime it answer may be wrong.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/422392/chatgpt-seems-to-be-better-than-stack-overflow-both-in-speed-and-accuracy-what See [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/422393). That the LLM is fast and seemingly accurate enough for your use case is not a sufficient condition for letting people mass-dump AI generated answers.

Comment: If you are qualified to test chatgpt, just write an answer from scratch. If you can't write an answer that can be edited to suffient quality without chatgpt, you probably don't know enough to know if a chat gpt answer is correct or subtly but significantly wrong.

Comment: _"i think if the result is 100% accurate"_ And that's the problem. It's not. Not even close.

Comment: Please read this ; https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/423112/9570734

Comment: After you read all the answers here explaining why we don't need it on SO.

Comment: To be honest, your specific case is the exact reason I rail very hard *against* AI in code.  Someone who doesn't really understand what they're doing and can't really independently verify what the actual output of the LLM is would fare no better in a practical situation than someone who can copy and paste from Stack Overflow (ironically).

Comment: @Engr.AftabUfaq my point is that I don't trust you to validate an answer given by ChatGPT. What does "100% accurate" even mean? That it compiles/lints and runs without errors? What bar is that?

Comment: @CodeCaster Over-treatment is a very serious issue. Don’t go to the doctor because of simple headaches. If ChatGPT tells you that your headache is probably nothing, and it makes you cancel your plans to see the doctor, ChatGPT has made the world a better place. Calm down, rest, stop unnecessary medication, and stop wasting your doctor’s time.

Answer (score -42):

It seems like a slippery slope here.  Am I banned from using ChatGPT for doing my own research?  Certainly not.  So if I gain education by way of ChatGPT, am I then banned from conveying that knowledge by way of answering a SO question?  I wouldn't think so, as how I came to know something should be irrelevant.

So then, I suppose the question is "If I use ChatGPT to research a topic solely so that I can answer a question on SO, is *that* wrong?"  I can't think why it would be, so long as I'm properly curating the answer from my own knowledge.

And if that's ok, then the question becomes "How much does my answer have to differ from the ChatGPT answer that I used to inform myself so that I could answer the SO question?"

Comment: *"…if I gain education by way of chatGPT…"* Ah, I see this is a pure hypothetical, so we don't have to worry about the answer to it, because that's not going to happen.

Comment: _"so long as I'm properly curating the answer from my own knowledge"_ The fact that most people weren't doing this is why we're in this mess in the first place.

Comment: How you learn isn't going to turn into you write answers in a form that will 99% of the time be wrong but very well written.

Comment: Wow, 14 dislikes.  Guess I hit a nerve.  Funny how a dissenting opinion amidst a sea of minds that are already made up leads to downvotes with no real mention of why.  I'd love to know where the flaw in my logic lies.  I've already proven to myself that chatGPT makes a great research assistant.  So this response came from an informed position.  I could prove that statement if held to the fire.  But there's no interest here in evolving opinions here it seems.

Comment: Yea, i mean, funny how people express agreement on meta with votes, and how unpopular opinions meet a lot of disagreement. Almost as if the system is working exactly as designed. Funny! ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: So where exactly is the slope and why is it slippery? The announcement makes it pretty clear where the line is drawn and why it is exactly where it is. If you manually write about your own, verified knowledge then no one cares where that comes from.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi - If the metric is "copying/pasting from the chatGPT site", then you're right, it's not a slippery slope.  And by reading the notice of the ban, that's the way I read it.  The slippery slope would be if one wanted to take it any further than that...to say that one can't "paraphrase chatGPT output".

Comment: The problem is with people blindly copy-pasting content in bulk, without validating the contents... If a user were to take the effort to paraphrase the content (manually, not with some kind of AI), I'd presume they'd at least check if it's correct.

Answer (score -43):

It might make sense to consider integrating ChatGPT into the site engine itself.

This way, an answer received from it could be displayed in the least annoying way with a note indicating that this answer is not related to SF, was received programmatically and is most likely wrong; the latter could increase the possibility of drowning it in downvotes.

This will reduce the motivation to post similar answers, as well as create data for training neural networks (including in the minds of site users) that recognize the generated answers.

Comment: This has already been suggested in this post, multiple times.

Comment: Hm. In comments? Understood, please understand and forgive. :( I haven't seen similar answers.

Comment: What is "SF"? It would normally be [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/tour) here. Do you mean Stack Overflow?

Comment: You don't exactly have to look hard for it. They're all on this page. The answers are: [one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/421836/6296561), [two](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/421842/6296561), [three](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/421844/6296561),

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine: There's one difference this answer has from the others that suggest basically the same thing: this one would frame the AI answer as being likely wrong, and warning people not to post it or an answer like it. The others all suggested that the AI answer might actually help people solve their problems, and would get the same "benefit" without people having to post such answers.  That said, I don't think this is actually a good idea. but it *is* different; I nearly upvoted. (The dollars and electricity to AI-generate answers from the ask interface make this a non-starter).

Answer (score -45):

I was reading this post extensively and I'm really worried by the reactions.

The first thing I remembered was cab driver's reaction when [Uber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uber) came to my town. They reacted extremely angrily. They got together, persecuted Uber drivers. They used lawfare and political connections against Uber drivers, and they got to physical fights with Uber drivers to the point Uber drivers initially couldn't reveal themselves when they picked up a client because cab drivers where constantly looking for them and picking fights with them and their clients.

This scenery lasted a couple of months until they realized the inevitability of their fate. Some cab corporations even tried to educate cab drivers to give candies and treat client the best way possible. Nothing could resist Uber and today there are very few cab drivers resisting in my town.

Now when I read this thread I notice some very worrying trends:

First the level of ChatGPT answers on this matter (most upvoted answers) just shows how advanced it is. The sarcastic answer was terrifying.

Second, I saw that most people see the ban as the correct option, without having a reasonable way of distinguishing AI-generated answers from human answers. I think there are only two possible ways: letting users decide if it's an AI generated answer or having direct help from OpenAI itself. But I really don't think that humans will have the ability to tell one from the other. That leaves us with the only option of asking OpenAI for help. Has anyone contacted them yet?

Then the level of harshness with those who advocated ChatGPT integration (most downvoted answers) only reinforced the memory of cab drivers reaction. This worries me the most because disruptive technologies have to be embraced from the start or things will only get worse.

Adding to this is a very compelling pro-AI factor: the fact that some users are really fed up with aggressive answers from humans in SO and would much rather prefer to interact with a AI that treated them good. This is getting so critical that some people left SO altogether. I live in Brazil and I don't use the [Portuguese SO](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) because of extreme rudeness I got there several times. English SO is less bad, but I can assure you that if there were any other options people would embrace them *in a heartbeat*.

Just like I and many other people were fed up by cab drivers unethical attitudes like trying to figure out if the users knew the town so they could make a longer paths to the destination, not giving correct change, rudeness and many other things. That made Uber irresistible. As soon as it was available I never ever used a cab again. Since the first day it was on town.

Finally, remember that ChatGPT is learning and its answers will only get better and better. What are wrong or bad answers now will probably be the best answers in the future.

My advice (which will make my answer quickly get to most downvoted): If we can't get OpenAI to help, integration with ChatGPT is the only possible option. Create a clearly labeled automated answer for each post from ChatGPT and let users downvote it if it's bad as with any normal user.

This way users will have an immediate answer they know was AI generated and they will know there is a greater risk of being wrong, just like we know with automated translations of text.

I know this will be unpopular because it will make more difficult to build reputation points, especially if ChatGPT improves its answers. It's still better than losing all SO or making fruitless attempts to differentiate AI answers from human answers.

Any other option will not stand this test.

Maybe this means that some time in the near future SO will be no longer relevant because you can just ask an AI what the problem is with no need for human interaction. Well, if that is the case SO is already doomed and needs to rethink its business model from the scratch. If that's the case, it's better to embrace it as soon as possible. Humans can always help with comments and corrections at least while it still generates wrong or bad answers. But if it gets really good at it, there is no possible future for SO.

If you can't beat them, join them - a popular proverb.

Resistance is futile, you *will* be assimilated - Borgs.

**Edit**

So many rants, so many downvotes and the result is:

[image: Assimilation]

I have received a message from the Borgs. They said we were assimilated. 
But don't feel bad, Borg cubes are hard battle. You'll all feel fine in that Borg geek look. LOL

Comment: "*remember that ChatGPT is learning and it's answers will only get better and better. What are wrong or bad answers now will probably be the best answers in the future.*" then why don't we discuss this in the future, rather than the present. We act on what we have right now. And right now ChatGPT can generate content that is **very wrong and potentially dangerous**. Which is a big part of the reason why it was banned.

Comment: Instead of comparing people to physically violent folks, I recommend to actually acknowledge and address the points that have been brought up for the umpteenth time already.

Comment: Uber vs cab drivers is a flawed analogy. Using an Uber, you get to your destination, just like a cab. If you have an "answer" provided by ChatGPT or other AI generation (at the current level of capability), you don't have an actual answer. You have "eloquent bullshit" that *sounds like* an answer. It is, sometimes, an answer, but it's quite likely to be hilariously wrong, self-contradictory, and/or insidiously wrong such that it takes a subject matter expert to see that it's incorrect. So, it's not actually an answer and is likely to *substantially* mislead readers. That's not a replacement.

Comment: TLDR: Why should volunteers build and curate a library of answers that can just be generated on demand? Why generate just one answer when ChatGPT doesn’t provide the same answer consistently? Most importantly, why not just use ChatGPT directly?

Comment: I'll put it more laconically. You can ask ChatGPT whatever you want.  It might even work for you.  But you shouldn't be posting it here and representing it as *your* work.  Worse, you shouldn't really look to use it in your code and represent it as your work, since depending on what you're working on, you could get bit *hard* by licensing.

Comment: @Makyen I guess it would be like hiring a cab and having the cab driver confidently take you to some other destination and then drop you off. Eventually you might realise you're in the wrong part of town, or even the wrong town altogether.

Comment: I think AI is an important and useful tool; I use it.  However 1) including AI generated answers in SO, which is used as a corpus for AI training, creates a circular training; bad for AI.  2) Users can just go to chatGPT for their answers if they want an AI answer/experience; in fact I would suggest that 3) SO should remain a place where humans experts provide answers; it should keep it's distinction (and so then also remain a clean corpus for AI training).  4) Let's not homogenize SO and ChatGPT; they each have distinct advantages that go way if SO becomes a static repository of AI answers.

Comment: After ~30 answers that all state that AI is the future (I agree with that) and that ChatGPT is a big step forward (also agree), there is not a single post here that states a reason why ChatGPT answers should be posted on SO. Or how we deal with the fallout of people copy-pasting AI generated answers faster than they can be reviewed without any checking.

Comment: "But if it gets really good at it, there is no possible future for SO." Stack Overflow did not ban that AI. It banned the AI that's really lousy at it, but makes it really easy for someone who has no clue what they're talking about to post a dozen plausible-sounding, but wrong, answers a day.

Comment: There are ___so many___ misconceptions in here... And _none_ of them are not yet discussed in the answers here.

Comment: _"I saw that most people see the ban as the correct option, without having a reasonable way of distinguishing AI-generated answers from human answers <...> But I really don't think that humans will have the ability to tell one from the other."_ Blatantly incorrect. There's detection software out there that's plenty accurate to detect what is and isn't AI-generated.

Comment: _"This worries me the most because disruptive technologies have to be embraced from the start or things will only get worse."_ Why? Why should they be embraced? ___How___ should they be? Why is that an improvement to SO? That's just an empty statement.

Comment: _"the fact that some users are really fed up with aggressive answers from humans in SO and would much rather prefer to interact with a AI that treated them good."_ Why does that interaction need to be on SO?

Comment: _"remember that ChatGPT is learning and its answers will only get better and better."_ Blatantly incorrect. The "P" in "GPT" stands for _Pre-trained_. It's not learning, and it's not getting significantly smarter. Certainly not smart enough to provide answers with ___any___ measure of consistent technical accuracy.

Comment: _"If we can't get OpenAI to help, integration with ChatGPT is the only possible option."_ Again, why does it need to be __on SO__? Who is going to pay for that? What benefit is there to having SO embed the mediocre output, over users just going to ChatGPT if they want to?

Comment: _"I know this will be unpopular because it will make more difficult to build reputation points"_ That has absolutely nothing to do with this...

Comment: "_If you can't beat them, join them - a popular proverb._" We aren't setting out to do the same thing as a chatbot. we are not a chatbot. See also [The future role of Stack Exchange vs. emerging AIs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/386983/997587) and [Could ChatGPT be a viable way to answer people's questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384355/997587)- both of which I have written answers to.

Comment: Why are all the ChatGPT supporting answers analogies with things that have nothing to do with the subject matter?

Comment: This is a great answer. I've seen a few already that share this sentiment. In the near future, AI systems such as ChatGPT will outrank the highest ranking member of Stack Overflow. I believe that the notion of an AI user who could filter out questions, provide immediate response to users who optionally enable it would be a great enhancement to Stackoverflow.

Comment: "First the level of ChatGPT answers on this matter (most upvoted answers) just shows how advanced it is." - no, it really doesn't. Instead, it illustrates how vacuous typical marketing-speak really is. The top answer was labelled as being "for comedic and ironic purposes". Try actually reading the comments - you can easily see that people don't actually think the output reflects any insight, let alone being "terrifying". All the sarcastic answer proves is that people who wish to signal sarcasm in text are heavily reliant on certain conventions, as they lack tone-of-voice indicators.

Answer (score -49):

**Prediction:** SO will eventually incorporate AI trained on correct answers to clear questions.

================================================

Well, after all the down-votes and comments as if I had set a date for the end of the world, I noticed today, 15/09/2023, SO is now selectively offering its alpha OverflowAI search feature.

I expect that SO's use of AI will soon get into the answers side of things.

================================================

If it doesn't, the AI of Bing, Google or Baidu will make SO obsolete due to it being too slow to get answers to questions.

Of course, what is 'correct' in the training data needs to be truly correct, and not just what the OP decided among the early answers, as later answers may be more comprehensive or nuanced.

Raw SO answers would be poor training for AI because most answers are just not good enough or misleading, let alone the masses of unhelpful comments. The problem with AI is that it needs an eclectic and massive tranche of correct and accurate data for its training so that it is not going to be polluted too much by subsequent real-life data. SO is in a very good position to have its own AI, as it would not be sweeping up irrelevant or incorrect data that search engine AI would be incorporating now.

The role of moderators would shift to being more about checking the training data and AI answers than policing question quality, as language AI would easily pick up ambiguous phrasing and respond with suggestions, correct them, or flag for human attention.

Also, the increase in SO moderators aggressively closing newbie questions or commenters making snarky comments too often may just force more to go to AI answers. Popularity is relative to the help offered. Not providing help but insults instead will hurt SO when it is up against AI that is far more forgiving regarding the 'quality' of questions. See [The Tyrannical Mods of Stack Overflow](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IbDAmvUwo5c) for some examples, including some where even popularity didn't save them.

I know tech experts and mods on SO don't want to be customer service reps, but that really needs to be part of the role, otherwise the more forgiving AI will eat all SO's meals before it gets to see them.

We have so many free programming tools these days with documentation that is often unhelpful. Not everyone is building Apollo guidance systems, so do not need to know all the ins and outs of their language, but just want to get the task at hand done. Stifling a poor question instead of helping them work through their issue is going to kill SO for them. But that *is* a labour-intensive process, which is where AI could significantly alleviate the load by interactively converging on a result, or at least clarify the question.

SO has the opportunity to step up and meet the challenge of AI, or close off, and become irrelevant. The window of opportunity is rapidly closing!

**Response to comments**

1. Aggressively enforcing rules without taking the time to educate new users is what alienates new users.
2. Competent AI is NOT way in the future. ChatGPT was only released less than a year ago, and few were expecting it to do what it does, so I would expect capacity and competence to increase rapidly now that such AI is being put front and centre in search engines.
3. 'Why would we even have persistent AI answers at a future point when they can just be generated on demand as good as expert answers?' - that is exactly the existential question for SO posed by AI. The competency of AI can increase very rapidly with the right training, so unless SO adapts to the disruption posed by AI, it will be irrelevant, just because the current model is so heavily reliant upon competent human attention and a huge portfolio of loosely-structured Q&A decided by a popularity contest among those whose own competency is decided by a popularity contest. Populist 'truth' does not make for good AI processing!
4. Yes, some user and mods may not want to have to be like customer service reps, and so might be happy to have ChatGPT et al be the first point of call, but the big question is whether there will be enough users after that for SO to be viable enough to satisfy what Prosus expected of it when they bought it for $1.8b in 2021. Too few users and they will just have to write it off like many formerly popular sites before it.

When AI is given facts to prioritise upon (like BNF statements for programming languages) and training effort is made to avoid irrelevancies, the current SO paradigm will seem slow and archaic by comparison.

I don't say AI is going to be a universal panacea, but in the realm of sifting knowledge given an intended goal, its speed will trounce everything else that purports to be authoritative but is still essentially based upon hearsay, SO included.

SO will always be behind the 8-ball in getting its data up to standard given the amount of ad-hoc queries and its maxim that popularity is a reliable indicator of truth and accuracy. There is not enough unbiased humans to do that job.

Generative AI will not tend to find novel solutions to questions, but at least it does catch a lot of obvious coding errors and can make suggestions based on previous solutions. SO has been losing queries to the likes of ChatGPT, so ignoring its advantages would be folly on SO's part. They are using AI now, and are in a unique position to optimise what results are used to train their own AI. If AI helps take a load off of moderators, in a productive way, they should go for it. For some mods, that may be a challenge, but after all, they are volunteers with no voting rights when it comes to using AI.

Some have decried the incidence of wrong answers from AI, or that code may be insecure. Well, SO is based solely upon what the OP decides is the best answer, and everything else is a popularity contest. Nowhere is accuracy or security guaranteed by SO, because it is not feasible to do so, just because using people to do it doesn't scale. However, using AI to find the obvious errors will, like most computer-assisted technologies, up the lower end of answers, perhaps providing feedback as they are typed.

Comment: Newbie questions should not be closed here. No question is too "simple" for SO. If you see questions closed because they're "newbie", please raise a flag or otherwise let us know, because this is unacceptable. There are, however, plenty of questions that are [unsuitable for this site](//stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), for example because they are [off-topic](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), are unclear, are too broad or too opinion-based to fit into our Q&A format, etc. Also, the rate of questions getting closed hasn't increased. We've *always* aggressively closed off-topic questions.

Comment: As far as the snarky comments, I'm of two minds about that. In one sense, the *borderline* snarky comments are part of the "human" factor and part of what makes it fun and interesting to participate here. AI isn't going to be able to do that, but I'm not sure that's a feature so much as a limitation. As a nod to this, ChatGPT even has a feature where it can try to emulate different writing styles if you ask it to do so (e.g., "write a snarky reply"). For snarky comments that are over the line or otherwise unappreciated, they should be flagged for removal. Mods remove lots of these every day.

Comment: What does this prediction of some far away future have to do with the problems and ban we have *right now*? Why would people on a *volunteer* platform even be interested in "checking the training data and AI answers"? Why would we even *have* persistent AI answers at a future point when they can just be *generated on demand* as good as expert answers?

Comment: I don't think it is a good training set. *Practically* no one checks the technical merit of answers (each to their own precious reputation points). Just because it *looks* correct (or probably closer to reality: does not *look* incorrect) doesn't mean it is correct (just like ChatGPT's output). There is also a lot of noise in it: Most of it is low-scored duplicates with low-quality answers.

Comment: Pre-filtering and deduplication? Yes, that is a very good idea. That would also enable much better search results, on a separate (read-only) domain.

Comment: Language models don't _understand_ data. They don't comprehend factual correctness. That level of _comprehension_ is just not something current technology can even come close to. I don't see that happening any time soon.

Comment: I don't think we have to worry about Bing any time soon... [It's much more hostile than the snarky comments you've mentioned!](https://simonwillison.net/2023/Feb/15/bing/)

Comment: "*Competent AI is NOT way in the future. ChatGPT was only released less than a year ago.*" yet is not competent.

Comment: People made the same prediction about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ELIZA. When it comes to understanding the underlying concepts as opposed to the language used to communicate it, chatGPT has not fundamentally advanced beyond eliza.

Comment: @user1937198. That is just disingenuous. Eliza 'had no built in framework for contextualizing events', which ChatGPT definitely has and which enables it to pull information from multiple sources. Eliza worked for many people because it basically was doing active listening to script, but nothing more.

Comment: If only people would flag these inappropriate comments instead of making YouTube videos about them...

Comment: @Patanjali That basically means that ELIZA wasn’t trained automatically but "by hand". The basic idea of choosing the most likely response based on weighting the input words/grammar/patterns is surprisingly similar - the key part is that neither system actually understands its input and output based on the same semantics as a human expert or *technical program like a compiler* would. They’re just statistical models; ChatGPT is a more sophisticated model, but it still has very similar flaws.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi. A human expect and a complier are not equivalent. A compiler is unforgiving and is explicit. An expert always has a measure of incompetence, but MAY be able to make up for that with enough empathy and patience to help newbies with issues. The problem with SO is that there are not enough with expertise nor empathy or patience. AI can be made to have the patience, but its expertise needs improving through training and accurate data.

Comment: @Patanjali the problem with SO is that people come here and expect hand holding and tutoring, which is not what SO is about. Users don't *have* to come here for training. They can visit ChatGPT, if they wish, or many other places.

Comment: @VLAZ. And that *is* where AI will kill SO. Social media has shown that people like their help from one place, so if AI like ChatGPT is their first port of call, SO will be unlikely to be consulted. There is a reason why tech companies want the hearts and minds of schoolchildren; it embeds the brand in their consciousness. This is existential for SO because pretending that AI doesn't matter when it eats all the meals is foolish. SO will then be like the hospital with no patients = very easy to run, but failing its purpose.

Comment: @CodyGray. 'If only people would flag these inappropriate comments instead of making YouTube videos about them'. Did you view the video? It was mainly about the aggressiveness of the closing questions policy due to their supposed 'incorrectness', in support of which the snarky comments are framed. A more forgiving question policy wouldn't invite the comments.

Comment: I've watched the video before, yes. No, a more forgiving question policy would not solve the comment problem. If anything, it would lead to *more* snarky/rude comments because people have no other means of dispensing with off-topic, unclear, or otherwise inappropriate questions. This site has standards, and those standards are key to our having quality content. Like Wikipedia, you can't create an article about just anything, and it can't contain whatever you want to write in it. However, SO's quality standards are also enforced by humans, who sometimes get it wrong and/or are sometimes rude.

Comment: This is where flags come in, so that moderators can deal with the inappropriate enforcement of quality standards (i.e., incorrect closures), and/or users who leave rude, inappropriate comments. If people would flag these, then we could deal with them. However, if they aren't flagged, then we can't do anything about them, and the problem persists. Users are going to be wrong and do wrong things regardless of what the policy says. Correcting that requires other users to flag it. Relaxing the site's quality standards would only turn this into a complete cesspool, rather than an imperfect site.

Comment: @CodyGray. Yes, it wouldn't solve the current problem, if only looking at SO in isolation. But a 60,000kg gorilla just walked into the room and threatens to make the problem irrelevant by offering a much more helpful alternative, and one that is likely to be offered before any SO listing in organic search results if many use the AI option with a vengeance.

Comment: OK, so SO becomes a resource that people only consult when the AI gorilla can't solve it for them? Sounds good to me.

Comment: @Patanjali I don't think you really get it. SO isn't and doesn't need to be a tutoring service. If it takes ChatGPT to finally stop the tutoring questions coming in then that's a win for SO. Not a loss.

Comment: @CodyGray. That is the likely outcome, but the issue for you and SO is whether there will be enough choosing that to keep SO viable.

Comment: @Patanjali Look, why should we as users and volunteers care if SO isn’t viable anymore? Why should we want to be customer service reps? If there is a magical future AI that does flawlessly and patiently what SO does now with immense effort and frustration - great!

Comment: @MisterMiyagi. SO cost money to run. Prosus paid $1.8b for it in 2021. I don't know how they expect to make enough money to cover that investment, but if SO suffers a significant user drop off, they might end up writing off SO like has been done with giant tech sites that became largely unused before it.

Comment: @Patanjali you aren't hired as a consultant for how to make SO profitable. You have no insight into what the company does internally, nor what it plans to do. Your suggestions are thus 1. unneeded 2. not even relevant to the company. So, feel free to stop your financial strategy plans. Or just directly apply to SE Inc. for a position which would allow you to enact them.

Comment: @Patanjali Again, why should we as users care? If SO becomes obsolete - that’s actually great!

Comment: @MisterMiyagi. You should answer your own question. All I did was make a statement with some explanations. If you don't really care, why did you make comments, and why are so all so huffy now? We are all just chewing the fat here on a meta site, where opinions are expected to be offered.

Comment: @Patanjali Because there isn’t such a magical future AI yet, and as far as I can tell not in the next decade. Calling for a change that is both unnecessary and premature is subverting I disagree with strongly. That we shouldn’t care about making changes doesn’t mean that we shouldn’t care about not making changes.

Comment: This answer has survived relatively unscathed since Feb 17th... Editing rude language into it will only get it deleted, dude. I'd suggest you change the wording if you want this answer to stay here...

Comment: I'm unsure. Should I upvote for the prediction, or downvote for the rest? Hard choice.

Comment: Re *"SO is now using AI in its processing"*: Can you be more specific? Do you mean [OverflowAI Search](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426432/)? Or something else? In what way does it "clear" questions (whatever that means)?

Comment: an LLM is used in the processing of the answers to generate a summary, not in the process of finding the answers *to* summarize. though i'm sure the semantic search is also using another form of "ai" to find the answers, there's nothing groundbreaking about that... ML has been in use for search all over the web for many years. it's "about damn time" the search gets improved, though, the current iteration of this test only serves a very narrow usecase that doesn't cover the primary use of site search.

Comment: "_Aggressively enforcing rules without taking the time to educate new users is what alienates new users._" the site UI needs to do a better job at carrying the weight of teaching users. Aggressively enforcing the rules _does_ teach new users in the process, but it's manual work on the backs of volunteers and doesn't scale well, and leaves a bad taste in many peoples' mouths.

Comment: @PeterMortensen. I opened SO yesterday to have a popup announcing that AI was being used, but reflexively clicked it off before I had a chance to read its details. It hasn't popped up since. Presumably, was indicating that OAI is active now, rather than in alpha. If I see it again, I will try to resist the click and get the full text to put here.

Comment: @Patanjali if you read through the featured posts, you'll see the announcement that includes that popup

Comment: @Patanjali: As long as SO isn't using their AI to post answers, they are fully compatible with the ban on AI generated answers.

Comment: @BDL. Even if SO decides to provide their own generative AI answers, which they will probably do at some stage (search AI is just the front end), they can continue to ban use of other AI. SO has the advantage that they can train their own AI solely on their own data, thus reducing the 'pollution' from other data. SO already bans bots like GPTBot in their `robots.txt` from using their pages

Answer (score -49):

As GPT-4 is available for $20/month, [shouldn't you rewrite your policy](https://80.lv/articles/breakdown-creating-a-basic-doom-like-game-map-with-gpt-4/)?

---

ChatGPT is actually training. Given the fact that it gives wrong code (sometimes), it is normal to not accept answers exclusively written by the AI.

But this is only the beginning.

You are at the same point that chess players were when computer engines entered the board and started to play chess at a human level.

Chess adapted to engines, and Stack Overflow should adapt to AI coding systems, perhaps develop its own AI system (they have the site content to train its project; they could open it as an account subject to human democracy).

A few decades later, the chess engines have an [Elo rating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system) of 3300, while [Magnus Carlsen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnus_Carlsen) is rated 2900, so there will come a day when users will prefer to ask their code problems from an AI rather than a human (maybe soon). This will rid the site of bad questions that are not well-received and not answered. It will also help the site to evaluate its own content to detect errors (perhaps adding a warning: "The AI has detected a problem in this answer").

There still are chess players who would prefer that there weren't any engines, but by now chess engines have become friends of most chess players.

The AI coding systems should also become a friend of the community of programmers.

You are complaining about a first attempt, ChatGPT, the first project open to the public. It is important that AI is available for everybody, including the programming community.

Comment: How does this actually relate to the ban? It reads mostly like a vague outlook into an entirely hypothetical future which isn't there yet and frankly quite overoptimistic.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi because later AI migth answer correctly. Would then Stack Overflow revoque the ban?

Comment: We don't dabble in speculation here. Come back _when_ AI has gotten batter.

Comment: We can discuss that when that "later" actually comes and we know what those "later AI" actually are. From what has been discussed countless times already, I would wager no: If there is an AI that can just generate high-quality answers, there is no need to maintain a repository of those answers.

Comment: Soon. It has started to train. It took AlphaZero 4 hours to beat Stockfish (best non AI chess player engine) and chess is complex. You should start to discuss how are you going to use the AI. ChatPGPT is new just because it is .org and open

Comment: @MisterMiyagi So the site is going to see his traffic reduced (it is actually solving correctly easy programming problems and may have started to do).

Comment: That's not necessary bad. You migth focus on good programming challenges, instead of solving minor coding problems. And the AI can be a partner, a tool.

Comment: Chess is a whole different problem than natural language is. Solving questions it ___yet another___ different problem. Just because AI has gotten good at chess, doesn't mean it's gonna get just as good, just as fast, at solving problems. You're way overestimating the power of a __language model__.

Comment: Why are we even discussing this ___again___? All of the points in this answer have been covered already in older answers and discussions here.

Comment: "You are complaining about a first attempt..." No, definitely not, we've made a policy about ChatGPT and AI generated content *as it exists today*, which is nearly **60 years** after Eliza bot was released. While ChatGPT *is* a substantial improvement, it still *lacks entire categories of functionality* that would be necessary for it to consistently answer questions **correctly**, or even without being *hilariously wrong* and *self-contradictory*. The hurtles which AI still needs to surmount in order to be truly useful for answering questions are *hard* and will take substantial time.

Comment: @Cerbrus [It approves just a baccalaureate exam](https://elpais.com/educacion/2023-01-22/chatgpt-aprueba-por-los-pelos-el-examen-de-historia-de-selectividad.html). (Mars 2023)

Comment: @Universal_learner ChatGPT is good at most common *and* unique tasks covered by its training dataset. Most of questions that SO should address *aren't* in that category. A highly formalised exam is.

Comment: A Spanish paywalled article? Yea, no way I'm ever gonna read that.

Comment: Just the titular says three teachers examined ChatGPT of the University entering exam (at 18 years old) and approved just. It is like a teen, but I must admit he knows more than me of programming, and it is not speciallized in coding. I definitivelly find the tool usefull in my learning progression and would encourage the Company to create its own. Give this a couple of years and it will be answering coding questions better than you.

Comment: Then raise this point in a couple of years...

Comment: ok, I'll edit this, be sure

Comment: The current ChatGPT isn't OpenAI's first release. They were incorporated in 2015. So, look at where they were then and where they are now. From that, with *hopefully* some acceleration factor, you could estimate how much longer it will take, but even an estimate based on that would be *very* optimistic as to the time-frame for improvement. Will there be improvements? Of course there will. There nearly always are. The issue is that it's gotten to the point where *it's a problem for us and still has a long way to go until it's useful for what SO does*. We're dealing with it *as it is now*.

Comment: @Makyen I don't know how did it code in 2015 and I don' t know how AI works, but ChatGPT became a new, and now tons of journalists are using it instead of wasting his time in Google searches and website reads. Stack Overflow is also giving a lot of publicity to the project. Many students are now using it to solve their coding problems. I think that means it will improve more quickly than has been doing since 2015.

Comment: @Universal_learner I recommend to read up on how such an AI works, then re-annecdotes the examples you have just given. Those are quite frankly terrifying.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi For sure. I am a completely ignorant. But even the low quality, I tested it yesterday for first time and it was usefull to ask him some things about my applications code I didn't knew and that would be off-topic or too broad to ask on Stackoverflow. Google is going to substitute his searcher for an AI based system soon.

Comment: I mean, that's part of the problem. You look at it and see what you think are good answers/solutions... but you don't necessarily know what a good answer/solution is. New devs using this tool are running with answers from an AI that isn't built to provide accurate/good coding advice.

Comment: Even today, chess players have coaches. You can't learn to play good chess by just watcing an AI. Engines are a tool, not a substitution for human chess knowledge. Not to mention that as a chess player and software developper, I understand that writing code is a task several orders of magnitude more complex than playing chess. ChatGPT is the Scholar's Mate of coding

Comment: @David But [AlphaCode does better than 54% of programmers in a programming competition](https://techxplore.com/news/2022-02-deepmind-ai-tool-alphacode-human.html). Also, you can ask the AI "Explain me this" so yes, it can be a programming teacher, specially if you are a newbie as me. Stockfish doesn't analyze, it just plays. There is a sligth difference here.

Comment: @David With your experiene. Don't you think to ban ChatGPT use is nonsensical? It would be as if  Stockfish were not allowed as a tool to write chess books. How do you control that BTW? IMHO this is not a competition, we are diclosing knowledge.

Comment: @David This is as if we were in 1970 and Chess Stack Exchange said: Computer chess engines are banned because they don't sugest the best move. BTW, GPT4 is launched. So, what now? They should define a GPT4 policy? This is a nosensical. They shoudl just obligate the users to cite they use **this** AI or the other, and discourage AI-only answers as in Chess Exchange to answer Stockfish plays this is received badly and get downvotes.

Comment: @David Also...in Chess Exchange "Solve me this tactics" is not a well received question, as Stockfish does. Here it is going to be the same. "Why this code doesn't work" is no longer going to be a good question in most cases because the AI is going to solve that.

Comment: @Universal_learner Better than 54% means being totally average. Average for people that actually bother to do such exercises, i.e. many, many beginners. Exercises made specifically to be self-contained bites of challenges. Challenges with a huge body of available solutions. None of these match what [so] is striving for.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi So it is going to clean a bit the site, but not completely for the moment. I understand, I thought AlphaCode was faced to experts. The article doesn't say that.

Comment: @Universal_learner "This is as if we were in 1970 ..." No. This is as if Chess Stach Exchange said a) people are abusing chess engines to *massively* generate *hard-to-curate* answers and b) anyone who wants to can still ask the chess engine directly. Attribution doesn't remove the issue of volume and quality being too much for curators, and neither is lifting the ban needed for people to benefit from such tools.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi In Chess Exchange if you post Stockfish plays that here as an answer just get downvotes. You cannot hijack the Chess Exchange reputation system if you don't know anything about chess and you just use an engine to answer. You are dealing with this as if Stack Overflow were a chess competition between humans, where you can hijack the points system using an engine. Also, I wonder how are you going to detect a code (**not a text**) comes from the AI if it matches the documentation code?

Comment: What's so different in GPT-4 that requires re-evaluation of the policy? The article you linked is just the language model outputting some ___very___ common extremely simplistic "3D" code... That's not very impressive...

Comment: @Universal_learner Who cares? If a generated answer is indistinguishable from a "real" answer then there is no problem. False negatives happen, the cases were this doesn't matter, well, don't matter. FWIW, there is a chance a user posting code that an AI lifted straight from another source to get into problems for using code without attribution – not getting caught by the ChatGPT ban does not remove the other rules of the site.

Comment: @Cerbrus [I don't know](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/39696/does-gpt4-code-better-than-gpt3-5) Just buying a GPT4 license as I have a menthal illness and I can sugest it to be Sigmund Freud and talk with me as a schizoaffective. Just wondering how much is it going to help me disclosing my geology content in the apps stores as my apps are simply, nothign sophisticated. For the moment it is officially my apps translator, my ads generator in adsense and a complement to a my psychoterapist. All that for 20$/month.

Comment: (Magnus Carlsen isn't at 2900. That is his stated goal (to reach as the first one in history). Yes, with today's rating it could be rounded to that with two significant digits, but I don't think it is fair to do in this particular case.)

Comment: @Peter Mortensen 2852 today you are right. Also I think Stockfish is rated 3400 and AlphaZero somehow is 50 points better 3450 or so.

Comment: It is [GPT-4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPT-4), not GPT4.

Comment: That doesn't address 3300 being an unfair statement.

Comment: @Universal_learner the ban on ChatGPT is not analogous to a ban on Stockfish being used as a tool to write and review the lines contained in chess books. It's equivalent to a ban on AI-generated chess books, which aren't banned, but would be of no use to anyone even at a task where computers are much better than at writing code. "Solve me this tactics" doesn't really have an equivalent programming question type, but if it did, the difference would be that Stockfish actually gets the right answer pretty much all the time, while ChatGPT does not.

Comment: @David No that's a different question. There are others as if is going to be capable of writing a framework or a complet programming language. Here we are not writing tutorials, we are answering code problems or challenges.

Comment: @David You are right, and that's the reason of the ban. I just wonder if GPT-4 does. I am buying GPT-4 for 20$/month  and I will tell you if it does (I even don't care if my code is the most effective, I disclose the content of an excel as geology guides, if it does correctly and Firebase tells me it is giving no execution errors to the students I will use it). If I had AlphaCode be sure I would be writing my geology apps (that take me a couple of months to write) in a week.

Comment: @Universal_learner good for you. Just keep in mind that obviously wrong code is better than code that tricks you into thinking it's right but actually isn't.

Comment: @David I will check. I am anyhow buying GPT-4 for other purposes as a translator and a generator of my apps advertisements in adsense. Also [wondering if it is going to help as a complement of my psychoterapy](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/39696/does-gpt4-code-better-than-gpt3-5). I have Android and programming basic knowledges so I will just check if the code works and have sense with GPT-4. With ChatGPT (GPT-3.5) I agree it is not very helpfull. I need to tell it "No this is wrong code" lot's of times.

Comment: ...I wonder if GPT-4 can generate those *infumables* XML files you need to manually write for the design of the app. As for Java/Kotlin code, I will tell you if it does too. I am sure AlphaCode will do. [The best Google could do is to liberate some of DeepMind's AI products soon.](https://www.businessinsider.com/google-management-issues-code-red-over-chatgpt-report-2022-12)

Comment: Why do you care about this at all? if gpt or whatever does it for you, just use that? no point trying this site to be anything else.

Comment: "ChatGPT is actually training" to be clear, ChatGPT 3 doesn't use chats you have with it as its training data. You can't "teach" it something new and have it be able to use that new knowledge in separate conversations. Probably not an important point at this point but I thought I'd point it out.

Answer (score -55):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

If this issue gets too far out of hand, one possible way to mitigate this might be to integrate ChatGPT and show the user a possible answer before the question is even posted. Something like this:

> [image: Screenshot of user asking a question about removing an element from a vector in Rust, and the correct answer given through ChatGPT]

That would beat the answerers hungry for quick-and-easy rep at their own game. *If you can't beat them, join them.*

Comment: The two major problems with this is that the solution could be wrong/misinforming but work temporarily, and eventually, this service could cost money (it's currently in the "Free Research Preview"; though there are bound to be free clones of this caliber eventually)

Comment: Aside from that, it doesn't make the thing with wrong/incomplete/potentially dangerous (?) answers better.

Comment: The problem with this is that it provides answers which _look_ correct but aren't necessarily _actually_ correct.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luddite

Comment: It's all fun and games until `system("sudo rm -rf /")` appears and the user blindly runs it

Comment: If someone wants this, they should probably set up their own clone of SO and run it there. It's not like we don't have enough human generated crap to drown in already. | "If you can't beat them, join them." -- If we can't beat this, I'll go spend my time on something else.

Comment: This could be the perfect tool for the staging ground: *"Does this answer your question?"*

Comment: @bad_coder that's what this post is saying, and it has been heavily downvoted and explained why that's a bad idea. were you going for a joke on your name "bad_coder"?

Comment: It looks like it will need to implement in SO anyway, even if the result isn't show to end-user - just to detect answers that are generated by same tool.

Comment: Even better, for the FGITW: *"Is this your answer?"*

Comment: Aside from this just not being a good solution, the API ain't free, and at the rate SO is getting questions and answers, this will get very pricy very fast.

Comment: I'd rather see that money go to plagiarism checking rather than creating a questionable answer that may or may not be correct (but often isn't)

Comment: I don't know about you guys but this integration will be essential. Less unnecessary questions.

Comment: It would be the perfect tool for "Homework" questions. AI should be part of the answer to the question "What have you tried?"

Comment: @Spidy did you miss the part where AI writes crap answers?

Comment: In addition to the possibility of these answers being wrong, I assume the question author would, in many cases, be the *least* equipped to understand whether the auto-generated answer is correct – and whether it's recommending something dangerous/destructive (see Zoe's example). Subject matter experts who are posting answers and reviewing them might be able to judge the quality of the answer, but the question author usually *doesn't know what the right answer is* – that's usually why they're asking it in the first place.

Comment: This question is getting down voted and shouldn't. It's a valid solution in my opinion. This solves two things, 1-it puts the ChatGPT response directly into the thread which will deter others from using the response as their own. 2-It allows for collaboration and points out flaws in the AI. If AI responses are a security/safety concern, then disable it by default and allows users to enable it.

Comment: No, @mattmc. This just add the crappy generated answers in a even more official format, without any human oversight. Also, who's gonna pay for that?

Comment: @Cerbrus - Companies will find a way to pay for this. The question is, will SO be one of those companies? If not, fine. They will just continue fighting against the technology instead of working with it. It's only going to get better.

Comment: @forest that's what we do all the times, that's why we don't have a 100% accepted answers nor we accept all the answers that the community gives us, which is up to the one who asks the question, users should test it: I've seen many human answers which are good but not in scope, should they be fall under the same logic "look correct but aren't necessarily actually correct"? What's the criteria?

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine so you're saying you rather to check for illegal stuff and waste resources rather to use a tool that was done for programmers like us? Why  to be resilient about it and not promote it so in future we could have an AI that does precisely that (checks for plagiarism)?

Comment: @Sgdva I have no idea what you're trying to say. We don't need to wait for a future AI, we already have tons of plagiarism detection software, and it exists as numerous SaaS systems. SO hasn't integrated it because that's how they roll. If you're proposing implementing CGPT, my resistance to that remains that, unlike plagiarism checking, a CGPT can go unfiltered to a user who assumes the answer is good without anything dangerous in it, while a plagiarism detection bot, realistically, is half automatic and half manual review, and neither of those risks giving users dangerous code

Comment: Already now, people believe anything GPT says is gold, true, and 100% correct. As has been demonstrated countless times, that's wrong. A direct CGPT integration offering answers increases the risk it's perceived as accurate, and yes, at potential risk to unsuspecting users. Additionally, since CGPT exists, why would you need an SO integration? If it's so  good, just go directly to CGPT and ask it rather than taking the roundabout way of going via Stack Overflow, when SO doesn't own nor develop OpenAI nor CGPT.

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine when we go into Stackoverflow it is expected that we test the solutions, what's the difference on that regard with a 100% human response? On a side note: My mistake, I thought you meant that you'd like to spend on checking plagiarism (once it has happened) rather than invest on preventing, so I won't go further into that since I agree with you on that regard. Back to the topic: Who says that human wouldn't give us a dangerous code? Can you 100% vouch for that statement?

Comment: I can't, but unlike a CGPT integration showing users answers before they post, human answers can be rapidly intercepted and shut down. You can't do that with a solution that's only shown to a potentially inattentive asker. Checking plagiarism goes both ways, though; whether the check is done before or after posting is not particularly important when it's the same type of system that does the checking. The rest is implementation details

Comment: That's why is stated as a "does this answer your question?" Use it at discretion or something like that as legend, if that helps. About plagiarism: It is important to do it before it happens, so I don't agree on after the fact solutions, again, I agree with your opinion on before the fact. I can voucher that it has provided nice solutions these days and specific for my problem, as for example, regex strings, great tool.

Comment: There are a lot of comments here from people who seem to be under the mistaken impression that ChatGPT *only* writes incorrect answers, or even *mostly* writes incorrect answers. Neither of those are true IMO. ChatGPT is _way_ better than what you've probably come to expect from previous text generation systems, and you should probably try it yourself before jumping to conclusions. True, it absolutely does sometimes just make up complete nonsense that merely *looks correct*, but for simple questions it's actually scarily good a lot of the time. (E.g. See the mock up in the answer above.)

Comment: @Ajedi32 Being correct some of the time doesn't excuse the 100's of incorrect answers we've already found.

Comment: @KevinB That's irrelevant to the answer we're currently discussing, which doesn't propose posting the AI's response as a full answer pretending to be a post by a human. Read it again.

Comment: @Ajedi32 I have read it, and that doesn't change my response. It is overwhelmingly incorrect in questions that can't be answered by google's direct answer feature. This AI isn't for providing correct answers. that's literally not it's purpose.

Comment: @KevinB Sure, but what percentage of new questions on SO could also be answered by Google's direct answer feature (with a bit of effort on the part of the asker)? I'd argue quite a lot. Rather than have to close all those low-quality questions, wouldn't it be easier if the users would just decide not post it in the first place since ChatGPT already gave them an answer before they pressed submit?

Comment: All questions can be answered with a bit of effort on the part of the asker through google. However, SO is a Q/A Knowledgebase. We want the question to exist here if it doesn't already and will be useful to future users. The example cited here, while maybe solveable via google's quick answer or the AI happening to be correct in this case, if the question doesn't exist yet we'd prefer it get posted and a human answer it. If it *does* already exist, we don't need an AI to answer it, it's already answered. It's simply not the solution we need to solve our incoming question problem.

Comment: @KevinB Then post the question and the answer when the user clicks "Yes, this answered my question". There, now you have a quality question with an answer that has already been verified to work by a real human. You could even automatically mark the ChatGPT answer as accepted.

Comment: @Ajedi32 No, then we have a duplicate.

Comment: @KevinB You would have had a duplicate anyway. The only difference is that now you have a duplicate with an accepted answer instead of a duplicate with no answer.

Comment: A duplicate with no answer gets cleaned up. A duplicate with an answer does not and causes future duplicate questions to be less likely to find the already answered question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250243/discussion-between-ajedi32-and-kevin-b).

Comment: TLDR, we need an ai (or better search in general) that can find questions that already answer the question the user has. Generating new answers isn't a solution we need here. That's counter-productive to the product we are generating here. If another site or network wants to provide that as a product, more power to them.

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine, every post containing `system("sudo rm -rf /")` increases the chances the language models will include it in one of their answers. The doomsday clock is ticking.

Comment: “There are a lot of comments here from people who seem to be under the mistaken impression that ChatGPT only writes incorrect answers, or even mostly writes incorrect answers.” - The only answers written by CGPT I have seen, have been inaccurate and complete trash, so my impression is that the majority of not all CGPT answers must be similar

Comment: Guys, as much as you disagree with this answer, that's not a reason to delete-vote it! Don't abuse your privileges like that.

Comment: If you were even going to consider auto-generating an AI answer as part of the posting UI, it would need to come with huge disclaimers explaining where it's from, and a warning that it might be totally wrong, or worse subtly wrong or unsafe in some way that's not obvious to someone that needed to ask the question in the first place.  But that possibility is so large that, until AIs improve significantly, it's not worth integrating this.

Comment: Other commenters have covered the (likely) case that the AI is wrong, but this would also be harmful if the AI manages to get the answer right. The goal of Stack Overflow is to have questions and answers that are useful to everyone, not just the question asker. If the AI manages to get the answer right, this feature might discourage people from asking questions that will be useful to others.

Comment: I'm 100% behind the idea put forth in this post. There is an F-ton of potential in this technology in the future to stave off simple questions before they become questions and maybe even some thornier problems after they become questions as well. But what we have right now is just a really good word salad, not an answer engine. I went back to school to wait out the dot crash and spent some of it working with a team of Ph/D candidates working on a tool that parsed C code and offered advice to students. Worked about as well as you'd think, but this smurf is getting better. It'll get there.

Comment: The original post here is an announcement of a policy banning the use of ChatGPT to generate answers, not opening up a discussion for debate or requests to augment/mitigate said policy. A feature request for integrating ChatGPT into Stack Overflow to automatically generate answers thus doesn't really belong as an answer here, but rather as its own question. As such I agree with deleting this post as it is not an appropriate answer to this question. Please note, I am *not* voting to delete this post because I think the idea is a bad one or one that I disagree with (e.g., *not* a super downvote)

Comment: Why people treat stackoverflow users as a "innocent child"? If user is searching on programmers forum the minimum kowledge on programming languages, IT area or something related is expected. You cannot enter in a culinary chef competition without be a chef first or at least have some knowledge in culinary.

Comment: If you want to build some app/library from source using the build instructions provided by the repo, it's expected that you at least know what you're doing, you're not going to clone the repository and think that everything will magically compile automatically. Stackoverflow may miss a great chance to bring together the useful and the pleasant in one of the most innovative technologies simply because they think that the users on the platform are inexperienced people. It would avoid some repetitive questions like "how to do this" and without the need to close manually.

Comment: Like zoe's gave an example about when the user executes the command (sudo rf -rf /)... Guys what world do people live in? You don't need to have a basic linux course, much less need to use the system on a day-to-day basis to know what this command does. If the person performs the act of executing this command, it is the person's responsibility.

Comment: @IAsyncResult "*You don't need to have a basic linux course, much less need to use the system on a day-to-day basis to know what this command does.*" you seem to assume much higher competency than the average user has with the CLI. `sudo rm -rf /` is quite infamous so even non-CLI people tend to know about it. But there are also plenty of commands that aren't known, yet can result in non-obvious destructive and unwanted behaviour. Even if the intention isn't to be malicious, a simply typo can turn a correct command to destructive. Even with familiarity, the subtleties might escape notice.

Comment: @IAsyncResult you seem to assume everyone reads and understands code before copying / running it, it would be nice if that were to be true.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat So people are using stackoverflow and many other programming forums in wrong way just copy/pasting the code. Will not solve the problems. At least ChatGPT gives you the detailed information about that code. I recently went through a similar situation and could not understand a certain code for a game server, in the management part on the map, without even knowing the context, ChatGPT was able to explain it to me in a clear and objective way, it opened my eyes to see from another point of view (even simpler than I had thought) and it worked perfectly.

Comment: An example using a abstract syntax to talk with ChatGPT how to move bits https://prnt.sc/Ddgw5vzrnC1z see the huge detailed explanation about the answer.

Comment: @user4581301 That's exactly the problem. StackOverflow is not for preventing questions, it's for answering them. Not just for the asker but for everyone who comes after. It is undesirable for questions to go unasked, especially if they're quietly answered incorrectly in a way that can't be corrected like a human can.

Comment: @Different55 Not all questions are good. There are duplicates (which can be good if they make a better landing site than the original), typos, and trivialities like missing ';'s, in addition to flat-out off-topic questions. If a robot can answer those questions, they don't need to be asked and added to, and probably removed from visibility later to keep the noise down, the repository of questions and answers.

Comment: @user4581301 The amount of effort spent on trivialities would be much less than the time sorting out subtly but deeply wrong answers. The amount of harm done cannot compare to a trivial amount of time possibly saved.

Comment: @Different55 At this time, yes. The technology isn't ready yet. When it is, I say we use it.

Comment: @user4581301 As long as we're recognizing that it's current state is not ready and that taking measures like the ones suggested would be disastrous.

Comment: The big problem is folks are offering up language models that do not model programming languages. And even then more contextual smarts are mandatory. Token D having a high likelihood of following token tokens A, B, and C doesn't even come close to ensuring Token D really does make logical and grammatical sense in that placement. We'll need something a lot closer to real AI to do more than just fill in the blanks and perform the scut-work. I'm seeing the next step as something along the lines of the 90's RAD tools. generating code to automate repetitive tasks and common boilerplate.

Answer (score -73):

I get the point, but if you'll allow a lurker's five cents: I believe that ChatGPT has more to contribute to the platform than to hinder it. How about implementing the bot natively on the platform? Let it answer the questions and, if you want, put an alert saying "this is an automatic response and may contain errors". ChatGPT is helping me a lot, it's fast and practical. It may (yet) not be the right one, but it's enough to help get to the answer.

Comment: We've been [over](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/421836/6296561) [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/421842/6296561) twice already.

Comment: You clearly didn't read the other answers here: ChatGPT writes ___bad___ answers, contradicts itself in the answers, and is extremely costly to implement on a scale SE would require.

Comment: “How about implementing the bot natively on the platform?” - No; These CGPT answers are absolutely horrible and useless.

Comment: Aggressive responses are one of the things that discourage people from posting here, another advantage of ChatGPT. By the way, have you tried to tell him that the answer is wrong or bad? He usually fixes it. I won't insist, it's just my opinion. :)

Comment: [1/2] The problem isn't ChatGPT itself. Feel absolutely free to use it to solve your own problems. You may even use it during your research for writing an answer here. The real problem are users who copy-paste ChatGPT answer to SO without even checking if they are correct at a high rate. We had a user yesterday who posted 20 answers in a little bit over an hour, were at least a third of the answers didn't even match the programming language of the question or were outright wrong.

Comment: And who is going to tell the bot the answer is bad, if it's just automatically showing the author of the question (that doesn't know the answer) whatever it generated? Who's to stop the bot from giving a incorrect, or even dangerous answer? And who on earth is gonna pay for the bot?

Comment: [2/2] Unless you find a way that the person who copies the answer to SO makes sure that it's a good answer and tells the bot when he is wrong, this isn't going to scale. You can't rely on volunteers here to vote on these answers to get the signal. That's not going to scale on the size of SO.

Comment: “ChatGPT is helping me a lot, it's fast and practical.” - But the user’s based on output generated by CGPT are absolute trash answers. Low quality answers generated by CGPT are beyond unhelpful. Feel free to use it, just Don’t Post its Output, and experienced users in the community can tell when an answer is based on useless CGPT output.

Comment: If ChatGPT helps you, there's nothing preventing you from using it. But in doing so, you're fully aware that the answers you're getting are coming from ChatGPT, and you probably know enough to at least take them with a grain of salt. The issue for SO is people expecting relatively high quality, moderated SO answers could be getting low-quality ChatGPT answers, usually without knowing it, and that's not a benefit to anybody.

Comment: It's funny, but I think this is involuntarily giving the right answer. Sure, it's pricey and won't be added, but chatGPT answer as first answer would *not* be *the* answer, but a reference for any other answer to say: hey, this is an AI answer, if you're answering with this, you're an AI, and your answer will go straight to moderation (or, deleted) - (WOW, I've used the word "answer" more than anyone else here :D)

Comment: @nnsense "*a reference for any other answer to say: hey, this is an AI answer, if you're answering with this, you're an AI*" why do you think there is **the** AI answer here? ChatGPT can generate different answers based on how you've asked and/or based on your existing chat history in the session. Each can claim either A or B if there are two options available. It's not like any and all ChatGPT answers always choose A, for example. Yet again, the *only* thing ChatGPT does is generate *plausible text*. It doesn't take decisions on questions.

Comment: The topic here is: chatGPT answers are banned. Fine, so you need something to understand that an answer is indeed a taken from chatGPT, the only way I see is to have a reference, to compare. ChatGPT answers are more or less similar when the question is exactly the same, if someone used it just as reference to answer it's fine, the point is to avoid those which are copy/pasting from it. Can't think of any other way, filtering out chatGPT answers can't be just "guessed", that would create a lot of false positive.

Comment: The methods in use to detect chatgpt answers isn't producing a lot of false poisitves.

Comment: @BDL With respect to "You may even use it during your research for writing an answer here." - the replies & comments I got to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425211/current-position-on-proposal-for-the-responsible-use-of-ai-on-stack-overflow seemed to imply otherwise. Doing exactly that is what made moderators delete the original answer I had posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48119360/performant-2d-sdl-or-opengl-graphics-in-r-for-fast-display-of-raster-image-using/76472961?noredirect=1#comment134865427_76472961. Shows rules are really not clear...