# Is there a section for questions like "I've seen my question answered on Stack Overflow some time ago, but can't find that solution anymore. Help?"

Tags: support, search, old-questions

My current example: I want to catch all changes of an HTML text input field by redefining the setter like `oldSetter = input.setvalue; input.setvalue=function() { newValue==='bar'?... then do something; call oldSetter; }`

I know I have read the correct answer already, but can't find it anymore.

Should I just ask the question anew, or is there a section on Stack Overflow when I actually just want to find an old question?

Comment: Meta would be the place to ask, lacking the possibility to ask in a chat room based on your reputation points. How are you searching? I google "html input setter" and I get this as the top result: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40320686/setter-for-htmlinputelement-value

Comment: Note that asking a question anew might end you up with that question closed as a duplicate, which _can be_ fine as a signpost to the answer, but only after extensively searching for the original question and not finding it, or finding it and determining that it's structured in such a way that it's hard to find and that it's not editable to make it easier to find.

Comment: @Gimby I searched for "change setter of input" "change setter of input mdn" "change set function of input field javascript" and "catching all changes of an input field", once specifically for site:stackoverflow.com :/ And I searched on stackoverflow itself for "define setter javascript". I'm glad your linked question seems to what I was looking for! Ty P.S. And I read through many mdn-pages, where  I knew I once some months ago read the solution. But they change their structure so fast over there.

Comment: If you report precisely what you searched for, you didn't provide context to narrow it down. "input" is not specific to a browser environment. Note how I started my search query with "html". Google's algorithm is smart, but it can't read your mind :)

Comment: Using your search term I first get 3 to 5 stackoverflow links for "angular" questions about setters, only then the questions about html input. I solved my original question about the input setters now. (Though I still have lot of questions.)

Comment: Every upside has its downside I guess, Google personalises search results. That does not disqualify what I say though and might work more reliably in a different search engine.

Comment: Maybe you can search through your browsers history for the page since it should be in there somewhere.

Comment: @RobertLongson It was months ago, so firefox history could not help anymore, sadly: Years ago they crippled the history management of their browser. (Why ever. I have read dozens of complaints on bugzilla.)

Comment: ["guessing game..."](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Stack Overflow does not have "sections".

The site has a search feature. It is well documented, and offers many site-specific tools; but it still works very poorly a lot of the time (it can fail to pick up important questions that say `recurse` instead of `recursion` or vice versa, for example, even though it apparently does the sort of things internally that are supposed to avoid that problem).

External search engines are often a better choice. If you are specifically looking for a Stack Overflow result (for example, when trying to close a question as a duplicate), you may find it useful to add something like `site:stackoverflow.com` to the query.

There are [chat rooms](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/) that you may find useful - for example, look for one for the programming language you are using. Be sure to read room policies and rules before talking; but if you know you've seen a Q&A before, can describe what it was about, and *have a good explanation for why search isn't helpful*, people will usually be happy to help. Hopefully, someone will know exactly what you are referring to, due to commonly using that question to close duplicates. (I personally maintain a long list of "saved" Python questions, since `in:saves` is a lifesaver for searching for duplicates.)

As a last resort, [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) can help find some things. I once used it to find a question where the only thing I could confidently remember *that would uniquely identify the question* was some verbatim text in a comment I had left (and for various reasons, the obvious keyword search terms for the question were all giving me poor results).

Comment: I usually use google. | like to avoid chat rooms, but maybe I have to adapt. :/  | On SEDE: Nice, I didn't know this so far.

Comment: Keep in mind that SEDE is really a last resort - it will operate on cached data up to a week old, and you will have to be able to write an SQL query after reading through a bunch of documentation about the database schema, the particular flavour of SQL used, etc.

Comment: The OP would like a *human* search engine (e.g., to interpret the intent, point to FAQs, do the search for them, provide hints, etc.), not a *machine* search engine. Perhaps [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) (or similar) could be a surrogate for that. For [the past 12 years](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/10/04/asking-better-questions/), Stack Overflow has (also) been used as a *human* search engine (posting a duplicate question instead of finding the canonical question using *machine* search engines).

Comment: @PeterMortensen Of course it would be good if people first use a search engine (like I did, and read through like 10 MDN pages, because I knew I had read a solution there much time ago, too) before using ChatGPT or a new qeustion with a special "looking for old question"-tag.

Answer (score 1):

If you do a reasonable attempt at searching for the old question with the same problem, and are unable to find it, then feel free to ask it again. In the event someone is later able to find it, your question can be marked as a duplicate of that one and it will make it easier to find for others that have the same problem in the future. And if they can't find it, well then perhaps someone will come along and answer it for you.

The important part is you need to do a reasonable search, that ensures that you don't ask a question to something it was very easy to find the existing answer to, and ensures that when you do finally write it, you're phrasing it in a distinctly different way from the original question (assuming it still exists) that it will help others who have the same problem find the solution.