# Please show closable banner on top of the page linking to ChatGPT policy post

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, chatgpt

At the moment there is a great influx of ChatGPT-generated answers and that creates a lot of additional work for both elected moderators and other users that moderate the site.

It is very easy for newer users to miss the announcement on the side (Featured panel). Even seasoned users are being surprised as they didn't notice the new rules.

To reduce the number of AI generated posts and avoid mass suspensions for users unaware of the policy, please add a closable banner (similar to survey banners) on the top of the page linking to the policy announcement page [Temporary policy: ChatGPT is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned)

Make it clear in the banner text that ChatGPT is not allowed as many will not bother following the link and reading carefully.

Comment: A banner is being considered internally, for the record, but there's other concerns stalling it at the moment

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine I am not going to ask what stalls it, but the policy post shows clear community consensus and we need this more visible yesterday,

Comment: For transparency, the main concern is that a banner could encourage users who weren't aware CGPT is a thing to use it, which is the exact opposite of the goal. I still side solidly with needing more visibility myself, and SE does too, just without being entirely clear on how to best go about it. One current alternative proposal is showing a banner as part of the editor, or a popup when a post is started. Discussions around banners and/or alternative systems for informing users about the policy would be helpful either way though. We could be missing better options

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine Having warning in editor would probably be better and it would reduce visibility up to the point when someone wants to answer, but I don't know how much work that requires. Anyway, I don't think letting people know would increase number of people posting as some would surely be deterred from posting. And the ones that would risk suspension - well they cannot say they didn't know then.

Comment: "there is great influx of ChatGPT generated answers" - do we actually have any idea how many AI answers we are getting here?

Comment: "*For transparency, the main concern is that a banner could encourage users who weren't aware CGPT is a thing to use it, which is the exact opposite of the goal.*" this is understandable (known as [WP:BEANS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Don%27t_stuff_beans_up_your_nose) in Wikipedia), but on the other hand, various news outlets have made news about SO banning it (search for "stack overflow ban chatgpt"), so I guess the cat is already out of the bag.

Comment: @DavidG at least 500 answers were deleted in 1 day by a single mod.

Comment: @AndrewT. Interesting, that is a lot. Where did you get that info from? Also, I wonder across how many users that was too.

Comment: It has to be in the thousands at a minimum and more likely in the tens of thousands of answers. It also involves hundreds (more likely thousands) of user accounts. Though it's not possible to know exact statistics given that everything is being handled through custom flags and mods are still handling the "normal" things on top of this influx.

Comment: @DavidG from the network-wide mod chat room.

Comment: Re *"on the side"*: Do you mean under "Featured" in the right-hand (side) panel? (I am not sure about the name for that thing to the right.)

Comment: @PeterMortensen Yes, under Featured. I don't know the right name either.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We've now put this banner up (among other actions taken).

[This meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421991/new-help-center-article-and-banner-on-the-site-about-gpt-generated-content) covers what we've done today.