# How long will the ChatGPT-ban banner (2022-12-08) be visible?

Tags: support, account-suspension, chatgpt, system-message

A big thank you to the SO staff for the big honking banner (and linked-to Help Center page) we now (2022-12-08) have that says:

> [We do not currently allow content pasted from ChatGPT on Stack Overflow; read our policy here.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy)

How long will this banner be up?

---

One reason I'm asking is because the empowerment for mods to suspend even without prior warning would be quite different than regular norm for other suspension reasons (prior notice or warning usually given):

> Moderators are empowered (at their discretion) to issue immediate suspensions of up to 30 days to users who are copying and pasting GPT content onto the site, with **or without prior notice or warning**.

If the banner goes away, but suspensions without prior notice continues, wouldn't that be a little funky (in a bad way) in terms of fairness to violators? How else would they be expected to know about the policy? Not many people actually go read the Help Center.

Comment: "Not many people actually go read the Help Center" - So, maybe we need to add this text from the banner to the Terms of Use.

Comment: @kirogasa eh. Nobody reads that. Certainly nobody re-reads it. The only way in my experience to get some people to see it, emphasis on *some*, is to put the banner where the answer box is and only make the answer box visible by clicking a button. But still a lot of people will just remove the nag box without reading it.

Comment: related: [Testing an "AI-generated content" policy banner on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/426353/11107541)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The current plan, as it was discussed with moderators, is to leave the banner up for a week and adjust from there.

As I've shared [in this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421991/11092634), we'll continue to monitor this and talk to the mods, then make adjustments if needed.

Comment: can you update this? when exactly did it go down? what came out of the talks with the moderators? what-if any- adjustments were made?