# Testing an "AI-generated content" policy banner on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, announcement, a-b-testing, ai-generated-content

### January 10, 2024 Update

The experiment has now been graduated, and the banner has been enabled on Stack Overflow.

---

### January 5, 2024 Update

We will be graduating this experiment and adding functionality to enable the "AI-generated content" policy banner on Stack Overflow. While the variant group had no significant impact on answer rates, there was a reduction in posts flagged for AI-generated content.

**Results**

We ran an A/B test on question visits between September 21st and November 28th, 2023. Our control group did not see the new AI content policy banner, and our test group did. We split traffic 50/50 on 1% of total traffic and measured the conversion rate (the percentage of users who viewed a question *and* went on to post an answer to that question), on a session level, of visits to a question to posting an answer on that question. Sampling on the top of the funnel was due to the volume of pageviews Stack Overflow gets in a given month.

Here’s what we found, with the null hypothesis being there is no difference in conversion between the two groups:

| Group | Conversion Rate | Confidence Interval |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Control (No AI Banner) | 0.97% | [0.88% - 1.08%] |
| Test (AI Banner) | 0.98% | [0.88% - 1.09%] |

The test group only outperformed by 0.72%. With a p-value of 0.92, we fail to reject the null hypothesis that there is no difference in conversion rate between the two groups. This being the case, we feel confident that we are doing no harm to our answer rates by having the banner in place.

We also wanted to confirm that this banner reduced AI-related flags and flagged posts. We saw a reduction in the number of posts flagged for AI content and the total flags on those posts. Deletion rate on these answers was effectively the same for the test and control groups.

“AI Flags” in this case are flags that *reference* ChatGPT, LLMs, or the like, as we don’t have a distinct flag for this category at this time.

| Group | Questions Answered | AI-Flagged Posts | Flag Rate | Deletion Rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Test | 58,040 | 625 | 1.08% | 16.42% |
| Control | 57,953 | 707 | 1.22% | 16.49% |

**Decision**

Next week we’ll be graduating this functionality in order to enable you to address concerns with the rise of AI-generated content. As we graduate the experiment, the following changes will take place:

- All sites in the Stack Exchange network will be able to opt in (the feature is off by default, network-wide)
- We will initially offer two banner text options that all sites in the Stack Exchange network can opt-in to. Those options are the following:

  - `**Reminder**: Answers generated by Artificial Intelligence tools are not allowed on [Site Name]. Learn more`
  - `**Reminder**: Answers generated by Artificial Intelligence tools must be cited on [Site Name]. Learn more”`
- The banner will display once users select the answer field
- The [“new contributor” banner](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314287/come-take-a-look-at-our-new-contributor-indicator/314296#314296) will no longer be shown in the answer field
- All users will see this banner when posting an answer with the option to dismiss. Once dismissed, logged-in users will not see this banner again

**Next Steps**

We've created [a separate post providing additional context on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/395881/208518), and providing next steps on how sites will be able to opt in.

---

### September 21, 2023 Update

The A/B test went live the morning of 21 Sept 2023 as did the new [AI policy Help Center page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy). If you have any feedback or questions during this test, feel free to use an answer to this question to do so.

### Summary

We are planning to run an A/B test for two weeks on Stack Overflow in late September to draw attention to the site-specific policy about the use of AI-Generated content when creating answers on the site.

---

As part of the [agreements made during negotiations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/391847/moderation-strike-results-of-negotiations), we took the concerns raised during that discussion and worked on a design that we plan to A/B test here on Stack Overflow to see the effect it has on answering. We shared a preliminary design and plan with moderators a couple of weeks ago and are moving forward with sharing the plans for this project here on MSO. While the design is in development to be built, we still have time before we start the test to make adjustments to the text in the notice.

### The Test Design

We went through a few variations for placement and functionality to get to the design we're proposing below. For the duration of the test, we'll remove the "new contributor" banner ([example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKQWO.png)) on all answer fields for both test groups with the control group seeing nothing and the test group seeing the design below as they use the same space. Based on the outcomes of this test, we'll determine next steps for the "new contributor" banner.

We are planning to show this to all user types in the test group in the "Your Answer" area of the question page.
Here's what the design we're going to test looks like:

[image: The editor showing the banner design as described in the following paragraph.]

Directly under the formatting bar, there's a blue bar with text that reads "Reminder: AI-generated answers are not allowed on Stack Overflow." It includes a "Learn more" link to the Help Center page about AI-generated content.

For the duration of the experiment we don't plan to make the banner dismissable as we want to know that the test group was shown the banner each time they posted an answer.

### The Testing Phase

To test this design, we plan to do a two-week A/B test so that we can compare the new design with the current one and see if people in the new group have a reduced likelihood of posting AI-generated answers. We are currently only planning to run this test on Stack Overflow as it is one of the sites driving this change and the higher volume should help us assess the impact more quickly but are open to testing on or shipping to other sites once the initial tests are completed.

The metrics we plan to review include:

- Reduction in posts containing AI-generated content as determined by the number of validated flags and mod messages sent to users in the test group.
- Answer rate from test group drops at a rate consistent with the above metric with some allowance for cases that may go unflagged.

We will wait a week after the test ends before reviewing the data to allow community members time to flag and mods to handle those flags.

### What we need from you

While we're interested in your thoughts about this test, we're planning to start with the design you see here. Based on the results, we'll determine the next steps based on whether we're seeing an impact in the test group.

As noted, the current copy is a suggestion. We've considered a few alternatives but would be interested in if you have any particular suggestions you feel should be included.

Some notes for your consideration - since this will be shown to everyone in the test, the bulk of people seeing this banner likely have no plan to post AI-generated content. Going into detail about policy and reasoning should be saved for the Help Center - which we are planning to update before this test begins.

- The text should be short.
- The text should be informative.
- The text should be neutral.
- We only want to link to the Help Center page.

If you have any questions, please let us know - we really appreciate your help and look forward to working collaboratively to find a solution that meets our goals. Once this test is live, we'll update this post to keep you informed.

Comment: *"We will wait a week after the test ends before reviewing the data to allow community members time to flag and mods to handle those flags.'* I'm really not sure a week is going to be long enough. I have tens of flags for potential AI generated content with 1 pre-dating the strike. The team have a *significant* back log to go through, so it's going to take them time. A week to work through the flags isn't going to give meaningful results when, presumably, older flags are going to be being worked on more often. Unless for the entire duration, and a week afterward, focus will be on *new* flags?

Comment: Not to mention that it seems flags on deleted posts are deprioritised (which is honestly understandable), however, some (much?) of the community have taken it upon themselves to [delete content](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/426221/2029983) they suspect of being AI-generated. If these answers are deleted, and thus the flags not handled for some time, that could give some quite misleading results.

Comment: All great points and I definitely understand the timing of when we review the data can be quite impactful to the results we see - I don't necessarily think we need all of the flags to be handled to accurately gauge the outcomes, though. Depending on how many flags there are and how many get handled, we may be able to project the percentage of flags that would be validated to the remaining flags from the test period. It wouldn't be precise but I'm under the impression that's a pretty standard way of reviewing data.

Comment: Some new users seem to have problems to express themselves (read/write) in English. I think some might not understand the term *AI-generated* standalone. I'd change it to *Remeber: AI.generated answers (like from ChatGPT)....*. ChatGPT everyone knows... Just an idea...

Comment: I think the phrasing of the warning strikes a good balance between 1) being brief enough to not annoy legitimate users and 2) clearly articulating the policy.

Comment: Thanks - @Vickel I see your point. I do think we want to avoid naming specific companies in the UI directly but we can certainly include a non-exhaustive list in the Help Center information. I think we're open to alternative terminology if there's better options. :)

Comment: @Catija remeber **AI** in German is *KI*, in Spanish+Portuguese it is *IA*, I have no idea how it could sound in languages I don't speak. People are used to their "local" abreviation of Artificial Intelegence and might simply miss or missunderstand it in English

Comment: @Vickel Would you mind putting a bit more detail into your concerns and making them into an answer? I think it's worth keeping in mind and I'm worried they'll get lost in the comments.

Comment: Since you felt like you had to tell us where the banner was, the banner is bad.

Comment: @philipxy Describing images in text is generally considered a good practice, both for users of accessibility services and those who may be behind a firewall that blocks Imgur. While alt text is one way to do it, it can be nicer if it's worked into the normal text as well.

Comment: @philipxy I mean - I did intentionally not use a freehand red circle because I was trying to avoid that exact response - amusingly, I was doing the calculus of whether I'd get more points for the freehand circle or lose them for "having" to circle the banner to make it more obvious to people. Oh well! The description is not actually for people who can see the images, though - I opted to explain it in the post rather than hiding the image description in the alt text.

Comment: I'm all for describing what an image contains. I am constantly commenting to posters to that effect. I just didn't interpret text this way this time. In fact almost always when an image of a gui interface is put in a meta post people don't give the relevant text content in text as they should & I expect that is why I took your description this time as helping us find text in the image rather than just describing the relevant parts of the image. Anyway I commented after I went to the image & it took me a while to find the banner, then I read your description.

Comment: Now that there is a standard (heuristics) to fall back on when actioning a post for (possibly) being AI, why still this debate of allowed and not allowed? If someone doesn't like a post because they think it's possibly an AI copy/paste, show what actionable heuristics it falls under and take action based on that. And a lot of SE sites banned AI only following lead of some people's decision on SO. If you go to some of these per site meta's where they even bothered to have a discussion, some users (even mods) have expressed their view point that using AI for "help" is probably fine as long...

Comment: ...as is t's not a blatant copy/paste of something irrelevant generated by AI, something I have noticed many times that a lot of users are doing this just for solidarity (nothing against them, just a fact I have seen), so I'd say there really isn't a clear-cut definition of AI being allowed/disallowed on any site. What was the point of going through all the drama of the past few weeks and getting the heuristics, if we're just going to repeat the same "ai is banned" narrative because some people think that's the only solution?

Comment: @philipxy so, here's what I would have said if you had taken a more constructive tack and maybe asked about our design decisions rather than just calling them "bad" - as noted in the question, we did go through several designs and the feedback from mods did indicate some concern about it being easily overlooked. The goal of this test is to see whether something subtle but insistent can change behavior rather than immediately jumping to options that might be more overt but potentially more likely to cause a reduction in good answers. If it seems to go unnoticed, we can try something else.

Comment: For example, we'd been discussing with mods only showing a notification on a (high-character?) paste event but that could miss some people who aren't C&Ping directly from an AI tool (say using a script to slowly input text as if being typed) while potentially accusing someone who just happens to draft their answers in a text editor first of posting problematic content... so problematic both in TP and FPs. There's other options but we want to start somewhere simple and go from there.

Comment: @user13267 this text is for SO only at this point and will only be enabled on sites that expressly ask for it because they have policy that prohibits this content. The banner/notification was requested by mods and SO users repeatedly because the policy prohibiting the AI-generated content was easily missed and causing a negative impact on curators and moderators. My understanding is that some of the people who are mod messaged about this reply that they were unaware of the policy and some even apologize and state they will stop. As such, user education is needed, at least in the short term.

Comment: Again, "policy that prohibits this content" is itself a grey area in my opinion, as expressed in my comment previously. Who will make the request to have this visible on their site? The mods? Like I said I have myself seen mods expressing the idea of AI use for getting help in creating posts is probably fine, and if they now decide they want this banner just to show solidarity with what is happening in SO, that's a situation we are currently in already so I don't think anything will change.

Comment: If I remember there was a similar banner at the top of the page for a number of weeks many months ago whenever visiting the site, and the meta post about ai has been featured at the side for much longer at this point. Apparently that's still not enough for some people so the way I see it this is just something similar that they want for now, which they can complain about not being enough after some time. but again that's just my opinion

Comment: We generally require an indication from the **community** that such changes are deemed necessary - usually in the form of a meta post, @user13267. We can not perpetually have a banner on the entire site to notify users about this policy. Mods don't want to keep the policy featured on meta and that bulletin isn't visible on all viewports anyway - that's why we're doing this at all. It's a test. As has been stated, if there's no difference in behavior between the control and test groups, that's useful information. But having a banner up six months ago doesn't mean today's posters saw it.

Comment: I agree with you, I am not against the experiment. After all, nobody knows if this will be helpful until we do it, and see what happens. I was just thinking out loud that we had something similar on the site 6 months ago, we have had a featured link on the side perpetually for a long time now, and that's apparently not enough to satisfy a few users, so I just don't know how effective this will be for them. And we have heuristics for dealing with AI posts now so just use them instead of continuing the narrative of "all ai has to be banned"

Comment: Who will test it? Will you select a random people? If so, what algorithm?

Comment: @PetəíŕdTheLinuxWizard that's how we generally run A/B tests, yes. I have no clue what algorithm we use or why it might matter.

Comment: @user13267 "Now that there is a standard (heuristics) to fall back on when actioning a post for (possibly) being AI, why still this debate of allowed and not allowed?" Because we want to prevent users posting AI posts in the first place and reducing the workload. All AI is banned because it is not feasible determining the accuracy of every AI answer. This is not the only reason, but before we can even discuss others, we would need the solution for that one. SO community voted for banning AI posts with significant majority https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831

Comment: @user13267 If you want to discuss other sites in general and the process of determining whether AI should be allowed on some of them and under which circumstances, then this is discussion for main Meta, not SO Meta. Here all AI is banned for good reasons and you will just have to deal with that fact.

Comment: @Dalij "If you want to discuss other sites" no I dont, especially not with you for reasons I have already outlined to you in previous comment threads. I am only commenting my views on what seems to be a company post, only because they are asking for user opinions. How I deal with the fact that AI is banned for good(debatable) reason is not anyone else's business. I don't think raising an opposing viewpoint is disallowed, which is what I am doing. You can deal with the fact if it does not align with your view of the right solution, but please dont pull me repeatedly into pointless discussion

Comment: @user13267 This post is about banner, not whether we should allow AI posts or not. We have already determined that AI posts are banned on SO. I understand that you disagree, but you are in minority here and this my comment about you having to deal with it aimed at. We had this discussion, and community decided. Again, if you have the viable solution for dealing with AI posts on SO scale, based on correctness, then please post it. You keep wanting that we allow responsible usage of AI while you don't offer any practical solutions for dealing with unverified AI posts.

Comment: @user13267 You have every right to state your opinion, and just the same I have the right to state mine. I am not dragging you into pointless discussions, it is you who are dragging everyone else.

Comment: The title reads as if the banner will be (or has been) generated by some AI system.

Comment: Do the quotes help, @PeterMortensen ? Titles (much like newspaper headlines) often lead to shorthand that can leave them ambiguous. :D

Comment: Awesome. Pity it had to take 9 months and a major moderation strike to get to it.

Comment: Progress! Really thankful for all the hardwork that the people behind the scenes put in here, both on the community end and the corporate end. Thank you.

Comment: "*It includes a "Learn more" link to the Help Center page about AI-generated content.*" => Care to add that Link "somewhere" in that sentence...? => either on 'Learn more' or on 'Help Center page'...

Comment: @chivracq it won't be much use right now. The page needs to be overhauled, so the current content isn't representative of what it will look like during the test.

Comment: I find it strange that you don't include a link to the [policy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned) in the message. After all, the link to it would be right on the webpage anyways, and is very relevant to the message.

Comment: @ΞένηΓήινος in general we prefer to link to help pages when at all possible. The updated help page should contain all of the same info but wouldn't have the added distractions of the answers and comments confusing users.

Comment: I'm pretty convinced that in the end, we're going to, shall we say, lose this battle. Models will improve and one day generate correct answers that can't be distinguished from human answers. I'm all for this banning policy, but shouldn't we focus more on expressing its underlying essence so we'll keep valuing this essence, even when inherent policies change later? I mean, for me the essence is that answerers themselves believe in, and hold themselves accountable for, what they post. Well, maybe too remote from the current policy for now, but I'm sure it will get more important in the long run.

Comment: @GertArnold "...the essence is that answerers themselves believe in, and hold themselves accountable for..." Hm, sounds reasonable but how to test that? A test of faith in yourself and some accountability thing (like throwing in money that you may not get back if the answer is wrong)? I wouldn't know how to check that and I think that might not be possible.

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution We can't test that, but time will come we can no longer test "AI-generated" either (apart from some very obvious signals). At that point, all we have is to communicate this attitude clearly as a bottom line. It (somewhat) shows in the longer run in things like responding to comments on answers and improving answers when necessary (in stead of adding more noise), which currently I typically see missing on generated answers.

Comment: @GertArnold While I understand your points, they're somewhat tangential to this change. We may eventually decide to throw in the towel and remove this (or a similar) UI element but for now, we're trying to respond to the fact that the community is looking for help in preventing these answers or informing users about the policy in an attempt to reduce the impact on the sites struggling with AI-Generated content in answers. And that's OK. The text can change over time, too - if the policy does. It needn't be static.

Comment: @Catija I'm strongly in favor of triggering this banner on a high character count paste. There are some edge cases this wouldn't catch (but if you write a script to type your answers slowly, is a banner really going to sop you?), and I expect it would trigger a lot of false positives when, for example, pasting in a snippet from documentation. Even when the banner is triggered though, it's not an accusation. It's a reminder.

Comment: Would like to see this on the question box, too.

Comment: Don't the results just show the banner is completely neutral? No effect whatsoever? Surely a difference of 0.14%, isn't significant, is it?

Comment: @terdon while I agree, I'm happy with the _outcome_: explicit warnings.

Comment: @terdon, if it is exected to result in 8000 less gpt flags per month (if I understood described proportion correctly), then I'd say it has some positive effect.

Comment: I'm not objecting to the banner, I would have added it without any kind of experiment since it's a no brainer and if the banner had driven away people, then it would have been people who wanted to post AI crap so I would be happy to drive them away. I just find it strange that they went to all the trouble of running an experiment that shows the banner has no effect and then are presenting a difference of 0.14% as something real.

Comment: Where did the "8000 flags" come from, @markalex? I don't see that anywhere, and since the data basically show no significant difference in flag rate or anything else between the groups, I don't see how that conclusion could be reached. We're talking about 0.14 _percent_,  one point four percent of a single percentage point here. That isn't really a difference at all as far as I can tell.

Comment: @terdon, 8000 came from difference in flags near 80 * 100, because sample of 1%. (But of course it's extremely crude estimation). And regarding "presenting a difference of 0.14% as something real" I don't see that in this post. I see that they checked that such a banner doesn't drive away users/answers (and as result doesn't affect their bottom line) and they presented communities a chance to add said banner, if they (communities) so desire.

Comment: @markalex first, to clarify, I am not implying SE did anything wrong here. Or maybe just some wrong analysis, but no bad faith or anything. I'm just confused by the analysis. The post says "*While the variant group had no significant impact on answer rates, there was a reduction in posts flagged for AI-generated content.*" and they seem to be basing this on a difference of 0.14% which I have a lot of trouble accepting could be significant.

Comment: I can't say for sure how significant that reduction will be, as I'm not familiar with internal situation on the matter, and mods will be way better to comment on this, but any reduction, in my eyes is a plus. Additionally, 0.14% in the scope of SO mod flags, that count in hundreds of thousands, as I understand, still amounts to quite a something.

Comment: @markalex again, I am not arguing against the banner. If the experiment shows it makes no difference, that is still good enough a reason to add it. If it doesn't make things worse, I'm happy to have it. I am just worried by the apparent claim that the tiny difference seen is significant, since that suggests either that I misunderstood the results (which is entirely possible) or that SE misunderstood the results. So I am trying to clarify.

Comment: @terdon The 0.14% is the difference in *overall* flag rate for LLM issues, from 1.22%. That's a reduction of 11.5%. While not huge, it's quite significant. With 1,271,318 answers created on SO in the last year, the difference would be 1,780 fewer posts with LLM flags over a year. While not a huge number, each such flagged post represents a considerable amount of time spend by users and moderators to handle the issue, so is a good improvement. Hopefully, it will also reduce the number of LLM generated posts which are not flagged (as there are indicators there's a lot of those too).

Comment: More notably, IMO, is that this banner makes it **much** more likely a user will have seen the requirement not to use LLMs. The goal is to let those that are willing to follow the policy know about it, so we get fewer people *unknowingly* breaking the policy.

Answer (score 74):

> As noted, the current copy is a suggestion. We've considered a few alternatives but would be interested in if you have any particular suggestions you feel should be included.

as suggested by @Catija and to sum up my comments in the OP:

- Some new users seem to have problems to express themselves (read/write) in English. I think some might not understand the term *AI-generated* standalone. I'd change it to:

  ***Remember: AI-generated answers (like from ChatGPT)....***

  because ChatGPT everyone knows...

I've observed the lack of language knowledge many times during my many years here on SO. Communication with users who are not native/2nd language speakers is a major problem.

- Remember **AI** in German is *KI (Künstliche Intelligenz)*, in Spanish+Portuguese it is *IA (Inteligência Artificial)*, I have no idea how it could sound in languages I don't speak. People are used to their "local" abbreviation of Artificial Intelligence and might simply miss (in the sense of overreading/ignoring it) or misunderstand/don't understand it in English.

Comment: I think this is an excellent point, particularly since we have [evidence from the company](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/391626/historical-policy-on-the-use-of-gpt-detectors) that suggests questions that have historically been deleted as being AI generated are more likely to originate from countries where English is not the primary language. We should do everything we can to make the banner understandable for users whose first language is not English.

Comment: Maybe writing it out would help? *"Reminder: Answers generated by **artificial intelligence (AI)** are not allowed on Stack Overflow."*

Comment: FWIW, in French it's also IA and it seems to be the equivalent of II in Russian. To get foreign terms for things, I like to go to the Wikipedia page, look at the list of other languages, and hover over them to see the article title.

Comment: [The style guide says](https://stackoverflow.design/content/guidelines/principles/) *"Write for a 7th grade reading level."*. For example, *"Don’t complicate your ideas with business or insider jargon. Only use jargon when you have reason to believe it will improve user understanding."*. I don't know if it applies here or not.

Comment: Unless you’re Norwegian, and hear «AI» much more than «KI»… :( Damn, can my fellow people learn how to use their own language?

Comment: Yep indeed, 'AI'="IA" also in French (= "Intelligence Artificielle")... // Typo in the Answer, ... quickly corrected...

Comment: It should be "Machine Learning" instead. AI is the general term - we had AI before ML - ChatGPT is specifically using ML.

Comment: @wjandrea "Reminder: Answers generated by machine learning models are not allowed on Stack Overflow."

Comment: Since SO doesn't want to mention any specific product names in the banner (understandably), what about saying "GPT"? It does "resemble" ChatGPT and it is simply a NN model.

Comment: Is "Reminder: Answers generated by artificial intelligence (AI) language models such as ChatGPT are not allowed on Stack Overflow." too long?

Answer (score 10):

> The metrics we plan to review include:
>
> - Reduction in posts containing AI-generated content as determined by the number of validated flags and mod messages sent to users in the test group.

I'm wary of going by number of validated flags and mod messages to qualify what's AI-generated and what isn't. The number of pending AI flags is in the thousands (last I heard- about 5k), and they're not going to magically all be handled any time soon.

To really get accurate data to interpret, either you're going to have to go by something that doesn't take so long to process, such as just whether a post has been flagged with keywords about AI, or you're going to have to wait for those flags to be handled, which is significantly blocked by the slow progression of heuristics testing and approval, which is [significantly slowed down by the limited number of staff allocated to testing and approval (just Slate right now)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/394774/997587).

If you really go by whether a mod message was sent and flag validated, you will miss out on all the AI that is flagged but not handled by mods yet (because heuristics are severely underdeveloped (many are waiting for testing and approval)), and there's a whole heck ton of that.

Comment: Just launch it regardless of the results, the banner it's replacing was useless/redundant anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The term used should be "language model" - because it is more accurate.

In this vein I suggest the message be:

> Reminder: Answers from ChatGPT or other language models are not allowed.

*And maybe like a short wiki describing what hallucinations are and for that including the case where a [lawyer made a fool of himself using ChatGPT](https://www.forbes.com/sites/mollybohannon/2023/06/08/lawyer-used-chatgpt-in-court-and-cited-fake-cases-a-judge-is-considering-sanctions/).*

Comment: I think that "machine learning" is potentially too technical a term, and people may not understand that LLMs are "machine learning".  I would believe that they're more likely to understand that they are "artificial intelligence". (also, in the event that someone decides to generate answers by some sort of non-ML "AI", then...that also seems bad)

Comment: @RyanM Yeah well I suggested an alternative variant - implying the actual term - and citing an compelling case.

Comment: I don't think we should use that alternative, either, as we would also not permit answers from non-ChatGPT AIs.

Comment: @RyanM Updated my answer - and used "language models" instead.

Comment: "Language models" is perfect :D

Comment: The term used in the [community policy](/q/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned) is **AI**, specifically "generative AI" but in this context I assume "generated" implies "generative", though this isn't my field. On the other hand, the [official policy](/help/gpt-policy) only covers **GPT**.

Comment: A rose by any other name. Why does the term matter since no _AI generated_ content is allowed - the purpose of the banner isn't to provide some technically precise definition. If you can get some video game to generate SO questions then that's very likely off-topic and against policy too. There exists no situation where something AI-related can generate a valid SO question, so there's no need to split hairs over it.

Comment: Instead of getting mired in the technical details of what term is both broadly-understood and fully accurate (goals that are often at odds), especially because answers generated by any future or past artificial agent are presumably not allowed, regardless of the technical details, why not focus on what we *do* want? "All answers must be written by a human" or something similar.

Comment: @lmhamilt Well so we are technically accurate and not confusing. - besides I think the term "Language models"  is a good fit.

Comment: I work with AI professionally and I wouldn't describe ChatGPT as a "language model", at least not colloquially (but as a technical description, sure). AI and ML are the much more recognised terms (although "language model" has been gaining popularity). AI is more recognised than ML, and while AI is broad, it's also specific enough: I don't think anyone will try to post a self-driving-car-generated answer any time soon, but the distinction between pasting text as is from ChatGPT versus writing an answer based on the output of some model should be clarified under the "Learn more" link.