# Collectives updates: new features and ways to get started with Discussions

Tags: discussion, collectives, discussions-space

Over the last month, we’ve released a number of updates related to Collectives and Discussions. This post details some of those and also notes some upcoming changes.

### Discovery updates

#### Right sidebar module experiment

Today (November 15, 2023), we’re enabling the experimental right sidebar module previously announced [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426454/collectives-updates-to-the-community-bulletin-in-the-right-sidebar). This module uses matching logic (primarily tag-based) to suggest relevant discussion posts, collections, articles, and bulletins on question pages that are part of a collective. The aim is to increase awareness of and engagement with these collective-specific content types.

Based on early testing, we expect:

- 15-20% of all questions in a collective may have the module displayed
- Around 5% of all questions on Stack Overflow may have the module displayed

This experiment will run for 90 days and we will share an update to [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426454/collectives-updates-to-the-community-bulletin-in-the-right-sidebar) with the findings after the experiment concludes.

[image: An example image of a question page with the experimental module in the right sidebar, displaying a link to a bulletin, a link to an article, a link to a collection, and a link to a discussion post, with the links labeled accordingly and showing the title of each piece of content]

*The experimental right sidebar module on a question page*

#### Discussions landing page

On the Discussions item under the Labs section on the left sidebar, we’ve added a [new page](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/beta/discussions) that shows all discussions from all collectives. The list can be sorted by “Newest”, “Latest activity” (inclusive of new replies), and “Highest score”. New discussion posts can also be started from this page.

#### Activity indicators

Members of a collective now see blue dots indicating recently added content within a collective. The blue dots appear:

- On the left navigation beside the name of any collective with recently added content
- At the top of a collective’s overview page on the tab for any content type that has recently added content

The indicators disappear for a user once the content pages or list pages are viewed. Users can disable indicators per collective in user settings (Access > Your Collectives > Show new activity).

[image: An example image of a collective overview page with blue dot activity indicators across the top and on the left navigation; the image also highlights the left navigation link to the new page listing all discussions]

*A collective overview page with activity indicators displayed in the left navigation and across the top (blue highlight boxes) and with the Discussions page link on the left navigation (purple highlight box)*

### Features and related updates

#### Sorting and sharing

On individual discussion posts, replies can be sorted by “Oldest”, “Newest”, “Latest activity” (inclusive of new second-level replies), and “Highest score”. Posts and replies now have share links available, and you can view the timeline page for a reply by clicking “view activity” in the reply’s overflow menu.

We're also working on adding the ability to filter by tags for Discussions, both within collectives and on the new landing page.

#### Embedding a question or answer

When creating a new discussion post, the author can reference an existing Stack Overflow question or answer at the top of the post by pasting the URL into a dedicated field. Research with experienced users indicated a strong desire to discuss the nuances of existing questions and answers beyond what is appropriate in comments. The embedding option helps define a space for those conversations.

Check out [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/php/beta/discussions/77476914/what-is-the-rationale-behind-the-empty-needle-string-behavior-with-php-8-str-co) of an embedded question and answer in a discussion post from the PHP Collective.

[image: A discussions post with a question displayed below the post title with special styling followed by the text of the post itself]

*A discussion post with an embedded question*

#### Upcoming flagging/moderation changes

Next, we’ll be working on adding flag reasons to Discussions flags, so users can better convey their specific concerns about a post or reply. There is a separate [community conversation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426412) about curation and flag reasons, and the most recent list of proposed reasons can be seen on [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/426929/18279858). We welcome any further feedback there as we begin to build that. The flagging/moderation system for Discussions will remain separate from the Q&A system as we continue to experiment with this new type of contribution.

---

- **If you’re a member of a collective, have you found the activity indicators helpful in locating new content?**
- **If you’ve participated in Discussions, do you feel some could benefit from embedding a question or answer in a post?**

Comment: Is all this work on collectives is (still?) stealing development/release resources of the Staging Ground?

Comment: Are the collectives actually paying off?

Comment: Well, at least some of them, are *paying*, I suppose, @Dharman .

Comment: Will you measure reduced visits to meta/increased AI posts for users being shown the right sidebar module during the experiment? This seems to take the place of featured and hot meta posts.

Comment: @ErikA The experiment module does replace the Community Bulletin module on pages where it is displayed. We will be measuring effects on traffic to Meta and the Overflow Blog.

Comment: So it replaces **featured** announcements? That's an "interesting" choice...

Comment: hm. collectives get a unread indicator. meanwhile, the one year anniversary of [New activity indicator (bullet/dot) in Custom Filters no longer displaying](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383520/997587) has passed, and it is still in backlog hell "awaiting prioritization".

Comment: Design looks primitive compared to SO in general. I will be honest I want nothing to do with Collectives based on a 100% rate of seemingly low quality content

Comment: Thank you for the interesting update, embedding a question and/or answer definitely helps the reading flow of the topic as I do not have to open the link in another tab (and scroll through the page). The activity indicators also help a bunch!

Comment: the title of the discussion in the example screenshot is terribly ambiguous. whoever wrote it would benefit from reading [ask].

Comment: How often will discussions that ask about questions/answers *not* be questions that belong as a question rather than a discussion? I think the UI it creates looks great, it'd be even better if it were something that worked on MSE/MSO questions/answers rather than discussions. (also, funnily enough, this is already a feature of chat)

Comment: @starball "hm." Internal prioritization I guess. Bosses think collectives are great but the normal product is not, so they demand specific developments for collectives. Or an organization that has lost coherence and some units still produce output while others do not anymore.

Comment: I am a simple man, who come to StackOverflow to get help and to give one. Try to convince me to use either collectives or its new features first. One downvote is mine.

Comment: My folks, SO will never listen to what we say in Meta. It remains theoretical. They will keep adding and removing things we want/don't want. They just came here to _inform_ us what they wanted to get done. Downvote. I wonder who on earth wanted the OverflowAI, _enhanced_ search, collectives, and stuff. People wanted Companies, but they took it down.

Comment: @KevinB Feel free to do a standalone feature request for adding that question UI from Chat/Discussions to Metas as well. It does seem ideal.

Answer (score 6):

This box seems a bit weird, I get the point of what the team is trying to do here with bringing content to people attention that they may be interested in, but, why is the block showing me the *least* active discussion that hasn't yet been deleted from the NLP collective when I view this question?

[AI LLM model for analyzing agent - customer interactions of a contact center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77492435/ai-llm-model-for-analyzing-agent-customer-interactions-of-a-contact-center)

Surely it'd be more effective if it showed discussions that have proven to be interesting?

It's showing me this discussion:

https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/nlp/beta/discussions/76955830/langchain-vs-llamaindex-with-llms-for-data-ingestion

[image]

Comment: This is good feedback and we've noted scenarios like this where the tag matching isn't delivering the best result. If we do graduate this experiment, we'll look at what additional factors can be included in the logic without impacting performance.

Comment: Not only inactive discussions, but also some heavy downvoted ones. Browsing through some php questions I got a recommendation for a discussion that had -11 votes. So while I certainly was more aware of the discussions, I didn't really feel compelled to engage. At least not in that case.