# What's the status of the AI-generated content policy banner test?

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, a-b-testing, ai-generated-content

[Testing an "AI-generated content" policy banner on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/426353/11107541) says:

> The A/B test went live the morning of 21 Sept 2023 [...] a two-week A/B test

It's *way* past October 5th now... almost *two months* past it. I left [a comment](/q/426353/#comment978631_426353) over a week ago asking about it there and got no response.

- When is the testing going to end?
- When will the results / analysis be released?
- Has [my feedback about my concerns with the analysis method](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/427255/11107541) been heard? Will it have any effect?

Comment: Those responsible for running the test have been sacked^H^H^H^H^H^Hlaid off.

Comment: I guess the AI singularity took over SO but is not yet ready to announce itself to the world.

Comment: @MarkRansom Given the average quality of AI generated content around here, I guess it is still struggling to get "hello world" right.

Comment: @Lundin ah, but that's what it **wants** you to think!

Comment: This is the usual behavior. Reporting back on tests/experiments within a reasonable time worked in 20% of cases maximum in the past (even with different staff levels).

Comment: @MarkRansom Honestly that would explain so much :v

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Last week I posted [the test results](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/426353/1328704) to the MSO post, as well as [guidance for communities to request this banner be enabled on their site to MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/395881/208518).

Marking this as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) accordingly.

Answer (score 14):

On December 5, 2023, the results of the banner test were released on the Stack Moderators private Teams instance. These results included data on the efficacy of the banner along with details of what will be happening with those results.

The current plan is to publicly post an update here on Meta Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Exchange with the results in early January.

Comment: A heads up would have been nice. "Hey, we got the results! Still in the process of organizing/making decisions/etc, but ETA for results presentation is XYZ (date subject to change!)"

Comment: up to what date was data collected? did the data stop being collected on Oct 5th? Or does the analysis include data up until right before Dec 5th? Any word on whether [my feedback about the analysis method has been heard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/427255/11107541)?

Comment: Mithical's answer here is correct — we plan to release these results and share next steps in early January. Please keep an eye on the original post for those updates.

Comment: @JNat: Since the [other post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426353/testing-an-ai-generated-content-policy-banner-on-stack-overflow) has now been updated with the results (and a [corresponding announcement made on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/395881/sites-can-now-request-to-enable-a-banner-to-warn-about-their-policy-on-ai-genera)), should the [status-planned] tag now be removed from this post (and maybe an updated answer posted, pointing to those two posts)?

Comment: Thanks for the catch, @V2Blast — would have remembered to come by at some point as I cleaned my backlog, but appreciate being able to get it out of the way sooner ;P

Comment: @JNat: No problem! :)