# Has the 30-minute rate limit between successive answers from <125 reputation users been lifted? If so, can the help center article on it be removed?

Tags: support, answers, new-users, rate-limiting, chatgpt

On December 8 of last year, due to a flood of ChatGPT answers from new users, the rate limit for answers from users without 125+ reputation was [increased from 3 minutes to 30 minutes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421991/new-help-center-article-and-banner-on-the-site-about-gpt-generated-content). The [global meta FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide) was edited to reflect this change some time later.

However, just today, a user on the global meta edited this information out, claiming it's no longer correct. In [an answer they posted at the same time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/385820/377214), they claimed that on December 28, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74937572/phpredis-and-locking/74937701#74937701) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74937663/awk-invalid-char-in-expression/74937722#74937722) were posted by the same <125 rep user only three minutes apart.

As I don't have 10k+ reputation to look at the timestamps of the answers or the user who posted them, I can't check to see if their claim is indeed correct. I also searched this site for announcements of the rate limit being set back to normal and couldn't find any.

Has this site-specific override been rescinded?

If it has been rescinded, then [this help center article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answering-limit) claiming its existence needs to be removed.

Comment: Those 2 answers were posted less than 3 minutes apart, if they are basing their logic of that single example, their statement of needing 3 minutes is also incorrect.

Comment: @Larnu Yeah, if I had access to the timestamps (with 10k+ rep) I'd have seen the same thing. From what I can tell, the most likely explanation is that they were posted by two accounts which were merged.

Comment: That would be my assumption.

Comment: I'm of half a mind to roll back their edit on [meta.se] as well. Using a single example to change **an FAQ post** isn't a good precedent.

Comment: For transparency, I *have* reverted the edit, by editting the prior revision (and making no changes) and leaving reasoning in the edit description, rather than using a simple rollback.

Answer (score 10):

This rate limit has *not* been lifted. It is still in effect, and [the Help Center article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answering-limit) is still correct.

Comment: How do we account for the answers cited from Dec 28, then?

Comment: Merged accounts, change of IP +as the rate limit is IP not account based), caching, to name a few ideas, @KarlKnechtel  (the first 2 more legimate).