# What rules should there be for commenting on answers that are suspected to be AI-generated?

Tags: discussion, comments, behavior, chatgpt

#### The core issue

There have been a number of comments accusing users of posting LLM-generated answers (e.g., posts created using ChatGPT). There's also been instances of users (a user?) trying to [entrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entrapment) others (comments encouraging users to post LLM-generated content with the hope of getting them into trouble).

#### Alternatives to commenting

It's totally fine that users are concerned about LLM usage on SE, but posting comments along those lines isn't generally productive, and that's neither the intended use of comments nor a useful way to report a potentially LLM-generated answer. If you believe an answer is LLM-generated, follow [these directions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/421989), which can be summarized as "raise a custom moderator flag, and include as much evidence as possible".

#### Moving forward

Going back to accusatory comments: they aren't really helpful. If you're correct, and a user willingly admits it, then a mod is needed to address that user. But... if they willingly admitted it, chances are that asking nicely would have worked too, such as by asking "Hello userNNNNNN, did you write this answer using ChatGPT?". If you're wrong, then you've publicly accused a user of doing something they didn't do, which may lead to CoC violations or serial voting, neither of which are desirable. It can also lead to revenge-accusations, which are, of course, also problematic.

But, that still leaves the line somewhat unclear. For a few examples of comments:

- "[Temporary policy: Generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT) is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned)" (or the unformatted link)
- "Have you used AI (such as ChatGPT) to create some or all of this answer?"
- "This answer is AI-generated"

Where exactly do we want to draw the line between acceptable and unacceptable comments regarding suspected AI-generated answers?

Comment: If a contribution, is so easily compared to ChatGPT trash, it probably isn’t that helpful. Users should just flag commentary that crosses the line and downvote low quality contributions. Making a user who has submitted 10 answers in a 15 minute period, all that have a common format, that ChatGPT generated trash isn’t allowed in a nice respectful way is fine in my opinion.

Comment: @SecurityHound The problem is not the obvious trash, where you can downvote into oblivion, comment to point out blatant falsehoods or logical mistakes, and flag for mod attention. The problem is the answers that seem factually correct on first glance but there is a suspicious usage of AI-generate language patterns.

Answer (score 24):

The core issue as you have stated, posting comments accusing or asking users of using LLM in their answers, is not actually the core issue. It is just a manifestation of the real problem: obviously AI generated answers that are not promptly removed.

And it is not that those are not removed because people are not flagging them. It is just that those flags are not promptly dealt with. I am not going into reasons why is that happening because I am not a moderator.

If the AI flags on posts are not being handled for weeks then your suggestion that people shouldn't comment and should flag and leave the post handling to the moderators is obviously not working as it should.

While I fully agree that in normal circumstances we shouldn't be commenting under answers our suspicions about them being AI generated or not, the current situation may require additional actions including adding a comment after flagging a post, as this is the only way to warn other users including question askers that they should either avoid the answer altogether when looking for solutions, or at least approach the answer with caution.

As users we don't have too many other options for dealing with the scale of AI posts. Many users post more than one AI generated answer and downvoting them all is not possible as it steps into serial voting patterns.

Until handling AI posts gets back to the levels where flagged posts are promptly dealt with, people will leave comments under such answers and I would be against any rules that forbid commenting, regardless how messy those situations can turn up. It is far from the ideal, but it is currently the only tool we have that is working fast enough.

I wouldn't mind having an "officially" approved content for such comments to reduce the friction.

Comment: Anecdotally, I've seem to be coming across more possible AI-generated answers recently. Given that there is usually an increase in activity as people go back to school/university it's particularly unfortunate that AI answers are visible - it suggests to new and returning users that using AI is tacitly accepted.

Comment: I have no idea how the mod team is doing with all the backlog from the strike. Refusing to clean up accumulated flags caused by the strike may be part of the strike itself.

Comment: @Lundin I wouldn't be jumping to conclusions about why handling AI flags takes too much time.

Comment: I suspect the time taken to deal with flags is due to there being (a) a lot of LLM generated content and (b) no way for a regular user to deal with it other than a custom flag. I suspect there just aren't enough moderators to handle the increased workload.

Comment: @Lundin to my understanding, the flag volume was already overwhelming for the moderators before SE started interfering with their policy, never mind the backlog accumulated during the strike. We're talking about unpaid work from people who are outnumbered by regular user accounts almost literally a million to one (the "active" user count is obviously much smaller, but numbers are unclear.)

Answer (score 13):

> It's totally fine that users are concerned about LLM usage on SE, but posting comments along those lines isn't generally productive, and that's neither the intended use of comments nor a useful way to report a potentially LLM-generated answer.

It seems to me that this statement leads to only one logical conclusion, and that's to *not* comment on suspected AI posts at all, which I believe I disagree with.

> But, that still leaves the line somewhat unclear.
>
> ...
>
> Where exactly do we want to draw the line between acceptable and unacceptable comments regarding suspected AI-generated answers?

But that seems to run counter to the first quoted statement.

There's no *perfect* (or even good) answer here:

- *Any* comment indicating suspected AI usage, no matter how polite or benign the wording, can (but doesn't always) generate downvotes.  That's a significant downside to commenting

> posting comments along those lines isn't generally productive

- I believe that *reasonable* comments can serve multiple useful purposes

  1. First, they make the answer OP aware of the policy and that we suspect that their post is AI.
  2. In addition, they (hopefully) let the question OP know that there's a substantial risk of the answer wasting their time.
  3. They let other community members know that they should review the answer more carefully for issues.
  4. Often, questions with existing answers that "look good" won't receive additional answers.  The comment can be an indicator to other users that they should still consider answering the question.

> that's neither the intended use of comments

From the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment), comments:

> Request **clarification** from the author;

Nitpicking a little bit, but technically, a comment that says:

- This looks like it might have been generated by AI; are you aware of the [AI policy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1)?

... requests clarification from the user.

> Leave **constructive criticism** that guides the author in improving the post;

And sometimes *deletion* is the proper way to "improve" the post ;-), and I'm thinking about this even apart from AI.  If a post is off-topic, a polite statement recommending that the user delete it here and post it on a more appropriate SE site can be useful information that "improves the post".

In the case of AI, a polite comment recommending deletion can be considered constructive criticism as well.

Answer (score 5):

Here's what I personally think is okay and have been doing (this is not a recommendation to do the same, and I am not pretending to speak with any authority here):

- If I'm confident that a post is in violation of the AI-generated-content policy **and** I notice that the user has only posted a small number of such posts and hasn't continued in recent days, (in addition to mod flagging,) I post a comment simply linking to the policy. I usually use [Temporary policy: Generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT) is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/11107541), but one could equally well use https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy. For users who have a long streak of such posts, I don't bother with engaging them myself (I hypothesize that such users are more likely to take retaliatory actions or deny their violation of policy)
- If I'm not confident enough that a post is AI-generated even after taking a look at the user's history of posts, but I'm still feeling suspicious, depending on something that I can't put my finger on (mood?), I either ask other users whom I trust are equipped to make measured evaluations of whether something is Ai-generated to give their analysis / thoughts, or post a comment something along the lines of "did you use any AI at all in the writing of any part of this answer?". If the poster replies "no", then usually I just leave it at that and flag the post for mod attention to delete the comments. If they say "yes", I mod flag and comment linking them to the policy. Typically, the poster doesn't have enough rep to use chat, but if they do and I remember (I've been terrible at this), I use chat.

My doing this isn't a hill I'm willing to die on- just something I do because I think it's okay. I'm very open to being convinced otherwise, or being told to stop by someone I trust here (Ex. a mod).

Answer (score 3):

> Where exactly do we want to draw the line between acceptable and unacceptable comments regarding suspected AI-generated answers?

I propose that such comments should point out something specific that's wrong with the answer, such as an incorrect technical claim.  Especially one that the answer bases further arguments on, but if that's not the case then any will do.

And phrase it as "if this answer was AI-generated, [https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned%22).  The *if*, in combination with citing a specific problem with the answer, avoids the problem of seemingly baseless "accusations", I hope.

If there is a real person who didn't use AI on the receiving end of a comment like that, they'll hopefully realize that a reasonable person might think it was AI-generated if there's some conceptual misunderstanding in their answer, hopefully not take offense.

(There usually is some kind of fundamental misconception or lack of actual answer in AI answers that try to explain *why* something is the case, like  the dozen deleted answers on *[C# and SIMD: High and low speedups. What is happening?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56951793/c-sharp-and-simd-high-and-low-speedups-what-is-happening/75235162#75235162)* from Dec 2022 to Jan 2023 - see also my comments on several of those answers if you have the 10k rep to view them, for examples of comments like what I'm talking about.

That question is particularly bad for ChatGPT since it's comparing performance of two different implementations each of two different loops, but ChatGPT usually didn't even try to answer that and just spouted generic fluff about SIMD speedups in general, or spewed wrong nonsense.  Fortunately bad answers have stopped coming in on that question since Ben Voigt posted a partial semi-answer; probably that got it out of the list of highly-upvoted unanswered questions that made this a honeypot for catching people who post obvious nonsense without understanding it at all or checking for relevance to the question.)

---

IDK if this is a good proposal or not, so please vote accordingly and/or suggest refinements that might help.  (Or let me know why it's a bad idea.)

If an answer doesn't have any actual problems you can find, perhaps you shouldn't be commenting that it looks AI-generated, even if that probably is the case.  You can still flag it for moderators to deal with.

Other posts have mentioned that such a comment would attract downvotes.  If there's an error in the answer, downvotes are appropriate.  (Although if it's just a minor error that doesn't affect the main point of the answer, e.g. the kind a human might make if they do understand the subject matter, that doesn't usually deserve downvotes.  But if the post also looks like it's AI-generated, I have no problem with holding it to a high standard of correctness.)

---

One problem I can see with this is that it puts a lot of work on reviewers / readers to spend time reading what might well be AI-generated crap.

If there are other major signs of AI usage, like multiple long answers a few minutes apart, then reminding someone of the AI policy is a good idea in case they were somehow just naively coming back to their SO account after a break or something and trying to be "helpful".  If there aren't other clear signs like that, then we should be cautious and maybe just flag without commenting if there isn't anything to point to, or you don't want to take the time to look for something but the writing style looks AI.

Answer (score 3):

I don't really agree with you about the "intended use of comments".

The [help page about comment privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) reports the valid reasons for which we can comment to posts, with two of those three that are valid for these posts, in my opinion:

- request clarifications;
- "leave **constructive criticism** that guides the author in improving the post";

As long as we don't just abruptly accuse the author, and we instead kindly ask them (point 1) if they didn't just use AI to write a whole answer, we can also link them the AI policy, warning them about the reasons behind that policy and the possible consequences of ignoring it, eventually by pointing out why we believe that what expressed in their post is wrong, no matter how it was created.

This could lead to a user admitting their fault and actually improve their answer (I've never seen this, but I'm optimist that it *may* have happened), or, eventually, the post deletion on their part.
To me, any one of these alternatives **is** an improvement, both to the answer *and* to the whole post: in case of removal, nobody will see an invalid answer and attempt to use its contents.

Also, while I can understand the point about triggering downvotes, I wouldn't care too much about it:

- deleted answers revert the reputation based on its votes;
- based on my experience, most of these cases are about users who are new or have very low rep (if none at all), so the possible multiple downvotes would have little drawbacks but acceptable benefits, since they will also trigger more and more pressing notifications that would possibly get the OP attention sooner than later, possibly leading to a useful action on their part;
- multiple downvotes to a post or a user may get more attention to mods, or at least make their evaluation an easier or more considerate task (even if that may be a possible cause for a bias, but that's up to the mod capabilities and experience);

About the second point, I've seen some occurrences of these answers from users being on the platform for some time and having a limited or acceptable reputation (from 100-200 and up to a couple of thousands).

They probably are casual SO users that come here from time to time, and are not used to standard SO conducts or newer policies; they probably got a lot of rep just from a couple of good questions or answers, and they assume that such rep would make them experienced enough (we all know that there are users with high reputation only because they wrote the right question/answer at the right time). Then, they think that they could "help" without carefully considering their actions, or just want improve their rep for some reason: maybe they're bored and believed that they could easily "level-up", or they suddenly thought about their low rep and realized that they could do something about it with AI, possibly hoping that, by doing it, a new question of theirs could get more attention (you never know when you need it).

I tend to do more down than up votes, but I always consider DV implications along with user history, the given answer (and how much it can be "wrong") and their overall rep, including how they got it.
If the reputation is already at 1 and they don't have other (and recent) downvoted answers that would lead to it, I downvote, because an invalid answer is still worth a downvote (which is an important aspect for readers), and that wouldn't affect the honest attempt of a new user to get more rep, even if misplaced. And I also do it for higher reps (generally, above 100-200), because it doesn't affect that value so much.
In any case, if I do it, it's based on proper experience and by carefully checking with existing LLM.

Finally, while I could just *follow* the post, a kind comment warning about all this has a dual benefit: it warns the OP about the issue of their action before possible action is taken, and also triggers a notification if the user properly comments back, so I can eventually retract my vote. And, as said, if the post is deleted, the reputation is restored, so there is no harm done anyway.

Still, the flag is mandatory anyway.