# I failed this review queue audit on a plausible-looking answer, and I don't know why

Tags: support, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, specific-audit

I've started working on review queues, and I got [an audit today](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/33520469) that I didn't pass. I don't particularly mind that I didn't pass, but it feels like the audit was wrong. The audit was for an answer, and this was the question:

> I'm willing to switch from AWS to Azure, however I'm a bit confused on the differences between Azure Virtual Machines & Cloud Services! what I need is a small linux server, regardless the fancy names companies like to call it (e.g. EC2), I use it to run different small uni projects written in different languages.

This was the answer I reviewed

> Azure Virtual Machines (VM) and Cloud Services are both platforms that allow businesses to take advantage of the cloud computing benefits offered by Microsoft Azure. The main differences between them lie in the overhead costs, scalability, and security that they offer.
>
> Azure VM is a more cost-effective option but provides less control over the underlying hardware infrastructure compared to Cloud Services, which provide more flexibility for an added cost. Azure Virtual Machines offers you the ability to access remote computing power where you are responsible for managing the operating system, updates, and more. Cloud services, on the other hand, offer a higher level of abstraction. You do not need to worry about maintaining or updating your underlying virtual machine; instead, you can focus on developing and running your application

The audit system flagged it as:

> This post has severe quality issues. It is abusive nonsense, noise, spam, blatantly off-topic or otherwise irredeemable – readers will find it offensive or repulsive rather than helpful.

While I now realise that this answer was 10 years late (didn't catch that on the first pass), I don't agree that the post is "readers will find it offensive or repulsive". The answer seems valid, though not as complete as it could be, and certainly late!

Is there a review process for audits :) ? Similarly, what happens if you fail too many audits?

Comment: If you fail too many audits you'll be suspended from reviewing temporarily.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

*Actually*… the answer you reviewed looked like this:

[image: Screenshot of the answer, showing a hyperlink that stands out quite noticeably.]

The text "cloud computing" in the middle of the first paragraph is a hyperlink. It should stand out pretty well, given that it's underlined and colored blue. By hovering over it (or viewing the source or something like that—there's no need to actually *click* on it), you can see that the hyperlink goes to the following location:

```
https://technogeekscs.com/cloud-computing-courses-pune
```

Hopefully it becomes obvious to you at that point that it is spam.

That's how I figured it out when I reviewed this answer originally and nuked it for being spam. :-)

This is an example of [high-quality spam](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210448/we-need-to-improve-the-quality-of-our-spam): it's a post that *looks superficially plausible* (probably because it was copy-pasted wholesale from elsewhere), but has a spam link added/hidden in it somewhere. As a reviewer, your challenge is to spot this.

**Relevant Reading:** [How should I get started reviewing the Late Answers and First Questions/ Answers Queues?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288505/366904)

Comment: ohhhhh - It didn't think to look at the link, the content of the post seemed valid - I guess the audit was exactly right: "stop, look, pay attention" :) thanks for clarifying!

Comment: Not really related, but there have been a few that I reviewed that I had to skip because there was no option for "this answer isn't very good, but technically correct", e.g., the equivalent to a link only answer, where they've just dropped a block of (valid) code in with no explanation

Comment: The "this answer isn't very good, but technically correct" button is shaped like a downward-facing triangle—we call it the downvote button. :-) Flags should only be raised on answers that need to be deleted because they don't meet our minimum standards. [Actual link-only answers should be flagged as "not an answer"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265552). Relevant but code-only answers are just lousy answers, which should be downvoted, not flagged. *Sometimes*, they can be edited to improve them, but not always. Of course, skipping is *always* a reasonable course of action when reviewing!

Comment: I see - so that's separate from the review queue - just downvote and skip? That link you posted was very useful by the way!

Comment: @Zack Newsham: Even without the link, it should cause suspicion of ***plagiarism*** (or [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned)-generated) due to the near-perfect English, the verboseness, the (slight) [weasel wording](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weasel_word#Forms), and perhaps demographics information. Questions to ask could be: 1) Is this what a company would write to promote their product? 2) Is this what it would look like on Wikipedia, in a blog post, in the official documentation, or in a tutorial?

Comment: I was going to point out it looks exactly like the absolute garbage that ChartGPT generates. My suggestion if you believe that answer is acceptable, is to slow down in your review activities, and perhaps look at the question in another tab. Question itself is suspiciously off topic given the tag description.

Comment: It's not that the English is "near-perfect" (I like to think that I meet or exceed this standard every time I write an answer), but that it reads like marketing babble.