# Editing answers adding extra unknown characters to answers

Tags: discussion, bug, editor

I've recently observed it a couple of times. Whenever I try to edit answers, some extra unknown characters are adding to it, like so.

---

[image]

---

**Example in one image**

[image]

---

---

Is this a bug? Or anything to do from my side?

Comment: It looks like whoever posted the original code used [non-breaking spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) (or copied from an editor which uses them). Opening the editor is not _adding_ characters. They're likely already present. It's just when the markdown is parsed and rendered they display as, well, spaces.

Comment: You can clearly see the &nbsp; present as you open the edit view. They were thus present from before

Comment: Your GIF makes it clear the the version you wanted to edit had taken the unusual step of using non-breaking spaces, represented by `&nbsp;` HTML entities in the Markdown, in order to indent the code within normal lines of text, rather than use code formatting and regular spaces. When you changed that section of text to code formatting, the actual `&nbsp;` text was displayed. That's normal and expected. The issue is that those are being used at all by whoever edited the post prior to you.

Comment: Without a link to the post you were trying to edit, we really can't say what's going on other than your statements that you editing is adding unknown characters appears to be incorrect.

Comment: `&nbsp;` in code in (very) uncommon. Is it a signature of something? [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1)? Plagiarised code copied directly from webpages (blog posts)? Or not at all?

Comment: (Uncommon: custom formatting is usually using HTML tags `<code>` and/or `<pre>`)

Answer (score 8):

Not all new users are familiar with [Markdown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348746/were-switching-to-commonmark). But they do know how to use HTML. So they do. Instead of adding two spaces at the end of a line to force a new line, they use `<br>`. To not have their white-space collapsed, they use `&nbsp;`. And that works awesome in the preview and even after posting they see what they expected see. It becomes a problem if an editor tries to improve such posts by applying the Markdown for code, either by adding code fences or indenting the code-block by four spaces. Now the HTML trickery falls apart as they are  no longer seen as HTML  but as code that shouldn't be changed/altered/interpreted. See also [What HTML tags are allowed on Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites) to have a better understanding how markdown and HTML work together on posts.

For reference: This is the original source of the post that the OP had to work with: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/a62dea26-b3fb-40fc-bb34-a1f2e7f89478/view-source

You have two to three options as an editor.<sup>1</sup>

#### Option 1

Copy the code block from the rendered view (this works in Chrome, but I see comments that this might not work on Firefox) and paste that in the markdown and add code fences. I have done that below, click *edit* to see what it looks like.

```
images = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('img')

for image in images:
    imageClass = image.get_attribute('class')
    if imageClass == 'product-card__hero-image css-1fxh5tw':
        print(image)
```

#### Option 2

Surround the offending block with `<pre> {text here} </pre>` HTML tags. That does give you the correct style, but also some bonus white space. It has the "benefit" that you can leave the code block as is.

```
images = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('img')



for image in images:

    imageClass = image.get_attribute('class')

    if imageClass == 'product-card__hero-image css-1fxh5tw':

                print(image)
```

#### Option 3

Leave a (friendly!) comment for the OP with a link to [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and/or [Markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and ask them to edit their post to replace their code example with a straight copy/paste from their editor and then apply Markdown where needed.

---

<sup><sup>1. I had the expectation that option 1 and option 2 would render the same result. I can't be bothered or make a fuss about that not being the case.</sup></sup>

Comment: As to Option 1: I've confirmed that it does work in Chrome (i.e. that Chrome copies something that's not there) and not in Firefox (i.e. that Firefox copies the actual displayed characters).