# Add ChatGPT ban as a reason for deletion in the "Why and how are some answers deleted?" page in the Help Center

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, help-center, chatgpt

Stack Overflow currently has [a temporary policy in place](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) to delete answers that are found to be copied from ChatGPT. This is also confirmed and endorsed by [a separate Help Center page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).

At least for the duration of the ban on ChatGPT-generated content, I think it would be worthwhile to add this explanation to the ["Why and how answers are deleted" page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers) in the Help Center. That page gives a bulleted list of reasons why an answer might be deleted. I envision that a bullet could be added to cover ChatGPT-generated posts. It could simply link to [the existing Help Center page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy) that covers that policy.

Comment: Note that currently, SO just uses the network-wide version of that Help Center page, and doesn't have a site-specific override for that page.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Finally, answers may also be removed if they are copied in whole or in part from another unattributed source, including other answers on Stack Overflow. Answers copied from language learning models such as ChatGPT [may also be removed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy) even if they are attributed correctly.

[Done.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Well written, too, IMO!

Comment: Very nice; thank you! Please consider making "copied in whole or part from another unattributed source" a hyperlink to `/help/referencing`. (Or, alternatively, rephrasing to: "copied in whole or part from another source [without attribution](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing)", which to my ears seems ever so slightly clearer and also reduces the length of the hyperlinked text.)

Comment: @CodyGray Sure, changed.

Comment: Thanks again! Sadly, I can't offer another vote. Maybe some sunflower seeds?

Comment: In the [Temporary policy: ChatGPT is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/6574038) post, I couldn't find a policy on how/if to flag if a [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21496905/suntzu) only posts (bad) ChatGPT answers (100% score on https://www.zerogpt.com/), even with images of code, and users already complain. My best idea was down-/delete-vote and flag for moderator intervention. I suggest adding something easy to find in the temporary policy post. I post here because a question on this might be a dupe. Thanks.