# Is a ChatGPT answer reliable when asked about a given text generated by itself or not?

Tags: discussion, chatgpt

Stack Overflow already started banning ChatGPT-generated answers with [a temporary notice](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned).

In some cases, it is really difficult to distinguish between a human-generated answer and a ChatGPT-generated answer.

I found that if I ask ChatGPT with a piece of text within a quotation that it ever generated or not. The answer seems correct. Here is an example,

My question:

> "Asynchronous programming is a programming paradigm that involves breaking up a larger task into smaller tasks that can be executed concurrently, rather than sequentially. This can help to make programs more efficient by allowing them to take advantage of multiple CPU cores, as well as allowing tasks to be run in parallel without blocking the main thread of execution.
>
> In the context of reactive programming, asynchrony is often used to allow programs to respond to changes in data streams in a timely manner. For example, if a program is receiving a stream of data from a sensor, it may need to process each piece of data as it arrives in order to make the most up-to-date decisions. If the program were to block the main thread of execution while waiting for each piece of data to arrive, it would be unable to respond to new data in a timely manner. By using asynchronous programming techniques, the program can continue to process data concurrently, allowing it to respond to new data as soon as it becomes available.
>
> So, while reactive does not necessarily require asynchronous programming, asynchrony can be a useful tool for building responsive and efficient reactive programs." **- was that text generated by you ever?**

ChatGPT answer:

> **Yes, that text was generated by me.** It describes the concept of Asynchronous Programming, and how it is used in the context of Reactive Programming.
> Asynchronous programming can help to make programs more efficient, and also used in reactive programming to respond to change in data streams in a timely manner.

Now, I wonder if the answer on whether a piece of text was generated by the ChatGPT itself or not be reliable or not. If reliable, can Stack Overflow create a script to deny posts that are automatically detected machine generated? Wouldn’t it save some time and effort of people?

Comment: *"I found some moderators deleberately asking answerer post by post"* Do you actually mean [moderator](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) here? If a mod suspects that a post is made by ChatGPT, they have "better" ways of contacting the user than commenting on several of their answers. The mods have a wealth of tools available to them to detect ChatGPT answers, so they don't really need to ask the OP (publically). If they have proper concerns with the quality/source of the content, I would expect them to send a mod message.

Comment: What do you propose happens if the verification fails?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68818864/what-is-asynchronous-and-is-reactive-programming-must-be-asynchronous/75059682#comment132457602_75059682) is the comment in question; it was not posted by a moderator.

Comment: How many samples did you ask  ChatGPT "was that text generated by you ever?" and where were they sourced from? Without rigorous testing results I don't trust that it will be correct on this issue either

Comment: ChatGPT is a natural language generation model. It is improper to use ChatGPT itself as a detector of generated content. As for actual scripts to detect generated content, I imagine that at least some moderators are already aware of them.

Comment: For future reference, a mod can be identified by the "♦️Mod" in a box adjacent to their name, Sazzad. Don't confuse users (or curators as they are often refered to as, when talking about users that perform edits, raise flags, cast votes, etc) with moderators; moderators are a select few number of users on the site.

Comment: I'm not sure what's the point of this question. Are you bothered that someone questioned the authenticity of your answer, or that you didn't realize that chatGPT is banned before posting?

Comment: @blackgreen - the point is surely to provide a *proposed* solution to detection.

Comment: I just reran your example through ChatGPT and got the opposite result. The system isn't consistent nor designed to be able to detect its own output.

Comment: The whole reason that ChatGPT is banned is because it produces believable nonsense to the point that people adopt blind faith in it and thus will start to use it as the hammer to all nails. And then the proposed solution to catch people doing that is to... ask ChatGPT?

Comment: @Gimby the man who sold me the bridge apparently didn't even have it in the first place. I went back to ask for my money back. It went really well, he didn't have my money but he compensated me with some magic beans!

Comment: FWIW, '[GPTZero](https://etedward-gptzero-main-zqgfwb.streamlit.app/)' (a 'ChatGPT' Detector) gives "Most likely" (generated by AI) to the 1st Answer, and "Likely" (generated by AI) for the 2nd one...

Comment: @blackgreen no I was not bothered about why someone asked me. I was concerned about  some user’s efforts to find if the answer was auto generated or not. It was a suggestion saving times and effort for users as well as for moderators. However, I accept that there are flaws in suggested solutions after reading comments and answers.

Comment: @Larnu it was my mistake. I didn’t know if SO already deployed such type of detectors or not. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Did you know that questions about How ChatGPT works are on topic in [ai.se]? Ref. [Are questions about specific web apps, i.e. ChatGPT, on-topic on AI?](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2909/42632) They already have some questions like this.

Answer (score 22):

ChatGPT isn't self-aware.
ChatGPT doesn't know or recognize output. It doesn't *reason*, it doesn't *analyze* the input that way.
It also doesn't have access to chat history outside of the current conversation.

You just got lucky with your examples.

There are simpler, more reliable detectors out there.

Comment: The vast majority of "did you write this?" questions result in some speech about it just being a language model, that it doesn't retain a memory of previously generated text, and/or that it isn't able to recognise its own output. Whether it claims to have a definite "yes" or "no" at all is a complete wildcard, and not a guarantee

Comment: It's indeed just making up an answer. OP's answer on that question, when put through a detector, returns a **99.98%** likelyhood of it being fake.  Detector > ChatGPT.
It's also kinda ironic that they're drawing attention to their own rule-breaking here.

Comment: Indeed, it seems easier and equally reliable to just ask the [Magic 8 Ball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_8_Ball). The good news is, that's already part of my regular moderating workflow. :-)

Comment: I didn’t know about other detectors. In fact, I suspected that ChatGPT response would be too hard to detect because of its maturity. However, I want to delete the post as received so negativity but I cannot do it as there are contributors efforts. What can I do now? @CodyGray

Comment: I don't see any reason why this needs to be deleted, @Sazzad.

Comment: @CodyGray the post is getting too much negative votes.

Comment: That doesn't mean you should delete it, @SazzadHissainKhan . It just means people disagree with you. Why do you want to delete an answer which has been determined to be useful by the community?