# Should and could a GPT model be trained using Stack Overflow as a data source?

Tags: discussion, chatgpt

I'm aware that the creation of question's and answers using [ChatGPT is banned for now](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1).

Accepting ChatGPT's shortfalls when producing code solutions and snippets, it does a remarkable job for a model that has not been trained for programming. ChatGPT has been trained to chat and respond like a human. Indeed, the ChatGPT/Stack Overflow problem is that its answers are linguistically convincing and the narratives appear superficially correct (and sometimes are).

Are there any plans or projects to use the data held within Stack Overflow to train a GPT for answering programming questions? Tautologically, it would be the ideal data for training that model.

I am concurrently intrigued and terrified by what might be created.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that [so], among many other website, *was* used to train it.

Comment: Training it on Stack Overflow doesn't solve the core problem, which is that the bot has no way of knowing whether what it cobbles together is correct or nonsense. The most terrifying thing is that people truly have no idea what this technology is, what it does, or how it works. It's little more than a fancy Markov chain generator. It cannot program. Superficial correctness is not sufficient for a compiler.

Comment: If it were capable of citing sources when producing new answers and revealing possible duplicates when a similar question has been answered, that'd be quite useful indeed.

Comment: That's also very likely part of the problem, @KevinB . Some of the answers on [so] are truly awful (and written by human beings) and I suspect that ChatGPT had no idea how well (or poorly) those answers were received by the community. I have no doubts that it could easily regurgitate an answer that has some severe security issues, because an answer it was fed contained it.

Comment: See [Was ChatGPT trained on Stack Overflow data?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/38660/was-chatgpt-trained-on-stack-overflow-data) on AI Stack Exchange. TLDR: Yes it can.

Comment: @CodyGray After reading [GEB](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Godel-Escher-Bach-Eternal-Golden/dp/0465026567) I am convinced that our current computers are not about to become sentient.

Comment: Now I'm wondering if this soon to be deleted question is really this bad, or if there is extensive support for a [Butlarian Jihad](https://dune.fandom.com/wiki/Butlerian_Jihad). Yes I know ChatGPT does not think.

Comment: Sarah Connor? No, it's next door.

Comment: Context and intent are everything. When we get AI that can grasp that, I hope we get [Gort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gort_(The_Day_the_Earth_Stood_Still)) and not [Skynet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skynet_(Terminator)).

Comment: "Are there any plans or projects" - **By whom**? and **why ask us** about it?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, because I'm interested in both, if you know of any plans or projects and, what you think about the idea of plans or projects. Specifically, whether you think attempts are futile or, whether you have some philosophical or moral objection.

Comment: I mean, why would we have any more idea of the existence of those projects than anywhere else on the internet - for example, some appropriately on-topic subreddit? Perhaps start with a search engine? I would think that most people who attempted a project like that, would have some interest in advertising it, if it weren't purely for personal use or simple curiousity.

Comment: @user4581301 I'll take Optimus Prime myself.

Comment: @Gimby Always wondered about him. Anyone ever run him through the Sieve of Eratosthenes to make sure he lives up to expectations? So many people padding their resumes these days...

Comment: *"I am concurrently intrigued and terrified by what might be created."* - I am terrified that technology such as this will turn the movie Idiocracy into a documentary. Apparently, students are already starting to... "apply" it.

Comment: @Gimby, if teachers/assessors can automate the marking with AI the whole education process can implode in a self referential loop.

Comment: The bot is not smart. It just let's you know what it heard from a guy. It knows that certain phrases go together, but not which ones. For example, it can play chess, by simply producing moves it knows to be legal, but without any reason behind which moves were made and no ability to explain why they were chosen or what is actually happening in that game. It can give code and explain what the code does, but it doesn't actually know why it gave the code, nor what the purpose is. It is close, but it is not really up to snuff... arguably it simply cannot get there either.

Comment: Re *"it can play chess"*: But [it is not very good at it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8LZe0FJvRMo) (commented on by [an expert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hikaru_Nakamura) (close to a 2,800 [rating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system) (less than 50 players are above 2700))). It doesn't [even know the rules](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8LZe0FJvRMo&t=1m10s)!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. [I believe this bot already was trained on Stack Overflow data.](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/38663)
2. Having the bot answer questions would indicate that somehow the bot was able to *prove* that the answer was right, and thus far I have been less than impressed with what the bot has been able to showcase as "correct".  So, I don't believe it would be of *any* value whatsoever to leverage the bot to try to "answer" a question.  Answering a question without any basis in fact is not an answer ***at all***.