# My closed question had nothing to do with the duplicate

Tags: discussion, specific-question, duplicate-questions, reopen-closed

I asked [a JavaScript question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75152969/using-canvas-pointermove-event-on-phone-the-pointerleave-event-gets-fired) and didn't get any answer in a few days and I put a bounty on it and got a great answer.

Later that day, it was closed as a duplicate. The referenced answer was about "disable scrolling", which was not in my question.  The great answer did not mention "disable scrolling".

Per some meta thread, I made a comment about this yesterday, thinking it might be acted upon.

So, can I blame some AI bot? It's no big deal because I got a great answer before it was closed, but I thought somebody might agree with me that it is an obvious mistake.

Comment: It is quite unclear what you expect from this question... At very least consider if you are asking about "specific-question" to link to the question. While making an [edit] consider to clarify what you want as result and possibly explain what "AI bot" you hint at.

Comment: It's not a bot. We have no AIs or bots closing questions.

Comment: @CodyGray well ... technically .. "community" :P and it closes questions in some cases, like an OP accepting a duplicate.

Comment: Community doesn't ever make the decision to close questions. It only implements the decision of the author of the question to mark their own question as a duplicate. (Yes, I know you're pedantically nitpicking, @Tom.)

Comment: I'm a bit confused. You seem to be fixating on the first two words in the title of the proposed duplicate ("disable scrolling"), but [the answer to that question](//stackoverflow.com/a/43275544) is to set `touch-action` to `none`, and [that's *exactly* what you said you did to solve the problem](//stackoverflow.com/q/75152969/#comment132859487_75152969). So... how/why is it not a duplicate? Why do you think that the duplicate closure is/was a mistake? (Disclaimer: This is outside of my subject-matter expertise, so I don't have an opinion either way. I'm just hoping to prod you to explain.)

Comment: #Alexei Levenkov - "link to the question:" I had (SO# 75152969), which was edited into a link. 
#Cody Gray - "Community doesn't ever:" Well I didn't close it. Who did?
#Makoto - "I had made so many edits:" Sorry I capitolized "bounty".
#Cody Gray - "I'm a bit confused:" Yes, "touch-action" solved my problem, but my problem wasn't "scrolling".
A tough crowd in  here. I hope you guys have a good time. Thanks for SO. It's good.

Comment: @dcromley Off-topic, but none of the people you "mentioned" in your comments by using # will be notified. You can only mention one other user by using @, so you should answer in separate comments and use @<username> to get people notified.

Comment: "*Per some meta thread, I made a comment about this yesterday, thinking it might be acted upon.

So, can I blame some AI bot? It's no big deal because I got a great answer before it was closed, but I thought somebody might agree with me that it is an obvious mistake.*" => Relevance...? Which 'Meta' Thread...?

Comment: "Community" (uppercase) is the name of [a bot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1) which steps in to close questions as a duplicate when their author agrees that they are. That's not what happened in this/your case. Another user who holds a gold tag badge in one of the tags on your question marked it as a duplicate. They are not a bot; they're a real person. We grant users who have demonstrated expertise in the subject matter the ability to single-handedly mark questions as duplicates because, often, judging a duplicate requires subject-matter expertise.

Comment: If using touch-action solved your problem, then why do you say that your question is not a duplicate? The two questions appear to have had *exactly* the same answer. This is how we define duplicates: resolved in the same way. It doesn't matter what the title says. The title is the least useful thing to look at, since it relies on the person who knows the least (the asker, by definition) correctly diagnosing/summarizing the problem.

Comment: "Yes, "touch-action" solved my problem, but my problem wasn't "scrolling"" Yes, it did. The **reason** touch-action solves your problem is because scrolling happens otherwise.

Answer (score 8):

### Stack Overflow and AI "bots"

The [Community user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) implements some scheduled maintenance tasks, such as the [(very conservative) deletion of old, closed posts that show no potential for improvement](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba). It also implements tasks that were voted upon by the community. It **does not, however, use AI in any capacity**; and aside from randomly "bumping" some questions to give them more attention, it does not make decisions in any capacity beyond the published, documented algorithms.

[This user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3702797/kaiido) closed your question, subsequently replied to you in the comments, and is as far as I can tell very human. (Providing answers at nearly one per day for nearly 9 years is impressive, but certainly not a feat requiring automation.) The system does not show you this information, presumably to avoid revenge downvoting etc.; but the rest of us are shown:

[image]

Since we just recently [implemented an anti-AI policy for users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned), this could be considered a bit of a sore point for us.

### Why this is clearly a duplicate

Just because someone else explained the **same problem**, which is solved by the **same approaches**, in different terms, doesn't make the question not a duplicate. It's not necessary to have any domain-specific knowledge in order to understand the reasoning here, for a well-rounded, experienced programmer. I can learn enough *as I read* to come to the same conclusion that kaiido did.

The title of your question is: "Using canvas pointermove event on phone, the pointerleave event gets fired". That is: the question is about **how to prevent** the `pointerleave` event from being fired, while generating `pointermove` events (by touching the screen and dragging your finger around).

The reason the `pointerleave` event was generated, is because your finger unexpectedly left the canvas area. The reason for that is **because the page scrolled**, such that your finger was no longer within the canvas area. The page scrolled because your interaction with the canvas requested a scroll, as long as scrolling is enabled.

There isn't any customization for what actions request scrolling; instead, the solution is to disable scrolling.

Therefore, it is the same problem (the page scrolls when it shouldn't), solved by the same approach (disable scrolling, with the `canvas { touch-action: none; }` CSS).

The answer to which you offered the bounty is **completely irrelevant to that**. It shows how to adapt the code for desktop as well as mobile. Doing this *does not prevent the problem you reported*. The problem you reported is fixed by the CSS that you later reported using in the comments. The answer didn't help you solve the problem; the CSS that came out of your "several hours" did. The content is well written, but this is **not a "great answer", because it answers the wrong question**.

The linked duplicate **directly addresses the problem**. The top answer says to use the CSS that you ended up using. Further, the question setup describes your exact situation (italic emphasis mine):

> *I have a page with a section to sketch a drawing in. But the touchmove events, at least the vertical ones, are also scrolling the page* (which degrades the sketching experience) when using it on a mobile browser. Is there a way to either a) disable & re-enable the scrolling of the page (so I can turn it off when each line is started, but turn it back on after each is done), or b) *disable the default handling of touchmove events (and presumably the scrolling) that go to the canvas the sketch is drawn in* (I can't just disable them completely, as the sketching uses them)?

This is about as clear as duplicates get on Stack Overflow. We don't require any more precise matching than that, which is *why the close reason doesn't say "Exact Duplicate" any more*.

### Why it's important to close duplicates like this

The goal of Stack Overflow is, as described in the tour, "to build a library of detailed, high-quality answers to every question about programming". A **useful** library is **searchable**. Part of what makes questions and answers high quality, is being able to look for the question and see the answer right at the top.

It's important to keep in mind that Stack Overflow is **not a discussion forum**. One consequence of this is that, outside of copyright (which you retain despite Creative Commons licensing; in most countries it is difficult to impossible to waive copyright), a question that you ask on Stack Overflow **is not "your question"**. Just as the CC license entitles the company to reproduce and transmit your content, the site terms of service entitle us to *categorize* your content - including, without limitation: closure, deletion, identification as a duplicate, etc.

**Absolutely nothing about this is about you, as a person**. Questions are marked duplicates specifically so that you can see an answer directly; but **much more importantly** it's so that

- People who have new insight into the problem will put their answers in one place, where they can all be seen together; and
- *someone who has the same problem, and thinks of it in the same terms*, can use a search engine to find the answer.

The second reason is one reason why we do not always (understatement!) delete duplicate questions (another is simply to keep track of which questions are "frequently asked"). When an anonymous (or logged-out) user finds a duplicate question with a search engine, it will automatically redirect to follow the duplicate link. When these questions are doing their job well (because the *title* is good - i.e., someone who found the question with a search engine *most likely has the same actual question*), they are valued as "signposts". (We do want to delete questions where the title is misleading; i.e. where the OP wrote a title describing some specific, personal task, but the problem was caused by some common gotcha that has nothing to do with the task).

Comment: "*On your question, we see a banner which clearly identifies who closed the question:*" the author does not see information for who closed the question. It's intentionally hidden from them. [Here is what I see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MyKI3.png) on [this question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56869954/why-can-the-async-and-await-keywords-be-assigned-to). Note that *it was me who closed it*. And even then the notification tries to educate me on what duplicate closure is and doesn't tell me who the close voters are.

Comment: @VLAZ edited to account for that and correspondingly be less accusatory.

Comment: Oh that's new to me, I thought they could see who did close the question and I was actually relying on it a bit for they can call me out directly in case they needed more tailored explanation. To be fair I was kind of sensing OP might not see the relation entirely between the two Q/As in this case, and so I should probably have taken the time to explain to them directly when I did close their question. But indeed I'm a human, and have other stuff going on sometimes. Anyway, I hope I'll do better next time.

Comment: @Kaiido I personally follow a question I close as a duplicate, just in case OP or somebody else contests it, I'd be able to see the comment. It's OP and users without a CV privilege (3k rep) who don't see the close voters. At least not *directly* - checking the timeline will show the close voters but few know of this, so it's not something I'd rely on

Comment: @VLAZ I also do, sometimes, mainly with new users for which I'd assume the notification system might be obscure. But here given the OP's reputation is above 1K and since I was expecting them being able to reach out to me, I didn't. I certainly will next time I've got to dupe-hammer between two fires.