# Why are my comments explaining why I voted to delete an answer continuously deleted without explanation?

Tags: discussion, answers, comments, specific-answer

My question was answered, but the answer is not actually a useful answer to my question. I voted to delete that answer, because I started a bounty and need correct attention. When an answer is NOT actually an answer, I just vote to delete it. Maybe it is very correct and useful, but NOT HERE, to my question.

[How to fetch HTML content from url using ONLY URL Session to make it working with watchOS and SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75363027)

I left a comment explaining this, but it keeps getting removed.

Comment: there's value in a comment existing pointing out the flaws with a given answer, even if you feel the answer should be deleted. Though... i also wouldn't blame a mod for approving a NLN flag on one.

Comment: Apologies, I missed answer; my bad. Though my point stands; you're saying it's not recoverable. Most likely the answer has had a lot of downvotes already and probably some comments on why the answer isn't helpful/useful. There's no need to add more fuel to the fire.

Comment: the usual habit/consensus is to downvote if you don't like/think highly of an answer. It's only useful to delete if it's spam/etc

Comment: @NordineLotfi Not really; if an answer has no value, it should be deleted. There are many answers that are not spam or abuse that fall into this category.

Comment: I see. I don't think I ever came across that kind of answer, but I'll take your word for it :) (was only speaking of my own experience anyway) @TylerH

Comment: Depends what you mean by "no value", @TylerH . Downvotes already tell the user that the answer isn't helpful/useful. If the answer has no value then it's likely not an answer or perhaps dangerous; it's likely the OP knows that information already.

Comment: I learned a lot. And of course I can do nothing with this... but there is one user who is harassing me all the time. Why my question https://stackoverflow.com/a/75659009/ is voted down? Please explain me that reason... why? I wanna know what is wrong with this. Not duplicated, completely explained, example attached, no typos, bounty even awarded... why there is 3 votes down. Please tell me...

Comment: From the comment you've reposted: *"That answer doesnt meet my expectations because it uses server side, and the question is about to not to use server side."* Is not a reason to vote to delete, it's a reason to downvote... Delete votes *aren't* "super downvotes".

Comment: As I said on your last post. If you are being harassed, then you should use a flag to get the moderators to look in to it. Not rant on meta.

Comment: so... you posted a question, got an answer that didn't apply to your specific scenario, the poster deleted the answer, you got a second answer, repeating the same process, and after two rounds you still didn't edit your question to clarify? halfer did it instead? who is harassing who?

Comment: But it doesnt make sense and create a mess... And all of you are kings of the order. So why you allow to answer questions, that actually are not an answers for THAT specific question. You cannot answer question A in thread of question B. It is not the same. This is how it starts creating a mess.

Comment: @Larnu Yes, downvotes are the primary tool for things like wrong answers. But if an answer is just plain wrong, it should be deleted, except in the _very_ rare case that its wrongness is a useful learning/teaching tool. Off the top of my head I would guess that such useful wrong answers occur at a rate of maybe 1 in every 10,000 wrong answers (or even less frequently). If an answer is correct/works, but doesn't perhaps fit OP's specific needs, that's a different (also common) situation, where a downvote might be warranted, but deletion is not.

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk If you suspect a user is harassing you, please flag the relevant post (or the post closest to being relevant, if possible) with a moderator flag and explain your concern. They can investigate more thoroughly than we can here on Meta and can actually enforce any behavior changes, if any are called for.

Comment: So you cannot explain me what is wrong with my question that is voted down 3 times. The only reason is that 3 users voted it down because they didnt like my comment under the answer. That is all. It is not serious, but childish.

Comment: The answer in the linked post doesn't look as if it needs to be deleted. Sure, it doesn't fit exactly to your needs, but that's not a reason to delete. It is (imho) an attempt to answer and should be downvoted, but not deleted. Since that's the case, I would have probably also flagged a comment explain why you delete voted as "no longer needed".

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk you cannot attribute cause to votes on Stack Overflow unless the voters tell you why they voted. Votes are anonymous and do not require a specific reason be given.

Comment: Those votes are likely to the "Meta Effect" @BartłomiejSemańczyk . With respect, the fact that you posted this question, initially blaming a user who made a *helpful edit* to your question after you had missed out a **critical** piece of information (that any solution need to be client side), can leave quite a sour taste in people's mouths when the question (this question) comes in with such an accusatory tone.

Comment: @BDL, ok so why my qiuestion was downvoted and answer upvoted. Please check the history of comments under that answer (now they are all deleted) but halfer user directly said it is very correct answer and the author should not care about my opinion, and voted it up. Why? Is it seriously serious?

Comment: _"Please check the history of comments under that answer"_ Users can't see deleted comments.

Comment: re `So why you allow to answer questions, that actually are not an answers for THAT specific question.`. It is as intended. No one can enforce preventing or forcing "valid" answer based on expectation of different OPs. Remember that people answering do so from their own will. If they think it fits or might help for your requirements, it's still a form of help, whether to you (the OP) or future readers. If you think it doesn't help/fits, then just downvote as mentioned. @BartłomiejSemańczyk

Comment: @Cerbrus So, this way some users can do anything they like without consequences... ok, it is not fair and fine.

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk flag it. If you keep talking about it, all you'll get is the same correct information about how voting works and you'll stay stuck in a loop where you keep getting upset because people keep responding with things you do not want to hear. Nobody here can check for voting abuse, only the people who receive the custom flag can. Or they can escalate it to employees if need be. There is zero point in bringing it up again and again.

Comment: In programming, the approach you're looking for often is not a good solution. Answers that provide alternative solutions, _especially_ answers as detailed as this one, shouldn't be downvoted just because it doesn't follow the OP's restrictions, and they __certainly__ shouldn't be deleted. They provide additional insight. Alternative solutions.

Comment: @Gimby I flagged it and commented, but my comment was deleted, so noone understand why I flagged it and cannot flag it the one more time for the same reason... And this is the only reason (imho) for deletion. Other reasons are not suitable here.

Comment: *"halfer user directly said it is very correct answer and the author should not care about my opinion"* .... since you keep twisting the facts. I have a screenshot from the comments before they were deleted: https://i.imgur.com/PCEoO2i.png. halfer said the user should ignore your vote to delete. They didn't say that your opinion of the correctness of the answer could/should be ignored.

Comment: Okay, let's make this simple: @Bartłomiej, your intent to delete that answer is simply not how SO works. It's an answer to your problem, even if it's not the answer you _want_.

Comment: @Tom, yes, this is how halfer said. I cannot check it by myself and didnt remember correctly. I dont remember everything. In my opinion it is the same point of comment, but used with different words.

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk: I can't see the comments. And I didn't vote on the post. But even if they do now, that still doesn't mean you should delete vote the answer. The fact that the requirement that you now try to enforce wasn't even stated in the question when the answer cam in doesn't make it better. If you think that someone harasses you, feel free to flag for moderator attention, mods can see all the comments and decide on that.

Comment: I flagged it 2 times and of course... no surprise... mods decided there is no harrasment. Lets wait until someone will start treating you the same way like 2 persons me... Than we will see how you feel and what you say... ;) no offence...

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk I really can't side with you here; your question was missing important information, you got an answer which didn't provide the solution you want because you omitted that information, and now you want to delete that answer because you didn't tell them that piece of information? That would be like taking your car to have the paint redone (due to scratches) and then when you got it back refusing to pay because they only repaired the scratches rather than repainting the car blue, when it was previously black, despite never advising them you wanted the *entire* car repainted.

Comment: Looking at those comments, there _was no_ harassment. They complimented the post and stated that the deletion request is unreasonable. That's all.

Comment: I don't see any harassment in the screenshot posted above, only a comment stating that the deleting isn't called for, which I do agree with. I also see noone here threatening you. If you want to challenge the mod decision, feel free to ask about that, but that is not what your post is about. Why are your comments deleted? Because they explain an action that wasn't called for.

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk: I'm sorry, but the comment does not qualify as harrassment. Saying that someone can ignore a claim you made is not an attack on you as a person, your culture or your ethnic background. All it is is advice to the answerer about one possible way to react to something you said. In this specific case, that advice happened to match the consensus of how this site works, but even if it wasn't that's still not an attack on you.

Comment: _"When an answer is NOT actually an answer, I just vote to delete it."_ - it's important to know what "not an answer" [actually means here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265552/3001761). _"I voted to delete that answer, because I started a bounty and need correct attention."_ - a question can get multiple answers before, during and after a bounty so that's not a good reason either.

Comment: Bartłomiej - your behaviour on this question was an utter disgrace. I struggle to understand how you have the temerity to post on Meta after that series of embarrassments. The answer upon which you were heaping abuse looked like a good effort had been made, and thus it is not a wonder that you were getting downvotes on the question. Asking people to delete their answers to you is just not on, especially if they are a new user. (The answer author turns out to be using AI tools, but we did not know that at the time).

Comment: Above all else: Stack Overflow is **not a discussion forum**, nor a help desk. That entails, among other things, that the purpose of the question **is not** to help you out with the specific situation you are in, but to help build a *searchable* library. Therefore, we *aren't actually very interested in* whether the answer meets your personal needs. We are concerned with whether answers **attempt to answer the question, as asked and as everyone else understood it**.

Comment: @halfer I am not surprised your comment... What you do here and how you abuse the fact that you have a lot of free time and just look for something to improve (of course without any good reason, in my opinion it's usually clingy) shows that you can't come to terms with the fact that others they just use it as a tool, and it's not the idea of their life... where you demand perfection. This reflects very badly on your personality (I don't want to use any offensive words here, but I'll leave it as it is).

Comment: It seems like you are refusing to listen to the community repeatedly, Bartłomiej. When people tell you how Stack Overflow works, you seem to mentally filter out what they have said, and then claim that you are still confused. If your question is closed justifiably, and it is explained to you why, you still claim it was unjustified. If you try to delete someone else's answer, and it is explained to you that this is not acceptable behaviour, you will still claim that you have been wronged. I am at a loss to explain your motivations, and at this point I can only see malice.

Comment: Bottom line: **look at the downvotes on this Meta question** - minus 27 at the time of writing. Your previous Meta question - minus 27 again. The one before that, minus 34. This is a very clear message to you, and you need to heed it.

Comment: "When an answer is NOT actually an answer, I just vote to delete it." - This is a reason to downvote the answer.  It's not a reason to delete the answer, even if you are the author, I would go as far to say.  Especially as the author of the answer.  My advice to new users, don't submit low quality answers, expecting to get upvotes.  If it's bad enough to delete yourself, that is evidence, the answer probably should have never been submitted.  However, since you now submitted the answer, it's an answer that could potentially be helpful to somebody even if it's lower quality

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk  Insisting that you are right, ignoring contrary opinions and inventing conspiracies works much better on social media where feelings are accepted over facts.  I lost all sympathy with your position as soon as you entered victim mode:((

Answer (score 38):

First of all: Thank you for coming to Meta to get clarification about why your comments were being removed, rather than persist in posting them on the answer. Posting a question on Meta, or alternatively, flagging the post for moderator attention to get clarification, was a much better option than repeatedly posting.

The comments were deleted by a moderator because the community was flagging them as problematic, and the moderator that handled the flags agreed. When someone puts in the effort to answer your question, *even if it turns out to be the wrong answer*, we don't just delete such efforts <sup>*)</sup>, and telling someone to delete their answer, effectively saying that you want it gone, is not considered a very constructive way to provide feedback. For one, the answerer may be able to correct for the misunderstanding and improve their answer to fix the issue.

We don't just delete wrong answers like this, because the goal of this site is to not only help you, but any future visitor with a similar issue. And just because the answer doesn't quite work for you, that doesn't mean the answer is unhelpful for others. That's where the voting system comes in: you and everyone else with an account with enough reputation, can vote on the post, up or down. If the answer isn't helpful for you, vote it down, and if it *is* helpful to you, vote it up. And separately from voting, use comments to explain why an answer might not work, constructively, by pointing out what might have been missed.

Next, if you are getting answers that happen to have missed an important detail about your environment, consider editing your question to make it clearer. Writing questions is *hard*, don't expect to get it right every time. Instead, take 'wrong answers' as feedback that perhaps your question could be clearer.

Reserve delete votes for problematic posts. Posts where it is clear that no amount of editing effort is going to make it an answer, to any question, for example, should be deleted.

---

<sup>*)</sup> We do delete posts when they violate our policies such as the [ban on ChatGPT-generated content](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned), and this answer was generated by ChatGPT. If you suspect a post was generated by ChatGPT or violates one of our policies, please flag it for moderator attention and explain why. The answer here has now been removed.

Answer (score 17):

Before halfer edited your question, there was nothing in your question suggesting that calling a different server to do the work was unacceptable to you. Both answers, prior to halfer's edit, attempted to answer your question as asked.

If anything, I'd argue Halfer's edit is incorrect because it invalidates an existing answer, and that neither answer should have been deleted.

Comment: It was actually, in the title `using ONLY URLSession` and that is simple. Has anyone checked at least one time if that answer is correct?

Comment: The title isn't a good place to put critical information, @BartłomiejSemańczyk . Sure, you can include it in it, but that critical information should be in the question itself. At the end of the day we're addressing the content of the post, not the title; titles are an introduction to what the question is about. Titles can just as often be misleading.

Comment: My edit in rev5 was just a reflection of the OP's views on March 4th, added in a comment on Mattia's answer. I agree that thatstooeasyman may not have seen that, so feel free to wind it back, if that makes more sense to the activity chronology. (For sub 10K readers: both of these folks made answers that have both been deleted).

Comment: Now that both are deleted, there's no answer to invalidate with an edit