# Is there a policy under what circumstances moderators are allowed to make private information public?

Tags: discussion, moderators, legal, privacy, gdpr

I came across a Meta answer with comments that made me wonder whether there is a policy on what private information Moderators are allowed to reveal under what circumstances.

This policy should *at the very least* obey the laws of relevant countries, e.g., GDPR for people in the EU.

The revelation of private information makes me wonder whether this would be a violation of GDPR, if OP was in the EU at the time of posting.

The relevant exchange is:

> OP: Thank you for the clear explanation. That is helpful and I appreciate it. Having said, I think it's wholly inappropriate for you to post the text of a "in need of moderator intervention" flag in a public forum. Perhaps I'm wrong, but I don't think this text is part of the public-facing data of this site and users do not expect to see their posts held up for public discussion by those with moderator privileges.

> Moderator: @OP We keep flags strictly private, unless you bring up the issue in public, which you did by posting this question about the same issue which you previously flagged. It's possible I'm wrong about your question here releasing us from that privacy, but that's how I interpreted your question.

I don't think any EU lawyer would constitute posting a question as explicitly releasing the Stack Overflow moderator from that privacy.

It could be that in the US the concepts are different. But given that Stack Overflow also operates in the EU, it would be good if there was a clear guideline to make global moderators aware of what constitutes release and what not.

I'm not trying to make this about the individuals at all here. This is just the inspiration. To that end, I am not linking to the question even though it may reduce usefulness. The private part was later edited out by another moderator. But the comment still stands as is. So clarity on the general point would be helpful.

Update:

Response to highly upvoted comments that entirely miss the point that I'm not claiming with certainty that this particular case would violate GDPR (I'm not a lawyer). In fact the comment is a case in point for the creation of a policy as the policy would help clarify what is and isn't considered personal data.

Here's the comment:

> What Private Information has been exposed here? PII has a specific definition, and none of what you quote is close to PII.
> TL;DR: Keeping something private does not mean that the information is private in data terms, or that it is Private Identifiable Information (PII) (which is presumably what you are referencing here).

I think confuses US/EU terminology here. GDPR doesn't only cover things that *identify* you, but any information that is related to an *identifiable* person. The information made public is clearly related to an identifiable person.:

> The abbreviation PII is widely accepted in the United States, but the phrase it abbreviates has four common variants based on personal or personally, and identifiable or identifying. Not all are equivalent, and for legal purposes the effective definitions vary depending on the jurisdiction and the purposes for which the term is being used. [a] Under European and other data protection regimes, which centre primarily on the General Data Protection Regulation (GDPR), the term "personal data" is significantly broader, and determines the scope of the regulatory regime.
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_data

The valid question is: does the text of the message the user submitted fall under GDPR protection? I'm not a lawyer, but to me it's not obvious that it isn't. This post is about the question in general, whether there *is* a policy. Such a policy would help clarify what is or isn't covered. And avoid this discussion.

Update 2: People seem to misunderstand my point and think I'm asking a legal question. No, this is just one way to motivate why it's an interesting question to discuss. Core points to discuss:

- Is there a written policy?
- If not, should there be a written policy?
- Even if not, what *is* the unwritten policy?
- What should the policy be?

Comment: What Private Information has been exposed here? PII has a specific definition, and none of what you quote is close to PII.

Comment: Not to mention that the Moderator specifically states *"unless you bring up the issue in public"*; if the OP has brought up the subject themselves, in a *public* place, then they have already given implicit consent for the subject matter to be discussed. If this wasn't the case, any posts created to discuss flags would need to be closed, deleted, and redacted per your interpretation.

Comment: TL;DR: Keeping something private does not mean that the information is private in *data terms*, or that it is Private Identifiable Information (PII) (which is presumably what you are referencing here).

Comment: Did the flag contain any information that is actually protected by GDPR? The flag text itself, imho, isn't.

Comment: I updated the question with responses to @Larnu. The comments are actually a point in case: it would be helpful to know what information falls under GDPR protection and what doesn't. I don't have the answer. But the policy would take the question from one to argue about to one with clear facts from professionals (lawyers). One can still discuss that, but it would be a start.

Comment: *" it would be helpful to know what information falls under GDPR protection and what doesn't."* That isn't a question for meta, @CorneliusRoemer . [law.se] would be a better site, but I suspect that "What information is covered under GDPR?" might be a little broad; it's a non-simple subject.

Comment: @Larnu I'm sorry I was not precise. "it would be helpful to know what user related data falls under GDPR protection and what doesn't."

Comment: @CorneliusRoemer what's private is all covered by the [privacy policy](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/privacy-policy) and I imagine Stack Exchange legal has ensured that conforms to GDPR etc.

Comment: That's still defined under GDPR regulation and isn't a question for meta.

Comment: @RobertLongson it would not be the first company to not conform, especially as a somewhat US-centric company this is the norm, not the exception.

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine The questiona are: a) under what circumstances will moderators reveal information related to me that isn't public. b) was the action correct in this case to publish? Are these not questions for meta?

Comment: _"information related to me"_ is very broad. Whether or not this specific action was correct requires context. Also, that's 2 very different questions in one.

Comment: Are moderators even subject to the rules/requirements of GDPR? Wouldn't those apply only to the company, of which moderators are not agents or representatives? Are you bound by GDPR in your interactions with other individuals on this site? Those musings aside... If you're really trying to ask about the circumstances under which moderators will reveal the text of flags, which is presumed confidential (seen only by the flagger and moderators), then ask *only that* question. Leave out the red-herring references to GDPR, PII, personal data, etc.

Comment: @CodyGray the way I understand it, the site is subject to GDPR rules. This includes actions from site representatives. A moderator/owner/admin/poweruser/whatever can not legally share another user's PII without explicit consent. If that were to happen, those that run the site need to intervene. If they don't, there'd be grounds for legal action. Now whether someone would try to enforce that is a whole different discussion.

Comment: *" under what circumstances will moderators reveal information related to me that isn't public"* I assume that there are *no* circumstances where they *will*. There might be some where they discuss the contents on a flag you've raised which you explicitly discuss in your post though; especially when the contents of the post is incorrect or misleading (ther's been a few of those I've seen).

Comment: @CodyGray Learning my lesson ;) I never mentioned PII, that's the second level red herring brought up by others. Interesting point regarding whether moderators are subject. I don't have the answer. They may be considered as processors of the information and hence bound by extension. The fact that you don't know means it would be good thing to look into for the company.

Comment: @CodyGray Due to the moderation position you have access to data which falls under the GDPR. I would be surprised when the agreement between a mod and the company doesn't include the protection of private information, including PII, due to the requirement for the company to protect that data. So by that mods are subject to the rules/requirements of GDPR.

Comment: "*but any information that is related to an identifiable person*" that's an entirely silly distinction to make. Consider this you *posted* - I can see intormation about an identifiable person on your post. Ergo, according to your reading - your post is forbidden. Also forbidden - Facebook, social media in general. Which is probably why PII isn't defined the way you try to claim it is. PII is information *you can identify a real person with*. Not just any data related to a person. Contents of a flag does not have enough to pinpoint real name and address of user. Identifying user isn't an issue.

Comment: @VLAZ PII isn't the term thats used in GDPR. It's a US legal term that causes confusion. The entire point is that not just what identifies you falls under GDPR but anything that can be connected to you, e.g. because in a database it says "Name: Comment". That comment, even if it says "bla bla blub" is hence "personal data" under GDPR. And no, just because something is "personal data under GDPR" that doesn't make it "illegal". However, there are restrictions on what you can do with "personal data" held by a company. You can't make it public without legal reason.

Comment: https://gdpr-info.eu/issues/personal-data/
They're talking about the same data, they just don't use the "PII" abbreviation. You're questioning our source of information, asking if we are a _"EU privacy lawyer"_, but clearly, neither are you.

Comment: @Cerbrus To phrase differently. It is possible to identify the user who submitted the flag because the user is linked in the database. Hence the text of the flag is personal data. Hence there needs to be legal grounds to publish it on meta by the moderator in such a way that it's not anonymized and it wasn't. And the legal grounds to publish are shaky here - the user making a meta post discussing something related to the flag is not enough.

Comment: If the database were public, you might've been somewhere near correct. But it's not, and you're making massive leaps in logic to imply something bad was happening, in a situation where we have ___no___ context.

Comment: *"It is possible to identify the user who submitted the flag"* the user has already been identified, it's the OP who is asking about the flag. A moderator can't expose the identity of a user when the user has already exposed themselves. A moderator won't provide details of the flag unless the user makes themselves known.

Comment: Confused by the closure reason "needs detail or clarity". Can someone explain? And delete vote? Why? Because the question is potentially critical of moderators?

Comment: @CorneliusRoemer: I didn't close-vote, but without knowing the OP's flag text, it's unclear to me whether we are discussing an actual issue here or not. I think this is also the reason why the discussion in the comments drifted into a direction that you didn't intend to go...

Comment: @CorneliusRoemer While updating the question you may want to clarify your position on why *you* believe comments are *not covered* by CC by-SA license as any content contributed to the site. Also that whole thing probably should be asked separately without any GDRP... Maybe "To what degree flag messages are private and what are rules around publishing"

Comment: Thanks @honk, that's helpful. I really just didn't want to get people upset about individuals so I didn't link on purpose. I will update and add the links - unless someone here advises that I shouldn't. But seems like people would prefer to have the link. Good point Alexei on CC-by, didn't cross my mind.

Answer (score 18):

There is information that moderators have to keep private by the terms of the [moderator agreement](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/moderator-agreement).

This is explained in the [privacy policy](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/privacy-policy) it's basically identity data - your email address, password, your IP addresses etc.

Moderators have a duty to keep that information private and if they access that data for another user then that access is logged and they may need to explain why they accessed that data.

Some of this is the kind of identity information that is covered by legislation such as GDPR i.e. information that may identify you such as your date of birth, your location etc.

Then there is information moderators choose to keep private because airing dirty linen in public generally doesn't get good results. That's generally flags, deleted comments etc. If someone wants to discuss what happened to their flags or why their comments were deleted etc and they create a Meta post then moderators can discuss that and why they reached the decision that they did given that the poster has indicated that they want to discuss that subject. Disgruntled posters often post half-truths and Moderators then tell us what really happened.

Answer (score 16):

> Does the text of the message the user submitted fall under GDPR protection?

No, the submitted text by itself, does not.

If the user were to put their *own* PII in that message, then that specific part of the text would need to be redacted if the message were to be made public, but other than that, no.

If a user brings up a flag they submitted in a public place, then they're giving implicit permission for the contents of that flag to be made public.

Comment: "No, the submitted text, by itself does not." Are you sure? I explained why the term PII isn't necessarily the right one for GDPR. The user didn't bring up the flag in a public place, they didn't mention the flag. They just broached the broad topic. Implicit permission is a tricky field. What qualifies you to make these statements with such certainty? It could be that you are an EU privacy lawyer but I don't know.

Comment: What point is there to you asking questions on Meta if you're just going to dismiss and disagree with [every explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned/423554#comment949477_423554) you're given? If I wasn't sure, I wouldn't have written this answer.

Comment: What makes you so sure? Even if I disagreed with every explanation this wouldn't be a problem if every explanation was wrong. But I haven't even disagreed with every explanation. What makes you sure that this doesn't fall under GDPR?

Comment: [Because flag contents, by themselves, isn't PII](https://gdpr-info.eu/issues/personal-data/#:~:text=These%20data%20include%20genetic%2C%20biometric,convictions%20or%20trade%20union%20membership.). It's not protected under the GDPR.

Comment: These flags being private is a design feature. It's not a legal requirement.

Comment: This is a good point! However, by implementing this feature, the user expectation is changed.

Comment: And nothing about that has anything to do with the GDPR.

Comment: Yup, bad user expectations is a pertinent issue.

Comment: @Cerbrus So you are saying that Twitter admins should be able to post my DMs? Because DMs being private is a design feature not a legal requirement?

Comment: @CorneliusRoemer: If you are concerned (and you have legal standing), you should sue in the appropriate EU court, since the courts are where legal questions are decided. It doesn't matter what our (or your) opinion is.

Comment: @CorneliusRoemer don't strawman me. That's not what I was saying or implying. I already answered your question in the last paragraph of this answer.