# Can I take sentences like "with the help of ChatGPT..." as self-admission and flag only based on that?

Tags: discussion, flags, ai-generated-content

Let's say I come across an answer that reads:

> I found the solution with the help of ChatGPT, here you go:
>
> `code`

**Without other evidence** that the post is AI-generated, can I take this as an admission the OP used an LLM to generate the code and flag it for being in violation of the [no generative AI policy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned)?

Even if I can't reliably determine where the code is sourced from, the OP has just stated they used ChatGPT to create the answer.

Related Meta posts:

- [Is any mention of ChatGPT still against the rules?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425940/is-any-mention-of-chatgpt-still-against-the-rules) — this post is closely related but the particular situation of that question asker somewhat marred the resolution; also, this post is specifically about flagging.
- [If ChatGPT gives me an answer, should I leave my question unanswered?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/423841/if-chatgpt-gives-me-an-answer-should-i-leave-my-question-unanswered)
- [Can I use AI-written code in my answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426769/can-i-use-ai-written-code-in-my-answers)

Comment: Would you mind clarifying if your answer is your personal viewpoint (i.e., with your "mod hat" off) and the policy is up for discussion or if it's the new policy and you happened to be the mod to post/announce it?

Comment: @cocomac it is not a policy, because it’s not a new rule. I’m giving voice to existing flag handling practices (even from before the strike) in the form of advice to flaggers.

Comment: If "with help of X" is too ambiguous, people who had help of X but checked their contributions should maybe instead write "based on X" or "acknowledging input from X", which might be more clearly expressing the intent here. This holds true regardless of what X actually is. What people here probably suspect is that it's a slippery slope at some point. Do people really fact check their answers when they are based on AI input? Nobody knows and some probably assume guilty (when self-admissed). In that regard, the rational choice would be to write nothing about the origin. Not sure if we want this.

Comment: I recently came across a Java question that looked like a perfect fit for ChatGPT, so I submitted it to see.  The code ChatGPT generated was incorrect, which is probably why the OP posted the question.  I modified the code to make it work correctly.  Are you telling me I couldn't have posted the corrected code and explanation as a SO answer?

Comment: I understand that there is value in having a policy that is clear and easy to apply.  But to play devil's advocate, what if AI was used but only in some trivial way?  For example what if I ask AI for a refresher on the proper syntax for iterating over the items in a Javascript array, when that ends up being only a very small piece of the actual answer?

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc "Are you telling me..." The question is neutral with that regard, but some of the answers indeed interpret the rule like this. You touched the forbidden (AI) fruit, you are expelled from the garden (being able to answer any question about it) is the logic of that answers because the ban of AI here is seen as total. But other answers dispute that.

Comment: @JohnGordon "...what if..." Just follow the community consensus. If most people think that using AI even only in some trivial way should be forbidden, then it might be sensible to follow them. Of course you could think that if nobody knows that then effectively the rule cannot be executed in these cases and you can do instead what ever you want, but that wouldn't be so community oriented.

Comment: In my opinion the most important parts of an answer are that it 1) the code works 2) it is explained how it works 3) the solution is not unnecessarily complicated or oversimplified(and thus not versatile/reliable). While this doesn't exclude the use of AI it does require an experienced programmer to verify all 3 aspects. Simply copying and pasting AI output even after polishing it up a bit won't be enough for those 3 points.

Comment: After the long and drawn-out strike action, are we really already at a point where SE-adjacent persons like moderators are trying to water down the AI policy? Disappointing, but not unexpected.

Comment: @IanKemp I don’t really agree with Blackgreen’s conclusions here either, but I think “water down” is maybe a bit unfair. To me it seems like an effort to try to make sense of something which is ambiguous. Yes the policy can be interpreted as absolute, but I think we shouldn’t lose sight of the _intent_ of that policy. It’s mostly blanket because it’s simply too hard to specify a point by point set of rules to follow; not because anyone believes that it’s impossible for good content to exist with the help of LLMs. Maybe these kinds of ideas are a step towards a better informed/specified policy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### It does not count as admission

You shouldn't flag it on that basis.

The reason is simple. The phrase "with the help of" and variations thereof is not a direct translation, nor logically related to, "I **generated** the following with". In other words, *lacking further visible evidence* in the post itself or in the OP's answer history of LLM usage, there is no proof that any of the subsequent code has been **directly copy-pasted**, or inconsequentially modified from an LLM. It's unreasonable for a moderator to delete a post solely based on that, and it's not warranted to flag it solely based on that.

If you do have additional evidence that a post was generated with an LLM *beyond the alleged self-admission*, please state that in your flag text. If you don't, thus suggesting that the alleged self-admission was the sole reason for flagging, and moderators don't find any other evidence by themselves, your flag is likely to be declined.

This is like someone saying "I found a solution thanks to this book [code block follows]" and someone else flags it as plagiarism. If the code in the answer isn't identical (or sufficiently similar to be considered unoriginal) to that found in the book, it's not possible to use plagiarism *to justify its deletion*.

**A book, or an AI, could be instrumental in finding a solution without anything being copied out of it** — the book, or the AI, was used as a guide, as inspiration, as a starting point; and the poster eventually came to an original solution on their own. In the spirit of assuming good faith it's not reasonable to construe a remark like "with the help of" as "the following is generated by", nor it's reasonable to flag based on that.

In fact, such a remark may very well be fluff. [Quoting Thom A](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/425942/4108803):

> If your content isn't generated by ChatGPT, then any mention of ChatGPT is noise and doesn't belong in the post

If the post presents other issues (non-answer, link-only) it can be flagged and handled as such, as usual.

##### Variations

- with the help of [LLM]
- thanks to [LLM]
- I found the solution with [LLM]
- [LLM] pointed me to this

##### Unequivocally explicit admissions

*Explicit* admission of LLM usage is flaggable, but it must leave no reasonable doubt that the content of the post is LLM plagiarism. This leads to the next point:

##### The language problem

Yes, in the end it comes down to how you read the English language. Can we devise universally valid rules? I believe we can't. People with different English levels, different backgrounds, different native languages can and will interpret the same sentence differently. And this is why we can't assume that these remarks amount to admission. We don't know how the OP speaks English, and *they* might not mean "I copy-pasted the following from [LLM]". Deleting posts this way will lead to frustration and unfairness on all sides.

Ultimately, in these cases my advice is to focus on other indicators of AI usage. If these aren't available, flag conservatively. Eventually, ignore remarks of uncertain interpretation and edit them out.

If you are absolutely positive that an English sentence means the text was copy-pasted from an LLM, please do flag it, but in the end a moderator, who might or might not read English the same as you do, will have to decide what to do.

Keep in mind that the main goal, beside enforcing rules, is to do the good of the site.

##### How does this relate to the [historical policy on GPT detectors](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/391626/historical-policy-on-the-use-of-gpt-detectors)?

The historical policy was given to moderators as a binding guideline for enforcing the ChatGPT ban. It doesn't strictly relate to community flaggers and curators. Moreover, even if it was repealed as a result of the community strike, explicit admission that some content is generated with LLMs is still actionable.

Comment: Could one *assume* that a statement such as "With the help of [LLM]" in conjunction with other (intentionally not mentioned) indicators would, however, help indicate that the source is not original content?

Comment: @ThomA yes, but then the "with the help of" remark would be less relevant, if not inconsequential — similarly, a moderator might have something to justify deletion than the remark alone

Comment: It's actually weak evidence of copy/paste/verify.

Comment: @Joshua too weak to act on it. It might be evidence that an AI at some point was involved. It's not possible to conclude they copy-pasted-and-verified the code from that alone.

Comment: so is this saying that this is not a strong heuristic (sole-basis heuristic)? or is it also saying it's not a weak heuristic?

Comment: @blackgreen Could you share if you (or other diamond mods, if this policy was a group decision) get explicit approval from [the CM team](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99341) prior to posting this policy? (I'm specifically inquiring about this answer, not the question itself)

Comment: I would still post a comment to let them know that if they did copy-paste it then it's against the rules.

Comment: @starball this is saying don’t flag if the only thing you’ve got is a statement from the OP with uncertain interpretation. It isn’t about company-approved heuristics

Comment: Are you effectively saying, as a flagger, don't just submit a flag with "self admitted gpt", flag it with "The user noted they used gpt, and x y and z makes it look like it was created atleast in part by gpt" thus giving mods more to work with?

Comment: @KevinB no, I’m saying that vague statements such as “with the help of” can’t be considered self-admission, so if that’s the only thing you’ve got you shouldn’t flag for removal

Comment: Effectively, you're the mod here, and I'd expect mods to take each case on evaluate it past just what was in the flag. To me it seems odd that this Q&A even needs to exist unless you're wanting people to alter the way they are flagging these... and if that's the case... wouldn't it be more useful to instead express how people could better flag this content instead of giving a vague directive of "don't flag x"? By design we don't have a list of heuristics *to* flag for, so saying what *not* to flag for seems... lacking.

Comment: Would this be an admissable self-admission? *"just for information I want to show solution given by chatGPT, after trying 30+ solutions and wasting 2-3 days, only one worked for me."* like, where's the line? this is why we have exception handlers.

Comment: @KevinB it's not possible to draw the line, as stated in this answer, however stay assured that no mod will shy away from doing their due diligence on a flagged post, no matter how many of them we get. The whole point of this Meta question is, if you flag *just because* of a vague mention of an AI model, with no other evidence, that is a unhelpful flag and likely to be declined.

Comment: @blackgreen I disagree. Can you share if moderators have CM-approved guidance on determining if something is self-admission or if it's too vague? Also, do see you a potential problem for flaggers in stating that self-admission is fair game but that flagging "a vague mention" is "a bad flag" without differentiating between those? This comes across to me as stating that a flag may be declined based on whatever the mod handling the flag decides despite a lack of guidance. I also don't like describing good-faith flags that mods need to make a judgement call on (and users can't) as bad flags.

Comment: @cocomac I’m not sure why you think this needs CM approval. It is simply about sensible flagging. It isn’t sensible to flag a post *for removal* if the only thing you’ve got is a vague statement from the OP. Of course a flagger may genuinely believe that counts as self-admission. Here I’m saying that, in fact, it doesn’t and that you can skip flagging it. You can also decide that a particular post warrants deeper evaluation for [reasons], then you can state that in your flag.

Comment: @KevinB your example explanation “*just for information I want to show solution given by chatGPT, after trying 30+ solutions and wasting 2-3 days, only one worked for me.*” is telling me more than just that the author did use ChatGPT. It tells me that the author does not understand why this solution works (more precise: happens to appear to do the intended thing). This is precisely the category of solutions we want to avoid. Solutions looking good at first glance and perhaps even doing the intended thing in a first test, but perhaps totally wrong and dangerous.

Comment: As phrased, the current policy does not allow for any use of an AI tool when posting on Stack Overflow ("*All use of generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT1 and other LLMs) is banned when posting content on Stack Overflow.*"). That means you cannot use it even as you would a book or a tutorial, invalidating your argument here.

Comment: @TylerH I must say, it's really hard to word the policy in such a way that it's immediately understandable and at the same time not open to 1) circumvention 2) blind enforcement, where 1 and 2 are two sides of the same coin

Comment: @blackgreen I definitely agree with you there; writing good copy in English is not easy, even for native English speakers.

Comment: "*The phrase 'with the help of' and variations thereof is not a direct translation, nor logically related to, 'I **generated** the following with'.*" -- this is a straw man.  The policy forbids not just "I generated the following with...", but *all* use of Generative AI in formulating a contribution.  And "with the help of ..." does strongly indicate that the thing being acknowledged was used in a significant way in formulating the contribution.

Comment: @KevinB I realized I glossed over a couple important points you made in an earlier comment and didn’t address them directly. I felt this Q&A needed to exist because it’s not obvious why we might decline such flags, the decline text is too short and marking them helpful without deleting is even more confusing. As for how to flag instead, I mentioned it: focus on other actionable evidence.

Answer (score 49):

Belated Edit/Update: After private discussions with @blackgreen and others, I changed my viewpoint. Previously, my concept of *"all use"* (discussed below) was too restrictive. I was applying a ["fruit of the poisonous tree" mindset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fruit_of_the_poisonous_tree), but the policy doesn't intend that. A user can be "guided by" ChatGPT/LLM without obtaining the solution from ChatGPT. I now agree with Blackgreen that a statement that they "used ChatGPT" isn't enough *by itself* to allow a Mod to remove it.

It *may* well be the case that the user obtained the solution, in whole or in part, *from* ChatGPT, and this would still be against the rules. However, we need to be able to demonstrate that, rather than just rely on the vague statement.

---

I feel this question and answer came because of a flag I raised multiple times<sup>1</sup> on an answer, and apologies to @Blackgreen, but I still disagree with the conclusion in this case.<sup>2</sup>

But to quote *the very first sentence* of [the current policy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1) (It's H2/H3 in the policy, but I'll remove that here and add some emphasis to make it easier to read):

> *All* use of generative AI (e.g., [ChatGPT](https://openai.com/blog/chatgpt/)<sup>1</sup> and other LLMs) is banned when posting content on Stack Overflow.
>
> ...
> If a user is believed to have used ChatGPT or other generative AI technologies after the posting of this temporary policy ...

First, focus on the **all use**.  AI-**assistance** when answering a question has, IMHO (and with all the Mods I've chatted with), always been considered part of this ban since day 1.  If it's *"with the help of"*, then isn't it banned?  If it *says*, *"This code was written with the help of"* (or even *"with the help of"*), then is that not a self-admission?

> This includes "asking" the question to an AI generator then copy-pasting its output *as well as* using an AI generator to "reword" your answers.

And while not explicitly stated in the policy (but probably should be), **rewriting** an AI answer in your own words has always been considered to be disallowed here.  We have literally *thousands* of answers here that have been removed where it's clear that the answer came from an LLM but was rewritten by the user.  Regardless, it seems clear that this falls under the *all use*.

---

Quoting from @Blackgreen's answer:

> but it must leave no reasonable doubt that the content of the post is LLM plagiarism.

Two notes on that:

- The statement *"with the help of ChatGPT"* leaves no reasonable doubt that ChatGPT was used, and (per the policy quoted above) **all use** is banned.  If this isn't what the policy means, then it needs to be revised.  Again, I'm all in favor of revisions to the policy that allow some *sensible* and *responsible* use, but that's not the policy as it stands today.
- And, nitpick, but if it's properly cited as being *"with the help of ChatGPT"*, then that's not plagiarism, at least ;-)

---

Footnotes:

<sup>1</sup> I raised it the first time, obviously, because I felt this was a self-admission.  I raised it a second time because I felt the first decline simply must have been a mistake.  The third time, I reflagged it again because the "Decline text" made the assertion that *"ChatGPT with Bing"* was two separate AI's.  I clarified that this is *feature* of ChatGPT+, not two separate AI's.

The final decline reason states that the code does something that they've never seen ChatGPT do, but this is still unfortunately an erroneous conclusion since *"ChatGPT with Bing"* was used (by self-admission), which is the feature of ChatGPT+ which enables web-browsing when formulating the response.

This is pretty much identical to Bing Chat's "search and use generative-AI with the LLM model to formulate the completion.  And we've always disallowed that as well.

<sup>2</sup> Keep in mind that I'm probably the major proponent here of [responsible use of AI](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/389675/902710) (reference:"middle ground" section).

Comment: The point I’m making is that language such as “with the help of” isn’t sufficient, in English, to determine **the extent** of that help. It could be anything between “while asking ChatGPT about cats, I remembered about this solution” and “I copy-pasted everything that follows”. Without further evidence, such a sentence alone is not actionable.

Comment: @blackgreen In English, there's no way that I can read *"with the help of ChatGPT"* as anything other than *"I used ChatGPT"*.   Are we really getting hung up on *exactly* how they used it?  All of the heuristics we have are based on a *likelihood* of an answer being AI-generated or assisted.  Which is more probable (by far) - That they were searching for "cats" (or any other explanation) or that they were searching for a solution to the question?

Comment: We don't need to know exactly how they used it, but when deleting stuff we must have *some* ground to stand on. A vague hint that maybe an AI was used to attain a solution isn't sufficient ground to nuke a post (and possibly warn/suspend a user about it), therefore such a flag is not actionable *without other evidence*. If someone gets inspiration from an AI and then writes an original post, the post is original. We can't delete it.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds: "I used ChatGPT to gain some understanding, and then wrote this code myself" is allowed behaviour under current policy, isn't it?  And it's plausible.  So it very much matters whether the answer contains a direct copy/paste of ChatGPT output or not.  That phrasing could get used by people not wanting to admit that they didn't actually test what they're copy/pasting, but the use of the word "help" may indicate that they have at least tested the code.  Or had to change something to get it to compile / run if the code is from ChatGPT, although that doesn't assert understanding...

Comment: @blackgreen Ok, we seem to be in agreement that *"We don't need to know exactly how they used it"*, but then we seem to start going in circles again -- I just can't see any way in English to read *"with the help of ChatGPT"* as a "vague hint".  The *"some ground to stand on"* is the self-admission that the answer (even part of it) was created, *"with the help of ChatGPT"* -- As you said, you don't need to know exactly how.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I disagree that it can be construed as self admission, and my answer here explains why

Comment: @PeterCordes I'm not sure if you read my other answer that I linked to on [responsible use of AI](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389617/discussion-network-policy-regarding-ai-generated-content/389675#389675) (it's linked at the very bottom, so very possible that you didn't follow it).  I'd *love* for us to be in a situation where a user could say, *"I used ChatGPT to gain some understanding, and then wrote this code myself"*, but the community seems to think we're not there yet.  We have far too many users still using AI *irresponsibly* to sort things out, it seems :-/

Comment: If someone actually phrased it that way, I'd have zero problems with that statement in an answer. I might still look a bit more carefully at the code to look for newbie mistakes.  OTOH, if someone literally wrote "*I found the solution with the help of ChatGPT, here you go:*" I'd be looking carefully for any sign of nonsense that could have come from AI (assuming I knew the subject matter well enough to detect that), in which case I'd report *that* to mods, which would be strong evidence that ChatGPT had been used irresponsibly.  (And/or for other answers posted within minutes.)

Comment: Or is the flood of AI-generated crap still at such a high volume that we have to risk throwing the occasional baby out with the bathwater by deleting such posts without even reading them?  I hope that's not the case, but I wouldn't be surprised if it actually is, especially in places that tend to attract AI rep farmers like highly-upvoted but unanswered questions.

Comment: Thinking about this some more, most people that only used ChatGPT to gain insight and learn more before writing code from scratch themselves probably wouldn't have written "*I found the solution with the help of ChatGPT*".  Especially the "found **the** solution" phrasing does hint at irresponsible AI usage.  (Partly since very few questions actually have only one possible "solution", and the amount of credit it implies for ChatGPT is pretty high.)  (@blackgreen).  In fact I'd guess that very few people would attribute that much credit to ChatGPT if the code wasn't mostly from ChatGPT.

Comment: Oh, unless English wasn't their native language, as blackgreen's answer points out.  A bit of a thorny problem, since it does depend on reading a lot into the choice of phrasing.

Comment: @PeterCordes You're on the right track, I think.  But even when the user isn't proficient in English, isn't *"with the help of ChatGPT"* still, as you say, too large an amount of credit to be giving for anything other than assistance in the answer?  I'm just struggling to read it any other way.  A "well-formed English" answer would likely be something more like, *"I found this with assistance from ChatGPT"* (still disallowed, IMHO, in that form), but the non-native English version, I *think*, is more often going to be a simple *"with the help of ChatGPT"* or "*Thanks ChatGPT"*, right?

Comment: What about something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77344747/4032703) where the poster says that ChatGPT *gave* them the answer?

Comment: @EJoshuaS-StandwithUkraine Seems like a blatant self-admission to me, but keep in mind that I'm the one arguing that *"with the help of ChatGPT"* is a self-admission as well ;-)

Comment: "..focus on the all use.." I focused and I think this interpretation here is much too strict. If I had help of AI (and who doesn't nowadays) but afterwards completely reworked the content and checked everything, this is and should be a valid contribution. However, it would fall under "all use", so all use seems to be too strict in my eyes. It will only drive people to completely hide what they did and that is not a better situation. In the end, we only punish those that are transparent (or naive). The overall goal is to limit bad content and the question is if this goal is reached in any way.

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution I would go even one step further and say, someone who only used ChatGPT to develop the right understanding, followed by writing the code on their own, would not even mention ChatGPT in their answer. I do not thank my former teachers in every answer. Even less would I feel obligation to thank a machine that doesn’t care. In other words, any mentioning of ChatGPT is an attempt to talk down the answerer’s responsibility for the solution by pointing to the machine. Which is precisely what we do not allow. The responsibility must be 100% at the answerer.

Comment: @Holger Then edit this comment out as "not necessary". I think it is sometimes good practice to give context of where you get your solutions from. I don't see AI as a teacher but more as a source here and sources might sometimes be included. Unfortunately it's a source that mixes up other sources without properly detailing where itself is drawing its solution from.

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution it’s also a source you can not link to and a source without an author taking the responsibility for what has written there. So it’s actually not a source at all.

Comment: @Holger It's a source. If you use it you didn't completely come up with the result of your own, so it must have come from somewhere else and that is the source. I agree that linking to is unfortunately not really possible and reproducibility may suffer but it's still contextual information.

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution See my [proposal here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/426942/11810933) - I agree, and I'm not in favor of the current "don't ask; don't tell" policy.  Can we find an alternative?

Comment: At what point can we say that something's definitely an admission? Couldn't it become a little hair-splitting to language-lawyer their exact phrasing to see what is (and isn't) an admission?

Comment: @EJoshuaS-StandwithUkraine Well, therein lies the whole reason for this question and its answers ;-).  The rule about removing AI content based on *"self-admission"* goes back even pre-Strike.  During the strike, it was the *only* thing, under the now-deprecated "historical policy", that was allowed to be used for removal.  We've been operating under the rule that self-admission AI-answers were removed for 10 months, and yes, it's frustrating that now we're having to "language-lawyer" exactly what that means.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds "Can we find an alternative?" Yes we can. We should take a step back and ask a different question. It's much less about self-admission (except for blatant self-admission like "I just copied this from an AI, haha"). It's more about proving that you put work into an answer and checked it for yourself. Ask yourself how an answer can actually prove (or make plausible) that it's right. Instead of hunting for hints of AI, hunt for hints of good answers (the underlying premise is that AI cannot produce good answers out of the box, so achieving one goal achieves the other as well).

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution I think we're saying similar things, but not quite sure yet. I'd love to see you elaborate in an answer to [that post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/426942/11810933).  Perhaps you can say it better than I did in my since-deleted self-answer there.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I really wish you would undelete your answer on your question about responsible AI use. Being heavily downvoted by reactionaries, doesn't detract from the fact that it has interesting proposals that may well be useful in future. And understanding someone's view on this topic is always helpful for further discourse.

Comment: @IanKemp Exactly. On meta the score is relatively unimportant (except for estimating community consensus but at low numbers the uncertainty would be quite high anyway and we wouldn't know what the big majority not voting really thinks). It's important what you write. I even wish there was only a random sort order.

Comment: All this splitting of hairs shouldn't be needed. Suppose someone posts: "I found the solution with the help of illegal hacking into the network of company x, here you go:". This too would be a violation of SO's rules, by admission.

Comment: And again, we really don't need to worry about deleting a few posts too many. People who don't want their posts deleted can simply refrain from mentioning ChatGPT in the first place and thereby placing their post in a difficult gray area - that's the posters problem. Karma applies. I don't expect our moderators to be some sort of AI content lawyers and just deleting something isn't the end of the world.

Comment: @Lundin "People who don't want their posts deleted can simply refrain from mentioning ChatGPT..." That already says that there will be only limited return. People will simply not mention it except for some very naive ones. Why even bother to delete. If it won't hurt much it also won't bring much.

Comment: "*my concept of 'all use' was too narrow*" Do you mean "too broad"? "All use" is as broad a view as is possible; anything less would be more narrow, not more broad.

Comment: @TylerH Yes - Thanks for the catch.  I think I was going for something like "too narrowminded" ...

Comment: Oh, nice answer now. Let me flip my vote. I think there is another thing at play here. We should *never* take things written in "official" documentation as posted on this site literally to the word. Push comes to shove, writing things to properly cover intentions is hard and there are a lot of cracks and slip ups all over the place. This policy will be no different. The way it is written will not properly reflect the way it is intended. It is the Stack Overflow way. We used to have a lot of people who were good at reading between the lines, now I have to do it myself. Gah.

Comment: @Gimby I do understand the frustration, and I also wish the policy could be worded better.  You're absolutely correct - Closing all those little cracks in the "intention" is hard :-/

Answer (score 35):

I disagree with blackgreen's answer and agree with NotTheDr01ds here.

**Tl;dr - them thanking an LLM indicates they got value out of it. If they got value out of it, then they used it. By the policy, any *use* of LLMs is banned. As a result, it's self-admission, which is fair game to remove a post under our heuristics policy.**

In the interest of not inflicting the Meta Effect on a (maybe) innocent user, I'm not going to link the post I'm referring to here.

The statement "You can thank [LLM name]... [other text]"* could probably be reasonably extended to "You can thank ChatGPT *for doing something notable regarding what comes after the ellipsis*. I'd guess a reasonable user would assume the words "You can thank [something]" means that the "something" contributed in some way to the answer (and not something else entirely unrelated).

Given that the example in question is an LLM and not a book, let's read the AI policy (the MSO version, specifically).

> All use of generative AI [...] is banned when posting content on Stack Overflow.

(definition of ChatGPT and the note extending it to other LLMs excluded for brevity).

"All use" should include the usage of it to help find a solution. It was *used* after all, even if the literal output wasn't included in the post

If the OP thanks an LLM, that objectively indicates they got some value out of it**. In order for them to have gotten value out of it, *they had to have used an LLM!* Given that, it falls under them admitting they used it.

---

*Including variations with other LLMs, such as "You can thank Google Bard" or "You can thank Bing Chat"

**Unless you see it as sarcasm, but that's not how I read the answer in question

Comment: _""All use" should include the usage of it to help find a solution. It was used after all, even if the literal output wasn't included in the post"_ - That definitely goes too far in my eyes. For example, I learnt about `distinctUntilChanged` in RXJS from ChatGPT yesterday. If I'd posted my problem as a question here and this was the missing piece of the puzzle, I wouldn't be allowed to share a solution for it. Even though I can read the documentation for it, understand what `distinctUntilChanged` does, etc. I can't answer my question because ChatGPT helped me get there. That's silly, no?

Comment: The whole point of the ban on LLMs was to not be flooded with content that looked "OK" at first blush, but turned out to be wrong or flawed, was it not? If someone gets to their solution with the aid of ChatGPT, but the solution as written is wholly theirs, shouldn't that be acceptable?

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama if it was “wholly theirs”, they wouldn’t mention ChatGPT.

Comment: @Holger But at what point do we consider that something they learnt through ChatGPT and wrote as their own answer is no longer associated with ChatGPT? For example, ChatGPT just helped me with the final piece of the puzzle with something in Angular. I already had the majority of the code for it, it was just one minor tweak (`*ngTemplateOutlet` to `[ngTemplateOutlet]`) that made it go from "doesn't work" to "works". If I provided my entire solution to my problem, and said that I got there with the help of ChatGPT, that doesn't mean the answer itself was ChatGPT-generated. That's the point.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama Do you ever mention in your answer that your keyboard helped you writing it? ChatGPT is a tool which doesn’t understand the text it processes. If you understand what it really does and take full responsibility for your answer, there is no need to mention the tools used in the process.

Comment: @Holger No, of course not. Nor would I comment if ChatGPT helped me get to an answer. Do other people do it? Yes, hence the question presented here today. The topic isn't whether people should mention it or not. My point here is that merely using ChatGPT to help you get to a valid and complete solution should not be grounds for an answer to removed in the same way that posting an answer where ChatGPT did the majority of the heavy listing is.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama The application of the policy to questions seems to be achieving, whether it was intended to or not, the same goal as the old "lacks minimal understanding" close reason here. Someone asking something based on ChatGPT likely will not have enough understanding to recognize the issues with their generated code, let alone when an answer is useful. That being said, I don't necessarily disagree that questions should be excluded, but that's a request to change the policy.

Comment: I agree with @ProgrammingLlama here. I believe the part "All use of" covers "with the help of", but I don't think "when posting" covers "I found the solution". What time interval does "posting" cover? The user could for example have found the solution weeks ago with the help of ChatGPT, verified it is correct, and then found the question. I don't really think the rules should implicate that the process of "posting an answer" could start even earlier than when the *question* was first posted! If ChatGPT was used before that, and a claimed (and potentially manually verified) solution was found.

Comment: … In which case the user could rightfully credit ChatGPT's help for finding the solution and admit he used it, but it did not happen specifically *to post/when posting* the answer. To parallel plagiarism rules, once you *know* a particular information, the information is yours and you can freely restate it in your own words, without having to *cite* the source. You can of course *credit* the source, but that is not the same thing. Ad absurdum, imagine yourself 50 years in the future and posting "When I was young, I found the solution thanks to ChatGPT and it worked ever since"… Boom, deleted.

Comment: What about: "I asked ChatGPT, but the answer was wrong, so I ask here". He/she clearly admits having tried ChatGPT.

Answer (score 5):

> Can I take sentences like "with the help of ChatGPT..." as self-admission and flag based on that?

Absolutely. The current policy is completely and wholly unambiguous as to the banning of LLMs **for any content, in any way shape or form**.

Similarly, declining such a flag would be a violation of the policy and a dereliction of your duties as a moderator. *Don't do it.* You're welcome to disagree with the policy, but that doesn't give you latitude to disregard that policy.

If you're unwilling to enforce the policy as it stands, then you must - **must** - step aside as a moderator.

> Without other evidence that the post is AI-generated, can I take this as an admission the OP used an LLM to generate the code and flag it for being in violation of the no generative AI policy?

Absolutely. There is no reason to post "I found the solution with the help of ChatGPT" if you hadn't used ChatGPT (unless you're adding a red herring because you want your post to get deleted, in which case you're just wasting everyone's time).

> [from a comment] The point I’m making is that language such as “with the help of” isn’t sufficient, in English, to determine the extent of that help. It could be anything between “while asking ChatGPT about cats, I remembered about this solution” and “I copy-pasted everything that follows”. Without further evidence, such a sentence alone is not actionable.

Incorrect. "With the help of" unconditionally implies use of an LLM, and the policy unconditionally bans use of LLMs. There is no room for interpretation or opinion in this case; not one iota. Nor is there any amount of language lawyering you can try to use to allow such posts to stand.

Comment: Oh my god. Dereliction of duty? This is not the military. "Must -- **must**? OK, OK! I get it! You want to make sure there is no doubt. You want to have a clear-cut rule. But I'll tell you a secret: Life is complicated. Clear-cut rules typically do not do justice to that complexity. They are an inadequate attempt to reduce complexity; this is no exception. This site is about good answers. The *raison d' être* of moderators is to ensure answer quality. It would be a shame *and reduce site quality* if a mod deleted a good answer just because somebody was transparent about AI assistance.

Comment: Should I assume you've also called for the resignation of all the police officers in your area who don't ticket every single person they see going even slightly over the speed limit on a highway?  Seriously, moderators are elected to use _judgement_ when enforcing the rules. Should the flag maybe have been marked helpful because it was in line with the policy text?  Sure, maybe, but the moderator wanted to communicate that such posts are unlikely to be deleted, and responses to helpful flags are very difficult to notice. It's a tooling limitation, and we do the best we can with what we've got.