Improving description on raised flag for AI generated content
Someone asked a question on SO. Despite another user providing a great answer, the OP found a partial answer using AI so they posted it as an answer to their own SO question. On the other user's posted answer, the OP wrote in a comment:

Thanks a lot, meanwhile, an AI solved the problem in two seconds. :-p df$x<- apply(constats, 1, function(row) ifelse(any(row == 1), 1, 0)) and did it two more times only for the other. But still I get this question, what is the 1 margin here?

The code in this comment is identical to the OP's posted answer, an answer which also asks the question about what the margin of 1 is doing. Given that the OP verbatim stated "AI solved the problem" and they had a question about their own code I raised a flag, stating,

"OP mentioned in comments on other answer that this answer is AI generated".

My flag was declined with the comment:

"Declined - Vague language that suggests an AI tool was involved in creating a post is not enough to reasonably delete it. See also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/426916

The thrust of the linked Meta answer provided by the moderator is: "The phrase "with the help of" and variations thereof is not a direct translation, nor logically related to, "I generated the following with"."
The original comment does not align with this moderator's justification nor the linked answer provided. The language is not vague, and the OP stated "AI solved the problem", in contrast to some variation of AI helped solve the problem. Taken together with the fact that they asked a question about their own code in the answer, a reasonable person could logically infer that this answer was AI generated.
What language could I use to improve my future flags to ensure moderators don't miss these types of cases (without writing a full page explanation)?

I closed this post as a duplicate because there isn't much else to say beyond the two answers you already got, even if I understand that's not what folks want to hear. Unless the post contains objectively unequivocal language that what follows is AI-generated, or additional indicators of AI usage, it will not be mod-deleted.

@blackgreen among all mods I appreciate what you've done for cleaning up this site the most, but respectfully you're wrong here. To almost anyone familiar with R this was objective and unequivocally a wholly AI generated answer, that wasn't the question. The question was more nuanced: how could I improve conveying that in my flag. Thats what I was genuinely looking for. The fact that all mods simply responded with generic statements already saturating this site and closed it, instead of simply providing advice like last paragraph of the first answer, is discouraging and detrimental.

I appreciate the appreciation and I'm sorry you feel this way. I firmly stand by what I wrote in the answer quoted below. We cannot and must not ignore the language problem, which is a central aspect of moderation when dealing with alleged self-admission of AI usage. As I said, I closed this question because it does not matter what you write in the flag text: if the alleged self-admission is not completely unequivocal and there's no other sign of AI usage in the post itself, the flag will be declined, meaning that the moderator refuses to delete the post based on the alleged self-admission.

@blackgreen I'm certainly happy to leave this as an agree-to-disagree determination, differing opinions make the world go round. Thanks again for your efforts, I'm sure its not easy

For posterity, based on the advice given the best answer is to not raise a flag if the evidence is specific to a computer language.

I do think this is AI, but I don't think your flag text was sufficient to demonstrate that. The Meta answer the mod linked you to contains this paragraph:

Yes, in the end it comes down to how you read the English language. Can we devise universally valid rules? I believe we can't. People with different English levels, different backgrounds, different native languages can and will interpret the same sentence differently. And this is why we can't assume that these remarks amount to admission. We don't know how the OP speaks English, and they might not mean "I copy-pasted the following from [LLM]". Deleting posts this way will lead to frustration and unfairness on all sides.

As someone whose first language is American English, I agree that the phrasing of "AI solved the problem" implies that OP copied their code directly from AI. But that is an implication, nothing more. A high school English teacher might call this "denotation vs connotation" - you and I agree on the meaning of this phrase based on previous experience with similar phrases, but that doesn't mean everybody would agree on it, and you probably wouldn't find that in a dictionary. That's doubly true since SO is such an international site - if moderators are too willing to delete posts based on connotation, that will disproportionately affect users whose first language is not English.
Nevertheless, the Meta post followed that paragraph immediately with this one:

Ultimately, in these cases my advice is to focus on other indicators of AI usage. If these aren't available, flag conservatively. Eventually, ignore remarks of uncertain interpretation and edit them out.

There were some other indicators in this instance. OP only had 29 rep (which they got from two upvotes and accepting two answers from other users), and as you said, not understanding their code is a bit of a tell. Both of those things would have been good to add into your flag. I don't know if that would've been enough to overwhelm the presumption against AI-generated content, but it certainly wouldn't have hurt.

I don't see why you think this is a question of semantics. There's nothing ambiguous about, "an AI solved the problem in two seconds", followed by some code which the user states works but they don't understand. The policy states any content crafted, in part or in whole by generative AI will be deleted. This doesn't seem an ambiguous case. I also don't understand your suggestion that the user's rep should have been listed as a relevant factor in the flag.

@SamR I agree that it’s almost unambiguous. But I can barely see an interpretation where OP didn’t copy the code directly from AI, and I can imagine that mods would want to be cautious. The low rep is a proxy for them being relatively new to the site, which (in addition to not knowing what their code does) cinches it for me.

To put it differently, the mod thought it was at least a little ambiguous, which proves that it’s at least a little ambiguous. To me, that’s enough to request more evidence.

It's forbidden to use AI to post answers, but there's nothing wrong with sharing a solution you have learned through AI. The phrase "AI solved the problem" doesn't mean that the AI wrote the answer you are reading.

Did you read the question I posted above? “AI solved the problem” is not the only piece of evidence here. AI very clearly wrote the code in this case and this user posted the code quite literally not understanding what the code does (by their own admission). My question wasn’t if AI wrote the code, it was what language can I use to improve my flags and ensure moderators don’t continue to miss these types of cases.

@jpsmith there is literally no other piece of evidence anywhere, unless you want to consider not understanding your own code as evidence. But don't you agree there's plenty of programmers out there that don't understand their code? That's hardly evidence of anything. You don't need an LLM to make a bad programmer.

No I respectfully dont agree at all - I have never taught, worked with, or otherwise known anyone who would, without knowing what the function does, arbitrarily know to add a 1 in the apply R's function then ask "why did I add a 1 here?" There is ample and unequivocal additional evidence here, my question was how could I convey that. It appears this answer didn't even attempt to answer that.
