# Does the policy change for AI-generated content affect users who (want to) flag such content?

Tags: discussion, chatgpt

A post announcing new policy regarding AI Generated content was posted to the network-wide meta: [What is the network policy regarding AI Generated content?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389582/1372392). However, so far I haven't seen any announcements regarding changes in the local Stack Overflow policy: [Temporary policy: ChatGPT is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/21363224).

My understanding is that the new policy only applies to moderators banning users that create answers with GPT/AI-generated content. And we, humble users flagging such posts, are not affected in any way. However, the new policy post is not very clear on how it affects non-moderators.

How does the new policy affect flagging, and what should a regular user change in their behavior regarding AI-generated answers?

Comment: Well, they tanked our ability to enforce it. We're probably gonna post an announcement and/or update the ban post soon (barring a strike preventing this), but we're still discussing internally (and having extensive discussions with CMs on the off chance they revert the policy)

Comment: I look "forward" to seeing a huge volume of vomit being present on the site in the future. Personally, I enjoy eating my cornflakes in the morning while looking at s\*\*t on my phone. *This is just another sign of how out of touch the Stack Overflow/Exchange Staff are with the sites*

Comment: "...are not affected in any way..." The flags are handled by moderators, so not directly affected, but for sure indirectly affected.

Comment: any update on this? is the company willing to back off at all?

Answer (score 252, accepted):

The policy is not clear. It has not yet been effectively communicated to moderators. Worse, the statements being made in public are rather different (in details, but *critical* details, specifically the ones we find most objectionable) from the statements that have been made to us in private. Obviously, the wrongheadedness of the policy announcement aside, the way this was [not] communicated to us and the whole manner in which it was enacted is one of the most frustrating and saddening things about it.

So far, based on what we *think* we understand, the company has attempted to effectively forbid us from removing AI-generated content, except in very narrow circumstances. The entire SO mod team (at least, those who have been reached for comment) is profoundly against this, to the point of not being willing to comply with it. What we will actually do is still under discussion.

But to specifically answer your question (besides confirming that it's really unclear and nobody really knows the real answer), yes, the official policy that was announced applies **only to moderators** and does not affect regular users who want to raise flags.

We moderators don't know how we will handle such flags going forward. There are different strategies being proposed and discussed and even practiced internally. You may find your flags being handled in the same way as always, in a different way, or deferred. We cannot make any promises right now; we simply don't know.

However, we (the moderator team) are not, at this time, officially asking for (or endorsing) users to alter their behavior in terms of what they are choosing to flag or, more generally, what their quality standards are.

You should continue to flag content that you think is not appropriate and not suitable for the site, using your best judgment. It is the consensus of the mod team that regardless of what policies staff adopts, flags that are accurate and raised in good faith will not be declined by the moderator team.

The only thing that we would say is that the company is correct about one general point: the AI detectors are not very accurate, and their "verdicts" need to be taken with a major heaping of salt. To quote myself, from messages I posted in various moderation/curation-focused chat rooms over the past couple of days:

> [A]s we [moderators] have in the past, we continue to advise caution in relying solely on "AI detector" tools, because these tools tend to produce results that are fairly inaccurate (e.g., false positives). Instead, please take into account other heuristics and use your natural intelligence. Policy discussions aside, these make for better and more accurate flags.

And, of course, you should prepare your popcorn. May God have mercy on us all.

Comment: All hail our AI overlords. Investment decisions are made by AI, which result in C-level E's being assigned by AI, who make their policies based on AI, who now start writing day-to-day operations based on what the AI says. It won't be long before you have to check `[  ] Beep boop. I am a robot` before you can post your answer, optionally followed by a mild P=NP test.

Comment: I've been eating popcorn since "Be Nice" became official policy. It was the very obvious beginning of a very slippery slope that we're now starting to see the end of.

Comment: at least we can still downvote :')

Comment: I feel stressed about it as a casual outside observer - I really don't know how you mods continue the way you do. You have my thanks, FWIW.

Comment: "It is my sad duty to inform you that as of Six A.M. this morning we are formally at war with the Kilrathi. God help us all."

Comment: Thanks, @takendarkk. The stress level is... off the charts. I really don't know how we mods continue the way we do, either. Many of us are wondering right now, more than ever, why we bother. Hearing from users like you, who appreciate what we're doing, is actually quite meaningful, since you're the ones we're doing it for. Thank you for commenting. (Yeah, yeah, normally "thank you" comments are unwelcome, but this is Meta.)

Comment: So it was *you*, @starball!! ;-) But yeah, sarcasm aside, the most critical, fundamental, impactful, and, unfortunately, underestimated content-moderation/curation tool (i.e., the downvote) is still allowed and we have no indications that its days are numbered.

Comment: Looks like am not the only one fighting with the moderators. The Stack Exchange staff also oppose some of their actions. Way to go SO.

Comment: "Many of us are wondering right now, more than ever, why we bother."  Yeah, a lot of us have been wondering about stuff like that since 2019.  Some have been wondering since about 2012 or so.  It really feels sometimes like Joel set out to make StackExchange as "Experts-Exchange without the evil" and succeeded for about three years...

Comment: @Mason Wheeler: Yes, it was extremely well designed, but they forgot to take [the](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/10/04/asking-better-questions/) [Eternal September](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_September) event into account. It should be taken into account from the very beginning when someone designs the successor (as it is very hard to change after the fact).

Comment: Eternal September is a really hard problem to solve. When you get a flood of folks who do not give a <expletive deleted> about the site goals and just want their instant gratification, you really don't have a lot of options. Unfortunately the profit motive almost certainly means the wrong option from that limited pool will be chosen.

Comment: The difference for me, @Mason, is that, as terrible as the company's decisions were back in 2019, they didn't do anything that prevented moderators or the community as a group from moderating their sites and otherwise maintaining quality content. (They prevented *one specific* mod from doing that, while also launching a public smear campaign against her, not unlike the current ongoing smear campaign on MSE that we're a bunch of blundering fools who have been misidentifying posts as GPT-generated and issuing biased suspensions, but that's not the same thing as stopping us from using mod tools.)

Comment: There were a few questions I called out as looking like they were Markov chains years ago before being asked not to since they were more likely just very poorly written or the output of a translator. This is a similar problem. In the end I think it'll come down to the same solution. Downvote the bad content and wait for the server to ban the poster. Just pray that it doesn't fool enough people to start collecting upvotes. The only thing SO really has going for it is reviewed information. If that breaks down, the site's dead.

Comment: I absolutely get their point about the detectors being (very) unreliable, but FFS, **talk with the moderators about it** rather than dropping a restrictive policy from on high. Moderators are the front line! And if SE, Inc is looking at the bottom line, they might want to add up the cost of either not having moderators (rapid descent into a cesspool) or having to pay people to do it (expensive, and the results won't be nearly so good). Sending all of you mods good thoughts. 

Comment: It would be best if you complied, no policy comes out of a company without being discussed in some board room by all stakeholders involved.

Comment: **We** – *the community* who has contributed the content and moderation and everything else that makes these sites what they are – ***are* a *key stakeholder* in these Q&A sites.** We were not consulted. Demanding to be consulted, respected, and treated like the stakeholders that we are is *exactly* what the strike is about.

Comment: @CodyGray-onstrike I'm still not sure how this rule prevents moderators _"moderating their sites and otherwise maintaining quality content?"_ If a user posts a poor answer, you have a tool for that. If they do so systematically, you have tools for that. You can't use "probably GPT" as a reason but you can still use "it's crap". What material difference does it make?

Comment: @Mr.Boy Private instructions the mods received explicitly forbid that kind of workaround...

Comment: @Cerbrus Hold on, just to clarify, this is even if the answer suspected to be AI generated is straight up incorrect, not just poor quality? My thought was the same as Mr. Boy's, if that's true, that is incredibly backwards.

Comment: From what I understood, they can't use AI, or even suspicious of it being AI-generated as deletion reasons any more. An answer being "wrong" has never really been a deletion reason, just one to downvote.

Comment: @BrockBrown, 1. mods don't delete "straight up incorrect answers", regardless of their origin. Such answers are subject for downvoting, and can be deleted bu users (vote to delete, >20k reputation), but are not subject for flagging/moderation. 2. I believe mods can act on post regarding other policies, for example spam or very low quality. But most chatGPT answers are not suitable for this: they have reasonable quality, while might contain incorrect information. Using "incorrect" deletion reasons (like VLQ or plagiarism) is said to be privately prohibited by SE.

Comment: _"[...] they might want to add up the cost of either not having moderators (rapid descent into a cesspool) or having to pay people to do it (expensive, and the results won't be nearly so good)."_ - oooor, they might put up an AI to moderate content. :(

Comment: @MatijaNalis And if you want to see how well THAT works out, look at MS Answers. I don't think they've turned AI loose as a moderator there but it can't be far off.

Answer (score 47):

Ban them for plagiarism. People shouldn't be posting material they didn't write and passing it off as their own. If SE wants to take a pro-plagiarism stance, good luck to them.

Comment: Whether AIGC qualifies for plagiarism is totally up for interpretation by SO Inc. after all...

Comment: I don't know for sure, but based on many mentions of differences between public and private announcement of new policy, I will speculate that deleting AI content as plagiarism was also clear-wordedly forbidden.

Comment: See [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424952/discussion-new-ai-generated-content-policy/424955?noredirect=1#comment959803_424963) by Cody

Comment: Not sure this would solve things. Plagiarism hinges on knowing *what source* a post was plagiarised *from*. If relying on AI detectors is forbidden, then that's a problem no matter if posts are flagged for plagiarism or AI. It would be a shame to see actual plagiarism get shadowed by AI.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I think there are two differentl levels of potential plagiarism. The first level is done by the user who pretends to write his own answer while in fact it was generated by AI. I think there is no doubt that this should be flagged. But this could be avoided by the user by simply posting AI generated answers as community wiki answers and clearly stating that they are AI generated. The potential plagiarism that is commited by AI is the second level. There it is harder to judge how much plagiarism is involved. But up to a certain degree one can persuade AI to cite original sources.

Comment: @Sebastian I'm not saying it is not plagiarism. I'm saying it cannot be *flagged* as plagiarism because there is no way to say where it was plagiarised *from*.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi At the same (admittedly somewhat unrelieable) level as it was possible to detect AI generated messages on SO so far (they were banned after all), it is possible to say it was "plagiarised from this AI" (the first level of plagiraism that I ment).  For the other level (if and where AI plagiarised from)  I agree that there seems to be no way to tell...

Comment: @Sebastian The means by which "it was possible to detect AI generated messages on SO so far" have been prohibited to be used. As far as I understood the announcements and comments, this applies to *all* purposes of flagging the content. So even for plagiarism, they cannot be used to say "this was plagiarised from an AI".

Comment: @Sebastian I don't think it's reasonable to draw any link between AI-generated posts being banned and the ability to detect them. They could be banned on principle even if there were no way to detect them - plenty of precedent in actual laws around the world for this.

Comment: I'm pretty sure a _regular user_, regardless of reputation level, doesn't have the capability to ban other users.  So it's hard to see how this answers the question that was asked.

Comment: @TobySpeight, I believe hobbs meant flag mentioned post as plagiarism (and for mods in turn to ban based on that). But that position doesn't hold: SE has pretty strict position regarding plagiarism proof. You should provide evidence of plagiarism: link that will contain original content, that was plagiarized. For chatGPT it is not feasible. And if we going to ignore SE's rules, we can simply keep flagging (and mods banning) as it was before new policy.

Comment: Though I agree to with you somewhat, all knowledge was learned from somewhere else (by a teacher, from books, online, etc). So anyone posting any answer is 'plagiarising' if they don't actually cite the source.

Comment: @iBug see Slate (a CM staff)'s post [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/385002/997587): "_as detailed in [answer to: "Is attribution required for machine-generated text when posting on Stack Exchange?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/384648), we do consider AI generated content to be "the work of others" and the [requirements for referencing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) must be followed for all such content on the network._"

Comment: I dont care if the answer came from some AI system. I DO care its accurate and helpful. If as users, we keep flagging and downvoting inaccurate and unhelpful answers while voting up answers that actually helped then eventually the rubbish *SHOULD* disappear.

Comment: @JohnnyJP - I've seen people upvote and even select AI generated answers.  And in all 3 cases the answers seemed good even though they were wrong.  In the past I was able to flag these users who were bulk posting AI content and it was removed.  Yet, under the new (hidden) policy this rubbish no longer disappears.

Comment: Not understanding why you guys are soo anti-AI generated answers. Did you guys even check the latest Developers survey?  There is some really bad news for you guys.

Comment: @krish and I don't understand why you're so pro-theft and fraud, but there we are.

Comment: @krish the one that says very few developers trust them to be accurate?

Comment: @JohnnyJP Note that you need five downvotes to undo the rep gain from a single upvote. No matter how much rep you plan to spend on downvotes, you'll never beat the occasional do-gooders who upvote well-written answers from new users without actually checking them.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev JohnnyJP suggested to downvote bad answers to hide them, not to decrease the reputation (which is a side effect).

Comment: @hobbs I don't consider training models on publicly published content to be theft. If a human reads/views content and learns from it, then generates/creates words or images that reflect that learning, nobody bats an eye (as long as their words/images aren't a violation of copyright). IMO, machines doing the same is no different.  That said, I support preventing low-quality content, and the Mods' strike to keep SO healthy.

Comment: @jinglesthula but these AIs are actually trained with [copyrighted code](https://blog.desdelinux.net/en/as-expected-copilot-is-already-generating-code-protected-by-copyright/), and also notice that the training data are closed-source but even open-source projects often require attribution

Comment: @Tortar If a human reads through copyrighted code, becoming more able to write code themselves by doing so, then goes and writes code, is that human required to provide attribution for their learning?  They could be applying patterns and techniques learned from observing copyrighted code, but not actually copying the code itself.  If a machine does the same, is it any different?

Comment: so if I create a machine learning model which totally overfits the training data becoming a kind of hash table there shouldn't be any copyrighting problem since it is learning? And also, in my opinion, how a machine learns (currently) can't be compared with the way a human learns

Comment: Probably I wasn't clear, the code CoPilot gave as an answer in the link I provided was a copy-paste of the copyrighted code

Comment: @Tortar mmm, after reading up a bit, I think you're right.  I think an AI approach that actually just "learns" and then actually does create based on that learning would be one thing (and was what I thought Copilot was doing).

Answer (score 12):

The company alleged change in policy on AI-generated content should perhaps take into account fast changing regulatory environment...

Serving unlabeled AI-generated content to the European market can soon get a company fined, GDPR-style (search for instance for "european commission wants clear labelling of ai generated content")

Comment: There is no change in the policy regarding the AI-generated content itself. The change is in what mods are permitted to do to *identify* that content and how they penalise the posters of such content.

Comment: That particular headline seems to be Information Week, which has a rather pesky advertisement wall before the actual content. Perhaps see instead https://techcrunch.com/2023/06/06/eu-disinformation-code-generative-ai-labels/

Comment: That might as well become the deciding factor. If SE has a choice between losing users and making mods angry, users get priority because users=traffic=money, while mods are taken for granted. But if it becomes a choice between losing a few users or paying up to 6% of global annual turnover in misinformation fines, clear labelling of AI-generated content suddenly gets priority.