# What's going on with Articles on Microsoft Azure Collective?

Tags: discussion, plagiarism, collectives, articles

Recently, multiple articles per day are getting posted to Microsoft Azure Collective. Based on that publishing rate, I got a little suspicious, so started looking at a couple of them and it seems that they are (at best) a summary of existing documentation.

Let's take this for example: https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/azure/articles/75884804/understanding-proxyaddress-conflicts-for-b2b-guest-users-in-microsoft-azure-acti

It is almost entirely a word by word copy of the given source, with some redactions, but no added value or even paraphrasing.

Is it acceptable to copy and paste parts of the documentation, apply some minimal formatting changes, and post them as articles here?

Comment: In the past, this was allowed... as long as the author of the article is the author of the source. But how does that work for authors who are employees of the source? The author in this case doesn't seem to be a contributor to the source

Comment: @KevinB yeah, I looked at the 22 contributors, could not make a connection between the OP's account and those.

Comment: [Catija's answer](/a/418473) from when [a similar issue came up last year](/q/418451) seems pertinent here; based on that answer, this behavior _sounds_ like it runs afoul of guidelines, unless they've since loosened up.

Comment: They aren't exactly the same, though the exact phrase *"one of the things we check for is for a collision in the proxyAddress"* appears in both. And the next three sentences copied verbatim as well (converted into a list). If it wasn't for the affiliation, it could characterised as a plagiariser with higher energy than the typical minimal-effort plagiariser (wholesale copying/blatant plagiarism)—a plagiariser trying to hide their tracks by changing the text slightly (though no match for real plagiarism tools, I presume).

Comment: I don't think it is fine. Plagiarism is [plagiarism](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/plagiarism#Noun) - *"Copying of another person's ideas, text or other creative work, and presenting it as one's own, especially without permission; plagiarizing."*. Here is [a similar example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19676403/running-python-in-powershell/44457104#44457104), also copying straight from Microsoft documentation.

Comment: That kind is also lower quality than the original. In the example, [missing articles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Dax90QyXgI&t=17m54s) and [run-on sentences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_clause_structure#Run-on_sentences) were "added". It is probably never going to be fixed, and we are in a sense back to the bad old days of early 2000s horrible horrible forums and the hyphen site.

Comment: "Is it acceptable to copy and paste parts of the documentation, apply some minimal formatting changes, and post them as articles here?" If the poster here is the copyright holder or has permission to reprint then legally yes. Whether it is very useful to kind of duplicate content here just for the sake of duplicating content...

Comment: It is not just plagarism that is happening here. In my experience some of the Microsoft documentation is not very helpful (more citation required) https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419331/microsoft-azure-customer-engineers-giving-low-quality-answers?rq=1

Comment: Of the 22 contributors listed for the Microsoft documentation one is `prmerger-automator[bot]`, also listed are PRMerger6, PRMerger13 and PRMerger17. This must put the article close to the realm of  AI generated content policy https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424952/discussion-new-ai-generated-content-policy

Comment: Actually if you read the collectives article and the source documentation they are off topic for SO - more appropriate for SuperUser

Comment: "Actually if you read the collectives article and the source documentation they are off topic for SO"—that seems like part of the _point_ of Collectives to me. Let's get companies to buy a private area where they can more or less do whatever they want.

Answer (score 6):

This is expected. [zcoop98's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427136/whats-going-on-with-articles-on-microsoft-azure-collective?cb=1#comment977648_427136) references a question I asked which addressed essentially the same issue.

SE Inc. actively encourages Collectives to copy-paste their existing documentation and articles into SO Articles.

From an earlier Collectives tour:

> Our editor makes publishing content easy - choose the Markdown or WYSIWYG version. If the content exists elsewhere, simply copy and paste and your formatting comes along for the ride.

p.s. there's more discussion in the comments under [my answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/418498/6632744) to the same question.

Comment: yeesh. isn't that actively bad for the site? I thought Google search will rank lower content that is copied from somewhere else?

Comment: I guess the upside is we don't need to bother interacting with Articles at all. Just ignore them.

Comment: Your "actively encourages" statement is incorrect. The passage you quote here is specifically referencing the editor parsing functionality that allows formatting to be copied over from another text editor. As you noted, that text is also no longer present in any product tour of Collectives (the tour links to the community guidelines for articles).

Comment: That quote from the tour is/was problematic and was deleted since. I am not sure what good it does to bring it up now. I don't think that problematic quote was meant to encourage what you're portraying here (that was obviously saying our formatting is good as @Berthold confirmed). IMO, this answer assigns the blame unjustly. Plagiarizer is a representative of Microsoft on this platform, not an employee of SO. I am not happy with the status quo but I'd try to not lose the sight of fairness.

Comment: Looks like that passage is actually referring to the feature of Stacks Editor, that copy-pasting rich content in WYSIWYG mode will preserve the same formatting and even links (and I just knew this and just tested it).