# How to find a question by its old tag when that tag is synonymized with another

Tags: support, status-review, meta, tag-search

On Meta, [chatgpt](/questions/tagged/chatgpt) has been synonymized with [ai-generated-content](/questions/tagged/ai-generated-content), but when I go to its tag page, there are only 7 questions listed when I know that there were way more questions with the chatgpt tag alone.

Sure enough, there are some questions that are tagged [chatgpt](/questions/tagged/chatgpt) but cannot be found by neither [chatgpt] nor [ai-generated-content]. Here are two examples:

- [How can we determine whether an answer used ChatGPT?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421880/19123103)
- [Does the policy change for AI-generated content affect users who (want to) flag such content?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/424910/19123103)

Both of these questions have the [chatgpt](/questions/tagged/chatgpt) tag but when you click that tag, it redirects to a page titled "Questions tagged [ai-generated-content]" which doesn't list these questions.

Is this a bug or caching issue or status-by-design? How do we search for questions once their tags are synonymized with other tags?

Comment: I see 65 questions under https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ai-generated-content so that might be a caching issue on your end.

Comment: I do only see 7, not 65, so it's certainly not client caching (today being the first time i've visited that page)

Comment: Both comments are correct. Depends on which tab/ordering you're looking at - on Newest, it shows 7, while on Active and Score, it shows 65. It doesn't seem to matter whether you visit through the synonym tag or its target.

Comment: We had meant to put together a bug report when this came up. But it got lost in the shuffle. Synonyms and search are broken and there is no way to use search to discover these questions.

Comment: I made [a query to find tags affected](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1789355/unmerged-synonyms-question-count) and also [one to find links to questions that are undiscoverable for a given source tag](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1789356/list-questions-with-source-tag-but-not-target-tag-unmerged-synonyms).