# Total and count do not match

Tags: support, tags, api

A user [asked about the Stack Overflow API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77421451/295783).

After some digging, I found a few ways to answer how many questions are tagged `airflow`.

- **Tags:** https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/tags/airflow/info?site=stackoverflow

  ```
  {
    "name": "airflow",
    "has_synonyms": true, // this may be the reason?
    "count": 10263
    ...
  }
  ```
- **Custom filter:** (from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52506116/how-can-i-fetch-the-total-amount-of-items)) https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/questions?tagged=airflow&site=stackoverflow&filter=!w-*Ytm8YGWVl9..xoC

  ```
  {
    "total": 11509
  }
  ```

Why is there a discrepancy between the count and the total? Could it be synonyms?

Comment: This is related to this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427023/how-to-find-a-question-by-its-old-tag-when-that-tag-is-synonymized-with-another If I check the "Newest" tab for the airflow tag I see around 10k questions while if I see the "Active" tab I see around 11k.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's certainly easier to see what's going on if you try a tag with fewer questions (or indeed a site that has fewer questions so that the tags automatically have fewer questions).

In [Vegetarianism and Veganism](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/) we have some suitable tags where we can just count the tagged posts if we need to.

On that site the [traveling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/traveling) tag has 4 questions and the [travel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/travel) tag has 11 questions. [traveling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/traveling) is a synonym of [travel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/travel) and if you display questions tagged [travel](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/travel), you'll see there are 15 questions.

The [questions API for questions tagged travel](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/questions?tagged=travel&site=vegetarianism&filter=!w-*Ytm8YGWVl9..xoC) returns 15 i.e. the total number including synonyms

Whereas if you query the [travel tag](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/tags/travel/info?site=vegetarianism) you'll get 11

If you replace travel by traveling in the above queries you'll just get the values from the travel tag i.e. 15 and 11 respectively.

Presumably if the tags were merged rather than just synonymised, there would be only one tag and therefore only one value.

Regarding the [airflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/airflow) here if we look at the [tag synonyms page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms) and type in airflow, we'll see this row - the only one where the synonym has numbers against it...

| synonym | target | creator | created | # of Renames | Last Renamed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| airflow-scheduler × 1253 | airflow × 10263 | Jarek Potiuk | Aug 10, 2021 | 381 | 2d ago |

and 1253 + 10263 = 11516 i.e. the numbers pretty much match up to what you'd now expect.

Comment: The totals still don't quite make sense... In that, yes 1253 + 10263 is 11516, but there only appears to be [37 questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1795289) (at least as of the last SEDE update) that have the [airflow-scheduler] but do not have the [airflow] tag. Given this, we'd only expect the total number of [airflow] questions including synonyms to be **37** more than the number of questions tagged [airflow] alone which is nowhere near the more than a thousand difference.

Comment: It seems likely that you are correct and that these individual tag totals are being added together to get the 11509 number, but it really doesn't make sense to calculate the total this way since there can be many questions that have both tags... unless I'm missing something? [These totals](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1795288) seem more accurate to the real number of questions represented by the airflow tag.

Comment: @HenryEcker indeed it doesn't make much sense to report synonyms this way. Perhaps there are questions that had airflow-scheduler and airflow before the synonymisation.