# The [oracle] tag is currently "broken" following partial renaming of the tag

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonym-process

Following the meta-question [Rename [oracle] to [oracle-database]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/427484/1509264) someone has created the [oracle-database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle-database) tag and synonymised [oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle) to [oracle-database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle-database).

New questions are being created with the [oracle-database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle-database) tag (currently 26 and increasing).

However, the existing 17,000 Oracle questions still have the [oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle) tag (and not [oracle-database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle-database)) and we cannot filter searches if we want to look for duplicates (etc.) using the tag because [oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle) now redirects to [oracle-database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle-database) so that search is limited to the 26 new questions and not the 17,000 previous questions.

Another minor problem is that gold tag badge holders cannot dupe-hammer questions but that was to be expected during the migration process (but often the questions are tagged with [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) and [oracle-database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle-database) so we can dupe-hammer based on a different tag so this isn't as much of a problem as it could have been).

Do we just need to wait for the renaming process to be complete (since I'm assuming someone is going to run a script to retag those 17,000 questions)? If so, do you have an approximate timescale? Or is there a bug that needs fixing?

Comment: I found one question posted 2024-01-16 that is tagged with [[tag:oracle]] and not the synonym. Here it is for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77828580

Comment: Looking at [Machavity's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/427789) the merge fails when done by a mod. And a developer needs to step in. That's already been brought to the attention of the company via applying [[meta-tag:status-review]].

Comment: @VLAZ No, that question is already linked to in the question and it explains the root cause of the problem (Machivity started the tag renaming process and it failed and needs to be completed by a developer) but it doesn't answer all the questions of "What is the approximate timescale?" and answers on how to work round the problem would be off-topic for the question you've linked to.

Comment: Somewhat relevant here as well is how search interacts with synonyms [How to find a question by its old tag when that tag is synonymized with another](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/427023/15497888)

Answer (score 3):

As a partial work-around while the tags are being updated, instead of searching for [oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle) (which doesn't work) or [oracle-database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle-database) (which only currently contains the new questions), search for `[oracle*]` as it matches both the old and the new tags.

It will also match a lot of unrelated Oracle products such as [oracle-apex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle-apex) or [oracle-cloud-infrastructure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle-cloud-infrastructure) but, hopefully, specifying additional search terms when looking for duplicates will filter out most of the irrelevant results.

Comment: Not sure if there's something weird going on on my end, but when I [search for `[oracle*]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle-database+or+oracle11g+or+oracle-sqldeveloper+or+oracle10g+or+oracle-apex+or+oracle12c+or+oracle-adf+or+oracleforms+or+oracle19c+or+oracle-apex-5.1+or+oracle-cloud-infrastructure+or+oracle-apex-5+or+oracle-call-interface+or+oracle9i+or+oracle11gr2+or+oracle-xe+or+oracle-data-integrator+or+oracle18c+or+oraclereports+or+oracle-spatial) it expands it to a list which does **not** include the bare [[tag:oracle]] so the workaround does not seem to work.

Comment: @cafce25 It expands to a list that doesn't include [tag:oracle] in the expanded list of tags  (probably because of the synonym redirecting it to [tag:oracle-database]) but it does include those questions tagged with [tag:oracle] in the search results so the result works even if it appears that it shouldn't.