# Is ChatGPT content automatically detected?

Tags: discussion, moderation, chatgpt

Since [ChatGPT content is (rightly) banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/399649), is new content being run through an automatic AI detector? If users have to manually notice and flag content, a lot is going to slip through.

Comment: [No.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389582/241919)

Comment: ChatGPT is effectively no longer banned (see Andrew’s comment). [That makes us very unhappy](https://openletter.mousetail.nl/)

Comment: Detected in what context? There is [SOCVR](https://socvr.org/faq#what-is-smoke-detector-and-how-can-i-participate). It [is officially blessed](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/06/25/how-does-spam-protection-work-on-stack-exchange/). (I may or may not have mixed things up.)

Comment: It would be possible. Some tools exist (smoke detector...) that automatically check new content. The same could be done with AI generated content detectors. Doesn't mean that is was done like this in the past months, just that the technical infrastructure exists for it.

Comment: Not systematically by Stack Exchange the company, no. Some users are toying with various volunteer efforts to run detectors on fresh posts, but given the propensity for false positives, this is probably not something that would provide immediate value for automation.

Comment: @PeterMortensen SmokeDetector does not scan for AI-generated content. It is focused on detecting [spam.](/help/promotion) Flagging AI-generated content manually was certainly in scope for SOCVR before official policy made this moot.

Comment: Is this a naive question? Or is it a ploy to inform the community of the latest happenings since May 31st? BTW from the limited amount of literature I've read, AI/GPT detectors are somewhat unreliable in detecting GPT generated content, and this is especially true for texts such as proposals, resumes, and scholastic essays.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Why would it be a naive question? Just because something is unreliable doesn't really mean nobody would ever think of automatizing it? One could think of it as the shotgun approach and there could be advantages for generating candidates.

Comment: @For someone whose line of work is programming/developing–because why else does the OP have 30K rep–a question like theirs is naive this late in the day. Trusting in the [reliability and accuracy of an AI detector](https://www.makeuseof.com/ai-content-detectors-dont-work/#:~:text=In%20February%202023%2C%20University%20of,none%20of%20them%20are%20reliable.) is a little ironic.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Why would my work as an Angular developer give me any insight into the accuracy of AI detectors?

Answer (score 8):

No, it's not.

AI detection software isn't accurate enough to safely automate it.
All flags / deletions and other taken actions were manually reviewed.

There's a lot more detail about this issue in the [current strike's](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424979/what-has-happened-to-lead-moderators-to-consider-striking) [announcements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389811/moderation-strike-stack-overflow-inc-cannot-consistently-ignore-mistreat-an).

Answer (score -14):

I doubt it is, being that [ChatGPT answers are now permitted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389582/what-is-the-network-policy-regarding-ai-generated-content). This has led to [a strike](https://openletter.mousetail.nl/).

Comment: This is plain wrong. ChatGPT answers are still banned. It's that moderators aren't allowed to enforce that policy.

Comment: Delete this misinformation.

Comment: If only we had moderators, @user438383, we could do cleanup tasks like that.

Comment: @CodyGray-onstrike What's an moderator?

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine someone who buys a sixpack of beer and then throws three of them in the trash. Moderation!

Comment: Ecologically, that's a nightmare.

Comment: @Zoe A moderator is someone who continually gives freely of their time to clean up the site and respond to user concerns, but is repeatedly disrespected, publicly smeared, and otherwise treated poorly by the staff of the company who owns this site.

Comment: @Adriaan - I see no difference between a ban that you don't enforce and no ban at all.

Comment: I didn't know about the strike. Added my name, this is ridiculous.