# Why does the temporary policy have over 1M views?

Tags: discussion, chatgpt

What is appealing about the featured [temporary policy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned) that it has garnered over a million views?

I presume the majority of community members would prefer to have ChatGPT content allowed to help them earn reputation faster so why would they want to visit a post that states it is banned?

Where are all these views coming from really?!

Comment: Your assumption that community members would prefer to have AI-generated content be allowed is wildly inaccurate. Given the score on the policy post, particularly given that you can see the breakdown of upvotes and downvotes, it's unclear to me why you'd make such an assumption. There are, of course, a significant number of people who do want to use AI generation to farm reputation. There are many that have been trying to do that since the day ChatGPT was announced. I just don't see why one would make the assumption that *the majority* of people in the community would want to use it to do so.

Comment: As of 2023-07-17, the "[Temporary policy: Generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT) is banned](/q/421831/3773011)" policy had **overwhelming support, with 97.89% of users who voted approving the policy** (3,981 up, 86 down). Even when including responses from users who can't actually vote (1,408 up, 267 down, or 84.06% approval of just those who can't vote), the total approval rate for the AI-generated-content ban is 93.85% (5,389 up, 352 down). These sites, generally, operate on a consensus of the users. The approval of the policy to ban AI-generated content is one of the clearest consensuses we have.

Comment: @Makyen I understand that the net vote is in favor of the policy but the ratio of this net to the number of views is marginal, meaning the majority of viewers abstained even though the view count isn't very accurate (it counts duplicate views)

Comment: It's normal on the sites for the number of people who actually vote to be a *very small* fraction of the number of people who view the post. I'd suggest looking at some popular posts on the main site. For example, [here's a search of all the questions on the main site which have > 10M views](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3AQ+views%3A10000000..). All of those have a significantly lower fraction of views which turned into votes. If you are interested in exploring the ratio of votes to views on SO, then it's probably better to have a new question asking about views/vote ratios.

Comment: Assuming not unique page views, the policy has been featured for some time. I use the featured link to get to meta then hit Questions to view other posts. I may do this multiple times a day, most days. I also visited a lot to check for updates and new comments on that post specifically. Again, many times per day. Might be others do the same. Add in media publicity, the high-profile strike, that it affects all users and provides valuable context......It's a high-interest post IMO.

Comment: A lot of the community members would welcome a responsible use of AI to generate answers (or any post really) on the site. It's a few group of users who decided that all AI should be banned for everyone else and are now causing drama defending their "community consensus", downvoting everything that remotely says AI should be allowed, and accusing people who disagree to be trolls and argumentative. Since this is the post they point to as proof of their "consensus" and they are going out of their way to keep this featured, could explain the high view count. Everyone loves a good online drama...

Comment: ...and that is sort of their canonical post for it

Comment: @user13267 Your assertions don't match the reality I've seen. If not the ban post, which pro-AI posts have strong approval ratings to the contrary? "Responsible use of AI" seems to be a minority even within the pro-AI camp. Almost all of the GPT posts I've seen on Stack Overflow were virtually careless, incorrect garbage spam--not even well-intentioned, in other words. I have yet to see a well-intentioned GPT user that's clearly adding value.

Comment: @user13267 If you need some evidence to support my experience, [here are all of the GPT flags I raised before the strike](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/390376/399876). These answers are basically a ton of irresponsible spam. In at least one case, [OP specifically begs the answerers to stop using ChatGPT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75564711/what-is-the-best-practice-solution-to-embed-videos-from-different-sources-in-a-r/75645950#comment133450952_75636932): "Please... no more ChatGPT. If I want to use ChatGPT I can use it myself :(" (10k+ rep required to view)

Comment: @user13267 Also, I resent that you're suggesting the strike is "online drama". I don't want drama, I want to be able to contribute to the site I've spent a good chunk of half of the last decade trying to improve, writing 2k answers, raising 2k+ flags, 17k+ votes, and reference every day to get me unstuck at work without a flood of AI crap. If you look at my posts on meta, almost all of them are specific to this one issue that's serious to me, not like I'm just throwing drama for its own sake.

Comment: @ggorlen "Almost all of the GPT posts I've seen on Stack Overflow were virtually careless, incorrect garbage spam--not even well-intentioned, in other words. I have yet to see a well-intentioned GPT user that's clearly adding value." does not mean responsible use of AI can't be done, nor should be denied to users who want to do so by other users. If someone is posting just any garbage generated by AI, they should obviously be removed. Nobody is denying that.

Comment: @ggorlen I appreciate all your contributions and I am not taking a shot at you, so please don't take it personally. I am not in the habit of going after particular users here (feel I need to make it clear as some people (not you) just plainly accuse me of doing so without any basis). If you feel personally attacked I apologize. But I also don't agree with banning all AI, nor that some users should be allowed to decide something like this for everyone else. As for the strike, I am of the opinion that everything anyone does on this site is voluntary and everyone is free to not contribute as...

Comment: ...as they see fit (regardless of strike). It's completely their own business. What I do find annoying is a lot of these users (again, not pointing you out) going out of their way to show they are on strike, bringing up their strike at every possible moment, and hinting everyone else should do the same as well. And I am not talking about SO or this meta site or any SE site in particular, I am talking about the attitude I have seen in the whole network in general.

Comment: It's a hot topic. It'll attract attention from way more people than only meta visitors or even site visitors in general, even people who have left Stack Overflow behind will have read that post and people who are not developers as well. But even site visitors will probably periodically look back at it to see what has changed in it and potentially post new "somebody is wrong on the internet" comments.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Viewing the policy isn't the same thing as agreeing or disagreeing with it; that's what voting is for.

People would want to read it because the policy applies to everyone regardless of their preferences. Merely refusing to read the policy doesn't exempt you from it. I may want to rob a bank to help me get rich faster, but me refusing to read the law against that isn't going to prevent them from arresting me for doing so.

Also, where's your evidence that most people would prefer to have ChatGPT content allowed? I for one very much don't want it to be allowed. Allowing it would, in my opinion, vastly diminish the usefulness of the site. Keeping the site useful is far more important to me than accumulating more fake internet points.

Comment: I don't have evidence. I am just presuming.

Comment: @machine_1 Given the ongoing moderation strike over Stack Exchange making the policy effectively unenforceable, a lot of users clearly do *not* feel that way.

Comment: This doesn't actually explain why there are > 1 M views.. It's explains that the post is relevant to people, which sort-of implies that people would want to view it, but it doesn't actually explain why the views are so high. I'd suggest adding A) that the policy post has been [meta-tag:featured] for the last 7 months; B) that it's been linked to from a banner that was at the top of every page on the site for 2 weeks in December; C) it's been linked to from various media articles; and D) it and its answers have been modified many times, keeping it in the recently active questions list.

Comment: "I don't have evidence. I am just presuming." Presuming something, and then insinuating that something underhanded is in play ("Where are all these views coming from really?!") is not a productive nor honest approach to meta discussion. If you suspect malfeasance, say so, and give good reason for your suspicion. If other people seem to be doing something contrary to your mental model of them, consider the possibility that your mental model is wrong. In particular, if you expect other people to think like you do, consider that they are not you.

Comment: @Makyen Fair point - I was more responding to the argument that people's alleged dislike for the policy necessarily would suppress views.

Comment: @Makyen at least on google (when searching for "stackoverflow") that post is the fourth link. That may also attract some additional attention.

Answer (score 19):

> I presume the majority of community members would prefer to have chatGPT content allowed to help them earn reputation faster so why would they want to visit a post that states it is banned?

Yikes! If the majority of community members care about nothing more than getting rep without any consideration for adding value, that's an extremely sad state of affairs. It's basically the opposite of the site's mission statement, which is to curate a high-quality resource of programming questions and answers. What led you to the rather extreme assumption that most users see the site as a game to accrue fake internet points?

<sub>(And, even if this was the case, ChatGPT is a poor tool for rep farming--most answers it spits out are obvious, wrong and wind up downvoted. Ironically, the best way to rep "farm" is learning to program, solve problems and write clearly. Askers who want a ChatGPT answer are smart enough to go ask ChatGPT. They're clearly here to speak with a human, so answering with a copy-pasted AI response is about as rude and valuable as answering by googling the question and copy-pasting the first thing that comes up. But I digress.)</sub>

---

Part of the reason the post has so many views is because banning ChatGPT was groundbreaking at the time. SO was one of the first major sites to create a full block on generative AI content, less than a week after the release of ChatGPT. The post gained press and was linked from many other places (tweets, news articles, blogs, reddit, etc). For example (picked randomly):

- https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=33861846
- https://www.zdnet.com/article/stack-overflow-temporarily-bans-answers-from-openais-chatgpt-chatbot/
- https://www.siliconrepublic.com/machines/chatgpt-openai-stack-overflow-ban
- https://dev.to/reggi/stack-overflow-bans-answers-from-chatgpt-1d30

These sites brought in a good deal of traffic from non-Stack Overflow users who'd likely never otherwise visit a meta post, much less the SO site itself. The ban post is newsworthy for programmers who don't use SO, non-programmers with technical interests, and arguably even for non-tech enthusiasts who care about the implications of LLMs on, for example, the content creation economy, like [writers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2023_Writers_Guild_of_America_strike).

Aside from the exposure outside of Stack Overflow's userbase, it was a featured post on Stack Overflow's in-application sidebar for something like 6 months, leading to higher-than-normal exposure to SO users. The reason for the abnormally long duration was, presumably, to help inform users who don't normally visit meta of the policy.

Furthermore, it's the most significant post in years, so why shouldn't it have many views? Since that post, LLM abuse has run rampant on the site and SE backpedaled on allowing moderators to actually enforce the ban in May, leading to an ongoing (at the time of writing) widespread [moderation strike](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389811/moderation-strike-stack-overflow-inc-cannot-consistently-ignore-mistreat-an) that may be one of the largest and longest-running in the network's history, if not *the* largest (I've only been around since 2016). The ban post is the foundation for everything that's come after it and is referred to continually throughout the discussion. The moderation strike is also newsworthy, even for non-Stack Overflow users, leading to further [mainstream news articles linking directly to the ban post in question](https://www.vice.com/en/article/4a33dj/stack-overflow-moderators-are-striking-to-stop-garbage-ai-content-from-flooding-the-site).

Page views only indicate exposure of a post, not support. Votes are used to indicate support. As [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425611/why-does-the-temporary-policy-have-over-1m-views#comment965978_425611) indicates, support for the ban is overwhelming, with 97% of votes in support--about as unanimous as one could expect (caveat: the post is locked, so the votes are a historical snapshot of approval for the ban at the time).

Now, here's to hoping SE goes back to allowing the ban to be enforced instead of following the AI hype herd and extinguishing its value proposition (i.e. a resource curated by subject matter expert humans).