# What are tips on getting started here on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

Is there anyone here that can help with some tip and advices on what and what to do to get started with the right track here on Stack Overflow?

I just thought of getting it all started here on Stack Overflow, I had the account over years now without making good use of it

Help & Tips For Getting Started

Comment: Have you tried reading through the articles in [help]?

Comment: Start by taking the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Then do an in-depth dive of the help center if you have further questions. If a question gets closed, as this one has, click on the link in the closure reason.

Comment: [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) has ruined [the use of lists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17204/six-simple-tips-to-get-stack-overflow-reputation-fast/17205#17205).

Comment: The help center is a good guideline, but it is full of holes and misleading wording too. The community FAQ is a more complete guideline, IMO. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251225/faq-index-for-stack-overflow . The most important thing to getting started is to know what NOT to do.

Answer (score -19):

Of course! Here are some tips to get started on Stack Overflow:

1. Search Before You Ask
2. Be Specific
3. Minimal Reproducible Example (MCVE)
4. Use Tags
5. Formatting
6. Be Courteous
7. Provide Feedback
8. Participate in the Community
9. Respect Guidelines
10. Learn from Others

Comment: ChatGPT answer...

Comment: I knew it was chatgpt as soon as i saw 'of course!'

Comment: @machine_1 - The "Here are some tips to get started on Stack Overflow:" is also a dead give away.  [The fact it's also a list.  The fact it's `MRE`, `Minimal Reproducible Example`, not MCVE is also a dead give away](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  The problem with ChatGPT is it pulls information from everywhere, so it's has knowledge on everything, but an expert of nothing.

Comment: I find it more sad that both the Q&A seem to have gotten an upvote before getting migrated. At least, that's what the rep levels would seem to suggest.

Comment: Yeah that would be a good table of contents for an answer. But the actual answer is missing.