# How should I ask questions on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, asking-questions

Okay, the title might sound like the answer is obvious. It has more than likely already been asked a thousand times and can be answered by posting a link to the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

But I'm specifically asking about Stack Overflow, compared to other Stack Exchange sites. I admit, I'm not the most avid and active member on this network, but I have been lurking here for several years now, occasionally I ask a question, and if I come by a question to which I might know the answer, I try to put in some effort in writing a comprehensible and readable text.

For all sites this works without any issues. Most of my answers and questions have upvotes and very rarely do they have downvotes. So despite not participating very often, when I do participate it gets appreciated.

Stack Overflow on the other hand appears to be a big exception to this. For some reason, I'm constantly balancing on the edge of being "question-banned" (and even have been in the past). My questions often get ignored, downvoted or even closed. Sometimes there's comments explaining why (even though usually it's because that person misunderstood something or made assumptions), but most of the time I'm left guessing why this is.

The same happened today, bringing me again closer to a question-ban:

[How to detect strikethrough text from docx tables in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77128728/how-to-detect-striked-through-text-in-docx-tables-in-python)

To me it feels like:

- The question is on-topic;
- I described the problem in detail, but not with too much irrelevant details;
- I summarized the problem in the title;
- The text was (aside from some initial typos) well written and comprehensible;
- It was written in a formal but polite way
- I showed some effort by already providing some reasoning on how the problem should be  tackled, but why this solution does not work;
- I included some related search results to show that I searched before I asked, but also to provide context and prevent people from giving incorrect answers.

So to me, it feels like I did it right? I even checked the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to see what I could have done differently. But apparently the SO community thinks otherwise?

Could anyone explain to me what I could have done differently? What exactly was "wrong" about my question?
And maybe also: how is the SO etiquette different than the SE etiquette? Or is this just my perception?

Comment: "So... does anyone know how this can be done? | Thanks!" That's fluff. It doesn't belong in posts. And unless absolutely necessary, don't include tags like "python" in the title.

Comment: It often helps to add a bit of code. Here, I'd add code showing that you're able to load a Word document, identify tables, and identify text in table cells, then leave a placeholder where you want to identify if (part of) that text is struck through. This makes the question easier to answer since they can use the same code as a starting point and make sure it's easily applied by you, as well as clearly demonstrate research and effort in solving it yourself.

Comment: That question looks fine now.

Comment: @AndreasismovingtoCodidact I thought adding "Thanks" would be considered polite, but I will refrain from using it in the future. Not adding "in Python" to the title feels weird though. Then it sounds like I'm asking "how to see if text is striked through?" ...? The answer to that question would be "open your eyes. if there's a line over the text, it's striked through".

Comment: @ErikA fair point. In my other questions I have always done this I believe. In this example I indeed didn't. I guess it was because the question more referred to documentation than to actual code. But maybe it wouldn't have hurt to at least include *some* code. Even if it's just for esthetic reasons.

Comment: @Dharman I doubt it. Downvotes keep pouring in. I guess I'll just stay away from SO from now on. It doesn't feel like it's a usable site like this.

Comment: @Opifex Yeah, it feels odd at first, but in end "Thanks" and other unrelated tidbits are "noise" to the "signal" (i.e. the factual subject of your question). Also, looking at your answer, please be aware that [Generative AI is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned) both for questions AND answers.

Comment: If the answer to that question would’ve been to open your eyes, your question shouldn’t have been posted on a programming site. The tags are used for categorizing the question, and to say what it’s about. Python is included there. Obviously you wanna read it with Python eyes, not human eyes.

Comment: @CharonX Sure, but would that one word of "noise" warrant a downvote? 
Also, I am aware of the Generative AI policy. Note that that answer was NOT written by it. I merely mentioned that it pointed me in the right direction into solving the problem. The text was clearly written by myself, because it includes a code sample specific to the problem and makes direct references to the original question.

Comment: @Opifex: "Downvotes keep pouring in"? Your question and your answer have ONE downvote at this very moment.

Comment: I don't know why the question is receiving downvotes. Maybe a python expert will explain.

Comment: @AndreasismovingtoCodidact not sure what you are saying here. Questions about MS Word might be off-topic, but they are definitely posted often on this site. On top of that, note that not everyone browses this site through the categories. I don't, and I would argue that most people don't, since the uncategorized page is the default homepage.

Comment: @CharonX "keep pouring in" was an exaggeration indeed. But consdering the context and comparing with my experiences on other SE sites, it's totally unfathomable to me how all my questions end up like this. Sure, some useful feedback has been given here on this meta post. But I don't see how they explain a downvote. Downvoting because someone said "thanks" is absurd.

Comment: @Opifex Mentioning ChatGPT in the answer is probably superflous (signal to noise again) - you included a link to the docs where the functionality is referenced and that is the important part - or even possibly counter-productive, since that one is a sore topic on SO. Also random downvotes are an (unfortunate) fact of life here (as are random upvotes), sorry to say. Don't take it to heart - if it helps imagine that a cat jumped on the mouse and keyboard and accidentally hit the downvote button, while simultaniously ordering 1842 custom-embroided tea-cozies (no refunds).

Comment: @CharonX I removed the ChatGPT mention from the answer. Not sure if it's SNR, because in this case it was part of my path to the answer.  But I can understand that it's a sore topic. Especially because (considering the topic in this Meta question) is threathening SO's existence. ChatGPT doesn't have random downvotes or upvotes.

Comment: The cat jumping on the keyboard doesn't really solve the problem I'm afraid. I don't care much about the number. I know some here see their SO rep as something to be proud of. But I'm definitely not active enough for that, so the number doesn't bother me at all. But getting question banned by cats walking over keyboards... that's a bit sour...

Comment: But the tags are on the question, so you see them when you see the question. If you see off-topic questions, the correct course of action, is to flag to close them, or move to another Q/A site in your discontent… ok, that’s off-topic to my comment.

Comment: The answer posted does not appear to explain how to detect struck-through text... does it? As mentioned by other users, putting some of your code in the question would help users to understand where were you starting from, and what exactly you were looking for.

Comment: @yivi Sure, I gave the example to detect bold text... The main problem in the question was not having a Run object, from which formatting can be read. The answer explains how to get the run object, which gives you access to all formatting.

Comment: *"But considering the context and comparing with my experiences on other SE sites, it's totally unfathomable to me how all my questions end up like this"* - that is because you are comparing apples and oranges. To begin with Stack Overflow has a monumental user base, millions of active users daily. It has a matching incoming stream of daily questions with which yours are competing, the bar is set very high as a response. Too high people might and have argued, but that is all cause and effect.

Comment: You are missing that the tag [tag:python] has 2.2m watchers. If you post a question about something with fewer watchers, there are chances that your experience will be different. On the other hand, there major languages like Python have communities with their own culture, so even posting a question about something with a similar number of watchers but related to a programming language / platform with a different culture might take you to have a different experience.

Comment: General advice: Give [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) a read and make use of the linked checklist.

Comment: Put all & only what is needed to ask in your post, don't link & expect readers to read entire other presentations & guess what is relevant & why. How you got to the references doesn't matter. A [mre] is typically helpful in code question. Generally noise doesn't lead to downvotes. Reporting that ChatGPT or your dog helped you is noise. So is your "path" to your post. Give facts necessary to describe & constrain your problem & question, supported by error-free code & informed references you name & if necessary quote & if so with credit. (ChatGPT, like your dog, is not such a reference.)

Comment: The primary issue I see is that a) the question says you read the docs yet b) the answer says you had to read the same docs fully. That’s textbook not-doing-your-research. Relatedly, the question already says paragraphs are what you need, so if the answer is „access the paragraph“ that’s also likely to be seen as obvious by some voters.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi this Meta post was created before the Answer to the Question was written. Sure, in hindsight it's easy to say "it was in the docs". But 90% of the answers on SO are simply references to the docs... At the time of writing, I doubt any of the voters knew the answer could be found in the docs, because it definitely is not obvious (from a Word-perspective) that you need to look for paragraphs in table cells. Especially if you're looking for so called Run-objects.

Answer (score 7):

It would be best to ask questions following the example of the **recently** well-received questions of the tags you will include in your question in Stack Overflow instead of following the example of your experiences in other Stack Exchange communities.

In the example, the question includes [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python). Look at this tag's [Top Users](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python/topusers) page. Pay special attention to the top [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) askers in the last 30 days section (bottom-left). Look for users who have several questions and the highest score first.

In the below image, the second and third users have 5 and 6 questions asked in the last 30 days. It might be a good idea to start looking at these questions.

Later, you might also look at cases with 1 question and a high score, but be careful, as certain circumstances might make the score grow abnormally. If there is something wrong, it will probably be detected and fixed.

[image: Top python Askers Last 30 days]

If you become a frequent asker, you might look at longer time spans using search queries, including operators like the number of answers and views.