# Can a "No LLM Usage" banner be added for the Collectives Article box?

Tags: feature-request, status-review, collectives, articles, ai-generated-content

Currently, when a user uses the answer box [on Stack Overflow], there was (should be?*) a box reminding users to not post LLM-generated content. It said something like this:

> **Reminder:** AI-generated content (such as from ChatGPT) [is banned on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned)

Inspired by [this other MSO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426908/extend-ai-content-policy-to-articles-and-other-content-that-is-meant-to-be-used), can a reminder similar to that be added to the text box for proposing Collectives Articles? I don't know how effective it'd be, but I'd hope that it'd discourage posting LLM-generated articles within Collectives.

---

*For some reason, I don't see it any more, but I haven't checked if a userscript or my adblocker removed it or if it's on SE's end.

Comment: maybe you don't see the box for answers because it's being A/B tested and the test doesn't seem to put specific users in a specific group (I get it sometimes, and sometimes I don't)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just checked and i'm still getting the reminder notice on SO when I go to answer a question.

On the matter of whether to add it to the articles form: we haven't seen a deluge of LLM generated articles, to my knowledge, so I think I would rather not, until / unless it has proven to be necessary.  We're concerned that it might have a downward pressure on non-LLM created content submissions as well, and I would hate to do anything that would suppress the creation of articles, which is an area in which we already struggle.

Comment: Good to hear the reminder isn't broken, but can you share how you (or SE) is estimating AI generated articles? It'd also be nice if you could share why you think it'd decrease content submissions. Thank you!

Comment: Well, our overall volume of articles is very very low. We've had only a couple that were flagged as likely LLM articles.  I'm going to ask that the heuristics working group that exists look into whether the same heuristics should apply for articles as for Q&A.  As for the second question, the decrease in content submissions, analysis is ongoing now, and I don't have an answer yet.  When I do, I'll share it.

Comment: Why do you think that anyone who does not use AI would be deterred when seeing warning about using AI? If I am not using AI why would I be worried about such notice? I really cannot follow your logic here. In Mobile Development collective two of two posted Articles are AI generated. I would say that pretty much proves that the warning is necessary.