# Link to non-existent "/help/gpt-policy" page in the Help Center

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center

On the page https://stackoverflow.com/help/answering-limit, there is a link like so:

> [influx of GPT-generated answers that have caused information that is objectively wrong to make its way onto the site](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy)

This link leads to https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy, which shows a "Page not found" page.

---

Aside from the Help Center page, at the time of writing there are other meta pages which mention the https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy link:

- [Example 1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/424265)
- [Example 2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/426908)

Comment: There is a `/help/ai-policy`.  Maybe someone recently change "gpt" to "ai" but did not update this help page.

Comment: @toolic The page was [deleted entirely](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/426939/6083675) and superseded by the new page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Help center page updated to link to https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy. I updated the two linked Meta pages as well.