# Can we remove the "temporary" classification from the Generative AI ban post?

Tags: discussion, meta, title, ai-generated-content

Regarding, [Temporary policy: Generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT) is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned), is there really a future where we will be okay with ChatGPT or any other AI answers?

If we reach a point where AI answers are so good that they could be allowed on Stack Overflow, will people even need to ask here?
Won't they just ask whatever AI can answer?
Will someone asking on Stack Overflow not expect a human answer since they have an alternative and still chose to ask?

If we never reach that point, is it really temporary?

Comment: The current policy being temporary doesn't mean *any and all restrictions* being temporary. It just means that the current restrictions may be temporary - even if just because they will be formalised more. There's a wide spectrum between "All use of generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT1 and other LLMs) is banned when posting content on Stack Overflow." and "No use of generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT1 and other LLMs) is banned when posting content on Stack Overflow.".

Comment: In a few years it will be replaced by "All human contributions to the site are banned".

Comment: @MisterMiyagi But _all_ current restrictions are temporary? Every rule we've ever had is subject to change, up to and including “be nice”. Realistically, that policy's staying in place until this fad passes, then we'll probably get a more generic version about "no semi-automated posting unless approved by meta".

Comment: Back when we had friendly Soviet troops temporarily stationed in our country for 20+ years there was a joke: Q: "What's the measurement unit of temporariness?" A: "One Forever". | And honestly, does this really matter?

Comment: We're approaching one year on this temporary policy. All of the reasons it was put in place still apply. If there's no specific, measurable, attainable goal that results in the policy being retracted, then the policy is not really temporary. We should edit the policy to remove all instances of "temporary."

Comment: @NickODell Right. And once the ban can be lifted (i.e. when it is no longer true that "the average rate of getting _correct_ answers from ChatGPT and other generative AI technologies is too low") there will be no need for humans to post answers, and therefore no real need for an active SO community at all. I suspect that _"temporary"_ was chosen as a convenient fig leaf, to give the appearance of being flexible and open-minded on the policy. Once a better way of getting software questions answered comes along, SO will suffer the same fate as cassette tapes, travel agents and typewriters.

Comment: @skomisa I think somewhere between "AI can not be trusted" and "AI answers are always right" is an intermediate state where AI is sometimes right, but having community scrutiny and criticism helps highlight places where it is wrong or incomplete. Imagine two AI answers - one judged helpful by dozens of SO users, and one that has never been seen by a human. You wouldn't give the two equal weight. I suspect the gulf between "cannot be trusted" and "always right" will take years of research to bridge.

Comment: @NickODell There won't be any day when the _"the average rate of getting correct answers from ChatGPT..."_ rises to some threshold that causes the temporary ban to be lifted. As you mentioned, there is no specified level for that threshold anyway. Rather, I suspect there will come a time when a critical mass of SO users will find alternative solutions, and whatever policy SO adopts won't really matter, just as nothing Netscape did mattered in its losing battle with Microsoft. SO would then become another AOL or MySpace; it would still exist, but with a greatly reduced audience/cachet.

Comment: NO, do NOT remove the ban. What makes Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange special is the peer-review among professionals, and those that want to learn. No one here signed up to be part of the QA team for a LLM hosted by someone else as a for-profit experiment. Allowing ChatGPT or AI generated answers effectively puts each of us in that role. Where now, if there is a lapse in reasoning in an answer, you can comment and determine the thought-process behind the answer and help the other learn. All of that is rendered meaningless for AI generated answers. The ban should be permanent.

Comment: Oh no, I understood, my vote just comes down on the side of removing "temporary" and replacing it with "permanent" `:)`

Comment: I have no idea how SO recognizes these AI-generated answers, but what could be done is that code is allowed to be posted, but definition, explanation, and comments should be non-AI generated. I don't know if it's possible or not, but that could be useful. Because for me may be my code can be a replica of what AI generated for the same problem, but the wording will never be same.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin No replacing with something else, simply removing "temporary" because one year is a long time and temporary typically isn't used for that long durations. It's just a simplification to ease reading and understanding.

Comment: @Alivetodie-Anant Definitely not possible, people who post AI generated Answer are people who want to farm reputation and 99% of the time don't even understand the answer given by ChatGPT, people who can explain the code simply don't need the AI to generate the answer for them.

Comment: @Daviid but sometimes I recognize that when I take an answer from AI that I am not able to solve, I am able to explain it in my words without issue. Bt yes I am agreed with your comment at the same time.

Comment: David, not all of them want to farm rep. a good chunk of them are spammers.

Comment: It’s been bugging me as well to see “temporary” on a locked post that’s been there forever. It’s worth noting that the meta post is pointing to [this “ai-policy” help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy) which explains the same policy without every mentioning it’s temporary, so there seems to be in effect nothing temporary about it.

Comment: Even if it was temporary I argue that it should not be temporary at all. As @MisterMiyagi points out (if I understood correctly) it doesn't necessarily mean that the ban will go away, just that the rules were put in place "in a rush" and they need to be fleshed out and might change. Even though I think rules can be updated even if they're not called temporary, I think I understand his point. (They can just outright ban AI generated answers and then 2 years later post an update to that rule, just like Terms and Conditions receive updates without ever being called temporary.)

Comment: Probably an argument not been put forward (enough) is that LLMs tend to "make up" knowledge, partly because of how the LLMs work internally. If we allow a huge influx of fake knowledge, eventually part of that fake knowledge might become "common knowledge", but is fake nonetheless.

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem yes, if we accept AI answers we will end up with people copying generated code and explaining it with their own words matter-of-factly as if it was correct when it could be completely wrong. Giving the asker a false sense of security.

Comment: Imagine something like *Nightshade* but instead of poisoning image data we end up with a poisoned LLM that gives out code with breaking bug or backdoors.

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution it's totally up to whatever you all decide. Whether that's simply removing "temporary" or replacing it with something else, I'm good either way as long as I've made known my $0.02 says the ban should stay, I've done that. How you want to word-smith it, is up to you. Were this a motion or brief or judgment, I may quibble more about the final form, but from a site display standpoint, I'll defer to you all with much more experience than I in that area.